# Is there a tutorial or example page

Tags: discussion

I'm sure this question has been asked dozends of times but I have found neither a question nor a suitable stack...

Where can tutorials or examples be posted?

I've seen a lot of good code examples and I'm sure a lot of people would like to contribute good examples, but where to put those?

Is there a Stack Exchange site for tutorials/examples?

(I don't even dare to ask this question, so please forgive me in advance)

Comment: Tutorials are off topic for all of the Stack Exchange Network. Code examples are only on topic if they are an answer to an on topic question; everybody can post such a question and then self-answer it in order to post an example.

Comment: wow thanks, that's the answer to my question!! if you post it in form of an answer i'll accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no such thing.

You could propose it on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com), although I don't think it would go over very well. Using the Stack Exchange Q&A format for tutorials would be a bit of "fitting square pegs in round holes". There is a limit to the length that answers are allowed to have, and most good tutorials probably don't fit inside that limit.

The closest thing we have is canonical questions and Community Wiki, like [The definitive guide to form-based website authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549/the-definitive-guide-to-form-based-website-authentication) .

Comment: This. Except, some tag wikis have useful links to FAQs and caveats etc. which could be considered tutorial-esque.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's what the [Documentation proposal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303865/warlords-of-documentation-a-proposed-expansion-of-stack-overflow) (currently in private beta) is for. In fact, the main focus of it is exactly that: examples - some might even call them mini-tutorials.

Go and sign up for the beta, and contribute some examples !