# Warlords of Documentation: A Proposed Expansion of Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, documentation

It’s been [7 years](http://blog.codinghorror.com/alpha-beta-and-sometimes-gamma/) and [10,000,000+ Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/10m) since Stack Overflow was launched. The amount of good that has been done for the field - all the developers helped, all the person-hours saved, all the beginners who grew into professionals - is hard to overstate. I cannot express how proud I am of what we’ve built together (and not just because it let me see [our arch-enemy](http://blog.codinghorror.com/whos-your-arch-enemy/) vanish from my Google results); this community has realized the goal of "making the internet a better place" beyond what anyone could have predicted.

Lately we've been asking ourselves "what else could we do to improve developers' lives on the internet?". Jeff’s original [announcement of Stack Overflow](http://blog.codinghorror.com/introducing-stackoverflow-com/) said this:

> There's far too much great programming information trapped in forums, buried in online help, or hidden away in books that nobody buys any more. We'd like to unlock all that. Let's create something that makes it easy to participate, and put it online in a form that is trivially easy to find.

Stack Overflow has made all of that a *lot* better, but there's one area that is still hanging around: **Documentation**. Just like Q&A in 2008, Documentation in 2015 is something every developer needs regularly, and something that by most appearances stopped improving in 1996. We think, together, we can make it a lot better.

#### How would adding Documentation to Stack Overflow improve Documentation?

1. Documentation is often an afterthought, obviously done just to say that it exists, with little concern for its quality. We've all seen plenty of this in our time. [image: Bad documentation is bad]
   We can bring a focus on quality, peer review, and "actually solves real problems for real developers"-ness to documentation that would be very welcome.
2. Often documentation is **lacking in examples**, or the examples are trivial and don't demonstrate typical use. Because Stack Overflow benefits from constant feedback from developers writing real-world code, we could greatly improve the quantity and quality of examples. Let's be honest: finding examples is *already* a common use-case for Stack Overflow; we might as well embrace it.
3. Much of the documentation out there is tied to release cycles, and thus **infrequently updated and rarely "complete"**. The community-contributed and edited nature of Stack Overflow would be an immediate improvement.
4. A lot of documentation descends from Javadocs, and while it was better than nothing in '96, **it's hard to call framesets with unshareable URLs "good" in 2015**. We can focus on creating the best UX for creating and serving documentation on the modern web.

#### What would adding Documentation to Stack Overflow improve about Stack Overflow?

1. We've heard repeated requests for a place for broader artifacts to live. Less "a specific problem you are having right now," and more, "what is there for me to use." We think Documentation could **provide a place for many of the useful artifacts that developers actively need, but we've been turning away** over the years.
2. Many posts are improved by citing official documentation, but today, that means using offsite links that are sometimes hard to find and that [may break](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141203/blogs-sun-com-is-dead). Having it on-site makes it **easier to find and incorporate Documentation into posts**.
3. There are Questions that come up repeatedly whose root cause is poor documentation. If you see a bunch of people struggle with Foo's Bar class, with Foo's documentation on Stack Overflow you could fix the Bar page and **mitigate a source of repetitious (often exact duplicate) Questions**.
4. A smaller, but just as real, benefit is that it opens up more opportunities for giving back. Oftentimes we'll hear from a developer who has benefited from a Stack Overflow Answer, but has trouble finding a Question they can help with that isn’t already answered. Documentation adds many more opportunities for [paying it forward](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pay_it_forward).

### The Plan: We need YOUR help to build this

The first step is to share some rough ideas we've been kicking around for what the Documentation "part" of Stack Overflow might look like and how it might behave, and get your feedback. This is still in an early stage, but most of the successful ideas in Stack Overflow originated from the community, so we want you all in the loop as early as possible.

The second step will be a private beta, where we <strike>break everything and make the team cry</strike> test out the tools and workflows, but not on Stack Overflow proper. **There's a sign-up form for this further down, so keep reading.** Private beta will be shipping in the traditional [six-to-eight weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/130213).

[image: Then a miracle occurs]

*Or we're wrong.* Maybe Documentation isn't as exciting to the community at large as it is to us, or we fail to iterate to a solution. Maybe we can't fill in that step.

[image: Failure is always an option]

But we think it's worth having a go at it. Interested? Give this post an upvote, and sign-up for the beta. Hate it? Downvote. Questions or comments? Well we've got more info below, but do post any and all feedback you have at the end - we want to hear your thoughts. After all, [Stack Overflow is you](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2008/11/stack-overflow-is-you/).

### How Documentation Will Work*

<sub>* we think</sub>

Tags that already have involved communities on Stack Overflow, such as [.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net) or [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), can have associated documentation created for them. Documentation is broken up into pages called Topics.

[image: Topic page]

Topics always have **Examples** and **Remarks**; other sections are optional.

Examples are collapsible and deeplink-able. We're putting them at the top of the page because we believe they're the most important - the information you desire is likely within them. We're expecting Topics to have more Examples than Questions have Answers, since Topics will be broader than Questions.

Because Topics are envisioned as being much larger than the typical Question or Answer, trying to compose them in our current editor would be painful.  So we're building a new one.

[image: The new editor]

You can edit individual sections or Examples, you'll see a live preview, and your changes are automatically saved as drafts. We're still using Markdown and [prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify) for formatting and code styling, of course.

Anyone with sufficient privileges in a tag can create or edit Topics, and those without those privileges can suggest changes for review *à la* suggested edits. Those who think a Topic is needed, but cannot themselves write it, can instead request a Topic using the creatively named Request Topic button.

[image: Searching for an existing request]

Requesters first search for an existing request to upvote, and if they find none, they can then enter a new request.

[image: Submiting a Topic Request]

We're anticipating the typical good Request will be smaller than the typical good Question. A good Question has some explanation of the issue, a reproduction in code, and lists things that the asker has already tried. A good Request only has to explain the deficit in the Documentation. Because of this difference, we’re going with a much lighter UI in comparison to the Ask page.

For giving feedback on existing Topics, voting and flagging are available. These look very similar to existing flows, so they're not pictured.

All actionable items (request, pending changes, flags, votes, etc.) are aggregated into a dashboard view for people looking to help out.

[image: Dashboard mockup]

Each "view more" and tab go to full lists like in the user profile.

*All this stuff is very early and very much subject to change; especially now that we'll be getting your feedback.*

### FAQ

1. How will reputation work?

   - You'll get reputation for peer-reviewed contributions to Documentation. Peer review may take the form of citations, suggested edit reviews, explicit voting, or a combination of all three. Reputation you earn from Documentation will be added to the existing Q&A reputation; there won't be two separate numbers. Obviously, we're still working out lots of the details.
   - We intend for participation in the Documentation parts of Stack Overflow to be about as rewarding, in terms of reputation, as asking and answering is in the Q&A parts.
2. What can be documented?

   - We're thinking "anything you use through code" as a really rough guideline, but we'll ultimately decide together as a community, just like with what’s on-topic for Q&A.
   - For the betas, we're planning to restrict ourselves to established and widely used projects. We're trying to test out the bigger stuff first, to make sure all the tools and processes can cope. If all goes well, eventually just about anything that sees some Q&A activity will be fair game to document.
3. What *should* be documented?

   - Anything where we can actually make it better. If a project already has awesome documentation that's easy to search and cite, then there's no need to duplicate it on Stack Overflow. We're interested in fixing what's broken with documentation, not just moving them onto Stack Overflow.
4. What's the line between a Question and a request for a Topic?

   - Topics are broader in scope than Questions. In fact, we're expecting that if you "asked" most requests, they’d be closed as Too Broad.
   - Topics should also have multiple Examples, so a request that can be served by a Topic with a single Example (ie. one block of code) is probably too narrow.
5. Is importing existing documentation encouraged?

   - **No.** We're hoping we can *improve* documentation, not just move it under the stackoverflow.com domain.
6. What license will documentation be under?

   - The same license ([Creative Commons Attribution Share Alike](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)) and [ToS](https://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service) that covers existing content. Documentation will also appear in our regular [data dumps](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange) once the private beta concludes.

## Register For The Beta

We’ll need to know three things:

- Your email
- Your Stack Overflow profile URL
- A list of 2-5 [tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=popular) you’d be interested in helping document

Please pick tags from the first two pages of [popular tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=popular) that have an especially active community. Things like [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23), [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r), or [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios) so we can test our system out against the real things that lots of developers are using in the private beta.

## Register and help Make Docs Suck Less

Comment: 4 minutes - 15 upvotes? Who can read such a long post so fast?

Comment: "We’re interested in fixing what’s broken with documentation, not just moving them onto Stack Overflow." - Assuming this works how you want, if a project improves documentation to the point where it's not needed on SO any longer, will there be a process to encourage users to go back to the project itself instead of continuing here?

Comment: I wonder how, in the case of something like .NET, this would be better than MSDN.  Maintenance would be another concern generally.  Things change.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, it will operate more like a wiki?  But with stricter editing standards based on other SO metrics (tag score and reputation)?

Comment: @Andy in the same way that a community could stop posting to Stack Overflow Q&A, yes.  Ultimately the contributors control the content, if they're convinced to tear everything down and point folks at the official docs then that's fine.  If it turns out we need to build tools for such a process, we will.

Comment: @Plutonix read #3 on the FAQ again. They don't want to replace existing documentation if the existing docs are good enough. However, I'm wondering how we could somehow supplement existing documentation with better examples, because some of the examples and information on MSDN (and plenty of other OSS documentation) sucks.

Comment: Along the same lines as the concern indicated by @Andy, would there be some process to discourage people from creating 'usurping' documentation sets that have the effect of making other documentation worse (or, more likely, die on the vine)?  The first thing that came to mind is [tag:asp.net-5] - docs.asp.net is really incomplete, but it's collaborative and could be made quite good with enough contributions.  What happens when all those potential contributors do it here instead? (comment a little out-of-sync with your response to Andy..)

Comment: I think this a great idea! I know I do not have much rep (under 1000), but I do hope I can continue to contribute for the documentation. I see many questions about core concepts in Ruby. Their error boils down to not knowing how to format arrays or hashes.

Comment: This is obviously still in the works, but if I have specific questions about this new feature, were would I ask?  Create a new meta-tag for stackoverflow-documentation?  "answer" to this discussion question?  Or over on MSE?

Comment: @Plutonix we have some ideas about handling version releases (tl;dr version tables and inference), as well as obsolescence (tl;dr flagging and markdown extensions).  This post was pretty long already though, so I cut it.  We'll have some super detailed stuff when the beta starts, you're correct that this stuff is tricky.

Comment: How is advertsing going to be integrated into the documentation pages?  I can't imagine that it won't, and it's going to impact UX, so might as well plan for it/get it out of the way/discuss it now.

Comment: Till when is the registration open?

Comment: @ryanyuyu Close to a wiki, with more feedback (voting, flagging, requests) and more of a focus on peer review (low rep contributions go into a queue, like edits).  The mindset is very much "take what works from Stack Overflow Q&A," so they will be similar but with lots of Documentation specific features (like the editor and dashboard).

Comment: What does "sufficient privileges" mean? Gold badge? :(

Comment: @Avinash But the pics don't have red circles on them.

Comment: So just to be clear that I understand the scope here, you are hoping to have a way to create cohesive documentation for... literally everything within the scope of SO? All languages, all frameworks, etc?

Comment: @casperOne current plans are "ad in the sidebar of Topic, hidden when editing / reviewing / expanding an example"; no ads on the dashboard.

Comment: WRT point #5, if the tag wikis are the recipients of plagiarized content now, I can't wait to see how the documentation pages end up. I definitely like the idea though.

Comment: @casperOne, eventually you're probably right - gotta keep the lights on. And Kevin points out we've given it a little thought.  But our general take is to design, develop, and test for what actually serves users first, cuz once you get that right, you both know where ads won't interfere AND you'll be helping more people, which ups the overall value of the adspace.  If you *start* with the need to get ads in, I think the product and all parties do worse.

Comment: @enderland long term, yes.  If you use if by writing code, and we can make the docs better, it'd be in this.  As with on-topic questions, the community may redefine exactly what's permitted as we move forward.

Comment: Love the idea, but worried about visibility if this is confined to tag wikis or a similar corner on SO with relatively low "through traffic". Would this perhaps warrant a separate `docs.stackoverflow.com` portal? With a Google-like search field, a tag selector, and specific information around docs? With users signing up separately, as they would to a different SE site?

Comment: Maybe we could take this opportunity to improve licensing: explicitly dual-license code samples in docs as MIT, not just Creative Commons, so they're clearly safe to reuse.

Comment: @BhargavRao Until the public beta starts- there's no harm in trickling people into the private beta; we just need the ability to allow "waves" of people in, and to make sure enough people are interested in a [tag] before opening it up.

Comment: @Undo exact privileges are TBD; though we intend for *everyone* to be able to suggest edits and new Topics, regardless of held privileges.

Comment: @Pekka웃 it's too early to know exactly how nav'll work, but we agree 100% that tag wikis are far too hidden for this - if this were successful, I could see it fitting in more like a category of content, like "Questions," "Docs," "[Cute Videos of Cats in Tubs](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=cat+tub&search_sort=video_view_count)," etc.

Comment: @Jaydles Kevin forgot the cat videos beta link in his post, plz fix asap

Comment: @Pekka웃 [here you go](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qkdXAtO40Fo)

Comment: Documentation can obviously be used in questions, but can we use appropriate existing questions (or better, answers) as examples in documentation? E.g. using "how can i do X with Y" as an example of an usage of "Y"

Comment: @Pekka웃, good catch. Remedied in my comment.

Comment: @PaulCrovella I don't think this will solve the problem that many people are too lazy to even read the documentation. There are many SO questions which could be closed with the according manual page.

Comment: @Sklivvz The licensing certainly permits it. Content-wise, I guess it depends on how well the shoe fits....

Comment: @Rizier123 that's a different problem with a different demographic though. The kind of serious people we want to hang out on SO need functioning documentation.

Comment: @Sklivvz a good example is in some ways a combination of a Question and an Answer, so conversion isn't exactly trivial.  That said, I do suspect there's a lot of potential in search SO for common questions and generalizing the best answers to make good Examples for Topics.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Yes, keyword: PHP, I think you exactly know what I mean :] (*Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for **professional and enthusiast** programmers.* I miss the enthusiastic and professional part a lot sometimes)

Comment: @KevinMontrose yeah, I wasn't proposing conversion, but a list of links to relevant explanatory questions

Comment: How would the project deal with the danger of documentational ghost towns? Say a bunch of people wants to create SO docs for something that already has decent documentation of its own. They may want to mine rep, or genuinely feel they can contribute something great but aren't allowed to in the project's own docs. Because the larger community isn't with them, the effort withers away quickly and leaves a half-finished pile of partially useful information. How to prevent that?

Comment: ... Would there have to be an Area51-like pledging process before docs are activated for a tag? Or would each doc tag by design start where it starts, if just with a couple of entries? Just thinking aloud, I realize there aren't any fixed answers yet.

Comment: Would it be worth looking for 2-3 medium to high visibility projects that might be interested in migrating their entire official documentation to a docs.SO beta - because their current doc system sucks, because they're tired of the maintenance, et cetera? If it's well done it seems likely docs.SO could ease the burden of many a project, help folks focus on *documenting stuff* instead of first choosing, setting up, and maintaining a documenting platform, all of which suck in one way or other

Comment: One of the most difficult things to enforce to maintain utility will be versioning. Here I refer to the version of the thing being documented. There is already much in the questions section that doesn't have good versioning and most of the time it works. How to inject discipline into the documentation consistently?

Comment: First, I'd like to recommend that the design lend itself to printing. I still print out documentation and write all over it, so make sure there's some thought put into the printer style sheets. Second, you said _"Topics always have Examples and Remarks; other sections are optional.
Examples are collapsible and deeplink-able. We’re putting them at the top of the page because we believe they’re the most important "_. I think this is wrong, and parameters and syntax should be required while remarks should be optional. And since syntax will usually be shorter than the examples, it should be 1st.

Comment: After spending a day trying to find information on an OSS system that has documentation more in the way of "here's a hello world example" and "it can do everything" rather than "this is how you do it", including removed classes even though they are in the documentation, I would love this kind of system to be in place for it. Then again, don't know how many people would contribute for that case when even the devs on the discussion board seem to answer only "yes, it's possible" or "you're doing it wrong" without actual help.

Comment: @EnergyNumbers man-hours is the [standard form](http://i.imgur.com/bjb3Ero.png) I thought?  Like the man in "manslaughter."

Comment: @Energy where I come from (politically correct), "person" is substituted for "man" in such sexist/dated terms, eg "person days of work", "person hours", "chair person" etc. It's a little clunky, but it honours and respects the equally valuable contribution of females.

Comment: @Bohemian that's a good option, post has been edited.  I just went with the form I've seen before, not a phrase I whip out all that often.

Comment: What's the ETA on the private beta starting?

Comment: [tag:R] is one of the given examples of popular tags. R has excellent documentation standards with examples and search facilities. This does _not_ prevent the flow of trivial, repetitive, and lazy questions from those who don't bother to make good use of the existing documentation.

Comment: @Pekka웃 it's not final, but the very rough plan is that a tag requires a minimum amount of activity to get documentation added to it.  Explicit commits may make sense as well.  The goal is explicitly to prevent ghost towns and wasted pages in searches, if we make some stub pages no-one finds helpful I think we're all in agreement that we done goofed; we want to prevent that.

Comment: @Undo When it's ready.  Really, we're working as fast as we can; I'm hopeful 6-8 weeks is a real estimate, but we'll see.  Sort of depends on the feedback we get.

Comment: I bet [torne](http://stackoverflow.com/users/12345/my-name) is getting a lot of profile views from that link in the sign up form.

Comment: @A.Webb Nothing will ever be 100% effective at stopping lazy questions, but I don't think it's unreasonable to expect improvement on the margins.

Comment: @Rizier123: Towards addressing [the problem you mention](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303865/warlords-of-documentation-a-proposed-expansion-of-stack-overflow#comment240200_303865), the ["general reference" close reason](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86043/) was proposed (by Pekka): "question is clearly and thoroughly answered in the standard reference/doc". I'd guess it's unlikely that this "Docs.SO" plan will actually lead to "close as duplicate of Doc.SO post NNN", but it still seems like a step in the right direction to get this stuff explicitly formatted on SO.

Comment: I'm personally a fan of this idea. A section for common issues and resolutions would be nice to have in a topic, even if it's just embedding top related SO questions. Many times when I come to SO I'm troubleshooting some error message and I'm just looking for common resolutions to see if one fits my needs (I've been staring at my code and can't see the problem). Using the screenshot above for Dictionary<TKey, TValue> as an example, maybe the user is getting a key error, googles, and finds [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/606636/best-way-to-handle-a-keynotfoundexception). Just my 2c.

Comment: The most available content on the web beside porn are programming examples and useful programming exercises about every language (detail) and about every topic I'm aware of. Having this, I don't get your initial problem.

Comment: @hek2mgl Have you never had issues with an undocumented obscure API? Or a well documented one, but no examples that show everything glued together?

Comment: I like the idea, but it shouldn't be part of Stack Overflow. It should be a seperate thing.

Comment: @hek2mgl what Jeroen says. There's plenty of documentation out there that is lacking in one way or the other. A unified platform for documentation that takes care of the huge technical hassles while providing all its content under a liberal license could be a huge relief for many projects.

Comment: @A.Webb R's function names are a bit bonkers. (I have a gold R badge but only learned of the poorly named, but very useful `rowsum` last week.) And `??` searching is a hassle. Topics like "indexing a matrix", "assigning to a matrix", "operations on each row of a matrix", "operations on each col of a matrix" would certainly be nice.

Comment: What is the **challenge** in writing documentation!? Is it interesting? What will I learn doing it?

Comment: @Frank I'm warming up to it, but you are more describing a community developed "cookbook" rather than what we see in the "How Documentation Will Work" example above. The "How Documentation Will Work" looks very much like the existing R documentation format.

Comment: Love the “Who’s Your Arch-Enemy” blog post. +1 for the pro wrestling references!

Comment: @Pekka웃 *huge technical hassles* are super rare. I've read tons of documentation pages in my life and they were nearly 100% correct. If not I've submitted a patch - and in my experience they were happily appreciated. When I didn't found what I was searching for in an official documentation, there were always tons of other results on Google, which were blogs etc. So again, I don't see even  a micro-problem here, except from offering an opportunity for more traffic on the site.

Comment: Why is it necessary to subscribe to 2-5 tags for private beta ? 1 is not enough ?

Comment: @XavierCombelle if you can only think of one that's fine.  I suggest 2-5 because we'll want to let people in in waves grouped by tags they're interested in, more makes it easier to group.

Comment: @A.Webb I posted an answer below referring to how ambiguous the OP is on this point of cookbook vs function-by-function docs (along with other R-related thoughts).

Comment: So basically all the w3c specs will be rewritten on this project because have you ever tried to read them?

Comment: I think this is great. I wish I had this for lodash. They have great 'simple' examples, but nothing that isn't a very simple use case.

Comment: I like the idea. However, please focus on a great and flexible versioning system right from the beginning. This is crucial for any bigger project IMHO.

Comment: Please also think about examples consisting of more than one file. An example consisting of multiple files would be "How to create a simple Symfony bundle". It would be even greater if you could download and use the example out of the box.

Comment: Man - This could be controversial, two sides battling out - On-Site Docs vs. Off-Site Docs. You just might invent a new tag! Perhaps a few if this is successful! You have my vote!

Comment: @j08691 Isn't it far more impactful and effective a teaching tool to say "You can do X with library Y. Here is how:", show the example, and then provide the syntax for someone who doesn't need to do precisely X but X`? Most documentation is written with an emphasis on syntax, but I would guess that people get bogged down in the syntax and lose sight of what they are actually trying to do.

Comment: Will topics be nestable?

Comment: Related links on new answers should include possible documentation topics.

Comment: I think that this is a good idea but it diverges from Stack Overflows Q&A purpose. SO is successful because we are very clear on what we are not. Make this a new site, don't build it into the SO site. That way it will succeed or fail without watering down SOs purpose.

Comment: @ZevSpitz not sure what you mean by nestable.  We definitely intend to encourage significant cross linking within Documentation, and make it super easy to find and link to Topics in Questions & Answers.  Cross-linking is going to play into search a great deal, if I get my way.

Comment: RE nestable: For example, the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/) has an upper level section -- Events, Manipulation etc. - that are each further divided into subsections -- Events > Browser events, Events > Document loading. MSDN is another example of this (perhaps not a very good one). Will there be a topic hierarchy? 1 level deep? flat list of topics?

Comment: @Kobi I've found that I get a far better understanding of the topic when I try to explain it to someone else. This particularly applies when I'm trying to understand/explain the broader ideas behind an API from it's details.

Comment: @ryanyuyu sorry for the delay in response, wanted to get some other eyes on re-using [meta-tag:documentation] for this discussion.  It's the appropriate tag for future posts ([meta-tag:too-broad] was my closest option that didn't require making a new tag, or reusing an existing one).

Comment: Will there be a seperate section that contains which version of a language a specific API or feature first appeared (or became deprecated) and which systems / browsers / compilers / etc. support it? For example for a documentation page for JavaScript’s `Array.prototype.findIndex` it would say that it has been first specified in ECMAScript 6 and it was first supported in Chrome 45, Firefox 25, MS Edge, Opera 32, Safari 7.1, etc. (and possibly, how many percent use these browsers, whether vendor prefixes exist, which browsers support something incorrectly or incompletely and how exactly, etc.).

Comment: @KevinMontrose regarding the title of this proposal, "Warlords of Documentation", is that a World of Warcraft reference? [Warlords of Draenor](http://us.battle.net/wow/en/warlords-of-draenor/)?

Comment: @Xufox we are thinking about some specific markdown extensions in the vein of customization we allow on a per-site basis (like [Balsamiq for UX](http://meta.ux.stackexchange.com/questions/647/can-stackexchange-license-balsamiq-for-mockups-on-ux-stackexchange), youtube for gaming, and so on).  Among them is a "can I use this"-style grid, with an eye towards javascript, css, and whole family of web technologies.

Comment: @Cupcake yuuuuup, no-one could come up with a better one so I ran with it.

Comment: @ZevSpitz current plan is "assume most everyone gets to Topics by Googling," so probably not a strict hierarchy.  Hierarchies get rough when you can't get people to agree upon them (where does [tag:.net]'s List go, Enumerables; Collections; Mutable Collections; IList implementors; etc.); so we're hopeful cross-linking (ie. Related Topics) and search can obviate the need for them.  Some have argued for a tag-equivalent (so 1 level of grouping, but no further nesting) if it turns out they're needed, which I can support if the need is demonstrated in beta.

Comment: I love this idea, and thank you all for continuously striving to make stackoverflow better and more useful. I can see a big gap that this documentation effort will fill, in documenting open source libraries and sdks on github that are fairly sophisticated and useful, but people either can't discover them or are too intimidated to download and "learn" them because the README.md has nothing beyond the default repository name :)

Comment: Ermmm there is a mistake in the first image after **How Documentation Will Work** The line in the third foreach loop says `Console.WriteLine(val);` should be `Console.WriteLine(str);`

Comment: This needs to support mobile ready/tablet views as a priority as there's nothing more handy than being able to use your phone or tablet (more realistically) as a second screen when you're out and about with just your laptop.

Comment: So who's the enemy that SO Docs will fight?

Comment: I echo concerns about fragmentation. For open source projects that already have their own documentation sites, they may lose volunteers needed to help write the docs in the first place. And let's face it - a custom docs site with interactive examples can be way better than a cookie-cutter wiki page. I think GitHub Pages is already making great strides towards solving the documentation problem. We just have to get people to contribute.

Comment: This should have infinity upvotes.

Comment: What happens to SO once we've _documented all the things_? Do we just refer people to our documentation instead of answering questions? Does everything become a RTFM interaction?

Comment: +1 for WoW reference... just please don't make me manage a garrison.

Comment: I like this idea and I would definitely want to try it out. However I don't think I can contribute much (if any) with my very limited knowledge and experience. Should I sign up for the private beta or would waiting till public beta be recommended?

Comment: @ace you can signup for the private beta, no worries.  Even if you can't contribute, you can almost certainly *review* some contributions.

Comment: @canon there will always be Questions that are too specific for documentation.

Comment: @DanielAbbatt we've already put some thought into responsive designs; we'll have phone/tablet friendly reading experiences much earlier than SO Q&A did.  It won't be a private beta thing though, since we need to nail down the creation of content first and we only have some many resources.

Comment: I was aware of our arch enemy before they hyphenated their name.  The only way I manage to read their name is *expert sex change*.

Comment: @KevinMontrose Do you mean DaniWeb when you say: "it let me see our arch-enemy vanish from my Google results." ?

Comment: The ExtJS docs used to have something **very** similar to this, but the community comments were removed for "being too disruptive". Balderdash and bother; the comments often gave SSCCEs that illustrated how to use a method/config much more clearly than the "official" documentation.

Comment: What precautions will be taken to ensure that this doesn't just turn into a way for application developers to simply crowdsource their product to Stack Overflow by creating documentation and requesting implementation of new features by way of topic request?

Comment: Where will the entry for Documentation sit? Will it be hidden in the tag wiki, or will it be its own entity?

Comment: Before I register-  you aren't looking for some particular guarantee of time from participants, are you?  I'm willing to try it and see if I like it, but I don't promise I can spend X hours a week on it.

Comment: The sample code in your screenshot would fit in the existing Q&A framework just fine as "How do I iterate over the key-value pairs in a Dictionary?".  I'd like to hear what this 'Documentation' feature means for such (often self-answered) questions.  Is it a replacement, and if not, how do we decide what content goes where?

Comment: @KevinMontrose Limited resources? You must construct additional pylons.

Comment: Great idea. I view it as taking community wiki to the next level! :)

Comment: I hate how you're basically following the MSDN format. The so-called "remarks" that get shoved to the bottom are actually the, "let me explain how to use this damn thing" that should be at the top (like in javadoc).

Comment: YESSSS! Because at least for android, the [documentation is already on Stack Overflow](http://blog.ninlabs.com/2013/03/api-documentation/).

Comment: Nice Idea! but what if we create an another meta site for documentation?

Comment: I'm not sure if that "dashboard" UI is supposed to be the main point of entry for a given tag, but if it is then the balance between actually navigating/reading documentation and creating it seems way off—both are equally important, sure, but quite literally only 10% of that screen is about existing, readable documentation and the other 90% consists of various ways to contribute. If I'm trying to solve a problem in the here-and-now just looking at that screen saps my will to live.

Comment: Kevin - seems really interesting, I'll be signing up for the Beta but can we drop (or provide alternative to) the creative commons license? They themselves don't recommend it for source code.

Comment: What about documentation sites that already exist like https://readthedocs.org/?

Comment: I absolutely love this idea. I've wished so many times that I could edit a crappy doc page myself to "fix" all their mistakes, which I only discovered by trial and error (or by pestering the devs). However, I do agree with many of the concerns mentioned thus far -- in particular, handling of **version differences**, and also **copyright and licensing** issues (e.g., just because you have access to an API, doesn't mean you have the right to re-use or share information about it with others, apparently).

Comment: One more quick thought -- I do think it would be great if product groups would eventually turn directly to SO's Docs *instead* of building their own crappy doc pages, just as many groups refer users to SO for Q&A support.

Comment: Will this site cater for "information compendium" questions like [this](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/46716/what-technical-details-should-a-programmer-of-a-web-application-consider-before) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/549/the-definitive-guide-to-form-based-website-authentication)? Because this is an area where it would shine, since "questions" in this format are frowned up today on SO, but there is obviously a lot the community could do there if these were acceptable.

Comment: @Mahn perhaps.  I think within a single tag, definitely.  Compendiums that cross tags really depends on how the community organizes, I think it'd be pretty great to give those a proper non-Q&A home.

Comment: @RocketHazmat we did look at readthedocs.  It's an interesting site, but they seem to be mostly interested in indexing *existing documentation*.  They don't encourage structure or styling consistency, since most of what they've got is pulled out of repos.  It's a lot closer to "import existing docs to the stackoverflow.com domain" than we want to be.

Comment: @ChristopherSwasey > 90% of *reads* for Questions come straight from Google searches.  I'm pretty confident the ratio is about the same for existing documentation, and very much doubt it'll be different for our Documentation.  People will "search > click on result > refine search" rather than "go to Stack Overflow > click Documentation > click .net > click [something] > etc.".  Dashboard is mostly about finding things to do, like the [tag:.net] tag page is.

Comment: @KevinMontrose That's a self-fulfilling prediction. If you design to reinforce that expectation then that's what you'll see, absolutely. It's a bit like ordering the pages of a book randomly and saying "well, most people use the index." I imagine they would, if the actual book had no overall structure. I'm not saying search isn't a huge deal, but I can't see how "better documentation" can side-line higher-level organization as a consequence. It also removes a cognitive framework that can be valuable for editors. Ultimately, it increases the risk of a surfeit of incomplete, patchwork efforts.

Comment: I'm very excited for this; I feel it's been one of the things that Stack Overflow could have been doing better for a long time. I also feel like this could be applicable to many other Stack Exchange sites, such as Photography (how to set up various lighting setups) or Parenting (how to change a diaper). Heck, on Arqade, you could end up with a modern replacement for GameFAQs!

Comment: Would you like the result to be similar to the great pinvoke site ? For example  .pinvoke.net: MiniDumpWriteDump (dbghelp) ; ; http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/dbghelp.MiniDumpWriteDump

Comment: Ah, mission creep. The problem with this is the same as Wikipedia's. It isn't and can never be a normative reference. What the world needs is for the producers to improve their documentation. Not yet another third-party site.

Comment: is there an option to indicate interest with no commitment?

Comment: Particularly hoping for those much-up-voted "off-topic" posts to have somewhere to live: Will this new documentation also have somewhere for comparing technologies etc?

Not so sure about leaving out documentation because existing docs are deemed already good enough: Who judges? There are some "great" pieces of documentation on Microsoft technologies, but that, unfortunately, have sent many novices down a route of very bad architecture.

Comment: tl;dr but I'd like to say that the PHP documentation is something to take motivation from, both technically, and information-ally. The url to doc format etc. are really nice. And they put syntax, definition and examples in a really easy to follow format. One of the rare good parts of PHP. btw http://documentation.org looks available

Comment: Idk if someone already said something about this or even if SO aims it, but in future this documentation environment could be hired as a doc cloud service for enterprises to place their documentation at. it would be handy where I work, since we couldn't find a nice(also modern) environment as well as problems to host it. A private doc with access to allowed SO users could even bring into SO some team mates which don't even know what SO is for but to search google and view solutions. It could get them in for real.

Comment: Can we please label the publish button "**WTFM!**"?

Comment: Thank you to the over 1000 people who have signed up for the beta so far!

Comment: When *typing* a question, would SO parse the title and/or code blocks to provide links to documentation? Stuff like "json_decode isn't working" with php tags could lead to (or show a snippet of) documentation about function json_decode - this could educate users that the documentation exists & is useful.

Comment: How will different **versions** of the language / tool / whatever be handled?

Comment: @CᴴᵁᴮᴮʸNᴵᴺᴶᴬ we're really excited to try things like that, but it's a little chicken-egg so it won't be in the initial beta.  I'm hopeful we'll be able to attack it before Documentation is public (assuming all goes well).

Comment: @m02ph3u5 we've got some rough plans to show in the coming weeks, the gist is "each [tag] has a list of versions, each Topic has a subset of those for the whole thing, and optionally has particular blocks version-tagged as well."  That should handle display and search.  Some additional magic around introducing new versions, and viewing older versions of Topics (like "at the release of X.Y.Z" or "when the link I came through was generated) is also being planned.

Comment: @KevinMontrose Could you add some of this to the original post? Also glad to hear. Signed up for the beta - looking forward to it.

Comment: Will it replace **W3Schools** just like SO replaced **Experts Exchange**?

Comment: @UweKeim the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web) has pretty much replaced W3Schools, at least in terms of community standing and usage, if not in terms of Google search rankings. That being said, I'd still love to see the unholy abomination that is W3Schools get blown out of the water of search rankings by something like SO.

Comment: Is it possible to create a big topic so it would like a tutorial? For example a topic about neural network that has one code example wouldn't be enough or it would be too big.

Comment: Should be "Unicorns of Documentation", I'm disappointed.

Comment: I don't know if you've already covered this, but SO today has some really awesome explanations of concepts that aren't really tied to a particular language or documentation. Say: how does garbage collection work (not really language agnostic but meh), how would one store a history state in image processing, what's a good process for TDD etc etc. Good topics, but pretty general. I'd love to see these general programming concepts stored somewhere for easy access. One problem would be how to categorize them, though. Basically these popular questions that often get deleted due to being "too broad"

Comment: @Jamen Yes to that, we don't need more War nor Lords...

Comment: Permalink headings please?

Comment: Seeing many projects on github without any useful documentation (good working code, no way to know how it works until you google again), is this maybe the move to also get set up a GIT environment, or get a really good integration with github (and maybe the number 2/3 in the code management list) in place? That would really give OS a push like we have not seen yet. Looking in the crystal globe: A good way to manage new features, more open discussions, easier way to contribute to projects since you do not have to follow X projects, but just follow SO.....

Comment: So this is like Wikipedia for documentations?

Comment: In response to all who claim "What if original documentation gets greatly improved?" I want to say: 1- If that happens, that might be a great achievement for SO that motivated them, 2- as @KevinMontrose stated documentations tend to be awful, that's a fact I have been facing for 14 years of software development 3- Of course documentations will get improved, but so is the resource we're gonna have on SO 4- I should reiterate again, it's hard to overestimate the fluidity and the power of SO community over any given company or community to improve documentations!

Comment: Whilst I fully support the idea of documenting good examples, would you envision this also being used for reference material (i.e. names and types of parameters, functions, methods and classes, etc...)? I'm a bit concerned that if SO tried to replace official documentation on reference material it could lead to bad situations when SO is not up to date.

Comment: Why again such an offending name "Warlord"? I think Joel's promised not to mention his hero-days at IDF/war any more in his programming-related work. Couldn't we ban the offending, death-smelling, military language from our coding activities?

Comment: What happens when lazy developers don't document because they know someone else will do it for free on StackOverflow????

Comment: @Troyseph Then it will have reached parity with lazy developers who don't develop for the same reason!  Having said that, anything which encourages other people to do documentation can only be a good thing. It's easy to see why people working unpaid on open source software can't be bothered to document it; it's boring.  Perhaps documentation-bounty is the solution. It's hard to see rep on SO having quite the same draw.

Comment: I learned AngularJS from **Stackoverflow**, not their documentation and now I have a job where I work entirely in angular.  Love this idea!

Comment: I'm on the fence for this one. A centralised documentation resource would be awesome, especially if it's crowd sourced. It would be like Wikipedia for documentation! On the other hand, I think it would complicate and/or clutter SO and direct the site away from it's main purpose: Q&A. Maybe if we could have a completely separate site for the documentation, that SO can hook into, that would be fab. Lastly, I think people are way too concerned about # of clicks/links to get to a desired resource, 2 clicks instead of 1 may be a 100% increase... but in reality it doesn't matter.

Comment: Could you please make the whole system multilingual by default? So that multilingual content can be provided?

Comment: This is a particularly good idea for #Apache-Spark, which is a great language/library but has extremely poor documentation.  Their API is documented, but tutorials and basic steps are lacking.  Maybe Stackoverflow Docs could bridge the gap.

Comment: Out of curiosity does this affect marking answers as a wiki? Overall I'm excited for this though! I think it will remove a lot of unnecessary content that can simply be directed to the documentation side of SO.

Comment: @KevinMontrose There are far too many answers and comments to ensure this hasn't been mentioned, but it would be great if down the road all of this documentation could be provided as a secondary resource in their IDE for Intellisense (as named in Visual Studio) or similar for developers to have direct access to it while working. While that may be outside the scope for the initial push, it should be on the roadmap to enhance the usability over time.

Comment: Aside from this, we've also discovered that we need a new villain.

Comment: God, I'd forgotten about Experts Exchange. *shudders*. Also, I think this is a great idea, and pretty much what I was asking for - albeit very badly - here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275243/stack-overflow-basics-tutorial-style-minisite

Comment: Suggest that we start with refactoring with those duplicated questions and answers on SO, those duplicated Q&A would be good indicator of the degree of document improvement. SO may generate a list of candidate topics by analyzing the distribution of Q&A.

Comment: Hypothetically, and eventually, assuming this succeeds, will it also be rolled out to the other SE sites?

Comment: This is a great idea!  Many of the questions on this site are in response to very poor documentation and worse code examples.

Comment: Documentation should not be subject to up and down voting. Documentation is not a popularity contest.... so ok, but it would have to be pretty much totally different from Stack Overflow.

Comment: Much of the discussion here comes from preconceptions about what it means for something to be "documentation," and whether that's even possible from a communal, unofficial source. If we look at the underlying idea behind this project, the focus seems to be on providing a repository for easily creating clean, community-generated, living long-form information on subjects too technical for Wikipedia. Sounds brilliant! The only thing I'd add is: also make it beautiful. Long form reading should be easy on the eyes. Picture a lovechild born to S.O. from a tryst with Medium.com!

Comment: @Andy and Kevin, I think as long as there's an ability to link back to the original document/specification page/section on the project site, this may not be an issue.  This may also allow "amendments" to existing documentation, and perhaps somewhat prevent people from trying to copy and mine/replicate a whole document entry on something.

Comment: All for it. I look forward with great anticipation to the day that a new OSS project publishes its docs on S.O.

Comment: Hate the name. Nothing good ever came from warlords, surely? Please use a more positive name.

Comment: @StigBrautaset, I think it's meant as a reference to the WoW expansion "Warlords of Draenor", not an actual title.

Comment: Great idea! I think additionally a **"How To"** category would be good as well ... i.e. "How to configure WCF properly" etc.which would explain it step by step along with the do's and don'ts

Comment: @KevinMontrose Will we be able to choose the structure of our documentation posts? For example, will be I be forced to begin documentation with a wall of code like in your image, or will I be able to start with something understandable, like complete sentences in English?

Comment: Glad to see I'm not the only one who has issue with the gendered and aggressive language used to title this concept.

Comment: I'm interested to see where this one goes - and in helping out. It's a well thought out and potentially disruptive idea that could transform a huge area developers and their kin are involved with every day.

Comment: @Plutonix about the MSDN: having a working example on every method would be one thing. Or a documentation on the fact that, even though a method is inherited, it's not implemented or doesn't work as expected. The infamous web control comes to mind...

Comment: +1. The example repository is why I support this idea so much!

Comment: personally i feel the interesting part in stack overflow is the comments and various explanations based on individuals perspective for same question, most of the time 0 voted explanation will be more useful to understand the issue. if at all documentation is going to happen then i suggest aggregation of comments based on topics should also be there which makes documentation lively. on side note some times i do find msdn as well as social.msdn.com has better answers for some peculiar problems, that's for me.

Comment: Consider EJP's comment starting with "Ah, mission creep", and also the initial concerns about changes to the described project: Are we going to be a service for hosting documentation? What's next: code storage in version control, issue tracking, interactive online tutorials? I'm honestly undecided whether any of that is good or bad. SO has huge talent in UI design, and web site scalability - _that_ attracts the crowd and made it big. So maybe expansion of that talent to solve other problems is the right thing to do for the devs.

Comment: Shouldn't the third example of iterating over a dictionary output be Console.Writeline(str)? :-)

Comment: I wish StackOverflow provided a blogging platform for developers - ideally with no downvotes or moderation. Also I wish StackOverflow allowed me to make my own "howtos" to share with other developers and record the solutions I find for problems.

Comment: I already find what I search on SO. Documentation site will not be hit because will be eclipsed by SO answers, which in my opinion already do perfect job.

Comment: @DukeDougal "I wish StackOverflow provided a blogging platform for developers - ideally with no downvotes or moderation." -- GitHub Pages covers that already.

Comment: If you are curious too like me here's the SO profile of [Jamie Dixon](http://stackoverflow.com/users/90678/jamie-dixon)

Comment: As someone who has dabbled in Minecraft modding, [tag:minecraft-forge] needs this _badly_.

Comment: So I tried to search the page, but didn't find anything about this: I'm relatively proficient in multiple languages (e.g. Java, C#, VB, JavaScript). Languages have many similarities (looping, equality test, assignment, branching), but not every language has an exact alternative to a given construct in another language (pointers, gotos, class properties, multiple inheritance, external assembly references, and on and on and on) - often for various arguably "good" reasons. If they do have an alternative, they might use a different word for it, which complicates finding info about it (continued)

Comment: If I'm learning a language that's new to me, say Python, I would be able to find info on branching, variable declarations/scope, etc. in a basic syntax comparison chart, examples, or a tutorial, but what if I'm trying to use something like Java's annotations/C# attributes? I can Google "C# attributes in python" and find that the python equivalent is "decorators" - I would think there would be room somewhere on an SO/Docs page for "translation" into other languages, possibly even selectable per user for which languages they're interested in / already know (continued)

Comment: For example, something simple like logical "and" could have a section on the page itself showing equivalent syntax: "&&" for Languages X,Y,Z, etc "-and" for languages W and Q or "And" for languages U and P, etc. For more complex concepts, like decorators, it would have a list of links to pages on the equivalent construct or concept for each language that supports it (JavaScript would be N/A [for now...]) (done, thanks for reading?)

Comment: Just curious, how are people selected for the beta? I've tried signing up (twice) but haven't heard anything.

Comment: @ivarni the beta is underway, but we're letting people in in waves.  Documentation is big and new, I don't want to burn everyone out on v0.1.  At time of writing, a little less than 1/3 of all the people who signed up have been invited.  Another wave will be invited Soon™, and everyone who signed up will be invited before the beta ends.

Comment: Can I assume that private beta signups are still being accepted since you still have a link to the signup sheet?

Comment: @JAtkin yep, beta is still underway so signups are still being accepted.  When the beta is ready to "end" this post will be updated to that effect (there will probably be another follow up post too, we'll see).

Comment: Ha, just found this post while searching for a (imho) related problem: writing up the "stuff you have to do before stackoverflow can help you - and once you've done that, you will find out that it's a duplicate of this,this,this and this". Do you think we can sneak that one in this project as well?

Comment: @KevinMontrose I'd really like to help. I THINK I signed up when this post went live... I have either not received an invite (likely) or deleted the email (also likely). I just signed up again, but see you are accepting people in waves. When will the next wave be?

Comment: @KevinMontrose could we also get an update in this post? (Like how the other meta posts have been doing updates) Will documentation fall under the CC-BY-SA or MIT license?

Comment: @HunterStevens Documentation will be whatever the license on SO is, which I'd kind of hoped would be attribution-optional MIT but currently still is CC-BY-SA.  The next wave will be when we're ready for one :)  They tend to come every week or two, but are gated by which tags you signed up for.  You haven't been invited yet, but you will be (everyone who signed up will get in eventually).

Comment: @KevinMontrose I read that SO wants attribution _required_ MIT license. Was there some change I was unaware of? Or would that be just for Docs

Comment: @HunterStevens that was a proposed change, it hasn't taken effect (and based on reception, won't ever take effect).  I personally find it odd that there was pushback on both the ["optional attribution"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/271080/130213) and the ["mandatory attribution"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/272956/130213) proposals (especially since CC-BY-SA is already "mandatory attribution"), but that's where we are.  Documentation isn't going to do something wild with licensing just because it can, integration with SO Q&A is important.

Comment: @KevinMontrose I read the first proposal as still requiring attribution, but the second doing so in a harsh (and clarified) way. But hey... <some witty comment here>

Comment: @HunterStevens the first proposal is "attribution on request by the copyright holder," it's optional for the contributor to request it essentially.  The second proposal (and current CC-BY-SA) is "attribution always required," the contributor doesn't have the option to not request.

Comment: @KevinMontrose Can we get a status update on Documentation?  I'm very excited about it, and I signed up for the Beta three times (haha) but I don't know what's going on and IT'S MAKING ME CRAAZZZZY

Comment: "If a project already has awesome documentation that's easy to search and cite, then there's no need to duplicate it on Stack Overflow. We're interested in fixing what's broken with documentation, not just moving them onto Stack Overflow." - this seems to be a somewhat different conclusion than code samples, images, pastebins, quotes, etc. I know it's a different beast, but maybe having SO guarantee its own stability and self-sufficiency is still worth having redundant sources for documentation? If you want to link back to the original, that's still possible, same as with pastebins/quotes.

Comment: Any update about the beta?  I know invites went out in waves, but will there be any more invites?  Had signed up initially but haven't received an invite yet.

Comment: @PetahChristian [an update post just went out](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319319/documentation-the-update-en-ing) - the beta is still underway.

Comment: Not a good idea.

Comment: @KevinMontrose If Documentation takes off for SO, are there plans to bring this to other SE sites?  There are a few where Documentation could be seriously useful.

Comment: #1: The entire existence of Docs.so is an afterthought, by definition. It is intrinsically impossible for StackOverflow to solve that problem. #2 'Lacking in examples' is not a sufficient motivation for deciding that there should be another whole system that is example-based. #3 'Tied to release cycles' is exactly what documentation should be. No real problem is being addressed here. #4 Yet another straw man. Javadoc does not consist of 'unshareable links', and there are many thousands of SO posts that prove it. Again no real problem is being addressed here. These motivations are spurious.

Comment: It's interesting how the name of this topic relates with the Warlords of Draenor xpac for WoW. Both of those were made with a very good idea in mind and in heart, but ultimately weren't that good. Maybe calling the next big feature "_Legion_" can bring a bit more luck!

Answer (score 868):

**Yes**! I support this idea, if the focus is to create **examples**.

I already use SO frequently to get a fast view of how to do something. For example, if I Google for "node.js write file", I want to quickly find how I can do it.

[image: Google]

## On Stack Overflow:

[image: Stack Overflow]

## On Node.js official docs:

[image: Node.js]

Which one is **faster** to get what you need?

I want to help writing docs for technologies that I like providing **good examples** for **fast access**.

Comment: +1 Immediate examples are so much more useful than *here is a bunch of words to parse*.

Comment: Exactly what we want to fix.

Comment: This example is very strange: the node/fs documentation you mention is full of examples. In fact the green links of your screenshot link to examples... See https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_filename_data_options_callback

Comment: @DenysSéguret I'd rather see the example straight up, than parse, understand, and maybe _guess_ which method link is relevant; that I follow, and _maybe_ find an example.

Comment: Not to mention, where on the page your answer is.

Comment: @DenysSéguret, I agree. The page is full of examples, but there are many and sorrounded by very detailed information. You can't find what you need in 5 seconds.

Comment: How would Qs like this one fit in when docs existed? Just a 'related question', which the now-answer to is _obviously_ just "check out SO docs"? Would there be a new close reason, like "answer is an [example in the docs](link!)"?

Comment: @DenysSéguret With something like that nodejs doc, there is so much information oftentimes people don't know where to start. With a simple, immediate example, it helps someone *just get the dang thing working* and from that starting point they can further review the docs and refine their code.

Comment: @DaveZych A documentation can always be made better but seriously those critics sound like coming from people who either don't know JS or didn't even look at [the page](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html).

Comment: @DenysSéguret Isn't that exactly what docs are for? People who don't know a feature of the language/framework they're working with? I've worked with NodeJS before (albeit not a ton) and I still get confused with their docs sometimes.

Comment: Why do you think it's important for the page that helps you to be called "Documentation" rather than a "Question"? The current SO is already providing what you need.

Comment: You already did get the example you needed. If you hadn't found one and were still having difficulty, you could ask a Question and request that the Answer include an example.

Comment: It's hard to take that example seriously. I mean you have a perfect nodejs documentation and tons of examples across the web (and the first page on google). If you are still see a problem to find out how to write a file using nodejs, you are simply not willing to find it. period.

Comment: If SO became the #1 repository of easily-searchable examples by language, framework, etc. **I would never look anywhere else**. Yes, one can google "How do I do X in Y-language/Z-framework" and you might come up with a examples through SO (sometimes), blog sites, etc., but if you want to do something in a not-so-popular framework or language, **who better to show you how than the experts**. I support this fully, as **99% of the things I search for in terms of software development are examples**. Yes, I know how to read the Oracle Java Documentation, but **that takes so frigging long**.

Comment: Isn't your example rather supporting the idea that SO already provides such documentation as it is, without any need for a separate site, or is that new documentation site perhaps an alternative way to host questions like this particular example, which many would vote to close as "too broad" or "showing insufficient research"?

Comment: @Bruno, "SO already provides such documentation as it is, without any need for a separate site" - it provides documentation, but it was not designed for that. Creating a new site with this specific use case would provide better results.

Comment: @Bruno, "questions like this particular example, which many would vote to close as "too broad" or "showing insufficient research""- yes, I believe that this new site would affect how we handle questions, but this a good thing. We need more quality questions where answers are not trivial.

Comment: @Zanon "*it provides documentation, but it was not designed for that*"... Every time I try to suggest on meta that the main driver of SO is askers having problems and answerers willing to help, with the knowledge building being a secondary, but intended effect, I'm told that SO has always primarily been a KB (especially by hardcore curators). Knowledge base and documentation are extremely similar concepts. If we're talking about "recipes", SO is spot on as it is. Class by class, method by method API documentation really belongs to the official stuff. Tutorials are a different category as well.

Comment: Out of this exmaple I see, there should be a "make documentation" button on SO to create links back and forth and reuse already available content. Also I think, it would be better to create a "getting started" collection than of documentation where such questions are easily explained and afterwards comes further information to details.
But I think, this example is pretty good. If I open node.js page, there are many links, where I would click on fs.write(..) since it is the topmost that sounds useful. So I won't notice fs.writeFile really and as beginner in node.js would go to SO ;)

Comment: I die a little inside when everyone starts going on about making it "faster" to go to examples without having to actually _read_. Without _reading_ and _perusing_ how are you going to gain any real understanding of what you're doing? Copy/pasting examples without understanding is exceptionally dangerous (IME leading to many stupid SO questions) and I'd really rather people went out of their way to put _more_ time into their research, not less. As such, all this "yes yes move everything to SO so it's _faster_" seems to be like the direct opposite of what we should be doing.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Perfect, just perfect. No doubt people will counter your comment with rationalisations, but no rationalisation gets around a fundamental problem.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, "How to tie a tie?" - you can learn with a 2 minutes youtube tutorial or with a 30 minutes lenghty explanation with the different existing techniques and the history behind them. I agree that people need to read more to avoid basic mistakes, but it depends on the situation. If you need to write a file just for testing, a basic code example is enough. If you are building a log library like log4net that will be used by millions, so you need to read a lot about how to write files. What we need is to give people the power of choice.

Comment: @Zanon In response to that I agree with some others that this just isn't the place for it. Contribute to the project documentation?! (Doesn't help you much with MSDN, I realise.) It seems silly to start a whole new repository for documentation and/or examples. Remember [that XKCD about standards](https://xkcd.com/927/).......?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit What actually worries me about this particular Node.js example is that it's effectively aimed at people who cannot be bothered scrolling down below the table of contents. Whilst I agree the ToC could be on the side for better presentation, this is taking programmer's hand-holding to a whole new level...

Comment: Documentation needs to be in version control with the code, but referencing bits of it from discussion would be invaluable.  Python notebooks are a good start for documenting stats/numerical justifications.  Good Python diagramming tool APIs (statemachine, dependsGraph, branchTracks, messagingDiagram, structLayout) from notebooks would be a start.  Being able to query the docs and run examples would be an eventual goal.

Comment: In the node example the answer uses `writeFile`. I press the link to the official documentation, next I press `Ctrl + F`, I write `writeFile`, done. A couple of seconds. Just saying.

Comment: Uh Node's docs are full of useful examples. I go there 100% of the time over SO for information regarding the Node API. Bad example.

Comment: @Qix, Node docs are great. I'm not saying that they are bad. What I'm saying is that there is too much information to read and parse until you get what you need. The difference is that SO is faster. Just that. What I hope for SO docs is another fast place to get useful examples.

Comment: I like the idea of giving examples. But I've also seen documentation with mostly examples and very little verbal explanation or technical specs (like list of calls and their contracts and properties for each object) that didn't explain or showed the full power of their api. I'd say if we focus on only giving examples to explain the usage, then we'd better aim to explain each use case possible for that particular api call, or add just the most common use case as an example but complement it with a good spec, and verbal description as we usually aim (but only in some cases has been achieved).

Comment: Examples are extremely important and often more useful than documentation. A poorly documented function may be fine if the usage is obvious. "GetRowEnumerator()" clearly returns a row enumerator, and hopefully you know what to do with that. But if you don't, a few lines of code showing a) what includes/imports are necessary, b) what setup variables are necessary, c) how such a thing is typically used i.e., in a while loop, d) how to handle errors, where to catch exceptions, how to clean up - when I'm looking for information, these are the things that I want.

Comment: This problem is exactly why I am writing [wat](https://github.com/dthree/wat) right now... to aggregate multiple doc sources to provide a basic description, *examples* and nothing more, instantly.

Comment: From my point of view i use SO and examples from it when i need to solve my problem real quick (stuck at some problem and can't find a way out). Documentation is sometimes "boring" but in most cases there is a lot of advanced use of methods that we could use and it's only mentioned in that "boring" documentation. At the end, SO examples are written by programmers which read documentation and summarized it so people which are having problem with some specific technology can instantly find solution. +1 for excellent answer

Comment: But isn't this what SO already brings to the community? The specific example is something I actually wouldn't really approve of, but I've used SO in this way as well. I'm not convinced that this will actually change the result of our searches. How many people actually follow documentation links? Most people are just looking for a plain answer to their specific question, which, in many cases, is already available (sometimes multiple times) on StackOverflow. I agree that much of the documentation available is bad, but this doesn't fix that. It might even cause ambiguity.

Comment: Fantastic example. I have created an Access database, with a few columns, one is the base code language in the record, the next are key tag terms for searching, i.e. "connection string",  "call to db", misc terms I might search on pertinent to the last column, a code snippet that performs the task in the language mentioned. I have a few hundred records now covering over a dozen languages. Would love to have something similar and a bit more structured.

Comment: Ideally I want to see two examples.  A simple one and a more complex real world one.  The best documentation I've ever used in book form was a Paradox Programmers Guide to PAL.  It had each function, and two examples - a trivial one and a real world one.

Comment: I for one need both a quick example to solve immediate tasks at hand (especially in a new domain), *and* access to the full documentation for better system understanding long-term. Generally, I need to frob a widget _now_ and need an example so I can build a frobber *this week*. But then, knowing how a frobber works and expecting to integrate with some related widgets *next quarter*, I have an anchor to jump into the docs with _and_ time to read them. Going straight to docs (that screenshot screams "wall of text" at a Node newb like me) is a forbidding learning curve without a project in mind.

Comment: ...So to me, having a docs.SO site [likely strongly based on existing examples in SO proper] seems like a great place to start searching for practical info on a topic. A hub; a documentation search engine curating links to the official sources [I'd propose a required `official source` link whenever possible] and floating the most immediately relevant stuff to the top, but *not* trying to build all of its own content. Imaging a future where this exists and is well built and populated, I don't see why I'd start anywhere else - but I also would plan to pass through the harbor to dive deeper.

Comment: It'd be great if "Documentation" supports Google Knowledge graph or another advanced markup features to let it [Google] show the best example[-s] even in the search result page. This'd be another -1 step to get the answer to simple and popular questions.

Comment: People learn in different ways, Some learn via reading extensive docs, some learn by looking at pictures or diagrams, Some learn by watching videos demonstrating/explaining the technology they are interested in learning about.... I think that which ever way is more comfortable for a person to learn is the way that they should learn, and not be criticized for doing it the 'wrong' way or for 'taking short cuts'...

Comment: This answer already proved what I was thinking, that there is no real need for this other that SO team don't know what to do next after SO is so successful. Just looking at the example here I see that the user already found what was searching for and is taking it from SO. Documentation site will not be hit because will be eclipsed by SO answers, which in my opinion already do perfect job. I think so much brain power spent on this could be used to more useful things.

Comment: I think if official documentation exists - however good or bad - it should be linked here on stackoverflow. Second point - webplatform tried to bring together all web documentation. And a couple of years later they still haven't - I don't think they are even moving very fast. But links to docs + examples may be a good idea.

Answer (score 603):

I'm concerned about the fragmentation this can cause.

> If a project already has awesome documentation that’s easy to search and cite, then there’s no need to duplicate it on Stack Overflow. We’re interested in fixing what’s broken with documentation, not just moving them onto Stack Overflow.

Some documentation sites like MSDN have both good and bad documentation. How do you see people decide on what documentation is good enough to not have to redo it on SO?

Is one of the goals to eventually see work being done here go back upstream to the official documentation of a project? If so, I think attaching a CC license to it could cause a lot of headaches down the line.

What if the official documentation is greatly improved, surpassing the quality of documentation on SO? Will you remove the content on SO?

These are just some questions that spring to mind, I'm sure there are other things to discuss about fragmentation.

Comment: I did not think about this... I think you brought up a great point. I think, maybe, we should group questions most likely asked in a single place. It is similar to the original idea, but I still think links to _official_ documentation is better. Links are always updated (for version changes), and like you said -- you can't CC something that was already created by someone else.

Comment: It could end up being something similar to the sponsored tags - companies may _opt_ to have their docs on SO

Comment: This is why I'd rather go to http://devdocs.io/ then having a wiki on SO.

Comment: But won't it be survival of the fittest? If people find the vendor docs are better they will link to that instead.

Comment: In the long run, we would like to be the official source of documentation for all the things.  That's a very long term goal.  We think that the changes we're making to documentation's unit of work, making it community editable, and the training aspects it brings to the rest of Stack Overflow are keys to its success.  So, frankly, all the things should eventually be documented here, but for the beginning we want to fix the worst parts.

Comment: These all seem like really good problems to have. In that any problem that arises due to having too much good documentation is, in some sense, worth having.

Comment: @NickLarsen Some documentation, e.g. the official D Programming Language documentation, is completely open source. Do you also plan on hosting that content on SO?

Comment: @JacqueGoupil this site looks interesting, but only to *.js users. all other programming languages seem severly underrepresented there..

Comment: @Stijn No.  We looked at the open source aspects of it and frankly it's still a lot of work to edit documentation via that route.  Of course if a project owner wants to maintain the control of their documentation, then there won't be anything we can do about that, but our intuition is that it will prove to be a negative over time.  Any content on SO will be new content, in whatever format we end up landing on with the possible exception of a project owner blessing the content on us, in which case it will still have to be converted to our format.

Comment: One of the problems I have with even really great documentation is that it tends to lack real-world examples. Lately, I've been using Google to find out how to use language features that I haven't fully grasped. Often one of the results is a Stack Overflow question. I'm biased, but the answers to a real world question tend to provide better help than the often abstract official documentation. Examples are the overlooked (and I think revolutionary) key to this proposal.

Comment: @JonEricson in my experience, the reason Stack Overflow is useful is because it is a practical answer to a practical problem. Examples/documentation do not provide that almost universally - what is useful is, "I want to do X" or "I have a problem with X" where X is specific enough to be what I want. When it's, "here's a lot of information about X" and I just want a single piece of it, I have to read through a lot of useful-but-not-what-I-need information.

Comment: @NickLarsen: "*In the long run, we would like to be the official source of documentation for all the things.*" - that's exactly what I'm concerned about. It would become a single point of failure, and a single point of control. Diverse and decentralised systems are safer and fairer. I'd love if you help to provide 21st-century-adequate documentation tools to the developer community, but I wouldn't like if they're hosted by a single company. Even if it's one that is [not turning evil](https://xkcd.com/792/).

Comment: @Bergi All of the documentation written on SO will be licensed the same as all of our other content, CCWiki, we won't even own it, and anyone can reuse basically however they want to as long as they provide attribution to the people who wrote it.  I don't think control is a real issue here.

Comment: If the end result of SO documentation is "documentation everywhere else on the internet is better than we could ever provide" then Mission Accomplished. I'll delete the code myself.  More practically, I expect that if there's no demand for documentation for X (because X's docs are good) nobody will ask for them, and nobody will create them.

Comment: @KevinMontrose "[If] documentation everywhere else on the internet [becomes] better than we could ever provide then Mission Accomplished. I'll delete the code myself." -- That might not be so simple. A regular occurrence at [Wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org) are deletion requests along the lines of "we moved the book to a more appropriate platform, can you delete the obsolete copy here?", with the default reply by the community being "The CC license is irrevocable, we might develop the text in a different direction, there is no reason to delete it". How would we handle such scenarios here?

Comment: @duplode if the community cannot be convinced the alternative is better, why should the community delete it?  And vice versa, if the community is convinced to shutdown a section how (and why) would we stop them?  I know we're discussing hypothetical cases, but I have trouble imagining a scenario where a strictly superior alternative is presented *and* it fails to convince a majority of contributors to move.

Put another way: we already delete sites, tags, users, and questions.  I'm not too concerned about documentation being somehow (and uniquely) un-delete-able if merited.

Comment: @KevinMontrose Indeed, and for that matter I do think the default stance at Wikibooks is sensible. The point is just that I don't expect such decisions to be smooth and uncontroversial. A somewhat related concern would be drama arising from open source politics, as highlighted by [this comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303865/warlords-of-documentation-a-proposed-expansion-of-stack-overflow/303871?noredirect=1#comment240261_303871).

Comment: @NickLarsen your CC licence is rather difficult to upstream; suggest using a more BSD/MIT-style licence. (I already dual-licence all my content and document that on my network profile.) Even CC-BY is more copyleft-ish than the BSD/MIT-style ones.

Comment: So, most of the concerns voiced have been around "where are the lines". I think one thing this answer demonstrates is that we need a follow up post that lays down some more of the "rules and guidelines" we've imagined exist.  Would you agree @Stijn?

Comment: @Kevin I agree. I'm not against the idea, just not convinced yet.

Comment: I’m also not completely convinced that having another prominent contender will not split up the documentation-willing userbase. For example for web stuff, we already have Wikis like [WebPlatform](https://www.webplatform.org/) and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/), and other strong platforms like MSDN or even devdocs competing with each other; and neither platform is really exhaustive on most stuff.

Comment: @NickLarsen: Soon you'll have libraries that export API docs as stub Q&As...

Comment: @NickLarsen "In the long run, we would like to be the official source of documentation for all the things." I think this is overly ambitious and will fail. The reasons are that the producer of code is the official source of documentation and that SO has a nice plattform but maybe not the best suited for all ways of documentation. Also it would require an awful lot of effort and commitment which is difficult to imagine with volunteers. I think that smaller goals are more realistic and helpful.

Comment: I'm very divided about this proposal, and particularly the issue identified here. Frankly, I don't think that [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com) is "the enemy", nor that links to it are any more fragile than links to SO, and I would really resist anything which might weaken that project. Undoubtedly there are other examples of good community-maintained documentation, and there are certainly open source projects with excellent documentation (Python, IMHO). The idea of creating "one true repository" strikes me as hubris.

Comment: Agreed. I would be much more enthusiastic about this proposal if the goal were to encourage/facilitate collaboration with maintainers of existing documentation (especially--though not limited to--"official" documentation). This would have the dual benefit of improving official documentation and providing SO Documentation a lot of initial content. "Usurping" should be considered a tactic of last resort, or an unfortunate accident. Also, this strikes me as related: https://xkcd.com/927/

Comment: @KevinMontrose: _"I expect that if there's no demand for documentation for X (because X's docs are good) nobody will ask for them, and nobody will create them."_ I worry that rep miners would simply copy the official docs; lots of people will search on the Docs site and find and upvote the copies. I guess the community would flag this and moderators would delete the copy, but it will be confusing to users, and will happen continually.

Comment: As long as it can be downloaded offline, I think that this project is a plus.  I thank @Jacque Goupil above for pointing me to devdocs.io, this is awesome.  I use Dash on Mac and iPad to do much the same.  I REALLY loved MSDN on CD/DVD when I was doing Windows development.  But with everything being online now, and you can't even run the AngularJS documentation without a webserver, it's a little irritating the state of things.  I can't go into the mountains and code at night disconnected from the Internet anymore.  In 1999 I could do that.  We've taken a GIANT leap backward in that regard.

Comment: Is it bad to have duplicates of documentation and examples?. I would rather have multiple of same example because they can differ a little bit and I can be the judge to decide which example helped me most.

Comment: "We want to control all documentation so we get more ad revenue, but in the meantime let's make a mess and fragment everything."  No thanks.  Not to mention the massive quality issues that are bound to happen, even if you somehow manage to convince people to do far more reviewing and editing than happens on SO currently.

Comment: I think that if the version of the API/library were able to be specified, fragmentation wouldn't be a bad problem. Angular Docs provide a dropdown, and the entire documentation can be viewed at any version number. jQuery does things differently, and simply specifies which verson of the API the method applies to. I think a combination of both methods would allow any fragmentation that were to happen, to be fairly small in impact.

Comment: As well, if an open source library has a release that doesn't start out having any docs, and these are required to be added over time, it seems like a Stack Overflow version of the docs might be more accessible to edit than a GitHub version, since the control is out of the hands of the maintainers. Sometimes, open source project maintainers are not very responsive to needs from the community.

Comment: WoD team: May I suggest you hustle to get a design win for this idea? Get a commitment from some significant project that they'll use WoD as their primary documentation outlet. It doesn't have to be a hugely adopted project like php or bootstrap, but it should be significant enough that the team has worked out the editing, distribution, translation, and intellectual-property issues. Alternatively, get Tim O'Reilly on board. You'll learn a lot.

Comment: See [my answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/304034/3159183) about how to address duplication and fragmentation problems.

Comment: @poke You already cited the 2 sites I was thinking of. I'll add http://caniuse.com with its information about Resources (and prefixes and support obviously)

Comment: What happens when lazy developers don't document because they know someone else will do it for free on StackOverflow????

Comment: Consider how a framework becomes popular. A developer creates it, hosts it on github or elsewhere, provides some documentation and people discover it and find it is useful. As more and more people discover it, it grows in popularity. One factor for popularity is that the framework solves an existing issue, is simple and is well documented. But that necessarily means the documentation is created first by the author. Do you expect authors to now come to SO and start creating documentation for all kinds of frameworks? I think the issue of organic creation will mean necessary duplication.

Comment: @KevinMontrose Rep farmers mean you'll get duplicates, even if it isn't copy/paste. On deleting, "the community" isn't monolithic. What will happen is part of "the community" will think the external docs are better (and "leave"), but part will always think the SO version is better - even if it's for arbitrary reasons like formatting. Since they're the active users, their opinion will likely carry the day. Thus the SO version will duplicate external docs and then won't ever get deleted. That's fine if you're aiming for "all the things", but please don't send mixed messages on your intent.

Answer (score 311):

I don't want to be too negative about this idea, but it does make me uneasy. The main issue is how it blurs the line between official documentation and community-contributed content. Explaining a bit further: a while ago someone proposed that [Hackage](https://hackage.haskell.org/) (the main repository of Haskell libraries) should make the symmetrical move and add user comments to the API documentation, perhaps with wiki curation *a la* Stack Overflow. I replied with the following comment:

> I see your point, but when I go to Hackage I expect to find canon, word-of-God from the developers, and not a blooming garden of possibly conflicting advice (as expected in /r/haskell or other discussion platforms).

Evidently the concern is not as serious for what we are discussing here, as Stack Overflow is (at least in principle) not an official part of any project. The core issue, however, is the same. As I see it, documentation, be it good or bad, is canon, information vetted by the developers. Treating user-submitted content as documentation risks confusion, obsolescence and, [as Stijn points out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303867/2751851), fragmentation. There might be effective ways to avoid that, but I would suggest treading carefully.

Comment: Fair point. I know I'd be pretty disillusioned if I ever found confusing, obsolete or fragmented information on a developer's official site.

Comment: @Shog9 lol. We're being chipper today, aren't we? :)

Comment: This whole discussion is bringing back unpleasant memories of installing MSDN from cd-rom.

Comment: This is a valid point.  Our approach is entirely based on serving the immediate needs of developers in the sense of "I searched google for a problem I'm having right now", with enough effort put into the back end to support the "I want to learn everything there is to know about this thing".  "Official" documentation doesn't really matter to the user in the first case, I just want my problem solved and as fast as possible.  I'd also argue that usually best practices are the result of people using it how they use it, not just how the developer wants it to be used.

Comment: @Pekka웃 But this then brings us to another problem: _Who is an "official" contributor_? What's the threshold? On the Internet, nobody knows you're a dog. Also, `FFmpeg`, `Libav`, or both? `Apache OpenOffice` vs `LibreOffice`? `eglibc` vs. `glibc`? `egcs` vs. `gcc`?  Adjudging who is or is not an "official" contributor rapidly brings into play questions of anonymity, open-source project politics and duplication, especially after controversial forks.

Comment: I don't think we're blurring the line very much, it's not as if we'll be saying "we're the official [tag:.net] docs", and we won't be co-opting anyone's branding or anything nefarious.  SO Documentation will look no more official than SO Q&A does; if a project wishes to endorse SO they could (I mean, long term; I don't _want_ any endorsements until we're out of beta).

Comment: Agreed. A good bad example is the "official" php-doc at php.net.

Comment: How would be handled the foreseeable controversial articles? If mr. X posts his solution and mr. Y posts an opposite one, what it would be seen like? Based upon users voting?

Comment: in my experience the examples provided by official documentation rarely provide the use case you are looking for.  The official source will provide the "basic" or "1-path" example.  Hopefully the SO version will provide the examples for other use-cases and/or for other combinations of code.

Comment: @KevinMontrose - [Nick said the opposite](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303865/warlords-of-documentation-a-proposed-expansion-of-stack-overflow?cb=1#comment240184_303867): *"we would like to be the official source of documentation for all the things"*.  I certainly think there is a need for community provided documentation augmentation, but I've also seen problems arise when [non-authoritative sources try to look like official documentation](http://www.w3fools.com/). I think this endeavor can be a great success, as long as it addresses the fragmentation and officiality concerns.

Comment: @gilly3 Nick's saying "if, in the future, the actual owners of the product/library/whatever **officially declare us to be the docs** that would be awesome"; not that we are going to declare ourselves the official docs.

Comment: Just because we're not canonical doesn't mean we're not extremely helpful.  Just like any other SO answer, it's up to the readers to decide how helpful something is--if it's bad documentation, it will get downvoted or edited.  End of story.  No real problem there.

Comment: Also, no matter how carefully you label these as **unofficial** documentation, we all know how carefully new programmers in a hurry pay attention to that stuff. A project like this will surely create _at least some_ complaints to the developers of a project about "incorrect" documentation" that exists here. It would not have to be a flood of such complaints to really sour the folks developing the tools we'd be trying to "help" by providing documentation.

Comment: On the other hand, I often find the user submitted comments on PHP.net to be much more useful than the official documentation.

Comment: The beauty of Stack Overflow is that, even though users can submit a "blooming garden of conflicting advice", the **voting system takes care of it.** People will upvote what is useful and correct, and downvote what is incorrect or unclear.

Comment: For the php.net example, its docs aren't bad [might be biased as core php-src dev], but it often lacks real-world examples and user comments sometimes are better docs than the actual docs. Also, I feel like php.net is suffering from a too high bar to edit. Yes, there's https://edit.php.net, but it's clumsy, and nobody likes that docbook syntax... [Sure, once you perfectly know that syntax, fine...]. Hence I definitely can appreciate an attempt for better examples/docs. Might even lead to php.net doc maintainers to search examples here… maybe… IMO, we really need to give it a try and we'll see.

Comment: How does this interact with basically bug fixes? I can imagine (because there are answers like this) where SO answers say 'Well, you should call this API to do it, but that doesn't work today, so use this other workaround instead.' That's obviously not something that would be in the original documentation. And, if they fix it, that example may need to change so people don't continue using archaic workarounds....

Comment: one valid opposing point..

Comment: @CorleyBrigman That's basically what a lot of comments on php.net are. Workarounds and bug fixes, but they never get fixed in a lot of cases except that the frameworks implement the work arounds sometimes.  What bothers me about php.net which people always claim to like so much is that there are almost no new comments when I look.

Comment: This concern could easily be allayed by titling it "Community Documentation".

Comment: @TylerH Not if developers are encouraged to transfer control of the documentation of their projects to SO, so that there would be no "Official Documentation" to contrast with "Community Documentation". Or if developers are brought in as moderators within the scope of their projects, so that it wouldn't really be "Community Documentation" anymore. The point is that there is an inherent tension between the concepts of "community" and  "documentation", and ignoring that tension means underestimating the importance of documentation as technical *reference*.

Comment: @duplode Why would developers be encouraged to transfer control of official documentation to an external community? There is no tension between community and documentation. You think a community is incapable of documenting something?

Comment: @TylerH Two answers, in two comments. (1) Quoting staff member Nick Larsen, "In the long run, we would like to be the official source of documentation for all the things". There are nuances to that statement, as the discussion in other comments to this answer shows, but it doesn't change that the proposal considers that replacing official documentation would be a good thing. Furthermore, and regardless of the intentions of the SO team, SO Docs would be (another) incentive for developers to give up writing their own documentation.

Comment: @TylerH But why that might be a problem? That leads us to (2) I said "conceptual tension", and not "actual incompatibility". Of course communities can contribute a lot towards the goal of having great documentation, and a community might even be able of documenting something on its own. However, no one is better suited than the developers to provide an *authoritative reference* on what their projects are supposed to do and how they actually work. And conversely, it is much easier to write good tutorials and examples if the corresponding *reference* docs are reliable and comprehensive.

Comment: @duplode If it goes that far (which I doubt), then authors will start to come to SO to write their documentation. There aren't really developers who don't know about SO anymore; if this thing takes off like Kevin, et. al want it to, there probably won't really be developers who don't post their documentation on Stack Overflow anymore, either. But again, I doubt it will be "the official source of documentation for all the things", considering it's not even "the official source of answers to programming questions for all the things", and that's the site's *main* (and currently only) function.

Comment: @TylerH The pitfalls remain though. If the developers don't come to SO Docs we will end up with two competing API docs corpora, none of them as good as an unified effort might be (cf. answers about fragmentation such as [Stijn's](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303867)). And even if the developers do migrate to SO Docs there will be losses: reference documentation will be kept apart from code, and developers and communities will become unable to shape their docs as they see fit (extrapolate [from this answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303931/2751851) to see how bad it might get).

Comment: It's like if you just let anyone write an encyclopaedia. Haha. That would never work.

Comment: @QuolonelQuestions The issue is more subtle than that. While encyclopedias are [tertiary sources](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:No_original_research#Primary.2C_secondary_and_tertiary_sources) and [textbooks](https://en.wikibooks.org) are, at most, secondary sources, reference API docs are primary sources. (By the way: As [a proud contributor to Wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/User:Duplode), I definitely believe in collaborative writing. However, a large collaborative project like this one must have its goals clearly stated and its long-term effects carefully considered.)

Comment: @Shog9 What like the documentation on Maven?  The community documentation is often FAR superior to the official documentation.  If it is useful and editable it can be more official and up to date than any corporately maintained project for large projects.

Comment: PHP has a "User Contributed Notes" section on the docs. See the official docs for [bin2hex](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bin2hex.php) as an example.

Comment: I think giving Haskell as a counter-argument against a proposal for a repository of examples is "shocking". I love Haskell, and I have worked hard for learning it, and I really enjoyed that I did. But it was the most example-deprived language I have learnt so far. I don't have browsed many packages in Hackage, or Hoogle, but the thing I do remember is that I have never seen one single example there: not one. I repeat I have only parsed a few ones only... but that is very frustrating and intimidating as a beginner.

Comment: @StephaneRolland My comments were not so much about the presence of examples, but rather at who should write or vet them, or, to use the concrete example, whether the issue of the dearth of examples in Hackage should be solved through free-for-all crowdsourcing. (In any case, this answer was written immediately after the initial announcement of this SO documentation project, when the scope of the proposal wasn't defined very clearly. The follow-up post by the staff did address quite well the objections made here.)

Answer (score 269):

Like Stijn, I'm concerned about [fragmentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303867/189134). However, I love one portion of this: **examples**. To me, great documentation has non-trivial examples of how a method or group of methods work together. It shows more than a single line of code and explains what's happening.

It's one thing to read a document that accurately describes how a complicated class works or how a method with tons of parameters does its magic. It's entirely another thing to see working examples of how they work.

If this can provide those examples and do it in a way that complements the documentation of popular (and unpopular) projects, I'll be one happy developer.

Comment: totally agreed. When I google a class or a function, what comes up is often an official reference followed by a stackoverflow question. Most of the times I click on the question looking for a usage example.

Comment: So maybe just examples instead of full documentation? And the next step would be **tutorials**...

Comment: So I was thinking along these lines as well. It's the examples that will add true value. But that means that the examples need to be peer-reviewed (duh) but also complete and self-contained. What needs to be there to make the example work needs to be there, or it's not really useful to the person that  needs the example. So, there must be enough sample data provided to make that algorithm function, not just the mathematical markup of the theory.

Comment: Some of the MSDN I use has lots of detail, but no examples and no guidance on how to use the software. So I support examples and tutorials.

Comment: Agreed AdrianHHH - Starting out on Microsoft products without examples and guidance, and just straight up nearly-meaningless (for a noob) documentation on MSDN, is harder than it should be.

Comment: Good examples are essential.  Not every piece of working code is a good example, so we'll need peer review and editing.  An example should be the smallest body of (realistic) code that demonstrates the feature, and everything important should have inline comments.  In my experience the push for this comes from two places: trying to actually *use* the example (and realizing it's lacking in some of this) or trying to *explain the topic in words" (write documentation).  We shouldn't be writing tons of text, but we probably don't want "none" either. (And yeah, then there are tutorials.)

Comment: Examples may be the best thing about this, but I think it should in no way be limited to examples.  If the developers of the product didn't bother to document HOW something works, and someone can provide that based on their understanding of the source code, it would be better to have that than not.

Comment: @Trilarion Yes examples and tutorials are probably a better way to approach this. Documentation is not very helpful without a code structure to go by

Comment: I have one major problem with tutorials: they're tutorials. They end abruptly, are full of holes and tend to tell people where to click but not *why*, or perhaps even more importantly why click there and leave out the part that explains *why not* to click somewhere else. The people who read tutorials are generally the people who need far more than tutorials (and end up on SO), and the people who can benefit from tutorials generally don't read them because they only actually need a tiny subsection of it that they didn't commit to memory yet. Lets write guides instead.

Comment: @Gimby Quite right on *some* tutorials. But good tutorials can be written to include the *whys* and the *why nots* and the alternatives.

Comment: @Trilarion and many others.  So, we've envisioned Documentation as containing several different "sorts" of pages (all in the same style view, with required examples and optional sections); including short Tutorials (and things like "Getting Started" or "Hello World").  Short Tutorials fit in this model, though long ones (several pages) don't really.  I think we'll be expanding upon this, and a bunch of other stuff, in a follow up meta post.

Comment: @KevinMontrose I see. It might not be what we others here envision. Tutorials are often long. Short tutorials might only be examples. Even good examples might become several pages long. Something that is shorter might be **typical use case** of a function instead of full blown examples. Maybe that is what you mean? I will certainly follow further meta posts.

Comment: I applaud this effort, and have often wondered why there weren't more substantive usage examples available. I also realize this is not just for one language, but as a concrete example the major problem i find when consulting Google's Android SDK docs is the abysmal lack of usage examples. My searches almost always necessitate locating a suitable reference elsewhere to see and understand what should actually be done.

Comment: @KevinMontrose - Trying to balance between snarky rhetoric trying for witticism and an actual question, how well documented do you expect Documentation to be?  Well-written documentation should have a good style guide; something better than "put examples here".  How do you plan to address that, if at all?

Comment: @AdrianHHH we're on the same page, lets just say that the only thing I'm rebelling against is calling it a "tutorial" as you can right now find them all over the net ;) What is proposed here is the replacement and banishment of the shitty tutorials, and I for one love it.

Comment: Instead of Documentations, Examples and Tutorials are a better choice, IMO. Because we don't come to SO to read a lot of documents, we just want precise answers and solutions. SO was meant to provide solutions and not the background history of why and what.

Comment: @Plutonix (+78 at the time of writing) seems right for .NET. +1 for making Experts Exchange your enemy though. Glad not to see much of that these days.

Comment: This is the best suggestion in my opinion, as I would be very cautious about trusting reference material from anything but the official docs. Stack Overflow exists to educate and guide, and examples would definitely compliment this site.

Answer (score 230):

I say the following from a technical writer's perspective. Creating software documentation is my job.

TL;DR at the bottom.

## How

1. Do you know why you see so much documentation like that? Because the technical writers *begged* the developers to answer an email or show up at a meeting for *months*, and the developers simply refused. And then it's time to get everything ready for the final build, and what are we supposed to do? Leave it blank? Better that it look sort of okay but not really be too useful than look obviously incomplete, because the devs sure aren't getting fired for failing to do their jobs (yes, documenting your work is part of your job), and we have no plans to take the fall for their failure.
2. The answer to this is the same as above: everything we get comes from the developers. All we do is turn it into comprehensible English, format it, and just generally clean it up. I'm sure you all know the saying, "Garbage In, Garbage Out"... if the devs don't provide the writers with some examples, *the documentation will not contain examples*. Since nobody likes doing extra work, the devs will only provide examples if Marketing forces them to do so, which only happens after users have been complaining about the lack of examples for a few releases. And that assumes that the company even has the resources to do this (e.g., "all of the examples for your language-agnostic tool are in language X. I want examples in language Y" when all the devs and writers are already pretty busy).
3. The documentation is as "complete" as we can make it. Some devs are awesome and provide a ton of clear information that we can easily turn into documentation. Other devs... not so much. Regarding the way that documentation is tied to release cycles: yes, that is certainly true.
4. That sounds like the sort of documentation that has never been touched by a professional writer. That's not a condemnation - sometimes there aren't any writers available, for a variety of possible reasons. However, that means that the documentation is going to be a *direct reflection* of the developer's attitude toward documentation. If a developer thinks that Javadocs are enough, that's what you'll get. If a developer sees the importance of a more modern layout (maybe they're a professional technical writer who codes in their spare time, like myself), they might actually spend a small fraction of their development time putting together some nice documentation.

## What

1. One of the things I like about SO is its attempt at concision (think of it as JIT compilation or lazy evaluation): instead of finding all *potentially* useful pieces of information and making them available on SO *just in case*, we try to limit it to things that are verifiably useful to some degree. How is that determined? It's simple: if someone actually encounters an issue, that verifies that someone might run into that issue. They then post a question. A "broader place for artifacts to live," however, sounds suspiciously close to hoarding. What if there's a `GetRowEnumerator()` that no one has ever actually needed to use? Would such a thing belong on SO? Should such a thing be included in Documentation?
2. Perhaps you haven't realized, but SO has basically become de facto documentation, even for products/projects that do have official documentation. Will you find the very basics; the things that are already very easy to find elsewhere (e.g. basic tutorials or how-to documents)? Nope! But that's okay, because SO doesn't need to duplicate the Internet. We only do the tough parts (ideally).
3. So, the people who ask a Question instead of Googling their Question's intended title are suddenly going to start Googling, just because there would be *even more results* in the Google search they don't want to run?
4. This is known as "kicking the can down the road." When the Stack Overflow Documentation is, through the significant effort of many developers (who are now inexplicably excited about writing documentation), reasonably useful, thorough, and detailed, how will people pay it forward? Adding another cell block to the prison won't improve the K-12 education system or the economy.

---

> *Or we’re wrong.*

Unfortunately, I think that's the case.

> But we think it’s worth having a go at it.

...and you're doing it anyway. Okay then.

---

TL;DR: I think the concept of adding "Documentation" to SO (or an adjoining site) is deeply flawed. It attempts to solve the problem of "developers don't like writing documentation" by having developers write documentation, and the problem of "people ask duplicate Questions instead of Googling" by expecting people to click a Documentation link in a Google search.

Comment: We're asking the community about having a go at it anyway, rejection is a valid possibility.  Most of this could apply to Q&A I think, many places had Q&A before SO (and many have it now) but their devs don't participate; and yet SO works. If people treat the Documentation section as a job, I agree it will fail. I also agree with What's #1 & #2.   Completionist documentation doesn't interest me (I don't care about documenting every .ToString(); only stuff people actually need). And yes, lots of SO content is better than docs; but we also *turn away* a lot of it as too broad, docs can fix that.

Comment: I also think you vastly over estimate how many existing docs, when they show up in Google results at all, actually help you when you click them.  Plenty of folks search around, and then end up asking questions *anyway*; we can't help those that don't Google at all, but we can help some of those who do.

Comment: The preexisting Q&A places were not sufficient. It looks like SO is sufficient. However, I think this format works so well that a separate "Documentation" area is redundant. I don't know if I would count on devs to suddenly be excited about writing documentation (or to do a decent job of it, at that).

Comment: Is this "Documentation" just supposed to prevent questions from appearing on SO? The kind that are basically "this seems like the sort of thing that should be in the docs, but it isn't"? Why not wait for some topic to become an issue? It can then become an SO Question once somebody actually cares about it.

Comment: With due respect to your actual experience writing docs, I think that your perspective "It attempts to solve the problem of 'developers don't like writing documentation' by having developers write documentation" is off. There's actually two sets of devs in this scenario: the ones writing the tools, who don't like writing docs, and others who are _using_ the tools and who may indeed like writing them (and may be good at it). The latter, I think, are the people _already writing answers_ on SO.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 We're looking to improve documentation in general.  By your logic, shouldn't no documentation exist?  Like, why not just wait for every issue to be a Question?  I think it's self-evident that there is value in consolidating into broad topics for consumption.  I do think Q&A and Documentation are complementary (which is why this makes sense to me as an extension of Stack Overflow), but they're not quite replacements for each other.

Comment: Please, no reductio ad absurdum.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 My apologies, I was not trying to dismiss your concerns.  I suppose we just disagree on whether there's value in preemptively improving documentation.

Comment: Sorry; I guess I'm a bit defensive about documentation. People pay for software/hardware, not documentation, so it can be difficult to justify a writer's value to their organization - particularly an organization without Apple-tier petty cash. This "SO Documentation" looks like bulldozing a building to fix the broken windows. We could make very nice windows if people would let us. You want to create value by preemptively improving documentation? You can get better documentation by telling the world that _documentation has value_.

Comment: Also, if people saw more financial and practical value in documentation, I would possibly still have a job next week.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, I sympathize, but your position seems extremely biased -- considering you literally feel financial competition by this free alternative.

Comment: Of course I'm biased. That is the source of my expertise. However, I'm trying to explain that the reason there's so much bad documentation is because people don't care enough about documentation. It's like telling the construction worker not to bother with the broken windows, and then complaining about the broken windows. And then, of course, telling the construction worker that you don't trust what he says because you think he's just mad about the plastic wrap being used as a window substitute because people really do need windows.

Comment: It's like not telling the bassist about scheduled practices and then complaining about the lack of a bass line. Maybe you should treat the bassist as an actual band member, and then you wouldn't have to get the sound engineer to hack together a bass line.

Comment: Disagree with current way answer is phrased: the proposal as I see it is to let people who care to write documentation (generally both sides are developers which makes it even more confusing). People who use the product have much better chance to create *useful* documentation compared to original developer who may have idea how to use the product/library (especially for large organizations).

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 The individual construction worker doesn't build the whole house; focused as he is on fixing his door/window, he very often cannot see how his door/window affects and is influenced by the design of the entire house. The ones who can do that best are the passersby who are thinking of buying the house, and the people who actually live in the house. Perhaps the developer-written documentation will very often reflect the developer's narrow focus on his/her method/property/class; this proposal enables experienced users to share that acquired broader perspective.

Comment: @ZevSpitz - Do you have confidence in the industry's ability to satisfy your documentation needs and wants, assuming you actually tell them your documentation needs and wants? Companies try very hard to do what customers ask for, so please make sure to ask for documentation of the type you think would help you most. Commercial organizations will be particularly inclined to produce that sort of documentation if they think it'll affect the bottom line.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 True, but not all projects have a commercial organization behind them. Also (although you probably know better than I), I would guess that large organizations have a certain amount of inertia, and would take some convincing that it is commercially worth their while to invest in such documentation. I am more confident in my ability to write more useful documentation, then in my ability to convince an organization to invest money to do so. ...

Comment: @TigerhawkT3  Perhaps with this proposal, I could then turn to the organization with a link to StackOverflow Documentation and say, "Your official documentation is missing the following topics. Please improve it.", which I think would be a tad more convincing.

Comment: You don't need to single-handedly change the industry's perspective on documentation any more than you'd need to single-handedly produce all the content on "SO Documentation." If lots of people start basing purchasing decisions, open-source contributions, etc. on [documentation](http://www.catb.org/esr/writings/cups-horror.html), I think the situation will improve, and there won't be a need for this "if you want something done right you have to do it yourself" outlook.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, I don't think your analogy is apt.  Better would be the concerns of a taxi-driver when hearing about the possibility of Uber being invented.

Comment: Sorry; I think it's more like [Apple inventing the tablet computer with the iPad](http://i.imgur.com/E5GLT.jpg). Your taxi/Uber analogy would only be accurate if the predominant way that people try to signal taxis was by sitting in their bedroom with the lights off and frantically waving their hand, followed by "why can't I ever find a taxi in this city?".

Comment: Technical writers would really love to fix the broken windows if you'd just give me some nice sheets of glass, but if you'd rather hoard all the glass and ignore us, you can feel free to reinvent the wheel and use sheepskin. P.S.: I hope you like mixed metaphors. :)

Comment: I think this answer merges two types of developer: those who developer the software and those who use the software. Only the first group matches your explanation. There are many developers who use software written by others and write blogs about what they are doing. These people like documenting things. But that writing is scattered and has little or no peer review. I see the proposal here as providing a place where writers can contribute useful stuff without needing their own blog that may or may not be easy to find and that, probably, has no peer reviews.

Comment: While I agree with many of your points and share many of your concerns, a remark regarding the *"...attempts to solve the problem of "developers don't like writing documentation" by having developers write documentation*" part (in addition to some things that others said about this already) : You seem to underestimate the **value of useless internet "reputation" points**. Some people really go *crazy* for some rep. (That's why I think that the rep handling is a crucial point as well in this proposal...)

Comment: You seem to be equating the proposed documentation with documentation written *internally*, whereas a far fairer thing would be to equate it with other third-party documentation/wiki sites. Unless you think no third-party documentation should ever exist? Yes, it'd be nice if  everyone in charge of deciding which language/product to use insisted their vendors had good internal documentation written by technical writers, but that's a dreamworld. We live in the real world where third-party documentation *is frequently needed* by developers, and SO is here to help developers get work done.

Comment: Sorry if this cannibalises your job. But honestly, if you think 'the devs wouldn't get back to me' is a justification for opaque, unhelpful writing of any kind, perhaps you should find another.

Comment: I see your frustration but, with respect, I don't think the documentation world *has* to be as grim as you're painting. I'm a technical writer too, and I routinely read source code, use the software, push back against counter-intuitive or inconsistent design decisions, and ask the developers "why?" & "how?". If documentation comes only at the end of the pipeline it's always going to be a struggle; the earlier you can get in there and be part of the ongoing discussions, the better. Also, I get better results from "I see X in the code; is that right?" than "tell me" -- even when I'm very wrong.

Comment: @JoDouglass - This "dreamworld" would be a reality if people actually cared about documentation on a higher level than "well, I installed this software and integrated it into my project, and now I'm finding that the documentation isn't so good. I may not have thought about it for a single second while deciding which software to get, and documentation is never listed as a feature in comparison charts, but I guess I miss it now."

Comment: @Jonathan_W - This doesn't "cannibalize my job." My job is already "dead." It would just be nice if I weren't constantly hearing about how my work is really needed and wouldn't it be great if someone could do this and why the heck is it so hard to find decent documentation. Am I invisible? A ghost? Phase-shifted due to [sneaky Romulans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Next_Phase)?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Developers frequently care about documentation - the support for this proposal and in fact for SO in general I would say shows that. Many of us frequently refer to documentation, so it's in our interests for it to be good. But developers quite often don't get to choose what languages, libraries, projects, software, etc. they must use. And even if it's considered, problems with documentation still have to be weighed against other benefits of a product. Do you think it's reasonable or likely for companies to abandon .NET because MSDN isn't always very helpful?

Comment: No, this isn't about whether "people" care about documentation. *Users* care about documentation because they *need* it; but for developers (of the software being documented), documentation is just another "feature," and, in the case of documentation written by a technical writer, one that's not even "implemented" by the devs themselves. This proposal is for (some) documentation to be written by people who have an existing incentive to care about it, rather than by people who do not. It's not clear why you think it's possible to fix the situation by changing dev behavior.

Comment: It is a little shocking how easily people are slipping into *ad hominem*. The main takeaway here is not that TigerhawkT3 is concerned about his options in the job market, but that Stack Overflow Documentation cannot possibly be an ultimate solution to the documentation problem, as the pitch for this proposal makes it sound like.

Comment: @MonicaCellio - I see a lot of source code, too, but it's mostly hardware languages that I have a lot of difficulty with. I mostly have to document software features, anyway - e.g., a module has a dialog box with an option like "Protocol." What do we have for that? "Specify the communication protocol." We don't list the possible choices or what they mean, because A) the devs don't have time, and B) if we did, we would also have to document the license-controlled options, which we unfortunately don't have a way of doing.

Comment: @MonicaCellio - And I do try asking "why?" and "how?", but it's kind of hard to push people around as an intern, and there's only so much I can do when devs flat-out ignore me for a few months. Not all of them do that - I've gotten some really excellent source documents - but sometimes I just get nothing.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I also don't think supporting this proposal *and* wanting better official documentation are at odds. If a product has great internal documentation, then it won't need a ton writing here - awesome. But lots of products don't, and sometimes _never will_ - perhaps because it's a small open source project, or isn't supported by its creators anymore. Or maybe it has no real competitors or is too popular already so the will never be much pressure on it to improve its documentation. The solution you suggest doesn't negate the need for third-party documentation.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 oh, you're an intern?  It sounded like you were much farther along in your tech-writing career.  I know it seems grim, but it does get better -- not everywhere, but there *are* teams that actually care about doing this right.  I hope you're able to find one, ideally one that comes with a mentor who'll help you navigate the sometimes-tricky waters of this field.

Comment: @MonicaCellio - I graduated six years ago (remember the economy in 2009?), and all I've been able to get in this field is internships. While at my current internship, I saw people right out of college get hired with full-time jobs... as developers. Meanwhile, at the start of the internship I heard how our department used to have nine people, reduced to two full-time writers and myself. Then one of the full-time writers got laid off. Now I'm leaving because my internship has gone on for a year (the maximum), and all the company wants to do is keep me as an intern, apparently indefinitely.

Comment: I'm seriously considering abandoning the field, because the prevailing attitude seems to be "no need to put that on the feature list because it doesn't matter... no need to hire someone for it because it doesn't matter... whoa, gonna need some docs here; I guess we could just throw something together ourselves."

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 there are good and bad employers with good and bad working conditions. Your words here suggest that your employer is not at the "good" end of the range. You write clearly and express yourself well, so please keep at it and look for another employer. There are good one around. Best wishes.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 How do you propose that people assess the quality of documentation before buying? You can look at layout, you can look at the sheer amount of content that's been written, and you can go in and look at the quality of some of it, but in the end you simply don't know what you need until you actually need it, and the rest of the documentation being fantastic doesn't help with that one problem that's not adequately documented.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist - The same way we assess the quality of everything else: testing, reviews, word of mouth... you could make the same "you simply don't know" complaint about any aspect of any product. If no one makes a big deal about the way a particular keyboard's F10 key makes a funny noise, you won't know about it until you hit that F10 key. The solution is simple: consumers need to make it clear that they care about that sort of thing, and if something slips by, let the producer know so they can fix it. I don't understand this "it's not perfect, so abandon it and build your own" mindset.

Comment: I think it would be good to think about what kind of documentation you are thinking about.  As mentioned elsewhere there are differences between docs generated by APIs, tutorials, narrative documentation, and an encyclopedia. There is also basic documentation that isolates pieces and documentation that tells you how to solve common problems by bringing together different pieces in a certain not necessarily obvious way.  For me SO is particularly good for the latter. That is things that are not necessarily going to be documented because ... the list of stuff to do is not complete.

Comment: "All we do is turn it into comprehensible English, format it, and just generally clean it up. "  Developers don't speak comprehensible English. They speak code. That is what SO documentation is supposed to provide. Developers should be writing documentation for other developers. Technical writers should be writing documentation for non-developers.

Comment: @Britton - Nonsense. You just condemned every professionally-written piece of technical documentation as being useless and targeted at the wrong audience. Would you rather see something like "To accomplish the task of closing the software, you can access the option of the File menu is chosen and the Exit option is selected." (which is often the sort of thing an SME will provide) or "To exit, choose __File > Exit__." (after my cleanup)? And yes, this is for software that is targeted at developers.

Comment: @Britton - I'm also kind of surprised at "Developers don't speak comprehensible English." Most can make themselves understood just fine. A technical writer simply takes the information they're given and makes it _easier_ to understand. I only occasionally need to ask a developer for clarification on material they provided to me.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I should have been more clear. You just described something from a user manual. I'm talking about things like code library documentation which is what SO docs would be for. You are absolutely correct in that tech writers need to be writing things like user manuals, regardless of the audience.

Comment: @Britton - Yes, a user manual for users who are trying to design hardware with a mix of integrated design tools, C, Verilog, and VHDL. It's not exactly "how to upload a photo on Facebook." These manuals often include APIs, command-line documentation, and sample code. It sounds like you aren't actually familiar with what technical writers _do_, and I suspect you're not alone in that, which might be another key component in this whole issue.

Comment: Well, my last day was yesterday. The documentation for the main software product is actually [available online](http://help.latticesemi.com/docs/webhelp/eng/). I wrote (based on input from SMEs when available) the sections __User Guides > Implementing the Design > Bit Generation > Analyzing your Design using Soft Error Injection__ and __Tcl Command Reference Guide > Diamond Tool Tcl Command Syntax > Engineering Change Order Tcl Commands__.

Comment: In the ECO Tcl commands section, the phrases like "This command (memdram example)" indicate where I hoped to explain what the heck that command actually did and why you would want to use it, but the SMEs never got back to me. In the next release, you'll see that I changed it to simply read something like "this is an example of the `memdram` command." Because developers. You want better docs? Talk to the [man in the mirror](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PivWY9wn5ps).

Comment: `Will you find the very basics; the things that are already very easy to find elsewhere (e.g. basic tutorials or how-to documents)? Nope! But that's okay, because SO doesn't need to duplicate the Internet.` Nailed it. I think this is the real part of the answer the mods should consider.

Comment: I'm upvoting your answer, because I think this is some valuable feedback and in any case a very interesting experience to read. But I disagree with your conclusion for the same reasons that have been stated previously by Kevin and Josh.

Comment: All of your points are *precisely* why this sort of documentation effort is needed, and there are plenty of devs who like to write up detailed responses to requests for information that would work *great* in such a documentation repository, they're already doing it now in response to questions on SO.  I can think of many times I've written up an answer with an example that could have gone directly into such a documentation site. Under this new paradigm I'd just write up the example there and link to it from my answer.

Comment: @Jason - No, my points are precisely why people should start actually caring about documentation enough to get it done right the first time. You don't have to MacGyver something together with PHP and toothpicks. And are you saying such a "Documentation" site would encourage you to give link-only answers? Or would you link it and duplicate the content?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 The people who have the responsibility to "get it done right the first time" - i.e. the developers creating the code to be documented, or to provide you the professional writer with the information - are not the best group to actually create the documentation, the users are (after using available sources to cobble together the information for themselves). And I'm not suggesting link-only answers at all, I'm saying I often write large answers that consist of lots of exposition along with examples; adding those examples to open-source documentation where appropriate is a good thing.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 to add a little more context to my assertion (that I'm merely echoing from others) that the users are better suited than the devs to create the documentation - I find it much harder to document my own code than to explain the work of others, code that I came to first from a user perspective and understand how *I* need to understand it.  That doesn't mean there's not a need for 1st level developer documentation, there certainly is, there's just a limit to how good it can be without significant user input. If you want to improve your job prospects, figure out how to incorporate that

Comment: Personally, I find that documenting something that someone else created with no input from the creator has a tendency toward "I think it works this way, so far as I've seen, for some reason," while documenting something that I wrote was more like "here's how it works, here's how to use it, here's what to watch out for" - weeks vs hours. But maybe that's more of an argument for including writing skills as a vital part of being a competent developer.

Comment: **I'm trying to explain that the reason there's so much bad documentation [...]** Ahh, you're saying we should be paying you more. Well, guess what, some people got more time than money, and not everyone with experience is getting paid well enough to pay you to do the writing. Besides, some of us fix our homes because they enjoy that kind of work, not because we can't afford the contractors. You're trying to keep the documentation writing in your guild. I personally hate that approach to any endeavor.

Comment: @KubaOber - No. I'm saying that the writers who are _already being paid_ for technical writing work would really love it if people stopped being hypocrites and made an actual effort to improve documentation at the source (pester the developer for better docs, cooperate with the writer at their workplace, etc.). I don't know where all this "you're just greedy and want more money you capitalist bourgeois mouthpiece; free the proletariat!" stuff is coming from, but I guess that's the bell curve at work.

Comment: @KubaOber - This is less like doing some home improvement work for fun and more like being out of town during the plumber's appointment and then getting back a week later and wondering why your sink is still clogged. All you had to do was unlock the door and say "that sink right there" and it wouldn't be a problem anymore. Instead, you still have the problem, you're out a few hundred bucks (you still have to pay even when you've set someone up to fail), and you're a laughingstock.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 "pester the developer for better docs" Let's be real. What would I rather do: pester someone with little guarantee that something good will come out of it, all the while I have to endure broken docs, or fix the docs and move on to better things? Pestering the developers is not going to happen, I don't think. The drive for good documentation must come from within the corporate culture, expecting customer feedback to make it happen is wishful thinking. If good docs aren't considered an essential part of the product, then you get exactly that: not good docs.

Comment: @KubaOber - How exactly do you think a company or development house determines the essential parts of a product? It's not [magic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wz-PtEJEaqY) - customers and users have to _say something_. Where I used to work, we actually cared a lot about customer feedback, but documentation requests were too few and far between for it to become a priority.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 If a company needs their customers to tell them how to do their jobs, we have a problem much deeper than documentation itself. If good documentation isn't in the culture of a product team, it's never going to happen. Give me a counterexample or two. I dare you.

Comment: Yes, better to leave it blank so that it doesn't look complete. This is so obvious that I stopped reading after that.

Comment: @dan-klasson - So, the options are either: A) perfection, or B) nothing? I must admit, that would have made my job much easier. "Sorry, I never got an adequate response for that pin input mode list, so here's an empty user manual."

Comment: By "Do you know why there is so much documentation like that" I assumed you were referring to the documentation in OP's twitter image. getRowEnumerator().

Comment: I hope this hasn't been said already in this thread, (I simply don't have time to read all the way through all the comments, as I am at work.) This answer voices my exact concerns. As a developer it worries me to see that we need docs for our docs. We should be patient and disciplined enough as a "species" that we document. We should be trying to build a culture that documents it's work, rather than "kicking the can down the road" as the author says. I've always thought the Django project was a zenith of quality in documentation, and the way that seems to have arisen was by funneling

Comment: contributions by those who could not yet contribute to source, to the docs. It worries me and excites me to see this on stack overflow, not because I think stack overflow will be a useful *or* successful product (I don't personally believe it will be either) but because it will encourage good documentation. However, I think that this choice has the potential to visit great destruction on the community as a whole and I encourage you folks to revisit your choice as an organization. Contribute in other, more meaningful and productive ways.

Comment: @Jonathan_W - When you order a meal at a restaurant and it arrives flavorless and burnt, do you question the waiter's competence?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I don't mean to be mean-spirited. My point is simply this: I understand that when deadlines loom, you need to get the job done, even if you don't have enough information to do it properly, but the poor end user still suffers, even if it is not your fault. To bring it back to the topic, I believe that crowdsourcing manuals can only be a good thing - after all, these sites only exist because the documentation can't possibly cover everything.

Comment: Downvoted because I disagree. You articulated why bad documentation exists (I never actually really knew it was that specific sort of reason, and it does make sense) -- SO is offering a solution. Devs aren't going to start giving "you writers" complete documentation information or examples. The fact is, bad documentation has existed for so long that I think this new effort to provide docs with EXAMPLES is actually one of the most exciting things I've heard. The alternative is that we just accept bad documentation -- but it's "okay" because "it's not the doc writers fault"? I disagree.

Comment: @HC_ - Who said it's okay? I never said it's okay. If you disagree with it being okay, it's not me you're disagreeing with. I said that it's _better_ for docs to look "okay" than to be entirely nonexistent, and that it's "okay" for the ordinary SO to be de facto documentation, neither of which is an "okay" in the context you're describing. If you read my post and some of these comments more carefully, you'd see that I'm urging people to start visibly caring about docs to the point that they can actually be improved at the source.

Comment: @HC_ - And the effort to provide docs with "EXAMPLES" isn't new at all just because SO is doing it, any more than the iPad was the first tablet computer just because Steve Jobs introduced it. I even made specific mention of examples in my answer. Overall, it looks like you read the first line of my answer, made a gigantic pile of assumptions, and downvoted. I guess I shouldn't be surprised - after all, this is how SO has so many bad questions that could have been answered by simply reading existing docs or questions.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Sorry, didn't mean to imply you exactly said that it's "okay." Just that effectively, you seem to be wanting to change developers -- which is unreliable. Developers  and documentation have shown what they are capable of in the past 20-40+ years or however long. You say "attempts to solve the problem of "developers don't like writing documentation" by having developers write documentation" -- no, it's not. All developers are not created equal. StackExchange INHERENTLY attracts people who like providing resources for others. Developers aren't going to change. SE is offering a change

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 The difference here is that SO has established itself as something that is **continuing to grow** and has a shot of providing an alternate documentation/example resource when the original source fails to -- which in my experience is almost all the time, because original documentation seems to be VERY sparse on examples, in my (limited) experience.

Comment: I believe that most product documentation is written people controlled by accountants. I am sure most developers would love to (help the technical authors to) produce good documentation. But the accountants say that there is only so much money to write the code and document it. When that money runs out the people must move on to other work. People contributing here on Stack Overflow have some time to give, to help others. Improving documentation is one way. The style and coverage may be inconsistent but you can expect some good results.

Comment: Now that Documentation is fully underway, I can already see point #1 under What coming into effect. I also find I haven't found it useful to look up anything in documentation yet...

Answer (score 119):

I was going to post more thoughts in comments, but an answer fits this better.

I am intrigued by this. I think it could go places. I really like the focus on *examples* than a bunch of words. Bunches of words (maybe) help highly experienced people. They don't help people who are looking for "how do I do X?" and they often don't help the more experienced people since they already know most of the blah blah blah.

Misc thoughts:

- **Keep in mind how people normally arrive at documentation**. I normally arrive at it through google, something like "[language] [functionality] [example]" as a search parameter. Unless this documentation is really comprehensive, I will probably still search that way.
- **Ability to close questions as dup of documentation.** This would be great, especially if you have a way to incentivize it somehow
- **Reputation:** just a general thought, this is still "too early to tell" I'm sure but keep in mind that writing a good piece of documentation or example can be 10x the work of a simple "do this" answer.
- **Design the system for users wanting quality over quantity.** Probably the main reason I don't post much on SO anymore is the firehose of low quality stuff. I like writing lengthy answers (which is probably why I like Workplace so much). This system should not be designed for people who like cranking out 20 answers an hour. It should be designed for creating quality content, not just quantity. This seems obvious but SO has a serious problem with this because of the firehose effect.

Comment: All correct.  The thing you left off is "there is only one topic for each thing" so you need to provide sufficient incentive for editing of existing content.

Comment: @NickLarsen it depends greatly on what that topic is... if you are talking about, "how do I use an array?" there may be dozens of scenarios you want examples for.  Which might be another related comment, this needs to have a clear scope for each topic and how that will all work. You are going to be using very common words to people, "Documentation" is a widely understood phrase, and if SO's model for that will be different that needs to be **clearly** figured out. Or you'll get the "comments aren't really comments" problem, too.

Comment: Comments are one of the things that sucks about existing documentation, so we're not really going to have them.  Instead there will be a flagging system or you can just directly fix the problems you see.  Don't think of topics as one to one with examples, a topic has many examples, but not too many or else you really need two topics.  If these kinds of design choices seem interesting to you, please join the beta list.

Comment: @NickLarsen I mean more the mismatch between how SE uses "Comments" and how the rest of the internet uses them. I'm pointing out that if this is called "documentation" but is really something different, that'll be a naming and branding problem

Comment: @enderland I do not believe we should ban short documentations however, as creating a documentation can become a community effort. Someone writes a small example, and someone else adds to it.

Comment: People should use alternative search engines more often. Virtually all posts here mention Google as the only one ☹

Comment: @mirabilos I'm still waiting for Google to let me down...

Comment: 1- I'm not sure that closing question as duplicate of documentation is a good idea. 2- What is Workplace ?

Comment: @XavierCombelle To answer your second question, Workplace is another Stack Exchange site.

Comment: You meant "firehose", right?

Comment: @DanGetz I did, but I think the concept of a firehouse is a bit more fitting anyways, I'm picturing a hose spitting out houses which are on fire. Sometimes that is what SO feels like if you browse the "Newest" tabs.

Comment: A firehouse is another name for a fire station, not a house on fire. Though I feel the same way.

Comment: @mirabilos: Compare "Kleenex", "Thermos", "Sellotape"/"Scotch tape", or "Xerox". "Google" has become a ["genericized trademark"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_trademark).

Comment: While I would also want to be able to close questions as dupes of documentation entries, I do see the issue that documentation pages are not necessarily as static as they would need to be for that purpose. It’s simple for questions: Nobody is going to edit a question completely, so using other questions as dupe targets is fine. But documentation is likely to change a lot more; for example someone decides to split up an existing page into multiple separate topics (because there is *so much more to write about it*). That is a good thing, but questions having the page as dupe target will break.

Comment: @NickLarsen My money's on "we don't need comments" being the new site's "we don't need meta". If you don't have comments as comments, you'll need some other mechanism to fulfill the role that comments normally cover, and I'm skeptical that flagging and "fix it yourself" is going to cut it.

Comment: The discussion here about the semantics of "comments" cracks me up and is particularly ironic considering the semantic wraparound inherent in meta. Anywhere else on SE, 3+ comments in a discussion flow: Instant banhammer on the discussion under the mantra "Take it to chat, guys"; On meta: [endless, mishmashed, hard-to-parse, semi-contextless chatter -- like this very discussion]; Anywhere else on the internet: [threaded, deliberate extended discussions]. I wonder what will SO's semantic wraparound for "docs" and "examples" and "tutorials" and "comments" be?

Comment: I also wonder how many minutes from the moment of launch before any docs site is overrun with god-tier editors with nothing better to do than proclaim themselves Protector of the Realm and render it a Wikipedia-level edit-unfriendly environment. That'll be swell. That and the low-quality firehose (in interesting opposition to one another) are already issues that drive confusion, annoyance, and feelings of repulsion in SE sites. I don't see how docs would be any better, especially since they will compete with official docs. This is a pile of hard problems.

Answer (score 94):

If this is to be a success, I think it needs to address concrete problems that active question-answerers currently have *with Stack Overflow*.  Problems like

- The endless flood of duplicate questions

  - ... which we know perfectly well have already been answered but it's hard to find the canonical duplicate
- No good place to put canonical explanations of things that someone didn't actually *ask* about but need to know anyway as a consequence of their question, e.g. "Never use `scanf`", "The type-based aliasing rules are *asymmetric*," and "You should consider using something *other* than a shell script to solve this problem" (to pick three things I find myself saying over and over and over again)
- The longer you've been on the site, the harder it is to find *interesting* questions to answer

Address these problems and you're more likely to get a critical mass of interested writers out of the starting gate.

I also want to endorse what several other people have said about making sure that documentation finds its way back to upstream open-source projects.  Many such projects know their documentation is terrible but have neither the expertise nor the brain cycles to do anything about it.  A community-of-practice that knows how to write good documentation for anything *and* how to cooperate with upstreams in getting it integrated could go a long way to solving that problem, and the SO community *could* be that community -- but it will take active cat-herding in that direction.  (And I know I would feel better about writing docs on a third-party site myself if there were gnomes making sure it got pushed up to the first party.)  Note that the appropriate licensing for docs going upstream is not one-size-fits-all; many projects want explicit permission to redistribute under *their* licensing and have varying degrees of paperwork that needs filed.

And finally, please look at existing community-contributed documentation for both what to do and what NOT to do.  The best existing (semi-)community-written documentation site I'm aware of is [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/),<sup>1</sup> and the go-to place for what not to do is of course the official PHP documentation with its cesspit of bad user-submitted advice at the bottom of every single page...

<sup>1</sup> I do not know how much of this documentation is written by MozCo employees versus the larger community; I do know there is an organizational unit devoted to making sure it doesn't suck.

Comment: "making sure that documentation finds its way back to upstream open-source projects" Yes, this. IMO this would mostly solve the fragmentation problem people have been expressing concern over.

Comment: I've always thought that the PHP documentation is really good, probably the languages greatest strength, as long as you ignore the comments. I particularly like the way you can type php.net/[function-name] into your address bar and get to the right page in one step.

Comment: @rjmunro Yes, the PHP documentation itself is fine.  It's only the user-submitted commentary, and in particular, the way the PHP core organization neglects it and considers themselves not responsible for its quality, that should serve as a cautionary tale for this proposal.

Comment: Oh good, I'm not the only person who thinks the PHP docco (and comment process) is a cesspit. The problem, as I see it, is that people don't comment to improve the docco - they comment to advertise their fancy workaround/solution/hack/bodge for a bug/feature that may or may not exist. I would rather read experts-exchange than a comment thread on php.net.

Comment: @Juffy PHP documentation are very good structured (tree structure of reference and structure of each topic itself), has great many versions and languages support, has both good and bad comments and the way to up/down vote those comments. And more valuable it has [platform for community to contribute and improve](https://edit.php.net/?project=PHP&perm=en/index.php) this documentation, i think, it worth having to look at it's good parts and take all good experience it has.

Comment: @Mikl - sorry, I should have restricted that just to the comment system. As a PHP noob though, the comments are generally massively unhelpful *for the page they're on*. Trivial example [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.php) - this is the friggin' contents page for the Variables section, not the page on how to initialise variables in strange and interesting ways. Why is there any comments on a page with no content other than four links? There's even a specific page for [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.php), but that comment isn't there. /rant

Comment: @Juffy Why did I click that link. Why.  *goes in search of the brain bleach*

Comment: @Juffy it's a good example of problem with comments management, if you need to divide one page into several and change the page type to category for this sub pages. I think in previous version there was one big page for variables. By the way, this problem can be on every platform, and on SO too, the example is there is some near the same questions that has different number of valuable answers and to read all of this you need to go throw all of this questions.

Comment: @Juffy (last part of previos comment) In this situation with php docs it's simpler, if you learn php you can just go throw all of it's basic reference (it can be done very quickly), and you will have nearly all information you need at first steps.

Answer (score 94):

## Name the expansion “Examples” instead of “Documentation”

If you ask most SO contributors if they’re good at writing “documentation”, they’ll say *No*.

And if you ask most SO users (us) what they’d like to have, they’re ***not*** going to say “good documentation“. Instead, as [Andy suggested](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303868/441757) and as [Zanon also note](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303885/441757), what users (we) always really want are **good examples**.

And **writing good examples is actually what good SO contributors are *already* good at**. Clearly, the best answers to SO questions are very often the ones with great examples.

And in order to provide a good example, you have to not only make the example code, but you have to *explain* the code—explain how it works, and why.

Giving good explanations like that for examples is, essentially, providing “documentation”. In the end, that’s what good documentation is. The documentation just falls out from the examples.

But calling it *documentation* doesn’t win us anything. Most of us in our work lives don’t like being asked (told) to produce “documentation” as such—and resent having to spend time on it instead of coding. In fact I’d argue that **most of us really don’t even like the word “documentation“**.

**But we all *do* like *explaining* things**—that’s why we spend time on SO! And we all do like giving each other **examples**—and explaining those examples.

So, **names can make a really big difference in the success of anything**. And given that fact, I think this proposed expansion of SO will have a much higher chance of success and of getting off on the right foot to begin if it has **the right name**.

So let’s *please* not name it **Documentation**. Let’s just name it **Examples**.

Comment: I agree. I think they're vastly underestimating the amount of baggage that word carries. There will be very few discussions of this project on its own merits if it has to bear that burden.

Comment: "*If you ask most SO contributors if they’re good at writing “documentation”, they’ll say No.*"  What evidence do you have for this?

Comment: I agree. It seems pretty clear that many of the negative responses here are due to the fact that "documentation" sounds like a duplication. I think that easily searchable "objective-oriented" examples are very useful without duplicating official docs. I also think this follows the Agile principle of working software being more valuable than comprehensive documentation.

Comment: I agree.  Nobody likes documentation (its always wrong) and nobody likes writing documentation (it sounds too much like "work").  On the other hand, everyone likes examples that work and enlighten.  Examples benefit the author because it is an opportunity to show off and help others at the same time. Readers like examples because it gets to the point.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to propose after reading about the idea. Examples would be the best part of documentation anyway. Documentation as I see it also implies some kind of *completeness* which will probably never be achieved in SO documentation. *Examples* do not have this connotation.

Comment: And explanations. Most of the Content Management Systems I'm specialised in developing are basically just .Net, but with a rigid framework  - so any .Net dev could pick one up easily if they just had a high level overview of the concepts behind the system. And as an experienced developer I sure as hell could use a repository of examples for when I forget what class to inherit or something.

Comment: I'd have to agree with this to a great extent (that "Documentation" might drive some decent contributors away) - not sure whether "Examples" is clearly the _best_ choice, but something along those lines. I don't know - "E.G." comes to mind as having that same meaning, but being similar in tone to "Stack Overflow", "Super User", and "Server Fault" -- but in slightly different words, often what is already available from developers is basically syntax - it's a thing that's built in and testable from many IDEs even! What is most often missing is examples.

Comment: I do, however think that any such system should encourage syntax to be specified. Smaller software/API projects might use such a site solely to host their documentation. If it ends up making sense, larger and larger projects might migrate to this system or (through some sort of docs/e.g API) include examples from this site in their official documentation, where they simply provide the structure and summaries that are relatively easily testable and then outsource the examples (?!?!?)

Comment: 200% this.  Examples = good.  Documentation = been there, done that, bought the T-shirt.

Answer (score 89):

This is a really exciting idea.

But I have a few concerns:

- #### "Versions" are Arbitrary

  .NET has major releases, but that doesn't necessarily mean that the individual libraries within the product follow those version numbers.

  For example, .NET **4.5.1** was rolled out fairly recently, but the "Product Version" of the Accessibility.DLL file is **4.0.30319.18020**. Meanwhile, on MSDN, the documentation for versions **4.5** and **4.6** of the Accessibility namespace are [lumped together](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation(v=vs.110).aspx), though the URL shows version **110**.

  So which version number is correct? Only the authors of the library can truly understand the significance behind a "version" and how that impacts individual parts of a system.

  And then there's open source projects and their [many branches and forks](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1b/Linux_Distribution_Timeline.svg). How does one keep track of version numbers in such messy situations?
- #### Not all documentation can be neatly tucked under one heading

  The best documentation provides broad overviews and then connects the dots between different parts of the API. Documenting functions and parameters will only ever cover a small part of an API's functionality.

  Recently I tried to wrap my head around OAuth. While the individual query parameters were pretty well documented, what I really needed was a detailed overview of the flow for my particular (uncommon) scenario.

  Looking at .NET again, there are some libraries that overlap one another. I depend on documentation to explain the differences between the libraries and to help me determine which fits my needs. It's just shades of gray from that to a comparison of [VB, C#, C++ and F#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/we7h0cz1(v=vs.100).aspx).

  Would this fit under SO's documentation? Just imagine the battles between those who say "yes" and those who say "no". It's uncharted territory and it's going to get ugly before it gets better.
- #### Does SO want to be everyone's documentation host?

  Already a lot of major technologies point developer to Stack Overflow to get their questions answered (in lieu of a standard community):

  [image]

  Do we also want projects to abandon their own documentation platforms and move everything to SO? A lot of those documentation platforms cost a pretty penny (if not the CMS, then the hosting and bandwidth), so the idea of a completely free documentation host where the community will help you out (so you can downsize your documentation team) would be very tempting. Do we want that?
- #### RTFM just got more complicated

  Is documentation going to be a separate resource from Q&A? If someone asks a very specific question that's already covered in the more general documentation, will it be closed as a duplicate?
- #### Incentives are important

  On second look, it seems that reputation will be earned via "contributions" rather than posts. Sounds interesting... can't wait to hear more details.

  <strike>How do I earn reputation with topics? Will my "answer" get upvotes?</strike>

  Answers to Q&A questions often overlap one another, and the most thorough and correct answer tends to be get the most upvotes. But that doesn't mean that the most upvoted question contains all of the information needed by everyone. This is already an issue with some very specific questions, and will only be compounded by the very "general" nature of a "topic". It'd more important than ever for the community to collaborate and create a single source of truth, like a wiki answer, rather than 30 answers that mostly repeat one another, forcing visitors to read through many posts to find their use-case.

  *But users don't earn reputation from wiki answers.*

  So back to the question... how do I earn reputation? And if I don't, then why am I spending time working on documentation when I could be getting rep (and warm fuzzies) by answering questions?

Comment: All these points are spot on, and we're still working on them.  We're showing this off early to make sure we're going in the right direction, there will be more details in the future and things are actually decided.  We have guesses that will be tested/proven/broken/etc. in the betas and beyond.  I'll expand in individual comments because length, and also voting.

Comment: Versions are arbitrary.  We intend to allow the community to add new versions, and once a version is added it'll be available throughout a topic for both *page* level and *markdown block* use.  What level of version is worthy of this will be decided on a per-tag basis; for .net the 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.5, etc. level probably makes sense.  We'll have to have rules for what happens when a new version is introduced; we have ideas, nothing firm.

Comment: We only showed off one topic page for length reasons, but we think Documentation can and should contain many different "kinds" of subjects.  There's the class level stuff, sometimes method, but also "Getting Started" and "How do I set this up" and even smaller tutorials (I think multi-page tutorials probably won't work though).  I don't think that's hard to convince people of, since it's so common in existing documentation.

Comment: We're OK with hosting useful content.  I don't think we'll really want to encourage people designating SO as their official docs when they just start of; but we'd be OK with them acknowledging that SO docs are superior when they already exist.  What matters is the end quality of documentation on the internet, not so much what (say) Facebook or Google most prefer.

Comment: RTFM is still a little rough, I could go either way.  Right now I'd say "if it really is RTFM, there's probably a duplicate question with an answer that links to the docs already" so use that.  I could be convinced to go the other way.

Comment: Reputation is super important, and making sure we incentivize the right thing.  We've got some guesses, but they're so early and have so many known issues I don't think it's quite time to get feedback on them yet.  I also want to see how the tools get used in practice.

Comment: @KevinMontrose - Good answers. I'd say that you'll have a hard time preventing smaller projects from moving their documentation to SO, or simply discontinuing their documentation site and redirecting people to SO. (I know it was my first thought for my company's documentation.)

Comment: @KevinMontrose - I'd also like to add that naysayers will always find reasons to not try something. Sometimes the best way to prove something won't work is to try it, and the best way to find the path to success is to walk down a few false starts. "*Pursue something so important that even if you fail, the world is better off with you having tried.*"

Comment: I think one of the problems this is trying to solve first and foremost is "RTFM" "Where's the FM?"

Comment: Regarding duplicates: it really boils down to how this ends up getting used. In some alternate future, every method that does X has a documentation page detailing its use and corresponding question that asks, "How do I do X?" that mostly just quotes (and links to!) an example from the docs. In some other alternate future, the question comes first and the docs mostly just quote the answer there. And in the grim future of Hello Kitty, there is only war.

Comment: It's sad that the Facebook devs _still_ can't spell "Stack Overflow". Sheesh.

Comment: @Shog9 - In the darkest timeline, Spolsky dies in a tragic stuffed unicorn accident and Atwood is driven mad by the loss of an arm. Atwood recruits Skeet to secretly lace all Stack Overflow answers with SQL Injection and XSS vulnerabilities so that they can impose reputation-based hierarchies of authority on the entire world, and the only useful part of the SO site is the regex tag (where even the insane Atwood will not dare enter).

Comment: @KevinMontrose Versions are one of the main aspect of documentation and examples. It will be great if you could integrate some tools to auto check code snippet in different versions (like [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/5rVEA) or [travis-ci](https://travis-ci.org/doctrine/collections/builds/57144859)). With [docker containers](https://www.docker.com/) we can test language or tools in every environment we ever need

Comment: Reusing common documentation across multiple areas (e.g. method overloads) is important. For example, Microsoft has a system for doing this to generate their MSDN documentation, and when they don't seem to use it, things can get confusing. I coincidentally bumped into an [instance of this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32554618/145173) shortly after seeing the SO documentation proposal.

Comment: I would say that little projects hosted on github will definently want their documentation on SO. It is really clumsy to keep a good documentation up on github.

Answer (score 87):

I did contribute to some (open source) documentation, and I prefer to contribute to official documentation rather than posting some example, explanation or whatever on some third website, wiki, or forum....

1. APIs can evolve for six months to six months, sometime with some minor changes which make your example obsolete. So if you have your own documentation, on your own website, you have to keep it up to date... Now imagine with a large number of APIs... You'll spend your life on that...
2. Making a good example isn't so easy. Let's take a basic example: You want to show how to load a 3D model in some 3D engine. Okay fine, you have to create a camera, light... set the scene... and also to set the input, which requires a third library...
3. If after crawling in the API, you feel like there is something missing, maybe it would be more beneficial to contact the authors than posting somewhere else. By doing that we limit one problem when you're searching on the Internet, the entropy.
4. Closed source code (if you really can't use open source): pointing the lack of documentation to the authors is still possible and my 1) is more than ever true.
5. you want to centralize APIs, the idea isn't bad in itself, but the fact is, ***ALL*** APIs are actually already centralized... on what people called the web. SO is right now doing something complementary of forums or mailing lists there is no structural need (my opinion) of what you are proposing, since it's already done.
6. Almost everytime I had to contact some authors, I got some answer. I have no doubt that authors like to be contacted. Often I got some thanx when I pointed some problem/lack in the documentation. Maybe your idea can a little upset some authors and contributors (I'm not talking about my case, I always contribute for small things). Don't forget some of these people may the ones who help on SO...

Your idea sounds like to me like a wrong good idea. But I'm just debating, and I'm open to the discussion; you can convince me otherwise.

Comment: Examples could come with the API version attached they are valid for and it would always be easier to adapt them for a new version than to start from scratch. But I agree that good examples can sometimes become really large. And I also agree that the goal should be to complete the official documentation, not to build an alternative documentation. A permissive license might allow this kind of feedback.

Comment: _Making a good example isn't so easy._ Of course it's not easy; if it was easy it would be in the official API documentation / all over the Internet already! But the users of the software can often provide more useful examples then the developer, simply because the developer 1) has a narrower focus on the precise API syntax that he/she worked on, and 2) is affected by the knowledge the internal workings.

Comment: _Let's take a basic example._ This proposal is less about basic single-method examples, and more about how collections of API parts can be used together, precisely like your example.

Comment: @ZevSpitz sorry but i'm not agree. If you want to show how to load a 3D model by using some function, you have to show the model in a window, with light and stuff...

Comment: What if I just want to load a 3D model, without a burning desire to use specifically function `xyz` in module `abc`? I would also want to know all the other details as well (if not in this example then at least an easily findable linked example). Official documentation examples are often unhelpful in this respect, because it is easiest for the developers to arrange the documentation by module and function, and the example is usually tied to the specific function.

Comment: This is actually one of the things MSDN gets right in the documentation of the Office API, VBA and some other APIs (generally the Automation APIs). Documentation is often split between **How do I**, **Concepts** and **Reference** -- [Word](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ee861527.aspx), [VBA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264383.aspx), [WIA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms630827%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). (It is admittedly almost impossible to find unless you know it's there; that is something this proposal also aims to solve.)

Comment: There are some languages or tools which has no documentation (online documentation) at all ([phpdbg for example](http://phpdbg.com/docs)). If it would be a place to make docs with large experienced devs community, it'll be great place.

Comment: @Mikl if you make a documentation for (E.G) phpbdg, I'm sure the authors will add it to the link "documentation" of the web page you pointed. Of course, I understand that if there is no doc at all, it would be better to add some somewhere. But honestly, I don't think that the case for many common APIs to don't have any documentation. So, I'm agree with you in the case there is no doc at all, but the question/proposition here is quiet more general...

Comment: `You'll spend your life on that...` No you won't. The *users* of your project will keep the documentation up to date, not you (the developers of the project).

Answer (score 69):

### Contribute BACK, instead of duplicating effort (and COPYing).

In my opinion, this is largely **duplicated effort**.

Most of the questions here concern something which is more-or-less open source. There are very few closed source things that have an API and enough users such that we would ever achieve quality.

However, for open source projects, the documentation should at least be eventually **contributed back** into the original projects. This may however mean we would need different license agreements for different APIs...

I'm *against* duplicated effort. I'd appreciate a **Wiki-like effort** that could import the existing documentation similar to **translation/l10n efforts**, involve the community in improving it, and eventually be merged back into the original project. This may also help with handling different versions. Think of e.g. Cyanogen, which has to translate strings of their Android version to many languages.

Also, it will prevent a lot of copyright issues, if it is setup such that it can legally import the existing documentation. If you start from scratch, a lot of users *will* copy the existing documentation even just to change a spelling error. It's already happening all the time on SO that people copy examples from other sources which may constitute a copyright violation. It happens on Wikipedia all the time, too. Users are concerned with usefulness, not with legal issues.

Comment: Counterpoint: MSDN is enormous, sprawling, and most if not all of it is closed to comment. I think I agree with you that duplication of effort is bad, and would in general think this whole idea is silly if not for MSDN. The ideal outcome for all this in my mind would just be that Microsoft open up its docs to comments that provide useful examples, descriptions of edge-cases, etc. After that, Warlords of Documentation can go away as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: But MSDN is just a subset. Think of jQuery, Java and such. JavaDoc never allowed comments. MSDN is a single provider, so to speak. That would be a warlords of MSDN.

Comment: You're right. jQ is another example of which I was reminded reading through here, plus Java docs for the folks who work in the larger shops which still use and build Java-tools heavily. I had a decent idea for addressing the effort-duplication issue... (see my [response](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/304034/3159183)). But the copyright issues are a much harder thing to solve (partly because the courts have not really caught up to the idea of what coders do, and just how much of what they do is the same no matter who does it – see "copyright trolls" who succeed esp. in the software realm)

Comment: I came to say this - we should be encouraging fixing the documentation itself wherever possible, instead of simply creating a new set. That way all users of the libraries/languages/frameworks benefit, not just those that use StackOverflow.

Comment: How would this work in the real world, with thousands of different platforms, documentation standards, hierarchies, etc., without everyone migrating their docs to one unified platform?

Comment: As a dev of a major project (matplotlib) I think this is the best response.  Effort that goes into SO based documentation should be directed upstream.

Comment: MSDN, at one point, was a lot more encouraging of community content. The typical contribution consisted of a technical support question, rather than helpful content. I'm sure the cost of moderating sealed the fate of community content on MSDN.

Answer (score 57):

One problem touched on in a couple of other answers is that documentation needs to evolve with the language, library or tool it's documenting. Apparently [obsolete answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261817/how-do-we-encourage-edits-to-obsolete-out-of-date-answers) are a pretty big problem here, and so would likely be a problem with documentation as well. One particular problem with dealing with obsolete answers, is while they may deal with older versions, many people may still be using the older version making the answer still useful.

I think that means that the new documentation feature is going to need to handle multiple versions of a topic explicitly. There can't be just be one version the Python topic for `urllib`, there needs to be at least one for each of Python 2.7 and Python 3.x. And no, just going with 3.x isn't really a good option, given that the 2.7 tag is more popular than the 3.x tag. On the other hand there are probably enough Python topics that would be same in all versions that completely partitioning Python documentation by version wouldn't be a good idea.

One advantage of having topics tied to specific versions (and not moving targets like Python or Python 3.x) is that they won't rot on the vine. Obsolescence becomes much less of a problem this way.

More generally I'm worried about the overall quality the documentation, I don't think there's necessarily the right expertise here to create better documentation than the web already offers.

Comment: How about a version tagging system? Topics which were correct and relevant in multiple versions of a language could be tagged with all of them. When a new version came out, all topics could be flagged as needing checking to see whether they could be tagged with the new version or not.

Comment: We have some thoughts on versioning.  They're less complete than some of what's presented here (and everything presented here can still change), but the gist is "master version table for each tag, every Topic has a list of versions it applies to, within in each Topic you can further mark individual block as applying to particular versions, when a new version is released we infer [heuristic TBD] which pages get it outmagically."  This will let us handle searching for versions, *and* let us do things like "when this version was added, what was the state of this Topic page."

Comment: I've often thought that online documentation should be like CSS, or derived classes, with a baseline set of facts as paragraphs, then a superset which is overlaid upon that superset. So the base text shows through unless it's been superseded by later information. To see older info just peel back a layer (casting?) where some of the baseline may peek through or a prior version might still overlay that. Then in SO fashion or like a wiki, in one "view" each layer gets peer reviewed, upvoted, and edited, while in a more "consumer-oriented view" the doc is just readable as any other flat text.

Comment: Versioning: I totally agree that there should be a handy mechanism for both, see for which target version a doc is handy as well as for 'marking' the right version while providing such a snippet. This discussion here reminds me pretty much of the Postgres documentation. What I like there is that the pages of a 'topic' (e.g. SELECT) stay the same but you can easily navigate to your specific target version. With this in mind, on SO, there are many answers for Postgres query questions telling 'this example is valid for PG < 8.1, for > 8.1 better use ...'. Maybe this could be some inspiration?

Comment: @KevinMontrose For me, the silver bullet for overcome versioning problem is providing the full environment specification for each code example (it can be hidden under some `Env` icon in the corner of code snippet block and pops up when it clicked), go further if it will be integrated with auto testing platform we can have results without time wasting (it can be hidden under some `Test Result` icon), for that test suite need to be done. And more, we can give full environment snapshot (system image) to instant run with one click (docker containers can do this magic)

Answer (score 56):

Stack Overflow already has severe quality and maintenance problems:

- Wrong or harmful posts do *not* get downvoted and remain for everyone to see and copy-paste from.
- Posts with content problems receive comments about those problems, the comments pointing out these problems receive upvotes, the problem remains.
- Users don't care about quality; answerers care about their reputation and askers just want to get their problem solved.
- The majority of the userbase is not quite proficient in English.

These problems, though maybe slightly exaggerated, need to be fixed before starting yet another site.

Also, documentation (or rather, class or function documentation) is not the place for everything. You shouldn't want to explain the entire concept of a "file", or a "database", or a "socket" at the `File`, `SqlCommand` or `Socket` class documentation pages. There are separate resources that thoroughly handle such subjects. If users don't want to educate themselves but "just want a working socket implementation example", and this proposed site is going to cater for that, we're going to have a bad time.

As others have pointed out, writing good documentation is hard. As I try to explain above, writing it in a context comparable to Stack Overflow is, again, IMHO, impossible to get right.

Maybe without the gamification of "fake internet points" it has a chance, otherwise I can only see this as a race to the bottom.

Comment: The problems you've mentioned may be correct if you look at each of them seperated. My english isn't the best for example. But as we have a collaborative platform here we are able get the best out of it. What are your suggestions? Your post isn't very constructive. Do you like to teach all non-native speakers better english? Or do you want all non-native speakers to stop giving answers?

Comment: @user I tried to address real problems that currently exist and that will propagate to the new site if not solved. If I had the solution to those problems, I would have mentioned them.

Comment: @CodeCaster I'm not sure that the problems listed would inevitably propagate to the documentation area. Certainly, the incentivisation and privilege structure for documentation needs careful thought, as does the peer review system, but given the focus and structure would be different (i.e. it's not a place for people to ask for solutions to their problems), you wouldn't have the major issue of loads of low quality questions being asked. Poor English can be edited, and I don't see that it's a huge barrier.

Comment: For some languages, libraries and tools there is no documentation at all. I would be happy to have an opportunity to make it. As for the language i think it would be great to have multilingual versions of documentation, because you can be good in coding and not good in english, and translation of good article in different language to english is much easier then write good article (it can be done by translator alone without coding experience).

Comment: This answer seems to best outline my concerns. Extending upon your concerns regarding examples, which examples will be selected for the documentation? It seems like there will be emphasis upon examples solving common problems, degrading the quality of the documentation for obscure problems. Additionally, suppose you have one large group of people who insist upon using an outdated, probably inaccurate resource, a smaller group of people who insist upon using more up-to-date, credible resources and many in between who don't care... This already happens among the realm of academia regarding C.

Comment: I fully agree with your first 3 points. I see so many posts that have accepted answers that either are not the best answers, out-dated, or provide insecure code. I guess my main fear is with users chasing reputation and degrading the proposed documentation system simply to earn points. I have no solutions to these issues but more attention given to them could surely benefit SO and the proposed documentation system.

Answer (score 54):

I think this idea certainly has value, primarily in the realm of GitHub-wiki style documentation of general topics and tasks surrounding a specific library or tool. There are a few important things to consider here though.

## Advantages of Official API Documentation

When it comes to language API documentation (for example, classes, method names and signatures, etc.), the proposed approach has a number of significant disadvantages when compared to existing solutions. Or rather, it lacks a number of the advantages that many existing solutions possess.

### Can be generated from code

Often when I see documentation for an API in a programming language, things like method signatures, class names, and return types are pulled into the docs using an automated tool. This has a number of advantages.

#### Completeness

Generating API documentation automatically practically guarantees that all methods and classes are at least *mentioned* in documentation, even if they aren't thoroughly described.

This also has the positive side effect of making lack of documentation for a specific method highly visible, so it's clear what areas of the documentation need to be improved.

#### More resistant to change

Tying documentation to code means that the documentation is inherently version-specific. There are documentation available for *all* versions of the codebase, even intermediate revisions not part of an official release.

Additionally, documentation generated from code usually pulls descriptive text from annotated comments in the source code itself. This helps ensure the documentation stays up to date, because whenever a developer updates the code they have a clear opportunity (and responsibility) to update the documentation along with it.

### Supported by the software's developers

Others have already mentioned this, but official documentation has the advantage of the ultimate experts on the system, the developers, being the ones writing it.

## Advantages of the Proposed System

This proposal is not without its own merits though. Specifically...

### Less friction for community contribution

Official documentation can often be difficult or impossible to contribute to. Even with open source systems, submitting a pull request isn't quite as easy as making an edit in a wiki-style system like the one you are proposing, and pull requests don't scale as well.

With closed source it's even worse, as there's often no opportunity at all for community members to contribute to the official documentation. In such a situation, this proposal could be an enormous improvement, especially if the existing documentation sucks.

### Examples

I really like the idea of examples shown in this proposal. I often find that a short example helps me understand how to use a feature far quicker than any textual description ever could. So much so that I've often found myself ignoring the text and skipping straight to the written examples when skimming over documentation.

## When is this system better?

The way I see it, the proposed system is better than official documentation in the following situations:

- When dealing with topics more general than simple API documentation
- When describing how to perform a specific task, especially where developers might be unaware of what methods to use for performing that task (there's a lot of overlap with Stack Overflow here)
- When the the official documentation is horrible and the community can't do anything to fix them

## Can we get the best of both worlds?

If the main goal of this proposal is to "improve developers' lives on the Internet" by greatly improving documentation, I wonder whether it might be possible to get the best of both worlds. Can we keep all the advantages of official documentation, while also getting the advantages of examples and frictionless community contributions?

I'm not really sure. I wonder if it might be possible to pull in auto-generated documentation from existing tools (like [RDoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RDoc) in the case of Ruby or [Javadoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javadoc) in the case of Java). Maybe Stack Overflow could expose some kind of API allowing documentation to be pulled in from an external source, and later pushed back with included community improvements? Or maybe it's better to stay away from API documentation in favor of more general topics? I don't really know. Does anyone else have any thoughts on this?

Comment: This is an interesting line of thought, because no matter what we'll be living in a world with both at launch.

Comment: @hek2mgl I don't think the response here is really so much a "no" as it is a "proceed with caution". Obviously there are some potential problems with this idea, but I don't think they're unavoidable.

Comment: I really like the idea of pushing or at least having the ability to push back. Very important for being able to push back is the right license. A dual licensing (CC for keeping the content here and a license allowing pushing back) might be in order. This of course means that one in principles says goodbye to the dream of SO being the one and only documentation source.

Comment: @Ajedi32, I think there's much to be said for the tying documentation & code together, like you mentioned.  I question whether you could import official docs across a variety of project documentation solutions and maintain any sort of quality.

Comment: @xdhmoore That feature (if implemented) would have to be initially limited to specific languages. Kind of like how code snippets only work for JS CSS and HTML right now.

Comment: I think it might be harder than that.  JS, for example, has multiple documentation solutions. And some documentation solutions are customizable.

Comment: @xdhmoore Yeah, sorry. By "language" I really meant "topic". Like NodeJS would have one solution, and the JS DOM might have another. That's also why I suggested that SO expose a standard API for importing/exporting documentation. That way third parties could write tools to import basically any kind of documentation into the system, making the whole idea much more flexible and scalable.

Comment: If I generate my docs instead of hand-write them (which is pretty common), what happens when some major changes happen and I need to update them? Do all of the user-contributions get killed?

Comment: @Qix Not if you pull in the user contributions first. Think of the user contributions as a branch in git. That's how I'm envisioning it anyway.

Comment: @Qix major changes meant that you have a new version of your app, the docs for old version, i think, should remain and both versions should be accessible, and no deletion is needed :)

Answer (score 52):

I want to brainstorm from the science of motivation perspective. Why would people be *willing* to contribute to Stack Overflow-documentation, and how to make their experience *less frustrating*?

**Consideration #1:** There is a very popular meme that Stack Overflow community is unfriendly, the atmosphere is toxic, the questions are routinely closed by insecure and troubled people with [deletionist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deletionism_and_inclusionism_in_Wikipedia) attitudes, and moderators are authoritarian and love censorship. (For example, see [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/3hqii7/stackoverflow_celebrates_ten_million_questions/) and the amount of sarcastic comments about duplicates).

It doesn't matter, how accurate this meme is. If Stack Overflow-documentation is anything like a wiki, there will be even more hatred and frustration. On Stack Overflow everyone writes questions and answers with their own style, their own examples, and their own opinions. On a wiki everything is supposed to be canonical, so people would constantly fight over which example is more canonical, which wording is more appropriate, there will be lots of references to more and more rules and style guides. It will be like Wikipedia. And this might provide bad incentives: wins the one who is more stubborn.

**Consideration #2:** Michael Snoyman [published a post](http://www.yesodweb.com/blog/2015/08/thoughts-on-documentation) with thoughts why people are willing to send pull requests with documentation improvements, but not contribute to a wiki. Please read this post.

For a wiki: maintainers think they are encouraging the community to write documentation, contributors are intimidated by the wiki, because they are afraid they aren't justified in editing it, readers rightly expect incomplete, unstructured, and messy information.

For documentation that is improved through pull requests: maintainers deal with documentation in atomic fashion using tools they know, contributors don't worry about inadvertently doing harm, because their contributions are checked by the maintainers, readers know that the information is canonical, because somebody reviewed the contribution before publishing it.

**Consideration #3:** When you contribute to a wiki, you always feel that you are stepping on somebody's turf. It doesn't matter, if wiki maintainers explicitly encourage you to contribute, it still feels like you can break something and make someone silently irritated.

When you contribute a PR, the worst that can happen is that it would be rejected. Stack Overflow-documentation must make sure that the worst that can happen to your contribution is rejection or downvote, not silent aggravation of the community, or edit wars.

**Consideration #4:** There is a psychological reason why I contribute to Stack Overflow and not Wikipedia. I believe this reason boils down to:

- Autonomy and ownership: My questions and answers are largely untouched by the community (they can be downvoted, but downvotes are less psychologically offending than somebody rewriting your words). My questions and answers are written in my own literary style, with examples of my choosing, with the idea and structure that I envisioned. On Wikipedia there's none of it.
- Persistence: Subsequently when I write a question and answer, and they are minimally conforming to Stack Overflow rules, they are going to stay forever. It feels like I contributed to the knowledge of humanity. It feels like I did something immutable. On Wikipedia my contributions are constantly under thread of futility.
- Atomicity: One answer means one indivisible chunk of contribution. It feels like I contribute knowledge brick by brick. My contributions feel tangible and measurable. They don't feel like opaque Sisyphean toil, where you don't know if you are actually contributing or just fighting against the wind.
- Visualization of work and gamification: Not only do I do atomic chunks of contributions, these chunks are explicitly measured by the system. These can be simple measurements in the form of "number of answers": yesterday I had 100 answers, but today I wrote 101th, yay! These can also be scores, badges.
- Visibility and recognition: Everybody can see that my answer was contributed by me. On Wikipedia my contribution is lost in the long list of commits on the history page. When I write answers on Stack Overflow I feel that my answers are recognized, that people see them and see that it is I, who wrote them.

**Consideration #5:** The following is quoted from [Doing Good Better](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1592409105) on how to find a job that maximally satisfies you, based on scientific evidence. This directly applies to motivation behind contributing to documentation. If for some reason you don't get your kicks, you won't do it. (BTW, the book is fantastic, read it now!)

> Research shows that the most consistent predictor of job satisfaction is engaging work, which can be broken down into five factors (this is known in psychology as the ‘job characteristics theory’):
>
> 1. **Independence** — To what extent do you have control over how you go about your work?
> 2. **Sense of Completion** — To what extent does the job involve completing a whole piece of work, so that your contribution to the end product is easily visible, rather than being merely a small part of a much larger product?
> 3. **Variety** — To what extent does the job require you to perform a range of different activities, using different skills and talents?
> 4. **Feedback from the job** — How easy is it to know whether you're performing well or badly?
> 5. **Contribution** — To what extent does your work ‘make a difference’, as defined by positive contributions to the wellbeing of other people?
>
> As well as job satisfaction, each of these factors also correlates with motivation, productivity and commitment to your employer. Moreover, these factor are similar to those required to develop flow, the pleasurable state of being so immersed in an activity that you're completely free of distractions and lose track of time, which some psychologists have argued is the key to having genuinely satisfying experiences.

Comment: Excellent point! I've stopped contributing to Wikipedia because my carefully sourced contributions were replaced by tripe. The problem is that the tripe peddlers are legion and have plenty of time on their hands to peddle their tripe. The experts are few and usually have more fruitful things to do than wage edit war with the tripe peddlers, so the peddlers win. The editorial practices on SO are such that if an expert posts an answer, the expert can expect this answer to not be defaced by a tripe peddler, but on Wikipedia all bets are off.

Comment: Motivation is a concern. Engineers who know a topic well aren't usually inclined to write docs, and developers notoriously can't write well. So I wouldn't want the average hack writing docs. That leaves it to those with knowledge And writing skills. Why would these folks spend time documenting software here? I write a ton of docs for FOSS and commercial software, but quite often I (and my wife) ask why, when I get paid for code and consultation. I like the topic here but will always need to weigh the value of time on SO vs elsewhere. Recognition and warm fuzzies have limited attraction value.

Comment: I often recommend to people who are trying to establish a reputation, or gain experience, that they go join active open source communities and write documentation.

Answer (score 50):

I like the idea, even though I'm not sure if it'll work well. The general idea has been around for a long time, another place in the SE system to put content that doesn't fit into the Q&A system. To some extent this can be used for canonical answers, blog posts, tag wikis, tutorials and similar content.

One concern I have is the increased potential for plagiarism. Tag wikis already receive a lot of suggested edits that are taken verbatim from Wikipedia. I would suspect that this new feature would receive direct copies from existing documentation by users trying to gain badges or reputation. This is of course already an issue with the regular Q&A, but I fear that it might be an even bigger issue if there is an obvious place to look for content to copy, the original documentation. I'd think about ways to support the users checking suggested additions for possible plagiarism, or maybe even an automatic system for that.

Related to that is the issue of users duplicating effort where good documentation already exists. With reputation on the line, I could imagine users adapting existing information without need just to earn some reputation on SO.

The other issue is assigning reputation for collaboratively edited content. So far SE has avoided this, community wiki posts don't give out any reputation. This is a pretty hard problem, and anything I can think of has severe issues. But I assume the SE team has something in mind here, I'm curious to hear the details at some point in the future.

Another consideration is the licence, it might make sense to think about an even more permissive licence to make it easier to integrate documentation created here into the official documentation, if the project wants to do that.

Comment: With plagiarism being such a huge problem on SO, hoo boy.

Comment: otoh, if the documentation of my tool is good enough that people plagiarize it on SO, why not set up my own account (if I don't have one already) and just port the whole documentation on block over. No more bandwidth fees, no more hosting fees. And a horde of people who want to improve on it. I'd do it.

Answer (score 47):

I generally agree with [Stijn](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303867/572). There is already documentation out there for many things - some of it good, some of it bad. I think that his points need to be addressed for this to make sense.

What worries me the most is that this is a very SO-centric feature. I don't generally have a problem with this, but I do when it's eating up resources that could be devoted to improving something that would benefit every site: tag wikis. There are many suggestions to improve tag wikis out there, from [improving visibility](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292364/improve-tag-wiki-visibility) to [mobile support for tag wikis](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292361/make-full-tag-wiki-accessible-from-mobile-view) to [general improvements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65021/improving-the-tag-wiki). The ability to create, maintain, search, and use tag wikis - improving a feature that already exists across the network - seems like it should take precedence over a feature that will benefit a few sites. I'm not sure all of what should be done with tag wikis - I'd like to see more attribution, more searchability, more rewards for working on them, more moderation ability (queues and such related to new tags and tag wiki updates) and maybe even the ability to create tags and tag wikis without attaching them to questions.

Since this is a network of sites, I'd like to see viable answers from other members of non-SO communities as to how they'd potentially use this on their site. I'm just having trouble coming up with good ways I'd want to use this on Programmers or the other sites that I frequent. If this is indeed an SO-centric feature that adds little value across the network, I'd like to see some kind of work on things that impact the other sites in the network as well.

Comment: I think for other sites like some of the ones under the "Technology" group (Mathematica, Blender) could use this directly.  And with a bit of tweaking, even some other sites like Arqade (console commands?), ELU (grammar rules), and Seasoned Advice (measurements/terminology) could see some benefits as well.

Comment: @ryanyuyu Couldn't some of those sites also first benefit from tag wiki improvements, for example? There may be some sites who can use some form of this. I'm talking about making choices to (a) fix features everywhere that would benefit most sites or (b) design, implement, and test a brand new feature that would only benefit a smaller number of sites. There's not enough of (a) happening.

Comment: I really sympathize with the need to improve tag wikis. But I'm afraid that tag wikis have _so many problems_ that we should at least consider alternatives. In particular, I don't think [adding more features](http://headrush.typepad.com/creating_passionate_users/2005/06/featuritis_vs_t.html) will help. At this point, it's too early to evaluate whether the documentation concept will be relevant to other sites. I think it will, but we're going to be using Stack Overflow as the guinea pig first.

Comment: @JonEricson What problems do tag wikis have, other than the fact that they aren't available on mobile, they aren't searchable from the site, and they don't do a good job providing attribution to contributors? Fixing those three things would go a long way to making community contributed non-QA content so much better for everyone.

Comment: @ThomasOwens: Those are all _part_ of the problem. I'd add that there's little incentive to update tag wikis, they are of wildly varying quality, making synonyms and deleting tags causes wikis to drop off the face of the site, there's no way to create anchors to individual sections or split them into pages, etc. and so on. Frankly, if tag wikis aren't outright broken, they are holding together with duct tape.

Comment: @JonEricson Honestly, I'd be really happy if the team sat down and took a look at usage on other sites. Look at a use case on a non-SO, and even a non-tech site. Look at Gaming, Cooking, Academia, or maybe a different kind of tech site like Apple or Unix & Linux or a softer site like The Workplace or Programmers. Maybe you're right and tag wikis are broken and it's not worth fixing them. But if you're going to build a new feature, I'd like to see it thought through for everyone and not just SO so that it can not only be rolled out, but be useful to everyone on the network.

Comment: I think the other sites could actually use this *more* than SO. Poor documentation is better than no documentation, and we have at least poor documentation for almost everything that SO covers. But, what authoritative online resources are there for musicians or cooks? I would love to see a community authored open source cook book that lists how long to boil an egg to avoid a runny yolk, what temperature is medium rare for what meat, and other such things. Or, a musical reference with things like the difference between a time signature and a key signature.

Comment: @gilly3 - For the cooking, there are various attempts at [open-source cookbooks](http://www.ibiblio.org/oscookbook/downloads/OSCOOKBOOK.pdf) already available (not to mention [Seasoned Advice](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/)). For the musical reference, I think you may be describing Wikipedia.

Comment: Perhaps this proposal would actually replace tag wikis, as the documentation in this format is far more flexible.

Answer (score 44):

**Some thoughts:**

The documentation [sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0bqw.png) enumerates a class's constructor overloads and their parameters. I don't think this is a good sort of thing to include, and could even be outright harmful. I think we should avoid anything that resembles standard documentation of functions, their parameters, their return types, their error conditions etc, for several reasons:

- It will always be a less authoritative source than the official documentation. For example, imagine if the official documentation says that
  a method may throw a `IllegalStateException` in some obscure multithreaded scenario but the Stack Overflow "documentation" leaves that 
  exception out, and a developer thus designs their code on the assumption that the method cannot fail, just who is liable when the 
  exception occurs? Is it the developer, for trusting the popular Stack Overflow documentation? Is it the Stack Overflow contributor who documented things ever-so-nearly-completely but not fully-actually-completely? Is it the API developer, who, realizing that everyone now depends on the exception not occurring, is faced with the prospect of reimplementing the API to cater to the common usage, whatever the cost? With third-party documentation, blame is *diffused* and no-one in particular is responsible.

  On the other hand, official documentation is more than just an explanation of what things mean. It's a **promise** about how things work, a contract that the API writer makes with the API users to support a particular usage. No-one other than the API writer can make such a promise, because no-one else is responsible for writing the code that honors it. If they don't honor it at least you have someone to blame.
- It will always be less complete than official documentation (which, even if it's auto-generated, will at least include mention of every API member, whereas rep-driven documentation writers could leave obscure things out).
- I fear it will struggle to cope with changes between API versions.
- Overall, I can't imagine that it will be better than the "Gets the row enumerator" style documentation it seeks to replace, although it will be better in some places and worse in others.

---

**If there is value in user-contributed documentation, it lies in creating the examples and tutorials of real-world usage.**

This could be good. I'm tentatively in favor of the experiment. However, I'm worried by the overlap with the Q&A format. I envisage a lot of argument about what belongs as a documentation topic and what should be presented as Q&A and/or tag wiki. New users will be especially confused. I've read this page several times and I'm still confused. If the line can't be drawn clearly then it's going to cause so much fuss that we should not bother with the feature, and should stick to Q&A and tag wikis.

---

Addendum: I'm not looking forward to the inevitable gold rush when the feature goes live. It is already the case that Stack Overflow rep is based much more on post *visibility* than on post *effort*, and a big part of visibility is being *first* to snipe in with an answer or question. (We all know this, and we all do it, even though we like to think our own rep scores are based on nothing but pure cleverness.) I expect that opening up an entire new section of the site will cause a new race to snag the common issues and popular topics. Speed and quantity will be rewarded with rep more than quality. It's going to be a race to grab land to plant the seeds of future rep growth, more than an altruistic collaboration to build ideal documentation.

Comment: The line is that documentation is general and questions are specific.  An example I've used internally, if there is a documentation topic for adding classes to elements in jQuery with sufficient examples, and someone comes to the site and asks how to add a class to an element in jQuery, it could be closed by pointing to appropriate documentation.  If the question includes the exact html of the posters use case, it is specific enough to warrant a question with a link to the relevant docs page.  Almost all integration type questions are specific enough to be questions.

Comment: Let's be honest: it's *always* the developer who is liable. Hence the common rejection of liability in EULAs...

Comment: Re: rep gold rush.  I've been working on exactly this problem.  Effort is worth about as much as it actually helps people, so there is value in visibility.  There are 2 clear fundamental differences in docs vs Q&A, 1) docs are broad and should typically help more people, of course yes there are still some less used tools and features to document, 2) there really should only be one topic for a thing, not 10 answers for it, so editing the existing thing needs to feel correct in this system.

Comment: Because these things are so different, we're open to testing new rep systems completely, but we're holding off until we have some actual usage data from beta before we waste too much time modeling fantasies.

Answer (score 34):

There's quite a few answers for the *nay-sayers*. There are answers for the *yay-sayers*. There's also a few answers highlighting *specific doubts*.

This answer is for people, who share *my* view:

- Cautiously optimistic;
- Skeptical (in the good sense);
- Willing to give it a fair chance;

Basically **this answer is for those who think the proof is in the pudding**. So regardless of my skepticism, please let me have some of that pudding so I can decide whether I like it or not.

[image: pudding]
<sup>[Source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Pistachio_pudding_IMAG0107_(11295959574).jpg)</sup>

Comment: Sorry, but no green pudding for me.

Comment: @bluefeet Would blue pudding be better? The pica is licensed CC so nothing a hue filter won't fix... ;-)

Comment: What is that dark stripe?

Comment: @hek2mgl Dunno, just picked the puddingiest pica from [the puddings category on wikimedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Puddings).

Comment: I think they are inner shells of pistachios.

Comment: Could also be almonds, since https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pistachio_pudding says so. :)

Comment: Eh... what is this answer for?

Comment: You've told us who this answer is for, but you haven't told us what the answer is.

Comment: Well, as often on meta, the *question* isn't immediately clear, so the answers will not be either. I think the question can be assumed to be at least one of ["*How would documentation on SO help documentation, and vice versa?*", "*Do you think this will work?*", "*Will you please register for the beta?*", "*Do you already have some feedback?*"]. I think my answer fits any of those, summarized as: *I'm positive yet skeptical, I don't know if it'll work until I've tried, but I'm certainly willing to give it a try.*

Comment: What are those "doubts" you mention?

Comment: @KerrekSB Not sure if you're asking a real question or whether that's sarcasm; there's 80+ answers, quite a few of which express 'doubts' about this idea (ranging from "this will never work" to "have you thought about such and such").

Comment: I agree. Seeing green pudding, I'd sniff it first. Prod it a bit to make sure it's not alive. Dip the spoon tip in it and tentatively lick it. If it isn't too bad, I'd try a mouthful - and, hey, perhaps it turns out to be surprisingly good!

Answer (score 32):

I love the optimistic *If a project already has awesome documentation that’s easy to search and cite, then there’s no need to duplicate it on Stack Overflow.* 
Yeah, right.

I'm a big fan of using simple diagrams to explain things so please please include something like Doxygen's use of Graphviz, PlantUML or any textual format for diagramming. Obviously a bias towards ease of use is needed.

Versioning is probably the biggest issue and I'm glad to see the comment that you have plans to cope already. It needs to be possible to not only search by version but also to see how things change between them so a parallel viewing option would be great.

Answer (score 30):

First, a little background.

I have [some experience on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/734069/nicol-bolas). One could call that a form of documentation. But I also am the primary contributor to another form of documentation: the [OpenGL Wiki](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Main_Page). I personally transformed it over the course of *years* from a [dumping ground](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Common_Mistakes)/[crappy FAQ](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/FAQ) into a legitimate and genuinely useful resource.

Not to toot my own horn, but I think I know a little something about documentation.

### The Forms of Documentation

All forms of documentation seek to provide knowledge. But the hardest part is knowing what form you need and how to index that form.

#### Reference documentation

The simplest form of documentation is what I call Reference documentation. These are often derided by newbies as being "only useful if you already know the answer." However, anyone with any real experience knows the importance of reference documentation.

Reference documentation is, essentially, taking each API or basic element of something, and explaining everything you can do with it. If you look up an API function's reference documentation, it should explain what the inputs mean, what the outputs are, and most importantly what the function does.

But the newbie's perspective on reference documentation is not unreasonable. Using my field of expertise (ie: OpenGL) as an example, take the function [`glTextureStorage2D`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glTexStorage2D.xhtml). That is a solid piece of documentation. It tells you what the function does. Namely, allocating storage for a texture object.

Here are just a few of the things that it *doesn't* tell you:

- What's a texture object?
- What does it mean for a texture to have "storage"?
- What are mipmaps?
- What are array layers?

And here's the thing. No matter how important it is to understand those concepts, reference documentation **should not explain them!** That is simply not its job.

The newbie perspective is not entirely wrong: you absolutely must understand the basic concepts of a system before reference docs can help you. And it is important to have such documentation, because reference docs become a lot less useful if they have to spend lots of time explaining such concepts.

The strength of reference docs are also their primary weakness: when done right, they're assuming you already know a lot about the subject matter.

Another weakness is that it often involves a *lot* of duplication of information. Again taking OpenGL as an example, just look at the text on [`glTextureStorage1D`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glTexStorage1D.xhtml) and [`glTextureStorage2D`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glTexStorage2D.xhtml). They are two separate pages, but they're almost identical.

#### Tutorial/Example documentation

Example-focused documentation is basically someone writing out some (presumably functional) code, and then explaining how it works.

Among the other things I've done for OpenGL is [write this](http://alfonse.bitbucket.org/oldtut/). I used to think of it as a tutorial, but I realize that it went quite far from being a pure "tutorial". One of the things I encountered while writing that was that I was constantly having to stop and explain how various elements of some feature worked.

Here's what I mean. In [Chapter 2](http://alfonse.bitbucket.org/oldtut/Basics/Tut02%20Vertex%20Attributes.html), I introduce the ability to interpolate colors across a polygon's surface. I explain that there are three ways to perform that interpolation: `smooth` (the default), `flat`, and `noperspective`. But... I couldn't really talk about the difference between `smooth` and `noperspective`. Why?

Because I hadn't introduced perspective projection yet. And without that, *there is no difference.*

I could have introduced perspective projection earlier, perhaps. But then I would have to hold off on having any per-vertex parameters interpolated across a primitive. That significantly limits the amount of stuff you can do.

I also could have introduced perspective correct interpolation when I introduced perspective projection. However, [that chapter](http://alfonse.bitbucket.org/oldtut/Positioning/Tutorial%2004.html) was already gigantic, and adding a seemingly random discussion about something that wouldn't be followed up on (the genuine uses for `noperspective` are few and far between) hurt the overall pacing of the work. It just didn't flow very well; it always felt kinda out-of-place.

The strengths of tutorial/example-focused documentation are that it's example-focused. The user sees code that they can download and run themselves. They get to poke at it to see what happens. And so forth.

The weaknesses of it are:

- They're generally no less impenetrable than references. Oh, there can be beginner focused tutorials/examples. But other than those, they will always assume some degree of familiarity with the subject matter. So beginners still need not apply
- Unlike references, they're usually not comprehensive. It's hard to provide a single example that *comprehensively* explores a subject. I'm more-or-less an expert in OpenGL, and I could never write a single, simple example that explores *everything* that `glTextureStorage2D` does.
- They can require a *lot* of boilerplate. Let's say I want to write documentation for how image load/store works. Well, I can't just do that; I have to contrive an example. I also have to create and possibly load images.
- They often have requirements other than code. OpenGL is a huge offender here, because to do anything beyond toy examples... you need data. You need meshes. You need textures. You probably don't want to write all your shaders inline, so you need files for them too. Web applications often have database needs. So even if you write an example, how do you deliver it? How do you deal with the large number of C and C++ build tools that exist? Is it just code on a website or is it something people can run?

#### Concept documentation

Unlike the others, the nomenclature for this is purely mine.

Concept documentation refers to documenting, not the individual behavior of a system's APIs, but the behavior of a system's *concepts*. That has been my general goal with the OpenGL Wiki: each page is about different concepts of OpenGL. Indeed, the only reason I imported the reference pages into the Wiki was because filing bug reports to get references fixed was (and still is) taking *way* too long.

Concept documentation fills a very important gap. Unlike reference documentation, it focuses on concepts within the system. Unlike example documentation, it can explore a concept *comprehensively*. My goal in writing, say, the OpenGL Wiki article on [Vertex Shaders](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Shader) is to explain *everything* about them. Every option is presented, either directly in text or with a link to more details.

It is also a very *searchable* form of documentation. Not the OpenGL Wiki, but that's more due to MediaWiki's search being crap. People tend to think in terms of concepts rather than API functions that they may not know exist. People may not be able to tell the difference between `glTextureStorage2D` and `glTextureParameter`, but they've heard the word "mipmap" before. So even just the headings and subheading will get quite a few hits in search engines, let alone the content.

Conceptual documentation is often bundled with reference documentation. In Doxygen parlance, these would be written as either [Pages](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/commands.html#cmdpage) or [Module/Group](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/grouping.html) documentation. The Direct3D documentation has a reference section and a conceptual section, though the concepts tend to be more of an overview.

The weaknesses of this documentation form are:

- It can involve a lot of text duplication, in the desire to be comprehensive. I ran into this a lot in my work on the OpenGL wiki. I try to use MediaWiki templates and other magic to reduce actual textual duplication where possible. For example, the Vertex Shader page has a section that [describes the built-in inputs to the VS](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Shader#Other_inputs). But there is also a page that describes [all of the built-in variables](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Built-in_Variable_%28GLSL%29) for each shader stage. Both pages are separate concepts, but share some data. So I made a sub-page and simply included it into both pages.
- It's hard to know where to *start* when you want to read through concept documentation. Concepts often refer to one another, but there's no logical beginning point. I've tried several times to come up with a starting point for the OpenGL Wiki, but as you can see from the main page, the best I've been able to accomplish is a [giant list of links](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Main_Page).
- Even if you explain everything about one concept, you still haven't necessarily explain how they all fit together. Example/tutorial documentation is better at assembling the pieces.

#### Learning materials

These are tools you're meant to read from beginning to end. You're expected to know more or less nothing when you start.

These are typically books, written by actual authors.

### On Documentation.SO

I submit that, while each form has its flaws, every form is *important*. There is a time and place for each form of documentation.

But Stack Overflow is different. SO is collaborative. So, which documentation forms fit into that collaborative ideal the best?

#### Reference documentation

This fits quite well. Once thing about collaboration is that it has to effectively work with drive-by users. Someone who isn't really invested in helping, but maybe they have a few minutes and wants to drop something off.

Reference docs make that happen. There is very loose coupling between different reference pages, so they can get filled in quite quickly. The C++ reference site is probably an excellent example of this. 3 years ago, it was nothing. Now, it easily crushes cplusplus.com as the go-to site for standard C++.

It is also good when dealing with curation. That is, it makes it easy to accept changes, and then have those changes smoothed out by the much smaller number of primary editors of the site.

#### Tutorial/Example documentation

On the one hand, a person can write an entire example and document it by themselves. But on the other hand, editing someone else's examples become a problem.

You *will* get code style wars; mark my words. You will get people who absolutely cannot stand one particular indentation style or whatever, and they'll just go in and "fix" it. Or worse, you'll get lots of different coding styles across examples.

I think a bigger problem here though is the lack of comprehensiveness. And OpenGL makes for a good example of this.

How many OpenGL programmers can write an example of buffer object usage? Lots. How many can write an example of Image Load/Store usage? Far fewer.

Which means that you're going to get lots of examples of ways to do easy/trivial stuff, with very few examples of the harder things the API offers. You'll see plenty of examples for "my first texture", but far fewer for "projective texturing". What's worse is that you could get examples of shadow mapping without examples for projective texturing, even though projective texturing is *required* for many forms of shadow mapping.

I just don't think a tutorial repository is going to work collaboratively.

#### Concept documentation

I think this can work collaboratively. Wikipedia is a great example of concept-based documentation being created and edited collaboratively.

It also shows many of the potential pitfalls of it. Everyone wants to put their own stuff in, but nobody wants to organize it. You'll never be quite sure that it's truly comprehensive. And so forth.

#### Learning materials

Good God, no!

Again, leveraging my authority on the subject, I would say that building learning materials by collaboration is a doomed proposition. A good work for learning requires *planning* and careful consideration of what new users do not know. At the very least, a good learning work requires someone coming up with an outline.

See, the best learning books introduce ideas, then build on them more and more. With each step, they add new concepts, but they are built upon previous ones.

I structured my "tutorial" series very carefully in this regard. Or at least, I tried to. Each tutorial tried to use functionality that was introduced in the previous one, and thereby reinforce lessons learned before.

That's not something you can do collaboratively, among a group of equals. That's something that 1-3 people need to sit down and actually accomplish.

### Required technology

Making good documentation in HTML is easy. Well, it's possible. Making good documentation in not-HTML... that's a bit harder. Each documentation form has its own needs as far as formatting, and not all of them are available in Markdown.

#### Reference documentation

Reference docs are centered around API functions. Even class-based docs like JavaDoc or Doxygen are still centered around the documentation of each function. So there must be some way of formatting function signatures.

Of course, every language has its own needs for function documentation. That's going to be a nightmare to work out in terms of formatting. DocBook makes a good show of it in its `funcsynopsis` type, but even that is focused on languages that look like C.

Not to mention, functions are often aggregated into classes or just conceptual groups. Not only does this need to be a part of any reference documentation scheme, it has to be able to import part of the function's documentation. This allows Doxygen/JavaDoc-style brief documentation that gives a quick summary of the function.

There has to be some facility for dealing with overloads. This is the absolute *bane* of Doxygen; having to find a way to document 5 functions that all have the same name, but different parameters. It wants to make them 5 separate entries, but no human being actually likes that. If Documentation.SO wants to handle reference docs, there *must* be a solution for this.

I guess my point is that formatting is really important for this, and not having it isn't optional.

#### Tutorial/Example documentation

The formatting needs here are actually quite minimal. The reason being that we already have more or less what we need: the ability to write blocks of code in a specific language.

Probably the biggest need that isn't available is some form of callouts. That is, the ability to label specific locations in a code block, and later refer to them in your text.

There's also the issue of breaking examples up. For longer examples, you will often want to present part of the example, talk about it, then present another few lines, talk about that, etc. So... how do you download the whole thing? Does there have to be code duplication, where the user writes the code into markdown and into some source file?

#### Concept documentation

There are fewer technology needs here, but there are still some needs.

First, as I experienced on the OpenGL wiki, inclusion is *crucial*. Being able to include a page in another page makes the whole thing far more legible. There are many articles on the wiki that, if you turned the inclusions off, would become a lot less easy to read. Even if you made the inclusions links, you still have to follow those links to get the whole story. Inclusion makes it easy to avoid duplication and repetition.

Also, linking needs finer granularity than "article". Section linking is crucial. At the same time, it's important to be able to turn a section into an article if it's become too big. MediaWiki's ability to make redirection pages helps here. You don't link to sections directly; instead you use redirects to go to needed sections. I imagine that they could come up with other solutions, but there does need to be some solution.

Oh, and the ability to manipulate the wiki with external tools is also important. Again, I speak from experience. I have made many "bots" for the OpenGL wiki, and the ability to rename pages alone made leaning some small bit of C# worthwhile.

Also a tool for automatically building a glossary would not go unused.

#### Learning materials

Who cares; we shouldn't be trying to do that anyway.

### The take-home point

Documentation is hard. Specific kinds of documentation exist. Some can be built collaboratively, and others cannot. And they all have technology needs that Stack Exchange doesn't provide yet.

Comment: "There's also the issue of breaking examples up. For longer examples, you will often want to present part of the example, talk about it, then present another few lines, talk about that, etc. So... how do you download the whole thing? Does there have to be code duplication, where the user writes the code into markdown and into some source file?" -- Anybody with thoughts on how to do that, please weigh in on [this tech-writing question on Writers](http://writers.stackexchange.com/q/5139/1993).

Answer (score 29):

I completely resonate with [stijn](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/247702/stijn)'s point on fragmentation.

I can infer from the "**How would adding Documentation to Stack Overflow improve Documentation?**" section that this project is driven by two main goals:

- Questions too broad for SO should be answered somewhere.
- A community-driven documentation repository should be available to anyone, featuring what's best, filling the gap in lacking official documentation and (my take) even challenging vendors to compete by improving their own docs.

I'm omitting the rest of the points listed in the question on purpose:

- Point 3 is about duplicate questions and providing better docs won't fix a thing in my opinion. If a user is too lazy to search, they are too lazy to search. Rewarding them with spoon-fed solutions doesn't help anyone.
- Point 4 is very narrowly pointing out Javadocs use an ancient format. In my opinion, that works albeit ugly - in fact the ugliness helps focus on content, so Javadocs are ultimately what you make of them. But all in all, I think that's a minor point.

**Conclusion**

What if, instead, there was a SO **tutorials** site?

The idea being, instead of competing with existing documentation (bad as it may be), the contributor provides community-verified tutorials to get people started with a relatively narrow scope for each topic, whereas the requestor asks for a tutorial on a specific scope.

That would help with the broad questions as long as they have any practical scope, and could grow into a network of related tutorials by SO's aggregation algorithms.

Then again, I might have omitted something crucial...

Comment: I think a tutorials site would be a great idea, and wouldn't have to be competing with, duplicating, or fragmenting the official documentation.

Comment: Check out [learnopengl hello window](http://learnopengl.com/#!Getting-started/Hello-Window), it contains tutorial, documentation, example, all in one (Note: when you hover the mouse on a function it brings up a box of documentation and example). Some inspiration could be taken from that.

Comment: A much better idea - its sure beats the "cargo cult of copy and paste" that an examples site would create that conflicts with official API documentation. This would be more geared towards understanding a product or feature as a whole before heading to the official references.

Answer (score 29):

I think this generally sounds like a good idea. php.net does a cut-down version of this, where there is commentary plopped in on the bottom of the documentation pages. The commentary is kind of free-flowing (and upvoted/downvoted), but the documentation is still owned by the project owner.

## 1) It must be opt-in, *not* opt-out

Some people control their own technology and documentation and don't want a community-run documentation site. Those wishes must be respected. You don't want to be like getsatisfaction.com was, a while back.

## 2) Handle 'ownership'

What if you deliberately choose not to document something because you're going to be phasing it out, or you know it's going to change? And then someone comes along and is 'helpful' and documents how it works *today* - and thus sends everyone careening towards a dead-end? Maybe you need an 'owner' who gets some kind of infinite voting reputation - maybe hook it into [GitHub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub) and let the project owners do that? "[Benevolent Dictatorships](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benevolent_dictator_for_life)" are especially common in the open source community.

## 3) Versions are critical

When you're documenting how something works in version x.y, it may be completely different or nonexistent in y.z.

## 4) Hybrid strategies?

Is there a way to let the project owner/product owner host the documentation, and then put Stack Overflow controls on/around it (A la [Discourse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discourse_%28software%29) or something like that) - but still allowing the project owner to control those changes? Will there be a way for someone to decide to 'import' their documentation back into this new thing? A way to export out?

Comment: :+1: For Hybrid strategies. Official documentation has a number of advantages that this system can't match, and it'd be great to be able to get the best of both worlds.

Comment: 1) opt-in/out: that's interesting and we'll have to think about it.  My first thought is, do you want to opt out of people asking questions about your thing on SO? but it's not exactly the same thing. 2) I think the case you point out here is very limited in practice, if it existed and people used it, it should be documented, once better thing is here, old page should direct to new way to success 3) along the same lines as #2, 4) if a project owner blesses it, it's possible we might allow it as long as it's up the rest of our standards, export will be data dump as with the rest of the network

Comment: I absolutely disagree with the opt in/ out. But the hybrid strategies is a very good idea

Comment: Long term all this stuff will be in our API, so anybody could re-host live.  The trick is, an API needs to be stable... and we'll be constantly breaking things as we respond to feedback.  So... eventually hybrid is a thing, no matter what; for initial launch?  I'm not sure it's possible.

Comment: @NickLarsen Sometimes people find methods and classes that were intentionally left out of the documentation because they were intended for internal use or weren't guaranteed to be supported in future versions, and then suddenly when people are using them they have to be left in for backwards-compatibility (see the Windows API for an example).  Are there any provisions that would allow the project owners to say "don't use this method" or "don't rely on this behavior because it's not guaranteed to remain" even before the new version is ready for release?

Comment: Check out the history behind "getsatisfaction.com" - people could open up 'comment boards' and it looked like it was an official forum, and then they (getsatisfaction) would send emails to the project owner saying, "Hey, look at all these unanswered questions!" - it looked like extortion.

If I have my crappy documentation, but that's the official documentation, I don't want your thing to make stealth documentation on _top_ of it. That's confusing and awful. And feels, also, like "extortion."

Knowing you guys, what you make will be good enough to make people switch without forcing their hand.

Comment: @Troyen if something made it out in the wild for any amount of time and people used it for whatever reason then it's probably best to say something about it in the docs, but it seems totally fine to mark it as deprecated or obsolete as appropriate.  There will mechanisms for those cases.

Comment: I don't think 'opt in' is a good idea. Because I think the people who _should_ be 'opting in' are also the ones that won't, simply because of the nature of the problem.

Comment: Here's my "nightmare scenario:" You have a project. You make a shiny documentation site for it. You try to make solid documentation. Somebody else (someone being "helpful"? Someone who dislikes your doco for some reason?) sets up a "StackUnderflow" documentation site (or whatever it's called), and puts some shoddy documentation on it. Because of SO's spectacular Google-juice, it gets ranked higher. People yell at you about your bad documentation. You don't want to use StackUnderflow. But too bad. You get a bad reputation for having shitty documentation. And none of it is your fault.

Comment: @Uberbrady I kind of agree with what you said and it really makes me think point 1 and 2 would be very important. I'm trying to drive traffic to my own projects for example and might not want SO overshadowing me with their "Google-juice". Plus, personally some of my projects have "methods and classes that were intentionally left out of the documentation because they were intended for internal use or weren't guaranteed to be supported in future" and don't want to deal with "helpful" people pointing those things out.

Answer (score 28):

As a developer on an open source project, I have mixed feelings about this idea. I'm sure there are many places where it could be useful - some projects just don't care about documentation. But the issue is that I don't want to see documentation for our project on SO.

Our code is on GitHub, along with all of the documentation. Anyone can come along and submit an edit to the official docs, and while it might not be quite as intuitive as a platform which is designed solely for creating docs, it's not too difficult with GitHub's inline editing and ReStructuredText support. Plus, the edits get to appear in the official documentation. If that's too much for someone, or it's more of an example than actual documentation, we also have the GitHub wiki open to submissions.

I also have a decent amount of rep in the associated tag here on SO. But I won't write any docs on SO. I won't approve any submissions by users who do not have enough tag rep and need to use the suggested edits platform (because if it's worthwhile, I want that added to the official documentation instead).

The permissive CC BY-SA license would make it possible for us to directly copy the submissions on SO documentation and incorporate them in our official documentation. But that just furthers the fragmentation issue, and creates more work than if the improvements were submitted directly to our organization in the first place.

But I do agree with the sentiment. There are many times that I have turned to SO, wikis, and other resources because the official documentation for something was so sparse.

## Opt Out

I think this is likely the best approach, if the documentation site takes off. Allow users with high rep in a tag to opt the tag out of the documentation site, and provide links to places to submit official documentation. Alternatively, allow someone who can prove they are with the project in question (i.e. listed on the web site, and confirmed via the email on the site) to opt the tag out. This allows projects like ours to still receive community-submitted documentation, without another site competing to do so, and maybe even find some new contributors who may not have thought about submitting the improvements directly. But it also means that organizations which do not keep the documentation up to date, and are not open to community submissions to the official docs, would get extra community coverage here.

Comment: I think this is really worth consideration. At the same time, I would be concerned about letting people connected with a project be the final point of decision on whether documentation can exist here or not. If a project stops having good/up-to-date official documentation, but the project owner won't allow it here, then it's unhelpful for developers who use that project and ultimately unhelpful for the project.

Comment: It's been pointed out elsewhere that documentation won't be for all tags, so it might not affect small projects, anyway. And maybe the state of the documentation elsewhere could be taken into consideration when it's being decided whether documentation should be switched on here for a tag?

Comment: @JoDouglass I agree with that concern. That's why I like particularly the idea of the opt out being determined by high tag rep users, as these are people who do care about SO and tend to help out here, so they're less likely to opt out for malicious (or less than honorable) reasons.

Comment: Agreed - I definitely prefer that to the project owners having the final say. For small projects - if they even qualify to have documentation switched on here - I would think that if they already have successful collaborative documentation then there's a good chance that high rep users here will already know about/contribute to/use it. It might even encourage the teams behind them to be active here so they can have a say!

Comment: Important remarks. Too few of the answers here are from the perspective of open-source developers.

Comment: It would be interesting to somehow give moderator status to project-owners.

Comment: @JoDouglass - I'm amused that you and Ryan think a developer would have 'malicious' reasons to opt out here. By 'malicious' I assume you mean they won't be sufficiently humbled by SO's (ridiculous) attitudes towards information duplication and (unhealthy) obsession with rules and procedures. It's alsmost like you're aware already that directing someone to documentation that's been annotated by 500 people arguing over the wording of the first sentence might not be totally awesome.

Comment: @DerfSkren Malicious was Ryan's word. My main worry is inactive projects which have opted out at some past in the past, or projects which started out well documented but have since become out of date. Whatever your complaints are about SO, I'd rather have some documentation than none.

Comment: @DerfSkren If you're that unimpressed by SO, then maybe you should find a different platform on which to rant.

Comment: @RyanP That was part of the point I was making. Searching in Google these days for programming help seems to yield nothing but StackOverflow results, many of which are simply restating (or worse simply linking to) parts of existing manuals or specs. Then there's the arguments. The point system that pays 10 credits to someone for taking "Thanks" off the end of your post. The people who claim every new post is a dupe in 10 seconds. Yes I do find SO annoying but I seem to end up here all the time. So yeah, call it a rant if you want but I for one will be extremely disappointed if SO does manuals.

Answer (score 27):

This seems like a good opportunity for collaboration -- some developers are great at coming up with examples but have trouble with (a) paring those down to the important parts and (b) writing the explanations that ought to go with them.  In this model, a less-experienced developer (who might not have written the example at all) could take examples written by others and build out better doc.  That seems worth experimenting with.

This means we'll need to award rep at the section level, not just at the whole-topic level.  Contributing a usable example should earn rep.  Writing a good explanation should earn rep.  These might be two different people.

Comment: Examples and topics will award rep separately in our current rep model.  We've decided not to post it now because we'd like to see how people actually use the product before we make any crazy decisions that affect rep.

Answer (score 24):

An issue I see with this is that while Stack Overflow Docs may become the de-facto source for documentation, it *can't* be the authoritative source if official documentation exists. In some cases, like actual standards documents, the documentation is correct by definition: if ISO publishes a new Technical Corrigendum to the C standard that contradicts what's written on Stack Overflow, the Stack Overflow documentation instantly become incorrect, no matter how well written.

Even if the official documentation is considered non-normative, you still potentially can end up with situations where Stack Overflow documents the way a system actually works, but contradicts the official documentation. It could well be that the official documentation is *still* correct and there's a bug in the system. The best course of action in such cases is to contact the author and inform them of the inconsistency so they can deal with it, not to pick one of the inconsistent options and document that. If Stack Overflow becomes the de-facto source for documentation, it may create situations in which the bug can't be removed without confusing everyone who uses the Stack Overflow documentation.

Normal Stack Overflow works fine, since we can answer questions about a specific scenario that isn't mentioned in the documentation, and then reference the document (or set of documents) that relate to the problem.  It's more or less explicit that the answers are subordinate to the formal documentation.

That said, I do think there is room here to supplement the official documentation in a way that the existing Stack Overflow does not. If Stack Overflow Docs concentrates on examples of common uses (carefully edited so as to not become exhaustive to the point of uselessness), this would help address a weakness of much of the existing documentation.

Several others have mentioned tutorials; I think that would be excellent, especially if said tutorials referenced the relevant parts of the official documentation in each section. Such references, coupled with the existing voting and commenting system, could help keep the tutorials and examples listed here at a higher level of accuracy than the ones that are basically "This is what I was told when I first learned how to use it, and I never questioned it".

So in summary, I think that creating a set of well-written, reliably-accurate examples and tutorials would greatly benefit the overall level of online documentation without running into the fragmentation issues that duplicating the documentation itself, since there's a clear division of purpose: Stack Overflow Docs is an introduction; the official documentation is the reference manual.

Comment: I think MDN provides a useful example here... It's the official docs for mozilla, but not the official docs for ECMAScript, HTML, etc... Much less any platform other than Mozilla's. Yet, it is frequently the best reference for ALL of these. Wouldn't it be *nice* if there was such a thing for C? For Java? For SQL...?

Comment: Mozilla can avoid a lot of the issues I mentioned by virtue of being a major implementation of those standards.  An equivalent situation would be if gcc had documentation of the C dialect it implements (which it does, although in that case, it doesn't repeat the standard but rather defines the implementation-specified aspects and gcc extensions).   Both are the authoritative documentation for *that implementation*.  Hopefully they also sync up well with the documentation for the standard, since if even the docs don't agree with the standard, I'd be skeptical of the implementation itself.

Comment: A similar case would be man pages for standard libraries on Linux systems.  They frequently contain GNU libc or POSIX extensions.  If you're writing for those specific platforms, those man pages are authoritative.  If you're developing fully portable code, the ISO docs are.  Stack Overflow doesn't contain an implementation for which it can be the authoritative implementation, so all it can do is repeat information from the existing docs, possibly introducing errors or as it goes, or just getting out of date as the real specification/implementations change.

Comment: I should've provided an example; [here's an arbitrary page on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius): note that it documents the syntax and behavior, links to the standard, documents deviations from the standard for various Mozilla software, *documents support for other major browsers, **documents deviations from the standards for those browsers...*** IOW, it's a one-stop shop: if I'm using that property, I wanna read MDN *even if I don't particularly care about targeting Mozilla browsers!*

Comment: The equivalent would be reading GCC's docs when using Microsoft's compiler, just because they do a better job of documenting the behavior than MSDN. *That's* why I say use MDN as an example here... They do it right. All documentation should be like MDN. But of course, it isn't; generally you're silly-lucky if a vendor even documents their own product well; expecting them to document how they deviate from the standard (if one exists) is heaven, expecting notes on deviations from other vendors is... What's too good for heaven?

Answer (score 22):

I have a few thoughts:

**Name.** A lot of answers are hung up on the use of "documentation," but it seems to me that the humbler name of "wiki" fits better and will ruffle fewer feathers.

**Scope.** Along the same lines: to me, it looks like "topics" can cover anything worth documenting (e.g., "how to collapse matrix columns in R"), not just separate docs for each and every function ("colSums", "colMeans" and more). However, the OP [can be read different ways on this point](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303865/warlords-of-documentation-a-proposed-expansion-of-stack-overflow?answertab=votes#comment240379_303865).

If it's just function documentation, it will truly be useless for R, where the per-function documentation is excellent, but the function names are all over the map, making it hard to identify the set of tools that can do the job.

**Structure.** I agree with @IVlad that it would be nice to have some structure. I'd suggest:

- *Language.* Each language is a silo, totally split off from the others.
- *Area.* Within each silo, the gold-badgers manage a small set of top-level tags that can be applied to topics. (For R: "estimation", "visualization of data", "reshaping data", "interface", etc.) Tags are voted on by gold-badgers, and are automatically deleted after accruing enough downvotes (and maybe blacklisted from re-proposal for a month).

I think (1) piggybacking on SO tags would be forcing a square peg through a round hole; and (2) any fancier hierarchical structure would just lead to scuffles, and later, apathy. **Edit:** Based on @KevinMontrose's comment on other programming languages (below), it sounds like even this simple hierarchy won't be possible, so we will be piggybacking. I suspect that tags designed for Q&A will not naturally extend to this new environment, though, and hope the idea of using a different structure will be revisited if this project takes off.

Comment: My only immediate positive thought relative to R was that it might be a nice place to expand on the Examples section in the existing specific R documentation pages, which can sometimes be pretty limited.

Comment: For scope - we're imaging most things allowed in existing docs would also be, basically anything that can fit in a single page.  Not just function/class/module level, but mini-tutorial (single page) and things like "Getting Started".

Comment: Structure is tricky, I prefer a 1-to-1 with tags (but requiring some census to create an area off of tag) because then we've got an easy way to "transfer" between Q&A.  Not so much moving text around, but reputation, badges, search, and linking all have clear relationships.  Language > area also breaks down around .NET (many languages, single area), Java (many languages, many areas), iOS (two languages, single area).

Comment: There are some tags I think 1-to-1 would be really bad for. Simply as an example, we have database, database-design, database-schema, data-modeling, and relational-database. There is bound to be overlap. We need a structure which ensures we don't have competing topics related to different tags, resulting in some tags being incomplete, or contradictory information between related tags. Maybe topics could be associated with multiple tags? Or both tags and the documentation area could reflect hierarchies?

Comment: (Continued from above.) For instance, if the .NET tag were set as the parent of C# and VB.NET, then going to the .NET documentation would display the topics associated with .NET itself, but with the ability to get to the C# and VB.ET specific documentation as subcategories. Going directly to the C# documentation would just take you straight to the main C# documentation page.

Comment: @JoDouglass something I could have been clearer about is that not all [tag]s will get documentation, there will be a "switch" (exact details TBD, maybe something Area 51-ish; maybe just a critical mass of Q&A). Things like [database-design] probably don't get docs, that content is better in DB-specific tags. I don't really think listing Topics is a terribly interesting feature, because there will be *so* many of them. Much more interesting is mining cross-links for relatedness, bubbling that up in search (and perhaps some navigation...) because the sets are much smaller.

Comment: @JoDouglass I think there's a meta-point here which is that "hierarchies are never perfect, and the way people navigate these imperfect hierarchies is through Google searches."  If this is true (and I really believe it is) then burning effort on hierarchies is something of a waste; we're best going with the simple things that have immediate use.

Comment: @KevinMontrose That's fair, but I hope an open mind is kept during beta and after go-live as feedback is received. I definitely click through tree views and the like in documentation elsewhere, but maybe I wouldn't if good quality "related topics" links were available. I am still concerned about information being duplicated (and potentially inconsistent) in multiple Topics.

Comment: @KevinMontrose As far as which tags get documentation - I hope it's not ultimately related to Q&A count. As I've said in a comment elsewhere, there are quiet tags which I suspect suffer from the fact that SO doesn't look like a good source of information for that tag, so people don't sign up and ask questions about them - documentation could drive usage. There are quiet tags that suffer from a high percentage of fairly similar "newbie" type questions which it'd be great to pre-empt with documentation. Completely get focusing on high activity tags first, though. Thanks for the replies!

Comment: @JoDouglass We'll have to triangulate on the rules, since we just don't know enough believe anything we say now will last.  I don't have my heart set on any particular approach, just a bunch of ideas for things that are worth exploring.  A hard Q&A count does have problems though, I agree.  What I'm imaging when a say "critical mass of Q&A" is some amalgamation of all Q&A activity along with a time window; so questions, answers, voting, # of users, total reputation, etc. within some period of time.

Comment: *Language. Each language is a silo, totally split off from the others.* I'm not sure if I agree here. What if we need to have some examples / documentation on how to wire different technologies together? Or in general for some integrational stuff. From my opinion, especially on this topic some good, well-funded examples would make sense as even with good official 'onboard' documentation for the single systems / silos, the wiring gets complicated pretty fast. Plus, this is a field where experience is very valuable. With silos, we could not benefit from that experience though SO user have it.

Answer (score 21):

YES!

Even the best documentation I've seen so far has its limits - they are either proprietary-built and therefore lack user contributions to keep them updated, or lack a committed user base. The most notable documentation sources I can recite will be MDN or jQuery API pages, but even those documentations doesn't help programmers efficiently - That is, to land, [optionally] understand the contract, [optionally] understand the implementation, [optionally] determine if it's the right method to use, and how to use it.

Several reasons I think the new Stack Overflow Documentation feature would help with this:

1. Narrow fields (Bungeecord Spigot, for example) which its official documentation is lacking can attract its users to SOD and therefore collaboratively build a wiki to help each other as well as the future readers.
2. Even fields that are big can benefit as well, as linking to Stack Overflow questions from Documentation would easily cover every bit of obscure behaviour and knowledge.
3. Usage examples demonstrates behaviour more concisely than text.

Comment: There are many more. php.net, cppreference.com, ... It's not like SO would be the first to discover that documentation could in principle be a community driven project.

Comment: "but even those documentations doesn't help programmers efficiently" -- The main purpose of documentation is being an authoritative reference on what some piece of software does. While it is a nice bonus when examples and other extra materials are effectively integrated into it, trying to cover all bases can lead to mission creep.

Comment: Please, please, don't call it SOD :)

Comment: @Trilarion I would not take php.net as an example of good documentation. There are a lot of bad things in it (even if by being a not bad developer you can avoid the trap)

Answer (score 20):

### ONE FORMAT

I have a dream, I dream of **ONE** format, just one format across different languages...visually and **meaningfully** one format please.

I am tired of wasting time on differences in the format.

(Or at least we can start by including documentation on HOW TO READ specific documentation)

Comment: Humorously, when I was doing research on this I came to *hate* every new format I ran into for documentation.  Like, 1/2 the world uses javadocs-style three frames; the other 1/2 invents weird combinations of columns and tree views.  It's so frustrating moving between different documentation sources.  I'm not trying to sell consistency as a win mostly because that assumes we take over a lot of documentation, which is not a given; but if we get there it's a big win for everyone.

Comment: I should add that we have considered the case where the styling is the point of the documentation, in particular for css frameworks like bootstrap.  It's not cut and dry across the board, for a large part of the documentation world, consistent presentation is a huge win.

Comment: @NickLarsen I totally agree about the styling but want to remark the *meaningfully one format*. It's a tougher task to harmonize e.g. how and where optional arguments (to a function) should be listed across Python and Java. Let's not talk about man pages...

Comment: Beware of https://xkcd.com/927/ though, which is where all of the previous **ONE FORMAT** dreams have ended up.

Comment: @amalloy That's a good one! Well, I hope that at least we can have *a* reference in one place on how to read all those formats :)

Comment: @KevinMontrose one format is a great thing. If we are about style of visual representation then it will be great to have ability to select themes (and to modify or build own themes) in profile settings. In perfection we should have the ability to change view of each language or tool documentation representation. It would be the great feature.

Comment: @KevinMontrose on other hand, one format, if it means terminology is hardly achievable, because every language can put different meaning to the same terminology. In this case, we should be able see all the meanings of concrete word in different languages(platforms,systems,tools and etc). And more over, terminology must be the vital part the beginning of each documentation

Answer (score 19):

Some thoughts, mostly related to the tags I am most active in, but I think they are fairly generic.

I think the documentation format should have more structure than what is currently presented. Otherwise, it's not much better than the "Share your knowledge - Q&A style" option where you answer your own question immediately.

For example, take the tags `algorithm`, `data-structures` and any programming language. You can have algorithms in pseudocode, you can rarely fully separate the algorithm from the data structure, and then you'll also have implementations in each language.

In this case, and probably others, there should be a way to link documentations. If you read the documentation for a Binary Search Tree for example, I think you should only read about it in pseudocode initially, but have links to implementations in various languages that users have contributed. Something like "Available implementations (according to your tags / according to popularity): ... | Browse all".

So I would add more structure, not just "Examples" and "Remarks". Perhaps:

- **Topic:** the topic documented, for example: "C++ iterators", "C# Lists" etc.
- **Parent topic:** make the documentation hierarchical, so it reads like a book and it is easier to find stuff if you're not exactly sure about keywords. Have a table of contents. For example, "C# Lists" might have "C# Containers" as a parent topic.
- **Child topics:** "C# Containers" can also talk about dictionaries, hashsets etc. This should all be displayed clearly somewhere, perhaps at the bottom, so it doesn't obscure the gist of the documentation.
- **Related topics:**, or **Suggested topics for you:**, or both. I'm thinking something dynamic. If I'm very active in the C++ tag and I'm reading about Python lambdas, suggest that I give feedback about the C++ counterpart. If I'm only so-so active in C++, suggest that I might find the C++ documentation for lambdas useful as well. What I mentioned at the beginning about algorithms and programming languages can also go here: "BST in Python" should not be a subtopic of "BST" or of "Datastructures in Python". I would introduce entities called "Proofs of concepts", where a certain concept is demonstrated by a minimal working example. This would be separate from examples, in that you would need to provide a fully working program with the minimum requirements for running it. In an example, you would only provide snippets.

  For example, "Creating a database using Entity Framework Code First". This would be a proof of concept, and something separate. Entity framework can be talked about conceptually at first, and this linked to. Don't mix too much code with the theory: a little is fine, more can be posted in a separate place dedicated to runnable code.
- **Documentation body:** I would leave this free form mostly, not everything has syntax or performance. Have guides about what should go here, but leave it a huge textbox for people to enter the actual documentation in. The good content will eventually bubble up to the surface.
- **A way for good content to bubble up**. Make a staging area for people wanting to contribute to documentation. I should be able to comment on what currently exists for a topic, or even suggest something entirely new, not just edit it. What if two people come up with very good documentations, but quite different ones, for the same topic? Upvotes should decide which is the better one. I'm not sure how to approach this exactly, but maybe have some "verified" status for something that has been approved as the final form (which can still be edited, just not changed dramatically) and "Subject to change" for something that is still being debated.

Comment: Hierarchy is hard.  We've found this with tags, is the appropriate hierarchy for List; Containers > List, or Enumerables > List, or Enumerables > Containers > List, or Enumerable > Writable Containers > List, or ....  A flat hierarchy kills all debate.  Related Topics is definitely a thing we need though; I think cross-linking can serve as an adequate substitute for hierarchy, especially if we build with search in mind (something we did a poor job of with the original SO beta).

Comment: Documentation body is, I think, just Remarks with a different name.  It's free form, completely unstructured (unlike the other sections).  We entirely intend for people to able to *suggest* new Topics; we aren't going to restrict unprivileged users just to edits, though naturally someone will have to review their submissions.  We do intend for drafts of Topics (new or edited) to be sharable before submission for formal review.

Comment: [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Rosetta_Code) is a place that lists [such](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Binary_search) [alogoritms](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Tree_traversal), [even](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Binary_search#Forth) [in Forth](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Forth).

Comment: One of my questions is whether documentation can be done well without hierarchy. I would think the hierarchy would be very specific to each technology. And whether a community-driven environment can produce high quality, consistent hierarchies.

Answer (score 17):

Definitely don't do some kind of mass import of APIs, and produce a parallel documentation effort to what the official efforts are.  Moreover, don't do it on a different domain or subdomain...fragmenting the experience and make you feel like you've "left StackOverflow".

There is probably something that's "not that" which could succeed and get people more directly to relevant information if they're searching on an API name.  But...it's "not that".  It would be more like a tag wiki, where it emerges on demand for an API that is "notable" enough (as Wikipedians would say) to be able to have reasonable maintenance for quality.

The problem StackOverflow Q&A managed to address already had thriving proof that people *wanted to do the thing the site was to be for*.  Forums existed, and people would contribute to try and help each other.  It wasn't that the will to participate in Q&A was missing, they simply weren't organized (and the site that had become search-dominant for organizing was sketchy, so they were relatively easy to replace).

This effort faces a different situation: more-or-less-anonymous community-written documentation is not fun, and developers do not like doing it.  There are not huddled masses yearning to write more eloquent phrasings for what an API parameter is called, just looking for a place.  Many responses here have pointed out the steep cliff tag wikis already fall off of when going outside the Q&A sweet spot, and that should be (relatively) fun.  This goes further and is not.

...aaand StackOverflow's core functions have not seen hardly any major feature updates *for years*.  This despite countless feature-requests with upvotes.  As others have pointed out the site is [not doing well "meme-wise" for being a place where the personalities in control are trusted](https://medium.com/@johnslegers/the-decline-of-stack-overflow-7cb69faa575d).  So yet-another-new-site before keeping house on the main one's problems with [simple proposals](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265671/pre-flight-screening-checklist-for-first-early-posts-adaptively-pick-three-item) seems misguided to me.

Comment: "more-or-less-anonymous community-written documentation is not fun, and developers do not like doing it" And yet, there are many examples of community-written documentation that *works*. [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/) being one of the major ones. So I disagree with the idea that people don't want to write such documentation. I think that *many* people don't, but some people do and they haven't had a place for that. Also, just because a "simple proposal" gets upvotes does not mean it should be done.

Answer (score 16):

Beside the concerns named by others, note that documentation is always bound to a certain release version of software. If a version is released, the documentation is supposed to be available immediately with the release, meaning it is written during the development cycle, before the release. Since only the developers understand the software or a new feature *before* the release, usually developers are the authors of documentation, which makes sense, doesn't it?

Having this you *can* only duplicate or improve documentation. Duplication makes no sense; I hope this is clear. Even the license of most products wouldn't allow this. If you want to improve the documentation, you are already free to support the development teams in various ways: Some allow to comment below the documentation pages, some are wiki-style, but at least every open source software project allows submittting patches. (Which were happily appreciated, in all situations where I submitted such patches.)

---

Another thing. Over the years a large amount of small (or larger) blogs have created nice documentation and explanations either behind the scope of the official documentation or in order to explain features that the official documentation missed to explain properly. Or simply, with different words. I like to enter 30 to 100 blog pages a day while searching for information. That's an Internet culture which I would like to see surviving.

Comment: There's plenty of stuff that's stable but that falls through the cracks of even decent official docs. [My most highly voted answer on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6120990) (which is far from being my favorite: FGITW, anyone?) is basically documentation of something that hasn't changed in more than 15 years, and apparently it's something that a fair number of people have been looking for and haven't found in Apple's reference material. My [next most highly voted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12357955/) is similar, although the comments below it are amusing in this context.

Comment: Have you tried to improve the official documentation? There were two times when I entered such a situation - an undocumented feature - when answering a question on SO. I've answered and created a bug request (both times PHP). Both bug requests had been accepted and had been fixed.

Comment: It's a fair question, but the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/allKeysForObject:) says substantially the same thing as my answer. To improve it would only be to make it more searchable, and I don't believe that I have any ability to do that as an outsider.

Comment: @JoshCaswell *I don't believe that I have any ability to do that as an outsider.* You can! :) Believe me, mostly such requests are highly appreciated (Add a link to your answer on SO, this makes the problem more clear).

Comment: @JoshCaswell There is a feedback button on the page. I guess it is made for that purpose. ;)

Comment: "I like to enter 30 to 100 blog pages a day while searching for information. That's an internet culture which I would like to see surviving." -- This wish is not just a quaint personal preference; your final paragraph makes a very important point. There are many ways one can write about software: API references, examples, tutorials, books, opinion pieces, polemics... Believing that any site can become become a satisfying one-stop shop for all information about software would be an illusion.

Comment: Apple doc improvement suggestions/requests go through [their bug reporter](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/). It's unclear to me how "you need to improve your Google juice" is a constructive, actionable suggestion.

Comment: @duplode Yes, that are my concerns too. And, thinking it to an end, I'm afraid of it.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I still think it should be possible to report that issue - if you really want it. However, is a single error on a single documentation page a reason for a takeover of all technical documentation?

Comment: @hek2mgl for me the reason to make such a platform for documentation, at least, is projects that has no such at all ([example phpdbg](http://phpdbg.com/docs) and many more open source projects which have no resources for that), and general position of developers is that you can see all you need just in source code (hopefully it's open source)

Comment: @hek2mgl _If a version is released, the documentation is supposed to be available immediately with the release._ It's not necessarily true, because of not all developers will suddenly update to the latest version, because they already start there projects on a stable version, and update is always can be dangerous on working projects.

Comment: @hek2mgl _Since only the developers understand the software or a new feature before the release, usually developers are the authors of documentation, which makes sense, doesn't it?_ Not always. If it's open source, anyone can understand, and more over, before release, there is almost always beta, and while beta you can make documentation.

Comment: @Mikl Why do you need Stackoverflow to improve the documentation of `phpdbg`? I mean you can help to improve the documentation directly on `phpdebug.com`. Have you tried that? Have you asked `krakjoe` (the author) what he thinks about that? Are you even expert enough to improve the documentation? I don't take your remaining concerns seriously, sorry I can't.

Comment: @hek2mgl As i have mentioned in other comment in this question, the one of the main problem which leads to lack of documentation is that it's really to much efforts it will take from me to contribute to it. This is so called high level of entrance or some sort of barrier, which stops the most part of people to contribute things whey realy can to with no pain (if it will be as easy as writing an answer or comment on SO).

Comment: @Mikl I don't think that the entrance level of contributing to open source projects, especially their documentation, is that high. Have you tried it? If you still feel that you are not on that level already, then hey!, accept it and improve your skills. Also please note, that if you don't understand documentation, this is mostly being the case because your background isn't funded enough. You should have some patience, enlightenment needs some time. Btw, you can kindly ask about phpdbg in the PHP chat room. The author and other contributors are frequently active there.

Comment: @hek2mgl it's certainly my mistake, i miss used the term of entrance level in wrong place :) My point was that if we have easy way of doing docs it will be good, and much more people can be able to contribute. I see no reason for making it more complicated as it can be. For me contacting with the dev is to complicated thing to overcome :) It's not about my level of knowledge though. I have contribute a little to phpdbg docs by answering questions here on SO. And i'd love to contribute more if it will be more options here.

Answer (score 15):

I worry about the same thing as [duplode](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303871/625403) does. One example that I imagine SO's documentation mirroring is "clojuredocs": it's an unofficial community-edited documentation site for clojure, but has an official-sounding domain name and is linked to often enough that new users often think it is the official documentation. Some of the examples there are okay, but mostly they are not great or well-explained. Often they are in fact wrong in some way.

I speculate that this is because the users who most urgently feel that more documentation is needed for function `f` are those who were trying to use `f` and couldn't find enough documentation. They find some mediocre documentation somewhere, cobble together something that addresses their use case, and now that they have a hazy idea of what `f` does, they want to contribute an example of how to use it. This is all very noble, but the problem is they don't really understand the function yet and are likely to mis-explain it or choose a bad example; meanwhile the folks who understand a function well enough to document it are mostly unaware that documentation is insufficient.

Maybe the proposed "request for topic" system avoids this, but on the whole I am concerned that poor documentation would flourish on a user-edited documentation site.

Comment: That's why examples should piggy-back on SO. A question of "how do I do this" attracts knowledgable answers. Then, you have fewer cases of well-meaning noobs writing examples.

Answer (score 14):

I remember how a project of mine came to an abrupt halt because of the missing documentation pages in the tools website. I struggled around for weeks trying to find out proper information regarding the tool, but I failed. In the end I had to change the whole model, and use some other tool, even though the new one fitted my project in a much better way.

My answer would be: **It's a great idea**. But my concern is, there are a lot of developers who are really good at writing code, but suck at producing documentation (including me). So, there might be fewer number of contributors comparatively. But all in all, it's a good idea. It's going to make the life of many developers easy.

Comment: `there are a lot of developers who are really good at writing code, but suck at producing documentation` I think part of the value of this feature is that the people writing the documentation don't need to be the same people writing the code.

Comment: @DavidRobinson I was going to say: There are a lot of developers who are really good at writing documentation, but suck at writing code!

Comment: @DavidRobinson Ya, but people who write the code, would be the best candidate for writing the documentation. And, what i was pointing at, the number of contributors will not be even with the number of developers.

Comment: @TomMedley I dunno if they should be called developers or not. I may be being a little to harsh, but it is like people who write the statistics for a newly developed car model being called automobile engineer.

Comment: @haris people who write the code are also good candidates for answering questions about its use- and yet Stack Overflow has proven that others can answer those questions as well. And would you say "People who answer SO questions are not real developers, because they didn't write the programming languages they're answering about"?

Comment: @DavidRobinson are there people answering questions about languages that they have not written code in?? o_0

Comment: @haris Not that they haven't written code *in*: languages that they didn't *invent* (Jon Skeet didn't invent C#). Similarly, people writing documentation about a library, API or package would typically be people that had used the library, possibly very extensively. Would you say that only Guido van Rossum should be allowed to answer Python questions on SO? Then why should he be the only person allowed to write documentation for it?

Comment: @DavidRobinson Ok, i understand what you are pointing at. Definitely people will be able to write good documentation for code that is written by others. Thats true.

Answer (score 14):

I support the creation of an online resource like this. What I don't currently understand is how this is meant to integrate with any Stack Exchange site, especially the ones that aren't Stack Overflow. In fact, I don't understand why the proposal is to make this part of the Stack Exchange network at all, rather than some totally separate project like [Discourse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discourse_%28software%29).

We already have blogs on every Stack Exchange site, yet most sites don't do anything with them. How do we know this feature won't also be widely underused? The fact that it's called "Documentation" implies it has no intended use cases outside of highly technical sites like Stack Overflow, so even other sites like Seasoned Advice which have an obvious potential use for it (cooking recipes) may fail to use it.

The implication that the beta is Stack Overflow-only tells me that it probably will be as underused as the blog (except on Stack Overflow). Unless this is meant to be for Stack Overflow only and never get rolled out to other sites (which isn't clear to me from this post), we should really have a non-technical site in the beta as well to prove whether or not this feature as currently designed makes sense outside of Stack Overflow.

Comment: Yeah, I get the sense that "documentation" is a bad name for what they're proposing. It could just be called a wiki with some very particular rules.

Comment: I think this is designed specifically for Stack Overflow, similar to code Snippets. It may never be activated on any other Stack Exchange sites other than the localized Stack Overflow sites.

Comment: I don't know... [Graphic Design](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) might want some documentation for Photoshop, Lightroom, Illustrator, In-Design, etc. It could be applicable across some sites if it's not limited to _API_ documentation.

Comment: @GregBray it can be activated on any site which needs some examples (snippets, tutorials, guides, howtos, patterns, use cases, algorithms, best practices, practical advices, tips and secrets for andvanced, overview, comparisons and test)

Comment: I doubt this will roll out to all sites; I had the impression it would be it's own SE site - perhaps `DocsOverflow`? `DocExchange`?

Answer (score 14):

## How to reduce fragmentation, duplication, and copyright issues:

### SO-docs should be a 'tool' and not a website

Or at least more than "just a website", as that inherently raises concerns of fragmentation and duplicated effort, as others have mentioned. This stems primarily from being on a *different domain/page* for some part of the documentation which was created by a community, versus the official stuff, which may be good in some places (requiring no community additions) and bad in others.

### How about a browser-extension to make this all a bit more seamless?

Showing supplementary docs *on-page* or at least *linking* to SO-community documentation on sites which don't natively offer editing or commenting would address the issue of fragmentation on docs such as jQuery and MSDN wherein there are no on-site tools for contributing information on the pages which need to be supplemented.

Having a way client-side to get access to additional help based off of the current URL would be a wonderful thing to have!

### Contextually linking or inlining community contributions would solve fragmentation-issues

I've thought countless times that if there were some sort of a Wikipedia-for-URLs wherein discussion *about* a given page – its quality/validity/merits/demerits etc. – would be extremely helpful. Similar to the way that Facebook or Disqus threads can be allowed at the bottom of a page *by the creators* of a page, it would be an interesting endeavor to provide similar functionality and display this content as if it were a part of the site.

Obviously, we'd want to restrict the service to sites of interest, and not allow discussion of things that aren't actually docs. This could probably be done by domain with a little thought.

Comment: I think this is an interesting idea. I wonder how far you can take this. Google Translate transforms existing pages without hitting copyright issues. Will such transformed pages show up in search results? How far would we go in transforming them?

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky SO has a good record of attracting hits through search-engines. If original page-titles are duplicated along with the right metadata, we could probably get it so that the comments/examples/revisions would show up in search-results as their own page, right above or below the original document assuming relevant search-criteria. Comments could be done as threads, atomic comments sorted by score (like SO answers or comments on PHP's docs) or for actual revisions: a git-style commit for a given page, treating the original page as the basis commit so we wouldn't have divergence.

Comment: I agree with the general idea that this idea is best pulled off as a collaboration between the existing docs sites and Stack Overflow.  Possibly by means of some sort of widget or API. Or maybe the solution is the build a documentation site engine of sorts that links with SO on some level so that questions and answers linking to topics can be marked to indicate that the linked documentation has changed, but also be able to look back at it's state when the link was made. This could help avoid the duplication/fragmentation issue and still solve the problems that are proposed to be solved.

Comment: Beside mere "comments", we could have edits (changing the text of the page), links (like are used on SO), mouse-over-links/annotations, examples, and related questions on SO, all hosted around the original page. It would be a wonderful abuse of copyright.

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky The copyright-issues would definitely need consideration... however, since having on-page annotations would *reduce* plagiarism, one might argue that it is a safer way to go. In most cases it should be hard to make a legal stand basically saying "Someone made a site that lets people discuss my content and I'm mad about it so they need to stop." as opposed to "Someone made a site without my permission that duplicates content I and/or my organization worked hard to create."

Answer (score 11):

We already have a form of documentation in the tag wikis. Now consider what problems there are with the information in tag wikis:

- It is most often incomplete, if non-existent, and always worse than what can be found from more official sources.
- The quality of the information is questionable. Most often it is just copy/paste from Wikipedia, until that was discouraged. So now instead, it is most often of *lower* quality than a copy/paste from Wikipedia.
- The main purpose of tag wikis: to prove usage guidance, is often missing. And when it is there, it might just be the musings of a single user and not community consensus.
- The cause of the problems is the low amount of people actually reading, let alone contributing to and proof-reading tag wikis.
- In addition, tag wikis is often just a collection of links to the official sources.

I can easily see how this documentation project would end up with the very same problems.

In addition: if I currently need technical documentation about anything programming-related, there's Wikipedia. **Why do we need Wikipedia 2?**

Or if you are not making Wikipedia 2, then what are you making? A low-quality shadow of it, without any clear usage guidance or quality concerns? Wikipedia  struggles with quality concerns and they have far more traffic than you can hope to achieve with this documentation system.

The only use I can see of this documentation system is that it would allow companies to move their documentation and support underneath Stack Overflow, as many companies already attempt. That may be of benefit for Stack Overflow and those companies, but it is hard to see how the *site users* would benefit from that.

Comment: Creation of quality tag wikis isn't incentivised by the current rep system. Nor is peer review very good. Editing doesn't bump the change in front of tag experts.

Comment: Tag wikis aren't great, but it seems odd to me to complain that because tag wikis have problems, a new system that's clearly going to work differently and looks like it would address some of those issues is doomed to failure. Tag wikis are pretty limited in scope and organisation, and aren't incentivised; the documentation suggestion seems to me to address those issues. I also don't see how this overlaps with Wikipedia, which rarely has examples as discussed here, and doesn't aim to document all features of programming languages, or cover issues like feature changes between versions.

Comment: @JoDouglass I think the comparison to tag wikis is a good one.  It's an example of StackOverflow stepping outside of the Q&A sphere and giving a space on the side to write a less fleeting piece of information.  The "community wiki" feature and "tag wiki" features are about making an artifact that people curate and work as a group on, which documentation is more like than it is like Q&A.  So if there's anything odd, it's the oddity that StackOverflow believes users here are equipped/qualified/interested in gathering to supplant official documentation, and do so under the SO banner.  I won't.

Answer (score 11):

Sorry, I can't comment or edit, so I have to answer ...

Someone else may have addressed this, I didn't read everything, but I read a lot and didn't see it. Just thinking, if this does come to be - and I'm generally in favor - it would be great to have a mechanism for cross pollination; e.g., I am answering a question on SO, and my answer might serve as good documentation because it includes an example. Maybe this is just automatically harvested, or maybe it would be good to have a button in the answer/comment, where a user can tag an answer as being documentation for X, just as they can upvote it or comment on it. Then, maybe it can be tied to documentation without replicating, just with linking.

Answer (score 11):

Will we have some kind of notification after the *"six-to-eight weeks"* ?

This post is growing and growing, and I think only a fool can keep up and read all the answers and comments on this post. I did it for a little, but then I lost all hope.

<sub>To the fool(s) who read everything, **no offense meant!**</sub>

I filled up the form and registered on [*"Register and help Make Docs Suck Less"*](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/13ynCK-DEy0osod8VIENajnbFJNZxXm1jyeupBrl5v44/viewform), but the only thing I received was ***"Your request is being submitted"*** or thereabouts.

Sorry for the dumb question, just to be sure, will we receive an email or a notification on Stack Overflow or something similar with the confirmation of have accessed the private beta?

Answer (score 10):

[image]

<sub><sup>[Image Source](http://insideoutrainbows.deviantart.com/art/SWEET-POTATO-PIE-404799940)</sup></sub>

To me it looks like the other half of a tasty pie.

What exists in SO is essentially the largest programming FAQ database ever compiled. What's missing is a standardised documentation platform to link it to.

It would be great if docs.SO became the platform of choice for creating documentation. The only real issue/barrier to success I can foresee is in the way ownership of content is defined.

As long as it feels *publicly owned* I think it will thrive, but if SE appears to take ownership of the content in some way, then developers may have cause for resentment.

What many here are missing is that a consistent UX/UI design across all documentation will increase their productivity immeasurably. Consistency is a pillar of good design, and should not be underestimated.

It's also nice to see such a huge initiative come out of nowhere. Great stuff.

Comment: **We need tutorials**.  When you see a user [ask 13 questions over the span of a week, all about `tableViews`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a4981166%20%5buitableview%5d), and the questions are all are duplicates about cells and reusability, you want to be able to **point them to a resource that explains the basics**, instead of educating someone point by point through a series of questions.  Some people help by flagging and closing questions.  Some people help by writing documentation.  I feel less comfortable doing the first, and more comfortable doing the second.

Comment: @PetahChristian True is (obviously since your comment is subjective), **"I need tutorials"**. Let me add, **... because I'm not able to use Google and the Internet at all**

Comment: @Dom And? What kind of tutorial are you missing?

Comment: @hek2mgl Water follows the path of least resistance.  The easiest thing is to ask someone else to answer your question, even if you don't grasp the answer you were given.  I'd rather see someone learn and grow.  Tutorials might help in that regard.

Comment: @Dom If an example explains what the code does, then it's no different than a tutorial.  [A new/favorite resource for me is lilbitesofcocoa](https://twitter.com/lilbitesofcocoa) because they're concise and easily digestible.  When I want more details, I turn to [NSHipster](http://nshipster.com).  Both are super examples, but one just happens to be more detailed.

Comment: @PetahChristian Have you ever bought (or rent) a book about a topic you are about to learn? Have you ever felt that goodness to learn *more* than you are asking? With 100s of good examples? I mean, what you are asking for *already exists*, in various releases. Don't you see that?

Comment: @hek2mgl Not sure why that's directed to me.  I make use of many resources.  But I know how and where to find help.  The specific SO problem is that when someone needs help, we can't say "Here's the resource that explains that!"  We have to hunt it down, then refer people to that resource.  The tutorials *are* out there, but the problem is, they're out *there*.  Where's the compilation of great tutorials that we should refer users to?  Just because it *exists,* that doesn't imply it's easy to find.  (I'm still looking for a great **up-to-date** Core Data book!)

Comment: Hmm, the term "Core Data" was completely new to me, but it took me ~5seconds to find good tutorials. What are you complaining about? Plus (20 seconds later) I found an O'Reilly http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781937785086.do .. Did you tried that?

Comment: @hek2mgl you're coming across as if this a feature request and our idea that we're pushing. We're just giving our thoughts to the discussion. I don't know why you're cherry-picking hypotheticals to counter but it's not really having any impact on the bigger picture.

Answer (score 9):

This potentially has applications outside of Stack Overflow too.

One of the biggest sources for gaming instructions are community-written wikis, usually hosted on sites such as [Wikia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikia), etc. They are frequently terrible. Often there are multiple wikis with different information.

This could kill those sites completely.

I appreciate that this is a Stack Overflow-specific thing for now, and that's absolutely the right way to do it, but can [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour) be top of the list for sites that get it next?

Comment: I would love these fragmented wikis for video games be killed, but this would only happen if SO-documentation software would be significantly better than *terrible* MediaWiki. Otherwise, SO-documentation would only increase fragmentation.

Answer (score 9):

## In addition to code samples, there is a need for supplemental docs on best practices and recommended usage scenarios.

It is all to common for official documentation pages (such as, *cough cough*, MSDN) to provide all of the "*what*" without any of the "*why*".  Extensive listings of classes, members, and required parameters are provided without critical information about intended usage or best practices/security concerns.  This, in my opinion, has a heavy influence in misleading the community at large towards creating applications that are poorly designed.

A great example is the MSDN page about Application Domains.  It provides a nice brief description of "*what*" it is, but it has no information about "*why*" it exists or when to use it.  **Incredulously, there is special disclaimer that this information should be viewed elsewhere,** ***and the link to that information is broken***.

See:

[image]

Comment: Indeed. Hear, hear.

Answer (score 8):

I really like this idea and this would be great for those obscure projects with old documentation, or minimal documentation and you basically have to read 20 source code files to figure out the purpose of an item or how to implement it.

However, for larger projects that have good decent documentation, I'd add as a requirement/feature linkbacks to the relevant items in the official documentation. I find it important that original documentation still will be the de-facto standard so we teach young coders that not everything is cut and paste. Learning to read bad documentation teaches you why to write good documentation :-)

For example:

```
        try {
            File file = new File(filename);

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    new FileInputStream(file), "UTF8"));

            builder = (JSONObject) JSONValue.parse(in);
            in.close();
        }
```

This is a fun example of how to read a [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) file from org.json.simple from a file. But we have many objects here. I'd propose a [regex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) filter on top of this, with a table that can be defined in a form that turns BufferedReader into a link pointing to the official Java documentation. And JSONObject pointing to the documentation on code.google.com

So basically you'd construct a table under your post (in [YAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML) to allow multiple links perhaps?) with:

```
APIDOCLINKS:
    BufferedReader:
        java7: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html
        java8: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html
    JSONObject: https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/EncodingExamples#Example_1-1_-_Encode_a_JSON_object
```

And all toplevel elements appearing in the text will turn into links if only a link is supplied, but if there are multiple links supplied it will give a dropdown of choices when clicked which version of the documentation you wish to watch/read.

Comment: If we added a link to the original documentation on line as a searchable meta field then it would be a trivial extra for someone to code a browser add-on to pick the appropriate pages on SO-docs when someone was browsing the documentation web site.

e.g. if a documentation/example has a link back to http://php.net/docs/some-function then a browser add on could pick up that the URL in the current browser was that URL and provide a pop-up list of SO-docs pages relevant to that function.

Comment: That would be a nice feature. Especially when browsing java docs, which come with the bare minimum of examples or implementation details

Answer (score 8):

I am surprised no one has brought up the following issue:

**If the documentation gets so good on Stack Overflow, why should developers of the languages spend as much time writing good documentation of their own, or worse, updating documentation at all?**

The long term goal of this proposal is that the documentation and examples written by the community will be the place *everyone* goes to reference a language. Is this necessarily a good thing? In order to write examples and documentation here on Stack Overflow, we need to look through the official documentation of that language. But what happens when all of PHP, for example, is covered here? Traffic to php.net/manual decreases drastically, and maybe the developers decide to leave documentation up to the Stack Overflow community. But, what happens when new versions come out? Will completed *official* documentation of a new release be delayed, lacking in quality, or worse just plain ignored? How will the community be expected to update documentation here on Stack Overflow in such a case?

I really do love the idea of community documentation. In many ways, I believe that is what Stack Overflow already is - to an extent. Actually creating an official grounds for this idea would be so beneficial initially, I am simply worried about the long term. As a PHP developer, even just the user comments at the end of each doc on php.net are useful, imagine an entire network of users coming together to make documentation better, for all languages.

Comment: Agreed. I rather believe in something like http://readthedocs.org - YES, facilitate community contributions to improve the quality of documentation. NO, don't completely outsource it to a community and centralize it, for the reasons you mention (official supplier will be less inclined to provide solid documentation), because it would often cause duplicate (and hence inconsistent) documentation, and/or would cause 'up-to-date' documentation to become fragmented.
All in all, I think it's a terrible idea.

Comment: I disagree with it being a terrible idea, I think there is a middle grounds that can be found. I do agree with every other point you made though

Answer (score 7):

## Make code samples public domain

While CC-BY-SA is a good license for documentation, please add a mention making this new site's code samples public domain ([CC0](https://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/)).

Nearly everyone copy/pastes samples into their code and then modify them. You would not read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/992413/226958), say "*I see!*" and proceed to rewrite it without looking, introducing a few typos and bugs in the process.

By the way, copy/pasting any code sample from Stack Overflow is [illegal](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/226/can-i-copy-paste-a-snippet-from-stackoverflow-into-my-gnu-gpl-project) unless your software is CC-BY-SA (which is not a good license for software). Even [trivial code like this](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/241/199) has been cited successfully in infringement cases.

Answer (score 7):

Please add equation support, preferably in the form of [MathJax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathJax). It might not be needed for most [Ruby](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_%28programming_language%29) documentation, for instance, but languages like [R](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_%28programming_language%29), [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB), [Julia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julia_%28programming_language%29), etc. require equations in the documentation.

Comment: yes, please; some contributors have started to work around this via http://www.codecogs.com/ but it's incredibly clunky.

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like an amazing idea in theory, and it could save a lot people a lot of time. But like Stijn and the other skeptics, I'm not sure whether or not this will be good in terms of fragmentation.

Let's remind ourselves that Stack Overflow was explicitly created to be a Q&A site (from my knowledge), not for documentation. Another implementation is to have this as a separate Stack Exchange network (like the ones on Area 51), where it go through its own paces before becoming official.

I don't know, it could work out alright and all, and I'd love to have my doubts proven wrong in this case.

Answer (score 6):

First off, I think this is a great idea, and could really help contribute to resolving some of the points right now where we're repeatedly fielding questions which are reasonable enough but not a good fit for the site, or where the asker needs to gain some basic knowledge of a topic. This could help cut down on the clutter that many people are concerned about, and give a very quick place to link to when people comment on/flag/vote to close some questions. I think this is the best of both worlds, because people would be helped - but in a way which encourages self-learning - and at the same time the overall quality of the question/answer part of the site would be improved.

A couple of potential ideas which either I haven't seen in answers so far, or have seen but have other thoughts on:

#### Flagging functionality for various tasks which need doing

*This fits in with some of my other suggestions, so read everything to get a full picture of this.*

I think it would be useful if various tasks needed on topics could be flagged up in the system. In some cases this would be manual (i.e. someone notices an issue with a topic, and flags it up), and in others it would be automatic (i.e. situation X occurs, and the system has rules set up to mean that in this situation, a set of topics needs flag Y setting). Once someone took the necessary action and their changes had been reviewed/approved/whatever, the flag would be removed.

#### Is it official?

If the creators of something we have documented here want to consider the SO documentation as their official documentation, it'd be great if we could have something which displayed which documentation was "official" and which was not. I don't know whether this would be something you'd decide on at a language level (i.e. it's all official or it's all not), or at a topic level (i.e. a language's creators would have some sort of review capability topic-by-topic where they could certify that each topic was still correct). If the latter, the flagging functionality discussed above could be used to flag topics which needed to be reviewed by the language's creators.

#### Version tagging

I know the issue has been partially covered in a few places, but I'd like to see version tagging - i.e. each topic can be flagged with multiple versions of a language, so we don't need to rewrite documentation for features which are identical between different versions. When a new version of a language is added, the flagging system above could be used to flag each topic to say it needs checking against the new version, and then as people went through and confirmed whether each topic worked with the new version, those flags would be cleared.

Where people confirm that a topic *is not* the same in the new version, a flag could be created to make a topic discussing that feature in the new version, if suitable. That could be manual, to avoid unnecessary flags requesting topics for obsolete features - i.e. a person responds to a flag saying a topic needs checking against a new version. They find the feature is different in the new version, so they check a box saying a new topic is needed, and save. This clears the "new version" flag and adds a "topic needed" flag which lets people know a topic mirroring topic X but for the new version is needed.

#### Copyright issues

I don't know the full ins and outs of this issue, but have seen it raised repeatedly as a concern. Could it be worth flagging up content for specific copyright reviews, where people are asked to check the new/modified content, do a search for anything similar, and then remove or cite (as suitable) any content which has been copied? If so, would everything be flagged after modification, or might it be possible for a system to be added which does automatic plagiarism detection, then only flags those topics which problems have been found?

#### Related questions and related documentation

It would be good to see links from both parts of the site pointing to related information in the other. Much like we have "related questions" when we're looking at questions now, I'd like to see links to "related questions" when viewing documentation topics, and "related documentation topics" when viewing questions.

#### Dealing with related tags

A couple of discussions have come up about how to relate the documentation area back to the Q&A area. We seem to be at least starting out with this based on tags - but many tags are related to one another. We need a structure which ensures we don't have competing topics related to different tags, resulting in some tags being incomplete, or contradictory information between related tags.

The two thoughts I've had on this are either allowing topics to be associated with multiple tags, or associating documentation areas on a one-to-one basis with tags, but setting up tag hierarchies.

A simple example for the tag hierarchy idea: If the .NET tag were set as the parent of C# and VB.NET, then going to the .NET tag's documentation would display the topics associated with .NET itself, and show a list of subcategories in documentation - C# and VB.NET would be listed. Going directly to the C# documentation would just take you straight to the main C# documentation page. There should be something to indicate in the C# documentation area that it's possible to go up a level to .NET, also.

*(Please note, these are just two pretty rough ideas on the tag/hierarchy point - this is a complex issue, and these are pretty much just starters. I'd love to see some more thinking through of the design on this point so we don't get stuck with something that's difficult to navigate or results in poor quality documentation.)*

---

Those suggestions given, I have one concern so far that I haven't seen mentioned:

#### Low activity tags

I spend most of my time on low-activity tags. I've seen people mentioning ideas where people with gold badges in a tag would have more documentation privileges for that tag. For low-activity tags this would be a killer; there may well not be enough (or any!) active gold badge holders. Please keep this in mind when figuring out how privileges will work.

Comment: That's an interesting idea about nesting tags; I hope something along those lines is feasible, but really don't know enough about the broad world of programming languages to judge. Regarding low-activity tags, I would suggest that they not enter docs.SO unless they become high-activity. Like CodeCaster, I think quality is a real concern, so opening this up broadly is a bad idea. And also, we don't *need* so many editors (or voters) in docs, I think.

Comment: @Frank As far as nested tags, thanks - it's only a rough idea, but the relationship between tags/documentation areas is an issue that deserves attention if we want this documentation to be high quality and easy to navigate. I think working through a few examples of related tags would reveal where there are problems with my suggestion and any others that have been made, and lead to a stronger eventual design.

Comment: @Frank And as for low activity tags, I do think it would be a real shame if that happened. I can completely understand focusing on the high activity areas first, but I think in some cases the low activity areas suffer for the quality of information available. If people don't see SO as a good destination for that type of information, they may not ask their questions on SO. Some tags could desperately use some documentation covering basic topics that get asked about repeatedly.

Answer (score 6):

For me the missing part of documentation is always quality examples, and those need regular software development practices and tools, so I can't imagine that without using a [DVCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_revision_control) and a local copy in an IDE.

So, for me a perfect universal third-party documentation resource would feature documentation browsing capabilities coupled with a DVCS management solution for code examples similar to [GitHub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub) or [GitLab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitLab) and a [CI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) build environment combined together to demonstrate the runtime outputs of the test cases.

Such an framework would facilitate existing VCS and IDE skills as well as development practices, using SO-Documentation-Examples as some kind of an issue tracker.

A [Git](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29) repository would resemble a large topic or a top level namespace in a class hierarchy.

An answer to a problem in code examples would require a pull request in a test suite or a demo project, which then could be merged to the body of reviewed examples, if supported by enough votes in the QA part.

With a DVCS working copy an implementor would be able to work in an environment of choice without the need to move back and forth between the IDE, numerous xFiddle and xPad environments and Stack Overflow itself with enormous amount of snippet copy-paste operations to provide a quality piece of code.

Many problems require cloning a known opensource project from GitHub just to browse for the snippets of code and tests for example usages of some library so the SO-Documentation-Examples with DVCS-based examples would probably serve that purpose better.

Comment: Interesting proposal. I'm not actually sure this is a good idea. I mean, to have full, compilable projects that have a lot more code than necessary for the given question. I'm thinking examples of how to use a Java Spring Framework annotation. It would take a web app project to run, or perhaps a stand-alone project (even though that's not a common use of Spring). Just to show how one annotation works. And it gets worse if we try to cram multiple examples into a single compilable project. Perhaps these sample projects could be an extra, or a part of a tutorial.

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky The main concern of having just a code snippet is that it needs to be copy-pasted from some other environment, where you have actually set up a solution already at least to compile and get some program output. If this job is already done, why bother copy-pasting, when you can just push a changeset? And, when it's done, how to keep it in sync and accurate?

Comment: That's a good point. But we must have short to-the-point examples, How about this: a markup syntax inside comments to cut up a compilable, unit-tested project into individual examples.

Comment: Very good idea, in addition we can use VM or containers (like docker) to save the full environment of script it needed to run, and problem with many versions of language and libs can be solved this way. Each container for each version, and more over for different platforms and dependency builds. We can have working example fully functional out of the box just in few clicks.

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky I think, examples can be of different sort (snippets, tutorials, guides, howtos, patterns, use cases, algorithms, best practices, practical advices, tips and tricks, secrets for advanced, concept, technique, tools, overview, comparisons and test). And all of this examples types are glad to be structured and easily found. Without an active community it's unachievable. I think, SO is the best place for it to happen.

Answer (score 6):

As far as examples, I think it should be more of a task of curation than generating new content. I don't think it makes sense for a contributor to open a topic page and start writing, "well you can do this, and then you can do that." The question-answer format is superior for a few reasons:

- Concrete questions yield relevant examples.
- Users suggest alternate ways of writing something, and the best way is voted (or at least the best way, which was added long after the question was asked and has no hope of getting enough votes, is somewhere on the page).
- A feeling that you're participating in a discussion with people.

I would like to flag good questions as something that belong as an example, and the link between SO question and doc example would be two-way. The place to propose new examples would be in the question, and the doc topic would host the example(s) chosen by the community.

Comment: I agree.  I'm not even sure that people will use documentation so much as just keep asking questions and answers anyway. I'd also be worried about the proposed "Topic" layout of documentation leading to a lot of duplicate or over-lapping topics, the same way questions are now.

Answer (score 6):

There is a difference between

> What all can a [class] of [language] on [platform] do?

and

> How to do [something simple] using [class] in [language] on [platform]?

The second scheme is why Stack Overflow is sought for, famous for. The difference is not big, just the way information is looked up these days.

So rather than try to repeat `The Docs ™` (top down, packages, classes, methods) shouldn't the effort be focused on the reverse linking and transforming ? The "how" part ? The answers are already there.

Documentation will emerge automatically. Dynamic, updated, curated, reviewed, commented, admired and hated.

```
Java -> nio -> Path -> getAbsolute() -> is ?
> The Answer // one of the answers, not a classic documentation page
> Answers    // Stack Overflow has many of these
```

Stack Overflow should do one thing it already does: provide answers.

I'm not opposing developer documentation on Stack Overflow (it'd be great), but I think the way they are to be created, can be what will make Stack Overflow different from traditional documentation sites.

Answer (score 6):

Rather than community written docs to supplement official docs, what if the docs are more like 'how-to guides', examples of how to use/write code using a specific language feature/api. I think is a specific example of what format the documentation could take?

Answer (score 5):

The proposal could be improved by adding a section for **How To** or **Step-by-Step** in addition to **Examples**.

I write tutorials for an open source project. Tutorials are valuable because they show how to implement something from start to finish. Good tutorials provide context, like a recipe, showing what ingredients are needed and a procedure for combining the ingredients (sequence or order is often important). As it stands, the proposal doesn't offer the structure needed for a tutorial.

You've called this a proposal for Documentation. And you've duplicated the structure of the formal documentation that is often written for a programming language or API. But the problem with language or API documentation is granularity. You can read the documentation for a method call and see the syntax and all its permutations without learning how to use it. Examples aren't enough because they don't provide context. What has to happen before the method is called? And what result should you expect? This is why people turn to tutorials.

You may argue that providing a platform to write tutorials is out of scope, too ambitious, or duplicates the effort of every blog writer on the Net. But the value of SO is to provide a popular destination with a consistent and well-thought-out structure for Q&A and this could be true for tutorials as well.

All you need to add, to begin providing the benefits of tutorials, is a section for **How To** or **Step-by-Step** in addition to **Examples**.

Comment: Consistent and maintained by the community? I don't really think that's possible, what with the variety of approaches people have to pedagogy. We'd just see a proliferation of tutorials from different perspectives, none maintained by anyone.

Comment: This isn't ideal. Each developer would follow their own methodologies. So maintaining tutorials would be too difficult

Comment: How to and step-by-step are really just aliases for Examples.

Comment: Great answer, totally agree. I think, examples can be of different sort (snippets, tutorials, guides, howtos, recipes, patterns, use cases, algorithms, best practices, practical advices, tips and tricks, secrets for advanced, concept, technique, tools, overview, comparisons and test). And all of this examples types are glad to be structured and easily found. Without an active community it's unachievable. I think, SO is the best place for it to happen. I wish it would be a big base of code snippets for all tasks i can imagine in all environments and languages.

Answer (score 5):

Another way that having all the documentation in one place could be beneficial would be cross referencing languages' API for people learning their Nth language.

For example, coming from [Ruby](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_%28programming_language%29) to [Objective-C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C) dealing with strings took longer than it should simply because I didn't believe what was required when I found the documentation.

So you could have a direct link from Ruby's string manipulation page to Objective-C's string manipulation page, and vice versa; or iterating over an array in Python to Ruby's enumerables, and Swift's, and JavaScript...

And if you included basic/ common algorithms people wouldn't have to try to guess if it's implemented (i.e. Ruby's `each`, or Swift's `for x in y`), and what it's called in that language. And since the user will likely be familiar with their native language's documentation it will be trivial for them to find what they want to do, and then follow the link to how that's done in the new language.

I had an idea for doing this myself for a while. But since you're taking this on anyway implementing simple many-to-many relationships would be a simple addition.

Comment: Brilliant! We need standard examples (eg, how to write an array to a file) that can be collated between languages/libraries into a single "crash course" page. Of course, while some standard examples are easy to define for languages, two domain-specific libraries will need to agree on some domain-specific examples to have in common.

Comment: This sounds pretty much identical to Rosetta Code.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I hadn't seen it, but yes it does seem very similar. And I'll probably use it moving forward. However the organization, presentation leave a lot to be desired.

Comment: @PeterTaylor , [Tasks in RosettaCode](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Category:Programming_Tasks) are much more complex when simple examples of language API usage. However, it can be used to find different implementations of the same task (algorithm). All the difference can be in the way of how you achieve the needed information. Cross-linked references of many languages is very good idea for me.

Answer (score 5):

As a fresh developer, I am seriously excited about this crusade. The idea of peer-reviewed examples and openly edited documentation can solve so many problems for existing and future developers. Think about all the people who would now gladly and efficiently go read the manual.

Seeing how platforms like Wikipedia, with enough community participation, can become actual reliable sources of useful information, I am convinced SO can do the same to documentation.

**This seriously has to be the next big thing in programming.**

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding why this post is so negatively received.

Comment: While I didn't downvote it, I guess those who did objected to the language. "Crusade" suggests an impious enemy. While it isn't truly offensive to half-jokingly say that SO was created [to fight an enemy](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/03/whos-your-arch-enemy.html), who would be the enemy here? The evil, feckless open-source developers who write terrible documentation? And "the next big thing in programming" sounds too much like empty marketese.

Comment: @duplode Well I guess maybe as a less experienced developer, I am way more excited about this than the sceptics. The "crusade" part I thought about editing, but the reason I put it there in the first place is because of the title of the post: "Warlords of Documentation". Anyways, thanks for the input. :)

Comment: "the reason I put it there in the first place is because of the title of the post" -- I see. It makes much more sense now, though it does remind me of the old adage saying that humour doesn't always translate well over the Internet. It is often true, unfortunately, but keeping po-faced all the time would be even more unfortunate :)

Comment: @AdamJensen: This is basically a verbal upvote for the question; either downvoters disagree that the proposal is good, and thus disagree with your answer, or they don't think that your answer really adds anything to the discussion, since there's not much argument put forth.

Answer (score 5):

Special attention need to be paid to versions of APIs in this or it's going to get really confusing fast.

It needs to be split into a `language-name/language-version/api-name/api-version/package/` split along with tags to make it easy to find things related to various topics.

Also it would probably be nice for each user to be able to create a "project" of sorts, and then include only the documentation related to that particular project within that space, so as not to have to include the full brunt of all the things related to the documentation, but to be able to choose when browsing that documentation, the documentation which relates to that particular project, if that makes any sense.  I do this already using Tiddlywiki when I'm learning something new, and I only need some parts of the functionality of a library for my project, and not all of it.

Answer (score 5):

Since I didn't see this mentioned yet: couldn't this be a job better handled by a search engine? There were a number of people talking about fragmentation. The documentation doesn't have to exist in one place for it to be aggregated in one place.

Couldn't you propose / promote a microformat, and urge search engines to surface that format in search results? Or create a JSON index format, and allow people to integrate their documentation into any documentation aggregator, not just SO? I think the original post makes the assumption that SO would end up being the best place to aggregate. That may actually be true, I'm not sure, but why make it the ONLY place to aggregate / add corrections? Walled gardens are necessary sometimes, but I don't see why they'd be necessary for searchable / indexable text documents.

Answer (score 5):

**This feature is fundamentally true to the nature of the site and its users.** It provides a platform for truly high-quality, peer-reviewed information on the tools that programmers love.

I feel like this is what a lot of users have always wanted Stack Overflow to be. Great documentation has no duplicates, it has no useless information, and the information is correct and helpful. It sounds like what those users expect of questions and answers on the site, and often work hard towards.

The problem has always been that Stack Overflow continues to grow rapidly, but the number of concerned users doesn't grow nearly as fast. Quality control on the Q&A site is analogous to attempting to stop the tides of an ocean. You can't stop oceans from making waves.

**I like this idea, because I think it gives users a more effective place to enforce that standard of quality.** There will still be plenty of users to enforce quality on the Q&A site, and certainly most users will frequent both parts of the site. But maybe this will be a chance to reevaluate what we expect of the Q&A site and how we want to let that part of the site grow differently than it has thus far.

Answer (score 5):

**Instead** of creating documentation, can we leverage the SO database? this requires new flags or some sort of nomination that proposes a thread for either **great example** and/or **great explanation**. Nominated threads would go to a process that cleans them up (for example, removing comments and problem specifics) so that what is left is a description of problem (with test data if appropriate) and solution. Some additional tags may be added for searching. These answers are then stored and receive priority in the 'have you looked at these answers' when writing a question, and can be passed on to the documentation teams for the underlying product.

Comment: This definitely seems like the way to go. In fact, the site has already tended this way with the better tag wikis (see [scala](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/scala/info) for example.)

Answer (score 5):

Actually this might be more a question than an answer: do you plan to provide a "localization" feature, so that the documentation/examples could be provided in **multiple languages? (french/english/german...)**

I understand that for a Q&A website (ie SO), it's problematic because translating the question and the answer requires a lot of work, but for documentation it seems easier (only the title requires "official" translation).

I think this could really help some people who might not be fluent in English to find some relevant documentation and examples in their own language.

Comment: Localization is must have feature of modern documentation. More over, it should be possible to post new examples in different languages, because translation to english can be done by other man skilled in translating, it increases the chance of mass contributing. And more, some languages are invented by people which are not english speaking and there documentation is in other language.

Answer (score 5):

This is not an answer, really, but something documentation-related that I'd like to get off my chest.

In many areas, documentation has gotten WORSE over the years.  Whereas 20 years ago, technical writers would be hired to write well-organized manuals, that expense is largely foregone these days.

What I've noticed recently is that with the increasing use of technologies like Bootstrap et al., which are designed to enable a single code base for content that can be displayed on a large monitor or a smartphone, there is a strong tendency to privilege the smartphone at the expense of the large monitor.  If it can't be read easily on a smartphone ... does it really need to exist?  Imagine a "twitterized" Stack Overflow!

This leads to content that looks great on a smartphone and also "looks great" on the large monitor EXCEPT for the fact that on the large monitor there is less information shown in **REALLY BIG FONTS**.  "Documentation" often lacks the necessary information density to do the job.    Imagine trying to read a GOOD javadoc on a Smartphone (or to code on one, for that matter).

This is another point that needs to be considered by anyone proposing to create a repository of documentation.

Answer (score 5):

I'm a little sad that this will be based off of Stack Overflow tag scores only - could scores from other coding sites (such as [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/tour) / [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour)) be added on?

I got the impression that if I had less than X (I'm guessing X may be 5) in a tag, I couldn't participate (maybe I'm wrong).

Here I have 22 on the [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) tag, and 0 on the bash [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tag). On Ask Ubuntu, I have 9 in [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), but 44 in Bash. It would be cool if these could be added together, so I could participate in the Bash section.

Answer (score 5):

Most of the answers here cover my main concerns, but somewhere in this mess it should be pointed out:

- "Official docs" following a specific (maybe DSL) format could be taken from the repositories, reducing fragmentation.
- Those who wished to contribute could do so on the repository itself.
- Some parts of the documentation wouldn't need to be from a repository (i.e. ES6 documentation).

The other thing I think needs to be re-re-re-re-iterated is tagging, categorization, et al. That will be the biggest challenge.

Comment: @PeterMortensen your edits are unnecessary. Please stop.

Answer (score 5):

## All in for documentation

There are a lot of projects out there that don't have updated good documentation. I have waited for something like this to come to Stack Overflow since there are **many** answers that serve as documentation.

Just an example:
[How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Anyone in any tag probably knows an answer they use frequently as documentaion. Offical documentation can lack examples or lack any real-life use examples.

I think this is a really good suggestion to add on Stack Overflow.
There will of course be problems, but the community judging will decide for each tag if they are rewriting existing documentation or other problems.

And we can allways raise a meta question if there are doubts about the documentation in general and tag documentation.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I like the idea, think good examples are the key and - as e.g. [amalloy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/304041/4763489) - I'm concerned about the quality of the examples.

Even being aware that

- the question of **"What is a good code example?"** has seen its own share of discussion (like [Should I demonstrate best practices in example code or be concise?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290223/should-i-demonstrate-best-practices-in-example-code-or-be-concise))
- there are whole book libraries and numerous dedicated web sites about writing good code
- the community will improve/rewrite bad code samples over time

I wanted to add my thoughts (in an unsorted and definitely *not* complete list) on what general guidelines could help SO Documentation in making the most out of code examples for users:

- Coding standards: there should be an agreement on a coding standard (per programming language) for the examples

  - I just want to prevent a mixture of coding styles and improve readability
  - Maybe even the coding standard itself could be open to the community and part of the new site
- It should compile in most environments

  - This seems trivial, but to achieve this I think some preconditions - like key compiler settings - should be at least mentioned
- Known keywords should cross-reference

  - As with other wikis or generated documentation (automatic) cross-referencing should take place
  - I like to click on things in the code and jump to "more information" (and it could get cumbersome and error-prone to do the required referencing manually)

Comment: About _Coding styles_. I think we can write nice feature (or implement already written one), which can afford automatically switch between coding styles. Some editors already have features to format code to needed template. It would be great if in UI we'll have a button to switch code representation, and more over, to write custom representation template, to fit evereones tastes.

Comment: @Mikl Formatting according to your own preferences would be great. If we continue on this line of thought I think we would get to features like [`refactoring`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025844/what-is-refactoring-and-what-is-only-modifying-code) and `code snippets`. But before we bring all the tools into the web server, it's maybe better to be open the web server to the tools. E.g. Visual Studio [Developer Assistant](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a1166718-a2d9-4a48-a5fd-504ff4ad1b65) plugin "puts millions of code snippets and code sample projects at your fingertips".

Answer (score 5):

First of all, **it's awesome to have community driven open source platform to structurize, crosslink, voting, commenting and discussing the data** that are already on the web or not present for now.

## For me, main goals are:

- Make the place, where **everyone can easily and fast find the data** it
  needs for specific task. It should have the ability to make task
  oriented search.
- Make the place, where **we can see all variants of solutions of all
  tasks with the ability to vote, comment, discuss of it's good and
  best parts**. Where can be also bad solutions (anti-patterns) with the
  detailed explanation of why it's not so good, and the cases when it's
  acceptable as less evil, it's very valuable information too.
- Make the place, where **we link together all those good articles that
  are already on the web, but it's hard  to find it so far for non
  geeks or professionals in some things. And more over it's not only
  hard to find sometimes, but hard to prove if it's content is good
  one**, because to prove it you must try it first and be a professional
  in this area to make some test and form an adequate decision. This is
  the most valuable aspect of proposal. Only large active community can
  contribute so valuable experts judgments on all the tasks and
  solutions.
- Make the place, where **people of different native speaking languages
  and different knowledge in different platforms and programming
  languages can work together on solving the common to all languages
  tasks**. Because it's much more easier to solve the task if it's
  already been solved in different language, you only need to adopt it
  to needed syntax and dependency. The main problem for so many
  developers is that they are in need of solve the task which was
  solved before so many times, and many devs who solved it before has
  so many experience that can be useful for others, the results of
  testing and implementing it in real life environment, a real life
  problems which occurs in their particular case.
- Make the place, for **all type of useful knowledge, in particular, for
  such examples types (snippets, tutorials, guides, recipes, howtos,
  patterns, use cases, algorithms, best practices, practical advices,
  tips and tricks, secrets for andvanced, concept, technique, tools,
  overview, comparisons and test)**

### Main feature in examples section is analysis

Main feature in examples section is analysis of each example with explanation of it's good and bad parts with it's advantages and disadvantages, this benchmarking results and test suites, with environment and dependency specification. I think, in general many so called bad answers are not so bad, but good in some specific cases and i wish it could be possible to know in which cases it's good and bad.
There are [some sites (like RisettaCode and others)](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Help:Similar_Sites) for documenting examples by task, but they lack feature of community analyzation and conversation of each examples.

I imagine, it would be a platform to search many different solutions with wide community analysis for every single task in programming world and in tech world too (administration task and others). For all tasks that can be reproduced and can be someone helpful.

I recently solves some task that i haven't find well published on the web, and i'm sometimes eager to contribute this new results to the world, but it's always to complicated and/or will not be visible by broad community.
If it will be the tool to easily share my knowledge i would be very happy.

### Outer linking with archiving

Outer linking with archiving (backuping, snapshoting) the linked version of a page in the state it was on the time it was linked ("retrieved on " field will be much good also for links and cites).
It should be outer documentation archiving machine which will generate fully functional mirror of linked doc page.
[for example see](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Archived_Pages)
If some standards will be created, we can use some sort of auto parsers to save the outer pages content for archiving purpose. We can use something like [pocket browser extension](https://getpocket.com/) for example, which is default and preinstalled in Firefox. It will make process of doc creating much easier.
All bad about outer linking as we can't guarantee that it will remain later, if we rule this problem, it would be great.

### Terminology.

One format, if it means terminology is hardly achievable, because every language can put different meaning to the same terminology. In this case, we should be able see all the meanings of concrete word in different languages(platforms,systems,tools and etc). And more over, terminology must be the vital part the beginning of each documentation.

### Glossary.

We should have glossary for each language and API. It's one of the best way to find explicitly what you want.

### Structure with different variations for each language.

I wish it's good to have some so called structure with different variations for each language. I think, we should take it from official sites, if present. It can be simple tree overview (map) of language. It's another one good way to find what you need, especially when you definitely know it was there.
And there is no problem in creating of such structure because it's already created for many languages and are well known and familiar to devs.
I don't propose unified global structure. But internal language structure of some sort (for example like tag wiki) will be much appreciated and useful.

### Localizations.

Localizations is vital and should be planed from the very beginning.
Localization is must have feature of modern documentation. More over, it should be possible to post new examples in different languages, because translation to english can be done by other man skilled in translating, it increases the chance of mass contributing. And more, some languages are invented by people which are not english speaking and there documentation is in other language.

### Versioning, dependency, environment specs

Versions are one of the main aspect of documentation and examples. 
Versioning and more precise dependency list with all environment specification are vital information too.
For me, the silver bullet for overcome versioning problem in examples is providing the full environment specification for each code example (it can be hidden under some Env icon in the corner of code snippet block and pops up when it clicked), go further if it will be integrated with auto testing platform we can have results without time wasting (it can be hidden under some Test Result icon), for that test suite need to be done.
It will be great if you could integrate some tools to auto check code snippet in different versions (like [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/5rVEA) or [travis-ci](https://travis-ci.org/doctrine/collections/builds/57144859)). With [docker containers](https://www.docker.com/) we can test language or tools in every environment we ever need.
And more, we can give full environment snapshot (system image) to instant run with one click (docker containers can do this magic). In it's Dockerfile filosofy it provide a clean text (script) representation of way to reproduce any of environments you can ever need.

Comments and feedback are highly appreciated.

Comment: I like the idea to add analysis results/comments to the examples and I agree to your thoughts on versioning. But I'm not sure if we are really talking about another "open source platform" here. For me the focus is more on the documentation (give certain topics more room to elaborate, incl. useful code examples) and more specifically on APIs or language constructs. And I would question if your task oriented approach may apply to all areas? To give examples: yes, for common programming patterns and no, for language/library specific API functions (the task being an implicit to the API).

Comment: @Florian i really don't see all the picture of what they are going to create about this documentation. However, i've read all comments in this thread :) and there are some which make me believe that this will be not just another canonical documentation, but something more. About task oriented approach, i believe it can be one of the good way (maybe the best) to find what you need. I mean, that it will be great to have many opportunities to find, such as relative links (cross linking), tags, glossary, overview, some sort of structure and task oriented search. More ways to find what we search

Comment: @Florian more about task oriented approach. ___At its simplest, Rosetta Code makes building a frame of reference for learning tools easier by providing examples of problems known to users along with solutions which use tools they're familiar with, as well as solutions which use tools they aren't familiar with.___ [(cite of Rosetta Code founder).](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/User:Short_Circuit) I totally agree with this. You ask: ___if your task oriented approach may apply to all areas?___ I think generally, Yes.

Comment: @Florian For example, ___for language/library specific API functions___, we have a task `find some node in xml`, in php there are several libraries (with it's own API) you can use to solve this task. In one API it would be in one line, in other it would be several user written functions, and i would love to see them all this analyses of it's advantages, bad and good parts.

Answer (score 5):

I think having a centralized canonical repository for API documentation could cause us to become too dependent on that "one true" documentation format that people seem to be asking for. This will probably be fine for traditional SDKs, since all we have to do is slap a "web x.0" interface on that old-school style of documentation - the format that hasn't changed in 15 years, because it is working. But I think it could slow things down for the evolution of how we interact with web services, which is still in its infancy.

The currently accepted practice for a web client is to hard-code all the URLs for all the resources you want access to, and to assume that all those endpoints will be available, and will always be shaped the same way. If you want to be really sure, you'll use the URL that has a version hard-coded into it. The automatic "REST" documentation toolkits that are coming out support and almost enforce this style of thinking.

This style of dependency is making it so we write our own "official" clients, and ignore all the others. It's making it so we have to support a semver style of deployment, and are forced to permanently do the traditional lock-step update/deprecate dance with our clients, or cause them all to break hard on changes. It's SOAP all over again.

There is a better way (full Richardson maturity model REST, including HATEOAS, and newer API doc standards that are only just barely coming into usage/coming into being), but the road isn't well-paved yet. I fear that the evolution of solutions to this problem will take twice as long to invent and to spread if the old-school style of documentation gains even more traction, and gets in the way of this progress. The more shared documentation exists, the more we'll entrench the thinking that documentation encourages, and the harder it will be to change it.

We could mitigate this by actively working to support more "canary" or "bleeding edge" style documentation formats - like the various hypermedia media types, link relations, micro-formats, and canonical "profile" descriptions. Supporting evolving/competing format would cause us to forego a "one true style", though, except for statically-versioned software (which right now is the majority, but ideally will decline significantly during the next two decades). But having a single place to host and promote all these things could be a huge boon for progress!

Answer (score 5):

As a project author, I think this could work really really well for us, ***if*** We can use Stack Overflow as the authoring tool, which saves to [GitHub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub), in a documented format (which we then might choose to extract from there again and republish on our own site).

Comment: @JoshCaswell I was under the impression that when posting to SO, they own it and license the content to other SO users under the creative commons license. But if that's wrong, I retract point 2.

Comment: That makes sense, I'm editing my post.

Comment: Looks like the other comment got deleted, so I just want to point out here that you own the content you post to Stack Overflow, and by posting it you grant Stack Overflow an irrevocable license to use it. More details here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/18223/299116

Answer (score 5):

By examining abstractly about why to document code, I think that the documentation that developers mostly search for can be split in three big categories:

### 1) What does it do?

It makes total sense: Developers search for documentation to find out what something does. There are many reasons for that: to find out if it covers their needs, to check if it does what they think it does, to understand the code and see its bigger picture etc.

### 2) How well is it done?

And again, similar to the previous one, many devs are searching for specific info about code, like time/space complexity, if there are better implementations matching their case etc.

### 3) How is it done?

Many developers search to find out how something is done for example in an API implementation, for educational and many other purposes.

Those things should be the base for this idea I think.
There might be more things to it, but these are the first things that come to mind of any developer when thinking about documentation.

Now, documentation should be faced like something more of a just "good policy for existing code". It should be based on the same principle SO was based: "Get helped, help others, don't be evil". We write documentation to help others understand, and we expect the same (and everybody loves *well* documented APIs/code etc).

I think this is a great idea, especially if this changes the way we think when we look at our code and how understandable it is to others, or even learn how to document right as a community of devs of all levels and ages.

Answer (score 4):

At first sight I loved the idea. The thing which immediately came into my mind is documentation for [windbg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windbg), a tag where I am active.

I just added a [similar case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32318817/exr-exceptionflags-contradict-lastevent) where the documentation is incomplete and spread over several places. The documentation doesn't even show an example of the output.

Actually, I have already asked Microsoft for permission of republishing a copy of WinDbg's help file online with the ability of adding documentation, adding community comments and notifications for interested users.

However, Microsoft never replied. And there's a big

```
© 2014 Microsoft. All rights reserved.
```

on every WinDbg help page. It's hard to overlook that.

So IMHO, this is a **legal issue** which may work for some products / projects but not for all - which is sad.

Comment: IANAL, but we're not talking about *republishing* existing docs. Writing up windbg docs on Stack Overflow would be no different than, say, writing a blog post detailing how to accomplish a particular debugging task, which is perfectly legal.

Comment: @AnnaLear The problem is that if we're talking about documenting API, you're bound to paraphrase at least what is or could be the official documentation, if you start documenting every class/method/function/.... There isn't a million ways to document `GetRowEnumerator`. It's likely that there would be an equivalent to the [FGITW problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9731/148833) whereby some users would start off by copying pasting large chunks from existing docs, so that  in turn may require substantial moderation overhead. Independently of copyright issues, this could be duplicate effort.

Comment: If we're to consider this more along the lines of publishing tutorials, the larger the documentation is, the more editorial leadership is required for making it coherent. That could become more similar to writing books, which tend to require a good "story-telling" aspect to form a good explanation to the reader. In my experience, this rarely works well if edited by committee, if what's documented becomes quite large (more than what you'd find nowadays in a blog post).

Answer (score 4):

From a commercial perspective, this could be a great way to provide structure to the many different APIs and SDKs out there.

From my perspective, however, there would need to be a private option so that development companies like mine can use the tool to document our own private system APIs so that they are structured in a way that (hopefully) will be become a standard and be familiar for all developers.

Comment: They could always give the source and you could host it on your own servers I think if you want private. It could be a Discuss plugin

Answer (score 4):

Where will Stack Exchange get enough knowledgeable folks to do all the writing?

The existing expert base will be instantly split into two groups - those who write examples on DOXXX.SO and those who post answers on Stack Overflow. Stack Overflow's quality will plummet as there'll be noone to moderate the site and write high-quality answers.

While the novelty factor will undeniably attract some people to DOXXX, over time fatigue will return - and it will be much faster than at Stack Overflow just because technical writing is a thankless systematic activity quite unlike answering questions off the top of one's head.

I would support instead the development team's efforts to:

- Improve Stack Exchange site-wide search engine;
- Fine-tune detection of duplicates and related questions;
- Provide for opening related questions' content including examples in the same page to make the experience seamless (each linked or related question should IMHO have an expander triangle next to it).

Comment: Good documentation can probably help close duplicate and redundant questions. If there's one good manual that answers 100 questions, that's 100 less redundant questions on the main site. Also, gaining rep for editing documentation seems quite the opposite of "a thankless activity".

Comment: @AdamJensen - explaining what another dev designed is akin to slavery - one's creative powers are severely hamstrung. It's just like teaching vs. doing things on one's own. I'm skeptical on whether DOXXX will make folks RTFM.

Comment: "explaining what another dev designed is akin to slavery" - it's very different from slavery in the sense that you aren't forced in any way to do it, and there's payback in the form of rep points.

Answer (score 4):

A lot has already been written about the benefits vs. cost of the proposal (and in such a short time).  I don't want to cover old ground, and with this already being such a long read I will keep this as short as possible:

**I don't believe that the overall effort is going to justify the benefits of the proposal.**

I agree that there are many gaps across various (official or otherwise) documentation sites/sources.  I also agree that a key problem is often with using a function or feature.  If you look hard enough you come across alternative sites and blogs with good advice (including questions on this site).

However, I don't see the harm if I post a question here asking how to use a function...  even if it has already been answered.  As already pointed out, it may be beneficial to actually sort out the site functionality so that duplicates are flagged a lot quicker (maybe suggestions are forced on a user before posting a question, possibly limited to newer/lower rep users).  How that is done is another debate.  In any case, it is irrelevant when I have a programming problem and I want to find a solution.  I am going to spend x amount of time researching then when no solution found I will post a question.

With the proposal, you are creating a massive headache for maintaining a number of third party documentation (e.g. what happens if an MSDN article is updated... how will someone here know?).  There will be potential conflicts with users constantly making amendments.  There will be bias towards certain platforms.  There will be confusion across different version.  And so on (I would say the last few examples are found across multiple comments/answers here already).

The only real benefit I can see is actually having documentation on certain design patterns or multi-function usage... which is maintained through each release of an api / library.  I mean the kind of high scoring questions on such concepts as copy/move/assignment in C++ (copy-swap etc).  It has a high score because people found it useful.  Therefore, these kind of examples would benefit from being maintained across time.

**I don't see how having a tutorial on function usage will greatly reduce bad, low quality or duplicated questions.**

An inexperienced user is still going to stumble across this site and ask the question.  The proposal will arguably only benefit more experienced users/programmers who will spend time researching the resource (that took a large number of hours to re-compile from other sources).

Answer (score 4):

In principle, this is great. However, we need to be honest as to how developers often use SO and take measures to ensure this use is not undermined.

Developers work to deadlines and often under unreasonable pressure from uninformed "lay" people.

Hence, developers often want to find a quick answer in two minutes instead of ploughing through twenty pages of documentation.

In short, if a developer is seeking a quick answer and is then redirected by senior community members to complex examples and lengthy documentation, SO will be more professional perhaps, but less useful to the over-worked front line coders this site serves so well.

Comment: Not sure I follow your meaning. The proposed site is aiming at ~1 page worth of content per topic, they've said.

Comment: Brevity are focus are definitely something we want to encourage - you get to the page you want with a single Google search is a reasonable goal.  I don't think anyone enjoys wading through page after page trying to find what you want.

Answer (score 4):

Would this apply to other Stack Exchange sites as well?

For example, I use Spanish Stack Exchange. There are tons of Spanish learning sites out there, but not many of them talk about one of the most obviously tricky things about Spanish (and, I assume many languages): the difference between similar words, aka. which one to choose in a particular situation. For example, in Spanish, there are two words for "to ask", "to be", "to know", etc.

Come to think of it, maybe there is something in taking the ideas behind programming language documentation and applying them to natural language documentation. Documentation != learning and most Spanish sites are very focussed on learning.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's a great idea. But what about the case/s where companies require an [NDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-disclosure_agreement) or claim their documents/APIs are copyrighted?

Will people be allowed to create documents for those and examples or???

Yes, I would love to always work with frameworks and products that are open source or that have open documentation, but it's usually not my choice.

Answer (score 3):

This is an excellent move by the Stack Overflow team.

Suppose that a user googles something like this:

[image: img]

Examples are scattered over so many links, so the user might get confused, might mix up several plug-ins, and get into a big mess. So the ideal step would be bringing in working genuine `examples`, `explanations`, `syntax`, etc. under one roof.

Since Stack Overflow is trusted by millions of developers, geeks, nerds, etc., documentation on Stack Overflow will have certain parameters of trust. The feature of adding user notes to such documentation would be more awesome. Users can add their feedback, their code by using that feature, thus increasing potentiality of documentation. A similar feature can be found on the [PHP main site.](https://www.php.net/)
You can add certain repositories for enabling any user to edit the documentation.

I'm sure that this will be a huge hit among developers.

Comment: The "arch-enemy" of SO was expertsexchange, which not great to say the least, and has now gone from most google searches. The danger of what you're suggesting here is to make people who've already kindly volunteered to publish their experiences in their blogs or other places, including official documentation, the arch-enemy of that new system. Not sure that's a great idea.

Comment: @Bruno It's not the same as this experts exchange case. EE is one site, and it's only one line in search results. Blogs and other places are many sites and many lines in results. If SO examples will be popular it will be on first place in search by there will be all others sites too. Existence of SO examples will not be a reason of closing all internet geeks sites. Opposite it will accelerate the web progression.

Comment: @Mikl I'm not talking about where people search, I'm talking about where people contribute their documentation. You'll only get people to search in that new place if people contribute to it first. There's little incentive for projects to write their doc both on their official site *and* on that new site, which would at best be duplicate effort if not competition. People who blog about tutorials are generally quite happy to publish it on *their* blogs.

Comment: What I was trying to tell was: All documentations should be in one place, not scattered over `google`. A user should visit SO and should say, "Aha! All documentations are here! That is so sweet". This won't have any impact on people who blog tutorials. Even I'm a blogger who tries to educate people through articles. And I want life of a developer to be easy. This documentation feature of SO is a great movement in that regard

Comment: @Bruno cross publishing is the way internet goes. And i think it's a good way, because of eliminating of one point of failure. Humanity, i think, shouldn't miss some knowledge if someone's blog will be accidental or eventually vanished. This site gives us opportunity to make our knowledge visible and easy to find to mass of people

Answer (score 3):

I think it's a great idea. Knowledge seekers currently have to go to multiple sources - and many a times, the internal guts of technology are not explained anywhere - there is tons of knowledge in how a popular framework used all the powers of a language to make it so useful.

Official documentation and text books are often constrained by the time authors have to put in for documentation and most often, documentation is still catching up -  A system at Stack Overflow which can revamp how documentation is done and organized can be a game changer.

Answer (score 3):

**The idea is brilliant.**

The first thing I imagined when I read the post was the following: a source of documentation for **all** libraries available. You'll say that this is not possible, too much data. Well, we got [10 million questions](https://stackoverflow.com/10m), why can't we get *10 million* documentation pages?

Nothing stops us! Imagine that you find a library with poor documentation (which happens quite often when you try something new) - all you need is to enter this amazing site (of course I am referring to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)) and you have everything you need instead of struggling for 10 hours (for a single usage of that library, if you want to do more stuff, more hours lost)!

If the library isn't there somehow, then if you post what you obtained other people won't have to research the same things again! And then, more and more AND MORE libraries will be added 'till we get all of them! What will this mean? That Stack Overflow will be (if it's not already) **the most important and used and useful programming website ever!**

> **BIG Thank You to the founders of Stack Overflow!**

[image: Thank you image]

Answer (score 3):

I think this is an important idea, and as a new user, feel it needs to meet the following goals.

1. Support for early questioners
2. Support for new answerers

### Support for early questioners

For people getting started in C, Java, and JavaScript, it is quite daunting. They post a "how do I start" post, but that gets burnt by too-broad, duplicate.

These are also pounced on by new-users like me.

### Support for early answerers

When a new getting started question is posted, apart from pointing the question to the documentation site, the answerer should look to ensure the documentation answers the question. If not, update the documentation to include those details.

Answer (score 3):

### *Heck yes!*

As the author of a couple of small open-source projects, I really want to provide some quality documentation, but it’s heart-breakingly harder than it should be.  I’ve been dreaming of something that is:

- Quick and easy to edit
- Clear to read
- Has great syntax highlighting
- Encourages contributions and collaboration
- Promotes good structure so topics are easy to find and search through

I’ve asked myself whether I should use:

- Github pages/wikis/markdown
- Readme.io
- ReadtheDocs
- MediaWiki
- Google Docs
- Another CMS like concrete5
- *Something else… (Could this be what I’ve been hoping for!?)*

Some of the challenges I foresee (as many others have already noted) are:

- How should it work on large projects with good official docs already.  Yes, there will be duplication, but does that actually matter?
- How do I structure the different types of documentation – API reference material vs topical documentation vs tutorials/walkthroughs.  It would be great if during the SO beta there could be a particular topic or language which was developed to a high standard to be used as a template or prime example for all others.
- Is the Creative Commons licence open enough for my project?

Answer (score 3):

Requests:

- Ability to create private documentation for unreleased projects.    This way I could develop the documentation while developing the project, and release it with the project.  In this case the SO Documentation would be the primary documentation.
- I think there should be a way to link a Question to the documentation (“I do not understand what it says here in the documentation” or “I have a question related to this thing which has been documented”).
- I think there should be a way to link documentation back to answers (so we do not have to copy over the existing examples and explanations).
- There needs to be a section near the top with warnings, when applicable.  These would be high priority warnings like security issues.
- System for linking to related documentation (documentation for inheritance, for example).
- Area for linking to official documentation.
- System for tracking which versions the documentation does/doesn't apply to.
- Good documentation on what is and what is not allowed as documentation.  It is VERY annoying when you spend hours writing something, only to have it removed because it does not match one person's interpretation of the rules.

I think an option to sync major documentation could be beneficial.  For example, an agreement with Google where Google provides an official feed noting changes to their documentation, and SO has a system to implement those changes.

I like the Performance section.

Answer (score 3):

Documentation is a zombie idea that has been plaguing IT since the 1960s. Everyone always agrees it is a good idea, but it never works.  Even though it failed time and time again, the idea keeps returning from the dead.

The problem with documentation is not that it sucks.  It is that users can't read documentation, and if they could, they wouldn't want to.

This fact is pretty much the basis for Stack Overflow's success.  If documentation worked, people would use it instead of asking questions on the internet.

Comment: Which is why we want examples.

Comment: @PeterMortensen: Yeah, and then practical examples are better than imaginary examples. And examples of intersecting technologies are more interesting than single technology examples. And proven examples are more interesting than theory crafting. Which is why you have Stack Overflow :)

Answer (score 3):

I share a few doubts such as fragmentation, but my overwhelming feeling is that you should just give it a go, for the simple reason that you cannot make things worse in the area of platform documentation and the SO community is large and active, unlike other communities.

And I'd like to add one point, hopefully not yet mentioned: when you start building this, it would be smart to think of a format that can be integrated into popular IDEs later on.

Think of it: you say the goal of your company is to improve the lives of developers. Wouldn't it be awesome to have usable documentation right inside your IDE?

Answer (score 3):

Unlike many others I don't see a problem with SO becoming a sole source of documentation or with allowing for duplicates of documentation online. I do think that SO would need to have a rule of not duplicating other content and of always linking to any existing content as a reference no matter how poor. Simply linking to other sources of documentation from SO will increase the chances the other site will show up on Google search results anyways.

The one thing that could be pretty critical to SO docs playing nice with others is to make it really easy to embed SO documentation in other sites. That way SO could directly benefit the existing projects that either aren't organized enough to co-ordinate a move to SO docs or are too small for it to be worth it to move to SO docs officially.

I don't see any concerns about users spamming official documentation here because they wouldn't get up voted. They would get down voted for duplicating content just like existing users get down voted for duplicating questions. Enforcing linking to existing content would help more users get familiar with the existing documentation as well. It would be fairly simple to code a filter that would check for existing whole sentences elsewhere on the internet as well.

Comment: "don't see any concerns about users spamming official documentation here because they wouldn't get up voted" This turns out to be wrong, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

I'd love to see something like this be a separate site. It doesn't really fall in the scope of "Q&A" which is what Stack Overflow (Stack Exchange) is all about...

I think the concept is awesome, but I personally think it should be away from Stack Overflow (but maybe still managed by the Stack Exchange team).

Comment: Stack Exchange team is understaffed (design first and foremost). Branching into a separate project will lead to more problems.

Answer (score 2):

If a company doesn't pay attention to the quality of its commercial product, then such product should die.

Writing some additional documentation that the company does not pay for is going to encourage such practices to repeat in the future.

Comment: Exactly what I fear too. A well-documented library (or product, api,...) generally means it's well written and well thought-out. I only trust libraries written by people who know how to write and take the effort to do so. The quality of a library can often be judged by the quality of the documentation. Libraries or products without good documentation should, and likely will, just die.
Instead, imo, effort should be put in making it easier to write nice documentation and allow contributions - on the product website itself. Like what https://readthedocs.org/ is doing. Eg: http://docs.asp.net/ .

Comment: if a _company_ is just one enthusiast which make some cool thing which no one made before and he in need in help from community to write some docs, i think, he and his project __should live and prosper__ On this moment i don't know real opportunity to attract large community for this goal. I think your answer is not very polite and correct at all.

Comment: @Mikl if company(single dev) wants help on documenting then library + documentation is effort of group of people not original dev. If that is so then such dev should open source the library and no longer pretend it is his own work.

Answer (score 2):

That is an excellent idea because Stack Overflow has potential to generate such documentation. 
However, doing that manually may be rather time-consuming. So can we do it automatically and users can manually edit it?
Recently, I employed some data mining methods in Stack Overflow data and built a prototype website which may be potential to finish this task in https://graphofknowledge.appspot.com/. 
[image]

I also started it with tags. And given a tag, our website can return its definition, asking trend, fine-grained (yearly) knowledge graph, top-voted questions, code snippets (optional) and popular links.

Of course, it needs to be improved a lot.But it makes me believe that Stack Overflow can be used to generate documentation and documentation will be a good expansion of Stack Overflow

Answer (score 2):

To add another example, the documentation for the Python Google API (for realtime, [Google Docs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Docs), [Google App Engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_App_Engine), [Blobstore](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/), etc.) is extremely unhelpful, and I often find myself reading through the source code itself because it's more useful "documentation."

And sometimes I have to tweak the code a bit just to get it working without bugs. Yet from the amount of questions about this software I'd like to think that there exists a community that would be willing to create documentation for this, so it might be one use-case we would try.

Answer (score 2):

I admit to not having read all four pages of this, but I have the first three. In that time I saw (what I feel) the biggest issue only mentioned once. (Okay I skimmed the first three, so I may have missed a couple.)

One of the biggest problems with this idea that I see is 'What is documentation?'

**The Major Questions**

When most people consult documentation they are looking for answers to one of five questions. (I am referring to classes/methods/functions here. Data members (variables) are usually much simpler.)

1. **What Does This Do**
   This refers to what does this method accomplish. Any good documentation must address the concept of what a method is for. What does it do? What changes does it make? For simple getters and setters this would seem trivial, but for a method which makes a change based on a complicated set of analysis, the documentation could get quite extensive.
2. **How Does This Do It?** This is often overlooked, and needs to be represented. In Python, for example, when a method returns a value, it is often a memory pointer to the existing stored value. But what if it was a true deep copy? More memory would be consumed, a few more clock cycles used, and altering one would not effect the other. The How **needs** to be addressed.
3. **Why Is This Done** (don't start screaming) An often quoted expression in Python is "Code is read far more often than it is written.", and this is quite true. If a coder on a development team were to die, and his part be taken over by a new coder, this part of the documentation would be essential. Not understanding what has gone before simply leads to recommitting the mistakes of the past. If a method were coded because it was needed to correct a problem that crept in from somewhere else, then say so.  If it is a bug fix, then for what bug? While not needed every time, since the reason is quite often obvious, this is one of the 'big 5' reasons people consult documentation.
4. **When Is This Done**  This is another one that does not always apply.  In many cases code must be executed in a certain order, or a new coming developer just needs to know where in a process to insert a new piece of code. To determine this, they turn to the documentation. If it isn't in there, then an excess of time is often needed to *diagnose* an answer to what should have been a simple question. Caller graphs are wonderful for this, providing a quick easily-viewed reference of the timing.
5. **Parameters / Returns (Values and Types)**  This should be a no-brainer, but it is often omitted, especially in languages where documents usually show the parameters in the constructor. The problem (which I address further as the latter part of this) is the new coder. I CAN code C. I suck at it, but I can do it. Figuring out return types from C code has caused me much greef over the years. Returns and parameters need to be explicitly mentioned for another reason as well. Overloaded methods, and / or languages (again like Python) which allow for multiple return types, from a single method. What is returned, and why, and (in rare cases) how it should be used, can be essential.
6. **The Other Questions** Other major reasons exist for consulting documentation, and they often define what needs to be there.

   - What errors could occur;
   - What errors are handled internally (possibly even *how* they are handled. Swallowed, corrected, passed off, what?);
   - (For GUI-type libraries) What signals/events do they catch (are they aware of, do the send, etc.) and with what data?

The list is HUGE as to what could be needed. Perhaps a method needs to exist where what is required for a project/language/library to be set by a user or a moderator.

**Part One Summary**

In short, just like a programmer needs to try to find a way to handle all of the crap a user can throw at the program so as to avoid incidental crashes, a good documenter must also try to predict what questions the reader will be trying to answer. So good documents need to address all of the 'expected' questions, and if a question is asked repeatedly on Stack Overflow, or one of its derivatives, then it should (hopefully would) get added to the documentation.

**Part Two**

But that is the easy issue. The big issue will probably get me flamed here, but I am going to raise it anyway.

**Audience Level**

I have been slinging code since the [Commodore 64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commodore_64) was a new thing, and I was building token ring communication for it before it was three weeks old.  I say this not to impress anyone, for I am still an amateur (by choice), but rather to impress upon the readers the fact that I **KNOW** how to crawl documentation. I've been doing it so long I can learn the rudiments of any language from reading source documentation (probably).

Good documentation, and good example code, are most often written by excellent programmers. But, like anyone, they write a level of their own understanding. They most often assume a level of knowledge held by the reader that is far above the truth. I write Python code quite well, and even with years of experience and my fluidity with the code, I am baffled by list comprehensions. And I have yet to find anyone who can dumb it down enough so I can get it. So even though they are often 'best practice' I have never used one.

Documenting code by example means that anyone has to be able not only to read it, but comprehend it.

**The next person to read a set of documents may be looking at the language for the very first time.**

It is **ESSENTIAL** that all of these examples and documents be understandable by someone with very limited experience with the language.  Especially since this will come to (if successful in even a small way) dominate the first page of returns from Google. So day-one-coders, week-one-coders, and self-teachers will all wind up here. It might in fact be necessary to (I hope not) to separate the examples from the documentation, or maybe even expand to tutorials and how-tos.

**Conclusion**
API-type documentation is not the only thing needed. A developer working on a program using a library will need the API. But at some point he or she might need the developer documentation as well. Putting it all in one place would be the way to go. Examples, tutorials, how-tos, whatever Stack Overflow decides to incorporate, must be clear and concise, but complete is even more important. But over-shadowing all of this is simplicity. When I took my first ever look at [Scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheme_%28programming_language%29) a few weeks back, all of the sites on the first page of my Google search were quite advanced, so it took me a while to find what I needed. This has the potential to be **HUGE**, and rather than try to fix it later, it would be easier to set a standard now that will scale up. Stack Overflow started as a place where *programmers help programmers*, but this will turn it into something else, whether you want it to or not. A School. And if it is done right, that is a great thing. So professionals teaching the 'best practice' approach isn't what is needed in this part. This documentation project should, in the examples, show the longer approach first (for ease of understanding), then the best practice approach.

Comment: About your edit note- Answers are ordered by score by default- You can also order them by activity (editing or posting, basically) or age. Your answer is currently scored 0, and it sounds like you have the default order selected. (You can change it with the tabs at the top of the answer section.) There are answers with less score than yours, currently, so even though yours was posted later, it is posted higher. This isn't a forum, so the post order is dynamic, in an attempt to make the higher quality stuff float to the top and be more easily visible.

Comment: @Kendra I thought of/noticed that after the fact.  But I leave in the foolish as well as the good, others might be able to gain some wisdom from it.  Heck just look at what I typed.  It could definitely have been said better (OK, I should have fixed that), but the message gets accros, and it's acceptable but not good form cause one to have to think while reading it, thus more sinks in.  Good and bad both have a use.  I am actually surprised it has a positive and not a negative rating, as I said many things that your average semi-pro or professional programmer would not like/ disagree with.

Answer (score 1):

I very much like the idea, and think that it could develop into a useful tool. I understand the difficulty with trying to create a hierarchical structure, but tags are difficult to sort through. Is there some consideration being given to semantic modeling? (it wasn't a tag I could use on the beta sign-up.)

Answer (score 1):

I added this to my [Y Combinator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y_Combinator_%28company%29) application's extra ideas part. (It wasn't accepted.) I really thought this topic through, how it should be, how it's going to make the world a really better place, because it will directly affect the rate at which technology is developed.

> If you had any other ideas you considered applying with, please list
> them. One may be something we've been waiting for. Often when we fund
> people it's to do something they list here and not in the main
> application.
>
> Wiki - examples - overflow: People don’t learn from
> definitions, people learn from examples. It is Wikipedia model for
> examples that can teach any topic.

I would like to contribute more than the regular "beta user".

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Comment: I was reading the answers and then this... I started to laugh, thx GEOCHET to make me laugh... it doesn't happen often these days...

Comment: Hooray for a sense of humor bob, something too many people seem to lack.

Comment: A day I read somewhere (I don't remember the source) « Humor it's a serious thing, people without humor aren't serious »

Answer (score -9):

The project has power, but the idea itself should change.

**Documentation should not contain working examples**, but fragments of code only if needed to better illustrate the topic during explanation.

Stack Overflow is a Q&A site: examples should be the goal of that part of it!
My idea of Documentation is much more like the Javadoc-style: each unit has its own brief description, and that's all.

I like that user interface.
Don't forget to permalink everything!

Comment: What about api docs ? Ever looked at swagger.io ?

Comment: @lxx Those are the Javadocs.

Comment: javadocs don't cut it anymore especially for web api's and services