# Naming the Documentation Feature

Tags: discussion, documentation

In ["Warlords of Documentation: Your Quest(ions Answered)"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306213/warlords-of-documentation-your-questions-answered), [Kevin Montrose](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/80572/kevin-montrose) mentioned:

> #### Is Documentation the right name?
>
> This is a tricky one, as there seems to be a fair amount of variance in what people consider documentation to be.  Are the long form articles on MSDN or http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/ documentation?  What if they’re linked from a class’s page?  And so on.  “Tutorials” or “Examples” feel too limiting, at least to me, considering that *some* type/member-level documentation will almost certainly exist.
>
> For now we’re sticking with the Documentation name, at least until the beta starts, but we are **[taking suggestions](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1I35fakw7EOhu0p-5YZ_VqXcTWtQ8VEa2DY7TbG_fCyc/viewform)** .

Knowing that [naming things is hard](http://zzzzbov.com/blag/two-hard-things), I'd like to see a bit of transparency on the naming side if this thing...that and I can't think of a good name myself, so I'm hoping the community will throw out some suggestions that we can rally around.

I was thinking that in the tradition of Stack Overflow and Server Fault we should use a name referencing an error of some sort. I was tossing around the idea of suggesting the name use a particular status code, but then of course it might prevent people from finding information relating to that status code (try finding information about server faults these days, it's buried a bit by the site itself).

So, what should we call the Documentation site?

---

**Please note: Docs won't live as a stand-alone site; they'll be a part of Stack Overflow.** They'll likely get their own top-level nav item ("Questions, Tags, Users, ... Docs"). We're naming that tab (conceptually), not naming a brand new site.

---

#### Disclaimer:

Voting on answers to this question should be used for weighing in on the merits of suggestions and remixing ideas to get the best name possible. **In the end you still need to submit suggestions via the [link to the form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1I35fakw7EOhu0p-5YZ_VqXcTWtQ8VEa2DY7TbG_fCyc/viewform)**.

Comment: That's a good point he made about tutorials and examples. While some documentations (Android, MSDN) have examples, I wouldn't consider an 'example' as documentation at face-value. I'm still struggling to come up with a word that explains 'documentation, tutorials, examples' and others all at once.

Comment: @JeremyBanks, if it's part of SO (like `name.stackoverflow.com`) then maybe simply "docs" would work.

Comment: A novice's perception of documentation: The `x-files`.

Comment: How do you vote for the `Documentation` name?

Comment: Not worth an actual answer, but: `:help *` (even though Vi actually takes you to the documentation for what happens when you press `*` in normal mode).

Comment: Are you still taking suggestions?

Comment: @TheBlastOne, yes and no, you can feel free to post whatever you'd like, but from the sounds of feedback I've received from mods/SO people, they're not really going to use any of the names we come up with here because the docs part of the site is going to be a part of the main site, rather than a separate site.

Comment: This is now live on SO. Based on my experience so far, I think it should be most accurately named "Collection of random crap".

That's the most honest name I could come up with. "Documentation" implies something that is structured, correct, on-topic and written by a person with deep knowledge of the topic. "Documentation" fulfils none of that.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

## Null Reference

It's not explicitly a type of error but it's close to one, fitting the theme and mild self-deprecation of Stack Overflow's name, and "reference" encompasses more possible uses than "documentation".

Besides, what's the fun in a name that doesn't ruin the searchability of a common error?

Comment: *"Besides, what's the fun in a name that doesn't ruin the searchability of a common error?"* How about StackTrace?

Comment: Absolutely love this, especially the play on words with "Reference"

Comment: *Ha!* Didn't expect a suggestion to come up outside the defaults ("docs.stackoverflow.com" et al.) that would actually be cool. It happened now - a name that actually continues in the vein of the original site's naming, nice.

Comment: Problem though: the .com domain is (predictably) taken. But that'd probably be a solvable problem.

Comment: Either "Reference" or "Library" would be good as part of the name.

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå, StackTrace is an excellent idea, why haven't you posted it?

Comment: I love the play on words too, but I can't get behind it because the one *reference* that this name makes to documentation is the term *reference*, and it seems that *reference documentation* is the least focused upon type of documentation. It seems that the main focus is on examples and tutorials and canonical articles. To that end, I think something more along the line of *cookbook* makes the most sense, but I can't think of a good play on words that incorporates that.

Comment: @Pekka웃 just do what startups do, remove/replace a few vowels and we're golden: "Nil Reference", "Null Refyrence", etc `:P`

Comment: This. This should be the name. I can see it now...

Comment: @Cupcayk good idea!

Comment: @Cupcake How about [nullref.io](http://nullref.io) -- startupy-enough for you? ;)

Comment: how about pebkac.com?

Comment: There's a bit of a misunderstanding here: **Docs won't live as a stand-alone site, they'll be a part of Stack Overflow**. They'll likely get their own top-level nav item ("Questions, Tags, Users, ... Docs"). We're naming that tab (conceptually), not naming a brand new site. "Questions, Tags, Users, ... Null Reference" doesn't make much sense. "Tutorials" could work, or maybe even "Refs", but it should be in that vein.

Comment: @DavidFullerton "Docs won't live as a stand-alone site, they'll be a part of Stack Overflow" I don't recall seeing that posted anywhere (Did I miss that detail somewhere?). Is that an official stance? If so, why wasn't it mentioned in the previous posts? It makes a difference on the types of names that would be appropriate to suggest.

Comment: As a thought, the part of the site could be named "Null Reference", but it could live at `reference.stackoverflow.com` and links to it could simply say "Reference" or similar.

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå: posted your proposal as an answer. If you intended to post it yourself, please tell and I will delete mine or try to transfer rights. [Naming the Documentation Feature](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/306481)

Comment: @zzzzBov it was mentioned in the previous comments I believe.  In the posts themselves I referred to Documentation as _part of Stack Overflow_ , and answered why we were starting with Stack Overflow instead of other Stack Exchange sites.  This was perhaps a little too implicit (the majority of the submissions to the Google form **are** using the "part of Stack Overflow"-interpretation though), so I'll be adding a new FAQ to the second meta post here in a second.

Comment: @KevinMontrose, keep in mind, Stack Exchange was just renamed to Stack Overflow, which makes "Super User and Server Fault are a part of Stack Overflow" a true statement.

Comment: @zzzzBov Documentation was announced before the company name change, though the follow up post did come after.  Also that statement actually isn't true, it's "Stack Overflow [the company] owns Super User and Server Fault [the websites], which are a part of the Stack Exchange network".  Stack Exchange wasn't made defunct by the company name change, as [noted in the blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/09/were-changing-our-name-back-to-stack-overflow/) - "Our Q&A sites will still be collectively known as the Stack Exchange Network."

Comment: Perhaps Null References? Pluralizing it kind of seems like the way to go, IMO.

Comment: @StevenDoggart In your [comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306346/naming-the-documentation-feature#comment249160_306380), I very much like your concept of a *"cookbook."* Please see [my proposal](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306346/naming-the-documentation-feature#comment250046_306456) which your comment inspired.

Answer (score 62):

## StackTrace

> Got an error? Read the StackTrace!

Proposed by Bjørn-Roger Kringsjå [in a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306346/naming-the-documentation-feature#comment248988_306380), but definitely deserves to be a voteable answer. Ruins the searchability of a common solution!

Comment: Great idea. I suggested this for the developer story, but I think it makes more sense for the docs feature

Answer (score 48):

I blatantly stole this from @miva2's comment, but it's too good to be buried in the comments:

### DocOverflow

Comment: I like DocOverflow for 2 reasons.  Firstly it links quite obviously to StackOverflow but also It is a place where overflow (eg extra) documentation lives.

Comment: Well.... it would have to be "*Doc Overflow*" to fit in with the rest of the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: @TinyGiant we're not trying to fit in with the rest of the stack exchange network yet, are we?

Comment: @McAdam331: As in the legal names of things on the Stack Exchange network contain spaces between the words.

Answer (score 38):

I think a pitfall of using 'Documentation' is it is broad and in no way related to StackOverflow. If someone has a question about (for example) Android, and I say "have you checked the Documentation for any help?" The other person won't know if I mean the StackOverflow Documentation, or the actual Android documentation.

For that reason, I believe we should come up with something that associates it with StackOverflow, and can be used in a conversation when offering help. Some silly examples:

- Have you checked the **StackFiles**?
- The **StackDocs** has some good information on this topic.
- I learned how to do it on **DocumentationOverflow**.

To me these sound kind of silly, but I don't think they're unreasonable. The important aspect that I wanted to contribute to this conversation is something that cannot be misconceived for another form of documentation, and can be clearly understood in conversation.

Comment: ...Stack Manual, Manual Overflow

Comment: @zzzzBov Stackipedia.

Comment: @McAdam I think your first two, or a variation of them, aren't bad. And good point about it being obvious *what* documentation someone is talking about.

Comment: @codeMagic Thanks. I look forward to telling people to RTFSF/RTFSD.

Comment: I like DocumentationOverflow! or just DocOverflow for short.

Comment: While this prototype is designed for SO, we don't want to go too far into a naming scheme that makes future expansions to other SE sites much harder to name.

Comment: @NathanTuggy valid point, but I don't think expansion into other sites was a consideration, since we're discussing tech documentation. However, that last idea could be easily switched to `DocumentationExchange`.

Comment: @McAdam331: I know once the feature is done I'll be pushing for its implementation over on ELL. We've got a limited set of current posts that could really use this treatment.

Comment: @cybermonkey it does or does not? Mine has no spaces, but your comment does and it contradicts itself.

Comment: **StackDocs** - I like this a lot. +1

Comment: ..., MemoryOverflow. But maybe it's too far-fetched and I admit I like "DocOverflow" as proposed by @miva2 better. Generally I agree with the point that it should be clearly understandable in conversation and - for me - this includes that it should not be too similar to "StackOverflow". So how do we find a name close enough to show the link, but different enough to not be mixed-up?

Comment: @miva2 glad you liked it! I went to the link and submitted it as my suggestion. If you feel that strongly about it, I'd recommend you do the same, hopefully that will help the moderators!

Answer (score 23):

## "Help us build a great library of canonical answers" - Joel Spolsky

[image]

This is what it would look like as one of the nav buttons on the main site.

## ***Canonicals***

This is the name I submitted using the link from the main question ([Warlords of Documentation: Your Quest(ions Answered)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/306213/1026459)).

The reason is that almost every active user on Stack Overflow is aware of what a canonical post is. Yet given that it is a widespread theme there is no special place for those types of posts on the site. Further, there is not even a construct for how to properly make one.

Making a canonical post is *very* hard and the users who successfully create them tend to be very respected users in those topics with a lot of reputation. I think one of the most famous ones is Felix Kling's ajax post ([How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/1026459)).

*This new "Documentation" feature is in my opinion the perfect place to house a project for canonical posts.*

- It has requests which should highlight the need for canonical posts (this in itself is very hard to identify today)
- It will be a place to search for canonical posts only as opposed to finding them intermingled in "the wild" (SO main)
- It will provide a construct for creating examples that many users can share in cultivating and maintaining
- It will separate content in a meaningful way making it both easier to find *and* create
- It will solve the issue of trying to name a canonical post to be something that google finds
- Using the canonical guidelines which already exist to some degree in the community will give a stronger direction for the type of content being created
- It will remove the disparity between taking over simple MSDN (or related vendor documentation) property names and descriptions and drive the creation of content related to using those properties while still retaining the ability to link to actual vendor documentation
- When there is a void of actual vendor documentation, a canonical post is best suited to not only avoid stepping on the toes of the vendor but also to creating a place where people can expect to see some examples with rigor that are accepted by the community

Documentation is simply *not* what the project is. Documentation often includes small snippets but the community here on Stack Overflow has far more rigor than the average vendor. As a community, we will create fully scrubbed content in this place and it deserves to be akin to a description such as "according to or ordered by canon law" more than something which resembles a stack of paper or a 3-ring binder.

> **Stack Overflow is not meant to be a library of reference manuals.** It's supposed to contain the same information as a library of reference manuals, in the form of millions of questions and answers. Combined with Google, that gives us the magical power of a library of reference manuals you never have to read! It's like, you got to the library, and there's a wizard there at the door, and you ask your question, and, instead of being told to read a book, you just got (are you sitting down?) the actual answer! - [Joel Spolsky](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/)

Comment: "Documentation is simply not what the project is" - I haven't seen anything that says the project is going to do more than be documentation. Examples are documentation. Samples are documentation. API details are documentation. I think the difference with this project is the focus on quality at scale. It seems to me that the plan is to (1) make more documentation (2) better. This is A Good Thing™ IMO.

Comment: @zzzzBov - The goal to make documentation better by doing documentation the exact same way everyone else does (clear correlation to MSDN styling being used) and then calling it the same exact name everyone else calls it does not necessarily lend itself to improvement. That would simply be a relocation. Relocation does not accomplish the goal of the project. In order to improve the ability to use vendor code, a place for the community to create not only examples but the set of exposed features is very important. That to me is not *simply* documentation. It is a set of canonical posts.

Comment: I hope to cut this debate short by saying that my definition of "documentation" is broad enough to encompass everything I've been hearing about with the coming changes, in the same way that my definition of "Q&A" is broad enough to include Stack Overflow, where many would argue that it is so much more than Q&A. I'm not saying that the name should be "Documentation", I'm just saying that it meets my definition of the word.

Comment: @zzzzBov - The word is very broad, "a set of documents". So sure, it can be anything and include everything written. I am technically creating a documentation of my point right now. As a result, it is so broad that there is no actual definition aside from what the current status quo of documentation is - a place where there is a bland list of properties and fields, perhaps some remarks, and if you are lucky an example or two. Using the name documentation gives the guidance to reproduce that. The guidance should be narrowed to something more inline with what the community should produce.

Comment: Regardless of its meaning, a broad word is broad for search engines too. Querying `Map<K,V> Documentation` on google nearly makes no sense, and one would end up appending SO, like `Map Documentation StackOverflow`, or ending in another website, for the first months at least. `Map<K,V> Canonicals`, on the other hand, looks focused, unused, and would definitely point you here.

Comment: +0. This is a very good idea in many ways, but given that my main concerns with the proposal had to do with canonicity (in a different sense) I unfortunately can't subscribe to it.

Comment: @duplode - We already have canonical posts here. They are not vendor documentation. In fact, the whole point of this naming convention is a departure from the idea of documenting, which would be in line with your concern about avoiding "user-submitted content as documentation." User submitted content would not be documentation, it would be a set of canonical posts requested by the community and actioned by the community. This would yield the benefit of aiming more towards the classical approach to examples and solutions that Stack Overflow excels at, and away from mimicking documentation.

Comment: @TravisJ I get that you are using "canonical" with the meaning it has within Stack Overflow, and in that sense "a place for canonical Q&As" is a great description of the project. What I mean is that the name you proposed is *also* subtly subversive. "Canonical" implies "backed by authority" (e.g. ecclesiastical authority behind canon law). Your suggestion suggests a shift of authority from vendors to the community at large, and that is why I sensed a tension between it and my own concerns...

Comment: @TravisJ ... however, unfolding the argument in this way makes your idea appear even more clever than it did at first, and so I will upvote it anyway :)

Comment: I haven't heard of canonical answer before reading this post.

Comment: Read about it from Joel Spolsky http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/ . Have you heard of him?

Comment: Canonical is the company behind Ubuntu, and we already have a Stack Exchange site about that distro.

Comment: Reading through all the suggestions, this is still my favorite. It hints at what it is, and for lack of a better description, just feels like a nice word.

Comment: Us Python folks already collect canonical question/answers. It seems like it has a pretty huge overlap with SOD

Answer (score 21):

Assuming [David Fullerton's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306346/naming-the-documentation-feature#comment249301_306380) is correct in that the documentation feature will be a part of Stack Overflow rather than its own site, I propose:

### Library

as in:

### library.stackoverflow.com

Because libraries are where you find all sorts of important information, not just books, but also movies, magazines, images, etc.

---

<sub>I am intentionally posting this separate from [my previous "library" related answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/306354/497418) because this one is geared towards being used as a subdomain instead of as a stand-alone site name. Do not hesitate to downvote this answer into oblivion as well, but please try to suggest better alternatives while doing so.</sub>

Comment: "To the book depository!" -- Homer Simpson

Comment: This could also be extended to *code library*

Answer (score 17):

## Examples

[image]

The end result here is that there is going to be a structure of topics that are easily (hopefully) accessed. Each topic will have sets of examples and remarks.

> "Topics always have **Examples** and **Remarks**; other sections are optional.
>
> Examples are collapsible and deeplink-able. We're putting them at the top of the page because we believe they're the most important - the information you desire is likely within them. We're expecting Topics to have more Examples than Questions have Answers, since Topics will be broader than Questions."  *[Warlords of Documentation: A Proposed Expansion of Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303865/warlords-of-documentation-a-proposed-expansion-of-stack-overflow)*

I have already written about what would be beneficial about using a recognizable name and why I disagree with "Documentation" in a [previous answer here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/306387/1026459) where I suggested Canonicals. While I still think that is a good name, perhaps using the name Examples will appeal to a larger group of people.

The word is widely understood and users would know what to expect for the most part.

The idea behind focusing on Examples is not only prevalent in the main post, but it was also the point behind the top voted answer (+652 at the moment) on that post

> "**Yes**! I support this idea, if the focus is to create **examples**." *[Zanon](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303885/1026459)*

Examples seems tempting to click.

Comment: If I were on stackoverflow, I would assume "examples" would contain examples of good questions to ask on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 12):

## Reference

As per David's comment on https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/306380/242:

> Docs won't live as a stand-alone site, they'll be a part of Stack Overflow. They'll likely get their own top-level nav item ("Questions, Tags, Users, ... Docs").

So if I was on StackOverflow, looking for some more in depth info on a topic, clicking a tab called 'Reference' would make pretty good sense to me.

Answer (score 6):

## Guides

This is short form of "User Guides" that seems to fit with other tab names, i.e., "Questions, Guides, Tags, Users, ...". It signals that it's an important and integrated part of this site, not a separate site.

Answer (score 3):

In his [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306346/naming-the-documentation-feature#comment249160_306380), Steven Doggart suggests the concept of a *cookbook*. Excerpt:

> It seems that the main focus is on examples and tutorials and
>   canonical articles. To that end, I think something more along the line
>   of *cookbook* makes the most sense, but I can't think of a good play on
>   words that incorporates that.

I like the cookbook concept. Consider that O'Reilly has published an extensive [series of books](http://shop.oreilly.com/category/series/cookbooks.do) based on the concept. Is the new content we envision for StackOverflow of to be of a similar nature?

Additionally, as I write, I believe that the [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/306456/1497596) by zzzzBov is the only one that specifically proposes creating a new sub-domain for the new content: **library.stackoverflow.com**

So, if what we're really trying to build is a collection of recipes (as opposed to an arguably broader reference library), I propose this alternative sub-domain: **cookbook.stackoverflow.com**

Answer (score 3):

I propose:

### CodeWiki

> -How do you use it?
>
> -Check CodeWiki!

Everybody knows that wiki means information. It's natural.

Comment: That name is already taken: http://codewiki.wikidot.com/

Comment: @shelvacu - 90% of proposed names are "taken". For me, it means it's a good idea :)

Answer (score 2):

## Margin(s)

For when you have

> a truly marvelous [example to solve this problem]

but it just needs a Margin that's large enough...

Answer (score 0):

I add another proposal:

### Wiki

> -How do you use it?
>
> -Check Wiki on StackOverflow!

Everybody knows that wiki means information. It's natural and simple.

Answer (score -1):

I propose...

**RTFM**

or if you want to be more pleasant and stick with the error theme, maybe something like

**ClassNotFound**

or maybe going old school with

**Study Hall**

or maybe they still have those. Anyway, I don't know if this would only have meaning for certain regions or not. But if it would be meaningful enough then it would cover docs, tuts, examples, etc...

Comment: I had considered proposing "404 101", but RTFM is an excellent choice.

Comment: @zzzzBov oooh, 404 is good too. Now I'm torn

Comment: And of course RTFM would stand for "Read This Fantastic Manual"

Comment: @zzzzBov of course! What else would it stand for? ;)

Comment: Sorry, but I just cannot endorse RTFM.

Comment: haha @bluefeet no worries. That was more for fun because...meta. That's why I also posted a couple serious options. :P

Comment: You forget @codeMagic that we hate fun.

Comment: @bluefeet I don't forget, I just hate haters of fun. I'm a rebel like that :)

Comment: +1 only because RTFM is funny, not because I really think that should be the name

Comment: Not mine but it's an oldie and goodie: I'd RTFM if there was a FM to FR.

Answer (score -7):

**F1** (<kbd>F1</kbd>)

I don't think it needs explaining, which is kind of the point. If it does then I'll take my failing like a man...

*f1.stackoverflow.com*

Plus it won't interfere with search results when people search specific errors like the "Server Fault" example.

---

I appreciate the traditional naming convention of errors, but this isn't a traditional SE site *per se.*

People searching for an error resolution would go to one of those named sites, whereas people looking for *more info* would come to **F1**

Comment: Really needs explaining. Is this a Windows thing?

Comment: Guess this is me taking it like a man then! Yes, predominantly a Windows thing - the F1 function key is  the usual go-to for "more info"

Comment: What do racecars have to do with it?

Comment: @JoshCaswell Because also when you land on the page it would play a noise like "nnnnnneeeeeeeeeeoooowwwwnnnnn" :)

Comment: Now _that_ I could get behind.

Answer (score -8):

## Documentation

The original name.

Answer (score -10):

This will probably get downvoted like the other Knowledge answer, but how about:

## Knowledge Overflow

To me, the problem with *Documentation* is that it suggests to me that the information came from the developers. "Documentation" is one of the things development involves.

And what you want to create here is really a knowledge base, despite the fact that many commercial companies have already used "knowledge base" for their own inaccessible and unhelpful collections of articles. Ahem. Your new site is supposed to contain information which is not merely an explanation of what's going on in the code, but also how-tos, examples, warnings about pitfalls. Knowledge.

And "knowledge" doesn't imply any connection to the original developers.

Now, coupling this with "Overflow" you both get the branding thing, and an implication that there is a fountain overflowing with knowledge here.

<sub>Though I'd probably want to avoid this:</sub>

[image]
<sub>(source: [basementrejects.com](http://basementrejects.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/fantasia-2000-sorcerer.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score -11):

Condensed from my original post (see edit history):

## Syntax Error

In the vein of Stack Overflow being a programming problem (the name an example of the types of things the site hopes to address) and Server Fault being a configuration or hardware problem (also a good example), I feel that Syntax Error is a good way to summarize a problem which occurs from **incomplete understanding of the technology or tools used**.

Comment: That was a fast downvote.

Comment: Which, if any, did you like?

Comment: Well some of your suggestions are already separated out, and I've voted on them already.  Really, I'm not a fan of anything from 8-14.  Basically, I think you shotgunned your answer too much.

Comment: That much is true. Hmm, should I just remove those, or make a new answer and delete this one, or what?

Comment: I actually kinda like Syntax Error...

Comment: I'm going to remove my extraneous answers; they'll still be in the edit history.

Answer (score -14):

## Farbizzle

Because it makes about as much sense as the majority of the other suggestions.

The point is that the name doesn't matter yet. "Documentation" is better than any solution mentioned here until we actually figure out what it is all going to be about, which won't be until *after* we've actually used it.

We could all be [doing much better things with our time](http://blog.codinghorror.com/meta-is-murder/) than discussing what we should name a feature whose purpose we don't even fully understand yet.

Comment: If **you** have better things to do, I suggest you do them. I enjoy coming up with names for things, and this is where I intend on doing just that. [It's ok if you hate fun](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/), but this is meta and I fully intend to have fun naming stuff.

Answer (score -15):

To extend @codeMagic answer

### RTSM

Read the Stack Manual

### RTSD

Read the StackDocs

Answer (score -15):

## No Comment

- comments are important kind of documentation
- has the twist required for Stack Exchange site
- indicates the problem the website tries to solve - lack of documentation
- set phrase you would use when you don't want to answer an unpleasant question, e.g. *Why don't you write documentation?*
- `nocomment.com` is registered but not used
- typography:

***//*** no **comment**

***#*** no **comment**

Answer (score -16):

## Man Page or Man Pages

A little on the unixy side, but `man` is the command you run when you want to learn more about another command.  Conveniently, manpage.com is advertised as being for sale, and manpages.com is sporting your garden variety squater page.

Comment: Of course this causes the mind to wander to "Man Overflow".... which might not be intended.

Comment: man pages are actually a real thing. The last thing you want to do is confuse people as to what they are.

Comment: I don't think this would sit too well with a certain (female) group of the programmers community. _(Even though it has nothing to do with that)_.

Comment: The reference is lost to people outside the *nix community, so I don't think it's such a great suggestion.

Answer (score -18):

I suggested the somewhat boring "KnowledgeBase" or "KnowledgeSource"

I puked a little into my mouth as I did so, based on how boring and rote the suggestion was.

Comment: Microsoft already has the Knowledge Base market cornered

Comment: Since SO relies on content from users, I suggest "Knowledge Generation Base". KGB for short.

Comment: @approxiblue thats a very dated name, surely we should be the Federation of SourceCode Buddies - FSB for short

Comment: @Jamiec Fair point, but I think FSB wouldn't have nearly the same brand recognition.

Comment: I suggested the same thing, actually. It's pretty bla, but it kinda works.

Answer (score -20):

Stackumentation was my first thought, but realized its sexist (stack__you__men___tation), so that's a no go.

There are things called eBooks.

So we could name this eDocs?

Or Virtual Docs? jk

Or maybe StackEdocs?

The unicorn is the unofficial mascot of SO, and it's most notable feature is its horn. So we could go with Horn eDocs? Or maybe that should just be specific to health.SE documentation.

Comment: I'm upvoting you just for the hilariousness of turning 'documentation' into a sexist word.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/1562/

Comment: You object to the syllable "men" but not the prefix "horny"?

Comment: `but realized its sexist` How in the hell did you come to the conclusion that a word with `men` in it is sexist? Are comments sexist, then?

Comment: Yes Rob it is, clearly we need to have more comwoments

Comment: @Rob Yes, that [triggers me](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/trigger)

Answer (score -23):

How about

### Manual Newer

Named after Manuel Neuer?