# Stack Overflow - Serving Programmers Even Better

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs, old-teams, documentation

In 2008, we set out to solve a problem that plagued every programmer in the world: the lack of an information resource that was free, vetted and maintained by programmers, where the best information rose to the top. It quickly became obvious that, together, we had achieved an amazing success.

As a community, we've always stood firmly against fluff-and-creep, decrying complexity in favor of continuing to develop the one thing that we have come to do very well - just like Curly:

[image: Curly]

Objective Q&A has come to be our hallmark, but there was something else that eluded us as a company for some years to come; we were extremely good at giving programmers exactly what they [need](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000043.html) and [deserve](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-programmers-bill-of-rights/), which didn't always include everything that they want. Q&A has been, and will always be, the core of our business, but our "one thing" turned out to be much simpler than we thought. **We relentlessly aspire to fanatically serve the way that programmers learn and grow professionally.**

A couple of years ago, we started having internal discussions that sounded like this:

> *What else do programmers need that they're not getting good enough solutions for elsewhere?*

Now, we've declined *many* requested features for fear that they would detract from the value and exposure of our core Q&A, and we held ourselves to the same standard in order to come up with ideas for making Stack Overflow serve all of you better. And most of this isn't new to Meta regulars, but here's the big picture view of roughly how things will look as we integrate Documentation, Teams, and Jobs into Stack Overflow:

[image: tentative]

That's right, everything under one roof and one account, available to you when and if you want or need it. Why *these* things?

#### Programmers need and deserve vetted, up-to-date documentation.

Some things have obsessively-curated and up-to-date documentation with plenty of practical examples that illustrate real-world use cases. So, we're going to focus on the *other* 97% of documentation.

It's one thing to list the order, types, and purpose of arguments along with the various things that something can return; it's another to actually *teach* people how to use it through examples that experienced programmers write and vet. We're used to anticipating questions people are likely to have - documentation and examples are a *great* place for us to put our collective insight and experience to work. We'll be talking about it more as it evolves.

#### Programmers need and deserve jobs that they love.

Some of you might remember back in early 2009 when user profiles had a check box that said *I'm interested in receiving job offers from employers*. That's how long we've been working on getting programmers the jobs that they deserve. Stack Overflow Careers is now a mature product, and it's time to bring it back to the main site instead of having it live in an annex.

We're going to get this integrated pretty soon, and it should fit neatly under the new "Jobs" tab:

[image: Return of the Jobs]

Many of you reading this have great jobs that you love, but *many more* do not, and don't realize that Stack Overflow has a product that could help get them a much better job. Some might have poked at it, but got lost in the hassle of having to sign up all over again and tell us things they thought we already knew about them. We always intended for it to be an integral part of the main site; it's time to make that happen.

We'll be talking more about Stack Overflow Jobs in the near future, and how we're taking on a new shared enemy — the horribly broken process of recruiting and hiring programmers. Because our name isn't $CANDIDATE and we don't even know Flash.

#### Programmers share a special kind of pride in what they do.

Working closely with other people on something that many come to value and enjoy brings a certain kind of ownership, a very special type of camaraderie, and a pride that many equate to parenting children. The way you collaborate builds awesome things; we've always wanted a way to let you make that collaboration part of your Stack Overflow presence.

The integration of Jobs gave us the inspiration that led to Teams. Your company can show off how lucky they are to have you, as well as the awesome things about working there that led you to join them. You can stand next to not just the people you make awesome stuff with during the day, but also the people you work with as you chip away at your open source projects in your spare time.

People will be able to interact with teams and companies that build the things that they use every day in a way that wasn't possible before on Stack Overflow, without detracting from the high-signal business of objective Q&A.

Want to use Teams without any of that Jobs business? Go ahead; we're good with that.

#### It's all there *when you need it*.

For many users, it should be a lot easier having all these things in one place. For those who only choose to use Q&A, or Docs, the rest will be waiting patiently out of the way. Two resounding, non-negotiable criteria were paramount in every decision that we made:

- Nothing can detract from core Q&A. Losing our focus on what we've built together is not an option.
- Don't annoy people with things that aren't relevant to their interests.

You may not need a job. You may have the entire C standard memorized and not need documentation. You might work from home because you find coworkers to be inconvenient distractions, and you prefer to keep people guessing. None of this is going to get in the way of how you've become accustomed to using the site.

#### So, what's next?

Documentation and Teams are currently in private beta. You can sign up ( [here for Documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306213/warlords-of-documentation-your-questions-answered) | [here for Teams](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307513/the-power-of-teams-a-proposed-expansion-of-stack-overflow) ) if you haven't yet and you want to check them out. While they're both still a bit rough around the edges, we're pretty sure you'll have a great time exploring them, and we'd love to have your feedback. As both come out of beta, you'll see them in the top navigation.

Very soon, we're also going to be eliminating the need to have two different logins between Stack Overflow and Careers. Careers will be accessible under the 'Jobs' tab in the top nav as shown, and all of the Jobs-related navigation will live within that tab. Once we have the logistics of bringing everything together ironed out, we'll share a more detailed plan and ask for feedback.

Again, all of this is still in the rough, but we wanted to share as early as we could. If you have questions, please feel free to post them. There's simply not enough room to cover all of it in a single post; we will be sharing more to cover each project in more detail in the very near future. We hope you're as excited as we are.

Comment: /me is sad they're not good enough for private betas -- but looks forward to seeing when these things happen.

Comment: @TZHX it's not about being not good enough! At this point it's entirely random chance. Your time will come. :)

Comment: _"Very soon, we're also going to be eliminating the need to have two different logins between Stack Overflow and Careers."_ Just for clarification sake, and I may have missed something, but does this mean that anyone who has a Stack Overflow account will already have a Careers account, or will that part of the site still need an "activation" of sorts? (If the answer is "Wait for the more detailed post for info on that" I'm cool with that.)

Comment: @Kendra More details to come, but they'll just act like two sections of the same site. You'll still have full control over whether you want your career information to be publicly visible -- we won't suddenly start sharing private data.

Comment: @DavidFullerton Cool- Can't wait for more details on this one! :)

Comment: @Haney: So TZHX wasn't good enough for the RNG.

Comment: @BoltClock That's probably fortunate, the RNG hasn't seen a dentist in _years_.

Comment: This seems pretty cool to me, the complaints about how it will interfere with normal SO don't seem to be very valid (except maybe in the case of moderators), since it really will be more like separate sites. If you don't want Teams or Documentation, then you simply don't bother with them.

Comment: Looking forward to testing out the documentation beta but a couple of thoughts just occurred to me. Firstly, would a valid answer on SO be "Here is the docs for this thing you can't figure out"? Secondly, would we ever mark questions as a dupe of a document article?

Comment: @DonyorM: Definitely. As long as these features don't fragment the question base like they looked like they would in the beginning (Team Q&A? Ugh.). I'm still not convinced, but things are looking better.

Comment: @Linuxios yeah teams seemed like a bit of a weird concept at first, but I liked it better the more I read about it.

Comment: @DonyorM: I'm fine with it now that they put Team Q&A on hold.

Comment: @Linuxios We're going to be posting more concrete details on the implementation of all of these features, it was just not possible to get it into one post. Stay tuned, I think we've actually gotten it right.

Comment: @TimPost: OK. I'm waiting expectantly :). I'm sure you've put some thought into Team Q&A, and I'll be at that post to see where things lie now. It's great that you guys listened to the initial concerns over that feature though.

Comment: @DavidG Answers still need to do something other than make people click yet another link, even when we know the link won't break. Closing as a dupe of a canonical, with documentation as that target? It'll be a while before we can talk about that, it's just too new right now.

Comment: I hope careers is going to be much better.  I used it both to attract and get talent as well as look for other work.  It disappointed me in both ways.  It was a difficult to use, buggy system that I simply disliked.  We even do not use it any further to find candidates.  Also @TimPost where is my swag?  Its been more than 6-8 weeks.

Comment: *"Documentation and Teams are currently in private beta."* - I was invited to Teams but not to Documentation. Docs are also running for some people?

Comment: @Zanon the first round of invites for Documentation have gone out, about 1 in 30 of the people who signed up got one (chosen semi-randomly).  More waves will be invited as we a) expand to the tags they signed up for b) fix the issues discovered by earlier waves.

Comment: I'm really tired of all these memes in Stack Exchange posts...

Comment: _sigh_, this is really long to read. Can we please have a better title? Serving me better how? (Disclaimer: I am not trying to be a jerk or anything, I really love what you guys do :))

Comment: "*Don't annoy people with things that aren't relevant to their interests.*" - Thank you, thank you so much! \o/

Comment: The way you've explained this here and put it into context within SE's overarching philosophy and goals has made me far more supportive of the whole thing.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt That's a sign that you're getting old.

Comment: @JeremyBanks I guess :-/

Comment: I've just been in my most recent contract for a week - the recruiter contacted me through Stack Exchange jobs...I've only had 2 contacts through there but both were directly applicable to me and at the right rates etc. On the other hand through other sites I've had hundreds of contacts but only 1% were right for me. Quality > Quantity.

Comment: A moderator with <300 reputation.

Comment: -1 for deleting the "Ask Question" button.

Comment: @DeerHunter We can do without such peripheral functionality. Now we can just all sit here and bask in our career glory with no annoying questions that take up our attention.

Comment: I think this is missing "Programmers deserve yet another social network site". In order to aid Stack Exchange with directions on what they should focus on, I have now deleted my Careers account.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Whenever i see a meme i wince; it's like people using textspeak or smileys.

Comment: @Alex Also meme images take quite some space…

Comment: As long as you don't add _permanent part-time employment_ as an option to Careers, I don't consider it as a mature product. For reference: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243698/179891

Comment: I would like a choice with the careers, I avoid LinkedIn.. if I want to find a job, I'll do so.. I really don't want to be approached by someone I don't know off the internet.

Comment: @DeerHunter, "Ask a Question" isn't going away or being de-emphasized. It'll still be *highly* visible on pretty much every page it is today.  It never really made sense as a nav tab anyway, so it'll probably become more button-like in a TBD location on all the same pages.

Comment: @MrsEd, then you won't be approached. This is about making it *easier* for  users who want to use more features, including careers, but it won't require you to use it or hear from anyone if you don't want to.  Careers is all about trying to be the *developer's* agent in a job search, so it's up to you what contact you want, or whether you choose to use it at all.

Comment: @Jaydles - kind of agree on a separate button UX-wise. Putting all eggs into one button row is a bit messy, and doesn't make much sense, though.

Comment: @Franck Dernoncourt memes? Can you show me an example? I guess I've been fortunate in that I do not recall seeing any...

Comment: I won't say I'm against good jobs for programmers. But as Norm MacDonald says, "I come from a long line of death" - ["That's why I can't get behind politicians...'our biggest problem is unemployment!'" and I say "What about getting old and sick and dying?"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nltU_HFjqaI). What about the program for making sure programmers don't get old and sick and die?  :-/  Okay hard problem, but, a more modest goal, [why not do easy things in the channel you control and give a nicer experience to those entering your world?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265671/)

Comment: I filled the form for Beta but didn't see any change nor I received any message or so.

Comment: Mixing jobs with other items does not look good to me.

Comment: is this a done deal?  is the code already written?  are the unit tests done?  (if the code is already written and you're using TDD, then the unit tests are done) ~~ a number of our peers have expressed below why this is not a good idea ~~ examples:  Bryan Oakley and @Burhan Khalid and tinly.  *if this is* **not** *a done deal, please put it to a vote* ~~ my vote is "nay".

Comment: `A couple of years ago, we started having internal discussions that sounded like this: What else do programmers need that they're not getting good enough solutions for elsewhere?` -- I was almost sure the paragraph that would follow would have something to do with how to get dates with girls.

Comment: I'd rather not have a Jobs button anywhere on SO, please. I don't even like seeing the adds for careers on the right. It's distracting when I'm working, which is 95% of the time that I'm on SO. On bad days at work I will want to click it, and I don't need that temptation.

Comment: +1 for documents. -1 for teams/jobs...so that makes +0.

Comment: ...Well, +1 for docs, anyway :)

Comment: jobs, I have one and just looking for solutions to keep it safe.....

Comment: Is there a way I can turn both the Jobs tab off as well as the Jobs ads?

Comment: @IgbyLargeman I was thinking that was the point of it...

Comment: I am hearing about this documentation thingy since couple of months now or even more.. Did you guys started already or still it's wip?

Comment: Let it be noticed that I linked to a family guy clip about "told you so" which was deleted regarded documentation, and I noticed.  StackOverflow has done many things right, but at the same time, it looks to me like Craigslist-level stagnation... and apparently, some kind of PC deletionism... all when a documentation effort that was *soundly* advised against was pursued despite that advice.  And just as highest-bidder was rejected vs. Area51, you would do well to [listen here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358569/)...know thy community.

Answer (score 280):

My own two cents: having jobs mixed in with the Q&A part of Stack Overflow seems to make as much sense to me as including a section on ramen recipes.

Teams, I can understand. Documentation, I can understand. Unlike those sections and the normal Q&A stuff, Jobs is actually counter-productive to the goal of getting my work done.

I would prefer to see the job stuff stay separate. Or, add a section for ramen recipes.

Comment: My own opinion on this: It won't _exactly_ be mixed in- It'll be like going to Google to search for an answer to a problem you're having, and never clicking the "Gmail" button up in the corner because that's not what you're there for. It's not like you'll go to the homepage of SO and see a mix of questions and job listings... (Not counting any sidebar ads you may encounter, but those probably aren't that big a bother for you.) Now if you have a problem with the "Gmail" link distracting you when you go to Google...

Comment: I don't particularly like it being there either, but, it could benefit me too if I were to post a job listing by giving the area of the site that I posted the listing more visibility. Adblock to the rescue!

Comment: @Kendra But the mock-up does not have "Jobs" in a corner the way "Gmail" link is. It's in the middle of top navigation of the site. A closer comparison would be [this layout of Google search page](http://i.stack.imgur.com/5qqST.png).

Comment: I agree with Bryan. If the jobs tab is added to the main navigation bar, then all of a sudden, around the whole world, programmers are going to be using a job search website as part of their everyday work. Even if the programmers themselves are comfortable with this, I would think that HR departments would start getting very nervous.

Comment: @Kevin *"I would think that HR departments would start getting very nervous."* maybe that isn't such a bad thing...

Comment: @NormalHuman That example is an exaggeration the other way, SO isn't planning to insert the jobs button where the search box is. It's going into the tab arrangement in the top right, which is only a little more of a prominent place than google's links when you open their page.

Comment: Ramen is a crucial aspect of any developer's life, far more important than documentation, working in teams, or getting answers to questions. Ramen forever.

Comment: From a programmer's point of view, it make no sense: Stack's about programming, right? From a recruiting agent's point of view, you can lower a ramen noodle into one of his ears, let go, and watch it fall out of the other; while it's falling, count how many mismatched job specs, candidates & buzzwords he sends out. From a hiring manager's point of view, it means that they get an SO link that shows a recruiter *verifiably* looked at relevant keywords, and found a match that looks like the programmer the manager wanted... **TL;DR: Your error is thinking that SO is only useful for programming**.

Comment: @Kendra dude, when you click the gmail link in google, it will direct you in a different app. in our case, it is permanently mixed with Q&A core

Comment: @NormalHuman That's what I thought too. very distracting. and they even sacrifice the "Ask Question" button for "Jobs".

Comment: +1 for Ramen recipes. You might be asking for a toggle option there I guess.

Comment: If no one else does, when this roles out, I'll make an script or something that replaces the Jobs button with a link to Ramen recipes (or ask for one on meta).

Comment: Who needs Ramen recipes. Just post links to "Ramen girl" downloads, and send one Ramen instance to my office every week, that would be enough to make me buy a Ramen hat on Docs if that will have winter hats.

Comment: @Ceeee that's right they sacrificed the "Ask Question" button for "Jobs."  That's because the Jobs site [sic] makes a lot of money.

Answer (score 112):

[image]

**Please do not do this**.

I browse Stack Overflow from work; as I suspect many of us do as it's a great resource for getting stuff done.

At my workplace, career.stackexchange.com is blocked by our corporate firewall. I fear if you add this to the main Stack Overflow page, it will end up getting it blocked as well ... and then that's all she wrote.

Comment: Don't you think they specifically blocked `*.careers.*` to prevent people from looking for other jobs while on the job? I doubt they have a rule just for `career.stackexchange.com`.

Comment: If stackoverflow ever gets block at your department, that's the time to be looking for a new job anyway ;)

Comment: I think the point being made is that content irrelevant to programming could cause SO being blocked. I guess, the wife or husband might similarly block SO if SO should decide to add a "Dating" tab someday as that's also what many programmers deserve and have trouble with. In that case, it is the time to find a new Q&A website rather than a new job/spouse.

Comment: @Cerbrus some firewalls keep a list of categories for specific domains, and administrators can block based on those categories. That means an administrator could just block a "Job Search" category, and on the next update of the list after the Jobs tab is moved to the main site... you know what happens.

Comment: If your workplace blocks careers.stackexchange.com it's time to get a new job. That's almost a violation of rights!

Comment: @remus Not really, but I can see your point. I always talk about brazilian law because of my work, but Cássio said something really on point, as he is Brazilian as well. In Brazil, lots of companies (even the huge ones, even fortune 500 with offices here) have the culture to block and filter many sites - some of those companies, like Teknisa and the old RM, block even SO based on your privilege access. They keyword "Job Search" and derivates of it is commonly blocked as well. That means, for these users, their life will get complicated now. And moving to a new job is not always a option

Comment: Specially when our country is going to smithereeens and our economy is in a deep recession, and junior's got it hard to get new jobs, specially if they leave because of such rules, who are too common here. Also, [it's not a violation of rights](http://www.ambito-juridico.com.br/site/index.php?n_link=revista_artigos_leitura&artigo_id=787).

Comment: oh, just to say that I do not condone such practices - but it's really common here and nothing new. It's already a part of the corporate culture, unfortunately.

Comment: That's pretty sad. Not unsurprising at all though, and hopefully one day it won't be like that.

Comment: It would be pretty easy to present a compelling argument not to block stackoverflow.com

Comment: @CássioRenan, that only can work for non-ssl connections. Some companies might be crazy but especially junior devs may not have a lot of choice for choosing a job.

Comment: @akostadinov, SSL does not hide the domain being visited. As I said, websites are not blocked based on inspection of their content, but by having a list of domains by category. These firewalls often do, when requesting for a page from a blocked domain, just give back a page with "This domain is blocked" or similar. For HTTPS, the browser will just reject the certificate for this page, but this still effectively blocks it.

Comment: @CássioRenan, right, usually not, forgot about SNI. Without SNI and without reverse DNS though it should be hidden as far as I know. Hopefully TLS 1.3 will have some good encrypted SNI support.

Comment: "Oh, see that sweet kiddy! Uhm... Let's not do this."

Comment: @CássioRenan i think you should lookup on the technology "SSL" - it very much "hides the domain being visited", in fact it "hides" EVERYTHING via encryption. It is not possible to read the visited domain in SSL streams - no matter how much money your company might have invested in industrial-grade firewalls and whatnot. Its technologically impossible unless SSL/TLS offers a ROT13 cipher :-)

Comment: @specializt 1 - Client connects and requests SSL encryption(nothing is encrypted yet) 2 - Server sends its certificate and public key... but it never arrives, because something in the middle intercepted it and sent something else, that is promptly rejected by the browser, as it is invalid. Don't tell me this can't happen: It's an everyday thing here where I work - and at most companies in Brazil, really. Even if I don't fully understand the concept - it's out of my area of expertise - blocking is a common practice and is not hindered by SSL or TLS at all.

Comment: @CássioRenan you clearly havent even understood what i wrote ... or your own claim, for that matter. Please do not make up claims without SOME knowledge. It isnt possible to decrypt anything inside of SSL streams and the fact that these can be BLOCKED has nothing to do with it. Everything can be blocked, under every circumstance. You just discovered logic.

Comment: @specializt If you agree that everything can be blocked, there's nothing to discuss. This isn't a question about the inner workings of SSL. It's a meta discution about some feature of the site and its implications on some users. You're missing the point.

Comment: Proxies, TOR... You can probably bypass most local 32 bit blocking software with a 64 bit browser.

Comment: For the last time: The point is not finding any means of bypassing the block (which is not as easy as you people seem to believe, for a user with limited privileges), the point is that **there are blocks**, and that **bypassing them may get you in trouble** in the place **where you work**. After all, the network administrator put them there **for a reason**.

Comment: It is true that many companies block careers.stackoverflow.  I might have to shift to some other Q&A website.

Comment: Life without **stackoverflow** is like **NullPointerException**

Comment: @specializt If the browser is using SNI, (and virtually all of them do at this point) the hostname you requested *IS* sent in cleartext.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication

Answer (score 60):

I think adding Jobs tab belongs to the opposite of the "Just One Thing" wisdom in the OP and what's coming after that quote:

[image]

Programmers need a lot of things: Legal advice about their programming practices, job-related health issues, career planning... Each of these belongs to a separate SE website if necessary IMO.

Comment: Very true; I am from the same generation of "small is beautiful" and "do one thing, do it well". A generation ready to be scrapped, as it seems.

Comment: Depends on how big "one thing" is - I mean, is addition "one thing" or is "math" one thing? Or Calculus only? "Software Engineering" is one thing, and it includes jobs. :)

Comment: So many good answers and only one up vote.

Comment: systemd anybody?

Comment: Jobs tab? Steve Job's tab?

Answer (score 31):

Currently, Careers is linked to from two sites: Stack Overflow & Server Fault. Will they both get Jobs tabs? Will they get *separate* Jobs tabs, or will the information be shared? Will people who currently have accounts on Careers and *one* of those sites automatically acquire a profile on the *other* site? Or what?

Comment: At this time, only Stack Overflow will receive the new Jobs tab. Instead of redirecting users on Server Fault to careers.stackoverflow.com, they will be redirected to stackoverflow.com/jobs.

Comment: @Hynes Can it redirect to Sysadmin/devops filter?

Answer (score 27):

I've liked how you will bring everything together in the same place.

[image]

However, does it mean that you have already decided that the new Documentation feature will be named simply as "Documentation"?

Previously, [the MSO community have elected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306346/naming-the-documentation-feature) the name "Null Reference".
While this name makes sense as a separated website like [nullref.io](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306346/naming-the-documentation-feature#comment249236_306380), with this navbar, a "Null Reference" box would be totally strange. That's why you will keep with the simpler "Documentation" name?

I'm not asking you to use the "Null Reference" name. I'm just curious if the name "Documentation" is the final choice. I also believe that "Documentation" makes more sense with this navbar.

And why "Jobs"? Will you also drop (or hide) the Careers trademark for a simpler integration?

> Stack Overflow is a fanciful name for a somewhat hard-to-describe system. As you observed, putting more fanciful names within it just makes things confusing, particularly when there are perfectly good descriptive words for the component parts. - [Shog9](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310066/stack-overflow-serving-programmers-even-better#comment270078_310076)

Comment: Why would you name it null reference?  That could be confusing to people who aren't first hand english speakers.  To me that sounds like a joke.  Documentation sounds more professional.  The jobs I agree with you, either change everything in the "Careers" site to say Jobs or change the link to "Careers".  Personally "Careers" sounds much more professional than Jobs. When someone says whats your job I think of burger king or mcdonalds - no offense.  But when I hear "career" it just sounds more more..well better!

Comment: I've said that I would name it as "Null Reference" if it was an external site. As it currently stands, "Documentation" fits better. I just want to confirm if they have decided that the name will really be "Documentation" or if they are still open for another name.

Comment: Let alone non first hand English, why name something "Null" which in fact contains lots of goodies?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a fanciful name for a somewhat hard-to-describe system. As you observed, putting *more* fanciful names within it just makes things confusing, particularly when there are perfectly good descriptive words for the component parts.

Comment: @JonH I also tend to expect that a "jobs" link on a website will link to a page describing open positions *within the company that runs the website*.

Comment: @KyleStrand - Yep that's very true good point.

Comment: @JonH I have been offered a carreer in McDonalds before. Don't underestimate the progression of jobs you can have there. That said I have a lot of respect for the people that work there for that such a low pay.

Comment: @Sumurai8 I worked in both bk and McDonalds...trust Mr I know.  I got to 11 bucks an hour at bk and that was nearly 20 years ago.  It is hard work...much respect trust me.

Comment: Can we shorten the "Documentation" tab to "Docs"? I don't see a need to spell the entire word out in the tab.

Comment: @NathanOsman IMHO "Docs" sounds too much like Documents not Documentation.

Comment: "Documentation" being larger than "Questions" in the header really gives the wrong impression.

Comment: @Zanon At this time we're moving forward with the name Documentation. When Documentation goes into public beta, it will be added to the main navigation bar.

Comment: @KyleStrand True, but most companies also don't offer a "Jobs" product like we do. In either case though, a person selects "Jobs" expecting to see… jobs, which is what they'll see. The difference here is we offer our jobs plus a few thousand more. :)

Comment: @JonH The reason for changing the link from Careers to Jobs has more to do with some honest internal assessment of our product. While we would love to help developers with their careers, our product currently is geared toward helping developers find their next _job_. We don't offer tools or services to help developers plan their career. Changing the name sets better expectations for developers on what they can expect help with: finding an amazing job opportunity with a great company.

Comment: @Hynes - That's fine I was saying either go with one or the other, if you guys want Jobs just update any reference to careers and make it very noticeable that these are not "internal" jobs.  Maybe a nice tooltip...

Comment: @JonH All references to Careers will be scrubbed.

Comment: @Hynes I realize that, but does everybody? And if I thought it were only a link to job opportunities with SO, I'd be much less likely to click (it sounds like a great company to work for, but I'm not very interested in web development as a career).

Comment: As a freelancer, I found myself being repelled by the word “Careers”. For me it conjures up the image of driving to a large office and sitting in a cubicle (or occasionally on a surprisingly square sofa surrounded by pot plants). The idea of pursuing “_an occupation undertaken for a significant period of a person’s life and with opportunities for progress_” actually makes me feel a bit sick. I refer to it as my “Work” (“_activity involving mental or physical effort **done in order to achieve a result**_"), and would happily see a tab named as such. In lieu of that, I’ll settle for “Jobs” ;).

Comment: @JonH Maybe there's transatlantic differences, but to me your career is e.g. "software development, specialising in embedded" and your job is "Senior Embedded Engineer at Foobar Inc." - viz. I would think it odd if you referred to a specific.. job (!) as "my career". Thus, to me, "Jobs" fits - I'm looking for the next job that will form part of my career.

Answer (score 16):

Knowing the background of Stack Overflow, it's easy to see why Questions comes before Documentation. But then if you do use the first option instead of the second, you'll be yelled that you should have read the documentation first!

So, I'd suggest to move Documentation to the first position. At the end of each part of documentation, link to "Questions and answers about Foo" (as the people in this workflow aren't looking for questions without answers) and only from there hint that you can ask new questions if you can't find an existing answer.

The goal of course is to highlight that Stack Overflow already has the information that you want, either in documentation or in existing answers. Asking questions has been historically important, but we need to de-emphasize that.

Comment: In time this would be a pretty great idea. In practice, taking the primary use case for a site and moving it down the menu chain would end up more confusing than not.

Comment: For most users the front page is google....

Answer (score 5):

[image: My crap UI]

Looks great. I approve (even with my sucky HTML... Imagine what it will be with Stack Overflow Awesomeness!).

---

However, I need to ask: what will happen to the old buttons? Will they still be there? Or will we have to wave bye-bye to some of them? In your example, we've got:

- Questions | Documentation | Jobs | Teams | Users | Tags

From an anonymous point of view... I have:

- Questions | Tags | Users | Badges | Unanswered | Ask Question

From a user-y point of view... I've got:

- Questions | Tags | Users | Badges | Ask Question

There's an issue with the new UI: If we're still to rely on Q&A for our core, how will people know where to ask questions?!? The button is gone!

Comment: I like the idea of removing "Ask Question" from the front page.  Make users search first, possibly even checking the "Documentation" (such as it is).

Comment: The "Ask Question" button will still be here when you're in the "Q&A space" (it won't be in the main nav, but it'll be around as a CTA — presumably a bit below the main nav). In other words, if you're looking at a documentation topic, there won't be a highly visible "Ask Question" button, but if you're looking at a question (or a question list), there will. We'll also keep an eye out on our stats to make sure we're not losing questions.

Comment: To echo @ThomasOrozco's comment, the "Ask Question" **Call-to-Action** (CTA) will still be visible within the Q&A area. The other links (Badges, Unanswered) will still exist, but demoted out of the top-level navigation. The top-level navigation (Questions, Docs, Jobs, Teams, Users, Tags) will remain the same for all users.

Comment: just like what they did with the logout button, they will hide it somewhere where you need magnifying glass to see it

Comment: @Ceeee But.... why would you ever want to log out? :P

Comment: @TinyGiant to change account? :D but i know logging out is not usually done when using SO, I don't usually logout too. but logout button != Ask Question button in terms of usage

Answer (score 4):

I think that careers was an excellent idea.  I mean, if one company deserves to become a global job marketplace, that would certainly be stackoverflow, which actually provides a tangible and directly related knowledge transfer service, rather than linkedin.

I only have one suggestion to make: the "Jobs near you" box on the right sidebar of the page is a) highly repetitive, and b) completely useless to me, since I have already concluded my job search, and I actually have a job offer from a company which found me through careers.stackoverflow.com.  So, there is no point in continuing to show me that box, especially since it has the same content all the time.  (I live in an area in which there aren't many jobs.)

I understand that you need to have a way of constantly reminding people that you also offer this awesome careers service, and I suppose that's what the careers sidebar box is all about, but I certainly hope that it will disappear once "jobs" takes its place in the main button bar.  Perhaps keep showing the sidebar box to unregistered visitors, but we regular users have no use for it.

Our career is much too important for us to fail to notice the "jobs" button, and on the long run, that's all the reminder that we need.

Answer (score 1):

I like the new UI. Specially the addition of Teams and Documentation to the Stack Overflow scope. I have read some discussion happening on the name like 'Null Reference', but I personally like 'StackOverflow'.

I just have one question. Where will the 'Ask Question' option be, because I have not seen an image shown in the above post? Till now 'Ask Question' is the starting point of any discussion on Stack Overflow and most of the developers are familiar with it. Is it moved under 'Questions'?

Comment: lol, this is what I asked...

Comment: @Zizouz212 Lol :-)

Answer (score 1):

SE should try to improve the [Great Firewall of China](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Firewall) issue, where external content can't be loaded without VPN-like tools.  I think the (probably) hundreds of thousands of programmers in China would appreciate that.