# Careers Unificintegration: Jobs on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

> **TL;DR**:
>
> [image: Primary Navigation]
>
> We're rolling out [Jobs on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs).
> Big thanks to the folks who tested early and reported bugs here on Meta Stack Overflow with the [jobs](/questions/tagged/jobs) tag - keep up the good work!
>
> <3

In 2009 Stack Overflow embarked on a mission to get programmers jobs they love.
We [started](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/jobs-at-stack-overflow/) by bringing in the Joel on Software job board. Then we [added CVs](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/10/introducing-stack-overflow-careers/) to help you show off your awesome skills, and [companies started coming to you](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/12/careers-now-open-for-businesses/). In 2011 we [launched Careers 2.0](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/careers-2-0-launches/) with free access for job-seekers, better CVs, and much better employer search. [Company Pages](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/08/finding-a-great-company/) came in 2013 to help companies show off *their* awesome. At the beginning of this year our [Job Ads](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/01/targeted-jobs-for-stack-overflow/) got much smarter with targeting. If you can't tell, we're fanatically obsessed with seeing this mission through. This isn't a side quest for us.

But because of some big user experience issues we haven't been as effective in serving programmers as we could be, or as we need to be in order to make the dent in the developer hiring problem we want to make. [Tim neatly summarized the issue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310066/stack-overflow-serving-programmers-even-better):

> Many of you reading this have great jobs that you love, but many more
> do not, and don't realize that Stack Overflow has a product that could
> help get them a much better job. Some might have poked at it, but got lost in
> the hassle of having to sign up all over again and tell us things they thought
> we already knew about them.

We did all this work on Careers and Careers *is* working, but we've thrown it in the guest bedroom closet, shut the door, pushed a desk in front of it, and tied a mean looking dog to the desk. You had to go to a whole separate site and create a whole 'nother account. We made you dance the get-a-careers-invite-from-who-knows-where-boogie before we'd grace you with a CV. If you couldn't get an invite from a friend/colleague, you might have requested an invite from us and gone into a queue where a Stack Overflow human would hand evaluate your request and artisanally craft an invite for you. **We went out of our way to stand in yours.**

There's a couple data points we have to help size just how many people we could be serving better. According to the 2015 Stack Overflow Developer Survey only 1 in 3 respondents said "I love my job".

[image: Job Satisfaction Question]

In addition to that, we did an experiment this year asking users how interested they are in jobs as they're signing up for Stack Overflow.

[image: Job Interest Field]

About 60% of people filled out that job interest field and about 60% of those people indicated they're actively looking for a job or are open to being contacted about a new position. **In total about 40% of people who sign up for Stack Overflow are interested in jobs, right now.**

It's clear that a large contingent of Stack Overflow users need and are interested in jobs and **we just have to stop getting in your way**. Putting the candidate experience from Careers directly under the Jobs tab on Stack Overflow is the best way to do that, so that's what we're gonna do. No more guest bedroom, no more multiple accounts and sites, no more hassle.

## Want to give it a try?

Jobs should be live for *everyone* now, so [go check it out](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs). If you find bugs please post your question here on Meta Stack Overflow and tag them with the [jobs](/questions/tagged/jobs) tag. We've already worked to create a job board experience that helps you put your best foot forward, but it'll get even better now that we have the chance to continue improving the experience with your help.

## FAQ

#### What's changing about Stack Overflow?

[image: Primary Navigation]

That is about the extent of the changes to existing Stack Overflow. There's nothing else changing about Q&A. We aren't going to put jobs that look like questions in the middle of a question list, or jobs that look like answers in the middle of the answers for a question, or any other dark pattern garbage. The Jobs tab will be there for you should you need it, and otherwise Stack Overflow is essentially as it was.

#### What's on the Jobs Tab?

In short, everything you used to see on Careers...

[image: Jobs Tab]

You can search jobs and companies, create/edit your CV, and read your messages right there.

#### What about my existing Careers stuff?

If you've previously linked your existing Careers CV with your Stack Overflow account, everything on the Jobs tab Should Just Work™.

#### Are you just showing my private CV stuff to the whole world now?

**NO.** Your private stuff remains your private stuff.

#### What about the API and the Data Dumps?

No change. There will be no Jobs or CV data in either the Stack Exchange API or the public data dumps.

#### What about my public CV link?

Your public CV links (like [this one](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jasonpunyon)) will continue to work, but they will redirect to `https://stackoverflow.com/cv/{your-chosen-slug}`

#### The Apply Button looks different on Stack Overflow?

Hooo' boy. I'd like to personally apologize to you if you've interacted with our apply button in the past. It was incredibly confusing and broken and there's no justification for it. We dropped the ball. There was so much wrong there that we redesigned and rewrote the whole thing.

Comment: The question is..do you really want me to test careers? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270890/apply-pop-up-does-not-make-it-clear-which-version-of-resume-will-be-attached?noredirect=1#comment878386_270890

Comment: @JonH: I was thinking about you specifically when writing this and I am personally sorry for what happened to you yesterday. I hope that the application process on Stack Overflow is a lot better than it was and a lot clearer about what it's putting on your applications.

Comment: @JonH: So yes. I'd love it if you were willing to trust us with your application again even though we messed up.

Comment: I just hope its not the ugly duckling like it has been.  I've been pretty critical of careers both from someone who has hired using it and someone who tried to use it to change careers.  In fact, I just got an email from one of your salesrep asking me if I wanted to give it another trial run for free.  I never answered her just yet (sorry Monica)...maybe I will but I will test the living hell out of this thing...because I really do believe in it..as critical as I am of it.

Comment: Here goes: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312454/searching-by-zip-code-loses-zip-code-after-postback

Comment: Here is another strange one: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312457/create-pdf-in-new-jobs-site-does-nothing

Comment: Am I the only one who clicked refresh some 100 times and then read the post after discovering nothing was happening? :P

Comment: Lot's of negative comments going your way, which is good because it makes you better, but I just wanted to say thanks. It was a little bit figuring out things - though not much more than elsewhere - it worked for me and got a good job interview out of it. I trust you guys a lot more than, to name one, linkedin, so keep up the good work. You guys are great, now go and be awesome!

Comment: what does "unificintegration" mean?

Comment: @bubakazouba Its the horrible love child of `unification` and `integration`. It basically just means they are merging them into one.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg Horrible? Words have feelings too, y'know. ;)

Comment: Clicking on "Edit CV" from my profile takes me to the sign up page. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: @JonH is this a ploy on meta about trying to get employed, in order to make SO employ you for testing? Now *that* would be meta;)

Comment: @TravisJ: No, I'm sure it's us. Please ask as a question with the [meta-tag:jobs] tag so we don't lose it? Thank you.

Comment: @JasonPunyon - Okay, I asked it here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312484/clicking-on-edit-cv-takes-me-to-sign-up . I tagged it support in case it was not a bug.

Comment: Really? Jobs stand between Questions and Tags?

Comment: Is this going to get Stackoverflow blocked at work? :(

Comment: @Benjol Yes it will.

Comment: @Matty When stackoverflow began, a stated goal was to wipe out experts-exchange. Similarly, I think killing off linkedin would be a worthy goal of stackoverflow careers. Admittedly, linkedin is a much bigger beast than EE, but they're every bit as shady.

Comment: When I first saw the screenshot of the new navigation bar, I thought that the capital white “J” on the green background was connected to the jobs stuff (and thought: is it really necessary to make it so prominent?). Only realised that it was @JasonPunyon’s avatar picture at the end of the post.

Comment: @Dónal, isn't linkedin a much more *general* beast as well, as in "so much more than programming"?

Comment: What will happen with Explore Cities feature from Careers site?

Comment: @IlijaDimov With the unification, we've chosen to discontinue Explore Cities. It is currently available on http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cities but we don't plan on supporting it long term

Comment: @AurélienGasser - Good I think the explore cities was kind of lame...it felt like I was booking a holiday trip at a hotel.

Comment: These feature announcements on Meta are all way to long measured by the content that is actually important. 90% of the content here is: "Careers is now represented as a Jobs button."

Comment: Yay! Now my evil company proxy won't be able to block it.

Comment: @usr that's why there's a tl;dr with a screenshot right at the top! :)

Comment: @Laura I could claim I didn't read the TLDR because post was too long :)

Comment: @Benjol preventing developers from using Stack Overflow at work sounds like a very counterproductive idea to me, to put it mildly. Are you seriously concerned that employers will do that? Is careers.stackoverflow.com currently blocked at work for you?

Comment: @Jason don't you think people deserve the right to  know the site they used for years is going to shut down? Many of those people (myself included) visit only MSE, since that is/was the Meta site for Careers, so a similar featured post there, and a banner in the Careers site itself, would be nice.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Yeah, getting a message up on MSE is a good idea. There will be e-mails out to all Careers users to let them know what's happening, we haven't sent them yet.

Comment: @Dónal is it? Tell me more.

Comment: @JasonPunyon -1 http://meta.serverfault.com/q/8510/203649

Comment: [Please don’t make careers stack overflow only](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/271121/242800)

Comment: @user2284570 are you sure "`It will mean it would only be linked to developers' jobs.`"?

Comment: @AndrasDeak careers will disappear in favor oo a stack overflow tab. As far I know that change won’t take place on ServerFault.

Comment: @user2284570 Aah, I see. I thought you were worried that the scope of Careers would be narrowed down to only programming jobs, which didn't make sense to me. But now I see your concern.

Comment: @AndrasDeak : yes in theory it won’t narrow the scope. But in practice it will *([I update my request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/271121/242800))*. I would have supported a single detached site for the whole network but not an so only one.

Comment: @Max, yup. So I guess in theory they could modify it to block just /jobs

Comment: "We've thrown it in the guest bedroom closet, shut the door, pushed a desk in front of it, and tied a mean looking dog to the desk." Did you put a sign on the door saying "Beware of the leopard?"

Comment: I personally liked the separation of the sites, and I don't mind creating a whole new account for it, since technically it's a completely different site with a different purpose

Comment: Please add an option to clear or hide "Your Recent Searches"

Comment: Just make sure you roll out updated Adblock filters to go with it, 'cause I'm [still not looking for a job](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236776/no-i-am-not-looking-for-a-job-but-thank-you-for-asking).

Comment: Will the CV be public?

Comment: @Giorgi You still have control over whether you CV is public, just like it's always been on Careers. You control whether your CV is public (with a URL you can give to anyone, whether they use Careers or not) and whether or not companies can find your CV and message you via our candidate database.

Comment: This feels to me like the time Google wanted to drive users onto Google+ so they unified Google+ logins with YouTube Logins.   Everything went great, and NOBODY hated hated hated hated it when they did that. So don't worry guys, this will be GREAT.

Comment: @Dónal LinkedIn may be shady, but there's no substitute for it and the functionality here has no overlap whatsoever.  Every interesting-looking listing I see here I look up first thing on LinkedIn.  No sane employer would prefer an unknown candidate with high SO rep over a friend of a friend/colleague.

Comment: Well, please get on with it.  careers.stackoverflow.com is still accessible separately and it seems to be broken.  At least the "allows remote" search filter isn't working.  None of the search results are marked "remote."

Comment: I'd love to have the Jobs tab also be on *all* other sites, such as SU or SF or even [ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/), [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/), or [Chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/). Then have a filter automatically put in based on which site you're coming from. I understand there's no chemistry or english or D&D jobs on Careers *yet*, but that's no reason not to try.

Comment: If you thought invites were a problem why didn't you just get rid of them?

Comment: *Suggestion:* Before you link to a blog post, ensure that the comments thereon are not full of spam.

Comment: @SamuelEdwinWard Invites are gonna be gone in a little bit.

Comment: Well done.  I was very happy to see that tab pop up.

Comment: @JonH *... do you really want me to test careers?* ... immediately conjured up, [*Do you really want to make me cry?*](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/b1/Do_You_Really_Want_To_Hurt_Me.jpg) for me. I'm going to assume that was intentional. ;^)

Comment: How about adding this to all stackexchange sites as a possibility? Christianity.SE for pastors and deacons, hermeneutics.SE for theologians, english.SE for teachers, linguists, translators. You get the drift.

Comment: erm... uni what?

Answer (score 86):

There were obvious disadvantages to throwing StackOverflow Careers in the guest bedroom closet behind the door with a mean looking dog and a desk in front of it.  But I appreciated it for one reason: it was implicit that **my CV and job hunting status are *not* subject to the everything-you-do-is-public StackExchange philosophy unless I say so.**  As long as the integrated Jobs feature continues to promise the same discretion (and it looks like it does) then great!

And just a small a UX criticism.  I cannot for the life of me figure out what ordering governs this list.  It certainly isn't ordered by category:

<kbd>[image: What ordering is this?]</kbd>

I don't have any suggestions, mind you.  But I think it's jarring to see "Jobs" between "Questions" and "Tags".

---

EDIT:  Courtesy @DavidFullerton.  The navbar UX is [on the radar](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310066/stack-overflow-serving-programmers-even-better).  Have a look:

<kbd>[image: Future nav UX.]</kbd>

Comment: See Tim's post on longer term plans: [Serving Programmers Even Better](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310066/stack-overflow-serving-programmers-even-better). This will seem less awkward when we also have Docs and some other things in the nav.

Comment: That is useful context, @DavidFullerton.  Thanks!  Nav looks more cohesive without Badges or Ask Question.  And Tags looks a lot more relevant to all the things in the list.

Comment: Please also make "Ask a Question" stand out much more.  I posted about that about a year ago with no replies.

Comment: @JonH a bolder 'Ask a Question' button will be included in the redesign.

Comment: @KurtisBeavers - That is awesome news - I've waited for that for quite some time.

Comment: *it was implicit that my CV and job hunting status are not subject to the everything-you-do-is-public StackExchange philosophy* - It is? I assumed the two things *weren't* separate.

Comment: @BSMP, yes, that is how I interpreted it.

Comment: @KurtisBeavers Please keep "Ask a Question" as a button in the main nav, and not just make a "stand out much more". I understand that you want to encourage users from asking a new question without first searching for an answer, yet that doesn't explain why you are adding an extra step to one of the most used features for the rest of us by putting it in a sub menu. SO's main purpose is Q&A after all.

Comment: Does anyone here know how I can move that Jobs button, so I dont click on it accidently, happening all the time,  to end or make it disappear. Some GM script in hand? Thank you.

Comment: @WeareBorg, That doesn't sound possible to me.  Not as an end-user configurable option, anyway.  [Ask that as a question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) here in meta, though.   You're a lot more likely to find an answer that way.

Answer (score 67):

### Please don't ever insert new buttons in the middle of an existing navbar, or reorder existing buttons within a navbar, no matter how much sense it would make in a clean-slate design.

This is a general UX principle.  It disrupts people's muscle memory.  Don't do that.

It's OK to add stuff to a navbar, but *only* at the ends.

As someone who has never and probably will never use the Jobs/Careers feature, I would also appreciate a toggle somewhere in account preferences to make all Jobs-related UI disappear and stay disappeared.  But that's much less important.

Comment: See also Twitter with Moments.

Comment: Up-voted for the toggle switch.

Comment: We're adding new things that didn't exist before - what's the alternative? At some point navigation has to change.

Comment: @NickCraver "It's OK to add stuff to a navbar, but *only* at the ends."

Comment: @nick - you have a point, but honestly in this particular case, that *was* a pretty bizarre place for the jobs link.

Comment: That the "Ask question" button stays at the very right (as it does on every Stack Exchange site, and is perfectly logical in general) seems more important than the sort order of the other tabs

Comment: @AdamRackis I fully agree that it is a bizarre place, but now that I think of it they are probably putting in terms of feature importance. Q/A is the #1 feature, then Jobs, then in the future, Teams... and then the rest of Tags, Users, etc...

Comment: I don't agree. These really aren't buttons that users are pressing very often, and the ones that are most important (Questions / Ask Question) are easiest to target by being at the ends. Your suggestion would be worse for the UX. (In either case, the new navigation revamp is many times more disruptive than this change could be.)

Comment: +1 for the feature to hide it completely, I use it but see it beneficial for others.

Comment: I have never heard of this UX principle.

Comment: "As someone who has never and probably will never use the Jobs/Careers feature...."  this is a money-making site, like any other business in the universe.  If you're someone who "will never use" the profit features, your opinion is only incidentally relevant.

Comment: `I would also appreciate a toggle somewhere in account preferences to make all Jobs-related UI disappear and stay disappeared` Until this (never) happens, download and install Stylish (or alternate CSS injection addon), click the button for it in the top right of your browser, click 'Write new style' > 'For stackoverflow.com', then paste this into the window: `@-moz-document domain("stackoverflow.com"){a#nav-jobs,div#hireme,a[href^="//careers.stackoverflow.com"]{display: none !important;}}`.

Comment: I support having a toggle to hide it

Comment: I wonder if your muscle memory has adapted yet. I bet it has.

Comment: Ad-block plus rule I use is: `stackoverflow.com###nav-jobs`

Comment: I think it's okay to insert an UI element into the middle of a sequence given that people are not primarily using the position of elements to locate them. In this navbar, all the items look more or less the same, with no color and no graphics, so people absolutely are relying on muscle memory. However, if the tabs had icons or colors, it would be more acceptable to insert and rearrange the elements, since the primary visual cues would remain the same.

Comment: Imho, the two most important buttons in that navbar are the first and the last: "Questions" and "Ask Question". Possibly "Tags" might have an important impact for some people. I doubt muscle memory is sollicited in any way to locate "user" or "badges", but I'm open to see statistics on site usage prove me wrong.

Comment: -100 My muscle memory works just as much from the left as from the right side.. Rightmost position = `ask question`, Left most position = `view question`. The two most frequent actions in the two prime spots. That makes sense. Everything in the middle is `must scan`.

Answer (score 20):

Some feedback from me. I thought to give StackOverflow Careers a try a few days ago and build up the CV.

1. Ok, I started the entries and everything went fine so far and then...
2. What exactly am I supposed to do after I think my CV is complete ? I do not see a confirm button. The right toolbar indicates something like 67% complete. Must I enter something in every field even if it does not fit ?
   What I am supposed to do ?
3. Whatever...after looking in my profile I got informed that my profile is under review. Ok, so it seems to have been saved, but I wondered why it is so confusing. Some time later I checked my spam account and found that a email verification mail got caught in the filter. I was not informed while visiting the site that you will send an email to verify the account, it was pure luck that I checked the spam folder before it got axed.
4. Sighing I clicked the link...and was greeted with "Page not found". I must admit I finally felt...unhappy.
5. So I wrote a message explaining the problem using the contact link in the "Page not found". I got no confirmation mail, even not in the spam. So I do not know if the message was received apart from the confirmation message.

I admit I am already a bit spoiled; StackOverflow has raised a formidable bar. So far...mh.

UPDATE 1.:

Got an nice email and the verification passes. Nice :) And then...

6. The mail text is perfect German, just the title worries me a bit: "Ihre Suchergebnisse werden ausgesetzt". You mean, you are going to maroon my search results ? They did't do anything wrong.
   It could have meant "stopped" if the thing destined for "aussetzen" is a verb. It could also mean 1. expose 2. skip 3. sit out 4. fail 5. intermit 6. offer (a reward), depending entirely on context, so used correctly it could be perfectly valid.
7. Finally, the mail informs me that I am "not searching, but open for offers". This is strange because I set it to actively seeking and yes, I checked it and it still shows a different setting. Mmh.
8. The text under my name (which incidentally cannot be edited, mh) says "bei selbstständig". "bei >name of firm<" would be correct, but "bei selbstständig" means approximately "at self-employed". And I am not "self-employed", but "job-seeking". Mh.

Do you have something like a bug database...?

Comment: Go ahead and post bugs here on meta! One bug per question, use tags [meta-tag:bug] and [meta-tag:jobs] like so: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?tags=bug%20jobs

Answer (score 17):

I'm one of those odd-ball people who enjoys working as a contractor.  My contracting experience is a big part of what made me who I am today.  I think it would be great if we could use this features to help contractors get gigs, as well, because as far as I've seen, what's on SO Careers is 99% direct-hire.

I would love to be able to make SO a tool that I can use to find gigs.

Answer (score 11):

I'm really happy to see you all integrating Careers with Stack Overflow proper.  Well done.

That said, can we expect some more love to be given to the CV generation?  [Prior](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127130/careers-change-order-of-sections-in-pdf-export) [issues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268184/careers-pdf-export-github-entry-titles) I've opened in this area appear to have fallen on deaf ears.

I hope the decision makers at SE agree that a well-formatted CV is important for this to all work together well.

---

Note, from the comments -
The GitHub URL issue looks like this, on PDF export.

[image]

Comment: First, I'll be the first to admit we've done a terrible job at monitoring meta for Careers issues and feedback. I promise this will get better, for realsies. 
Also, I'm fairly certain both of those issue have been addressed. If you hover over the entries on your CV on Stack Overflow, there are now up and down arrows to move entries. We also no longer show the full URL of a github project, that may or may not have resolved that issue. Can you check?

Comment: @Juice - thanks for the reply, and I'm delighted to hear.  On the GitHub URL, no, the full URL still shows in the PDF export, and still wraps.  I added a screenshot.  On the other, no, I'm talking about re-ordering entire **sections** - ie move education **above** work history, or similar.

Again though, thank you so much for the reply.  I really do love careers.so (or now so/jobs I guess :) )

Comment: @Juice - just wanted to follow up here.  Seems nothing has been changed  in any of those areas.  I imagine pdf export is useful to many, many people.  Will this be getting some love from devs anytime soon???

Comment: @Juice - just wanted to follow up again - any movement I can look forward to on pdf export formatting? I don't plan on job hunting any time soon, but it'd be nice to know I could format a decent looking CV if I ever did :)

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if this qualifies as a comment, or a full-on "question" over on some other meta, or what.  But as it looks like this Q/A post is seeking feedback, yeah, I have some of that.

## The job alert thing that sends me an email with the latest jobs?  Don't care for it.

Oh don't get me wrong, I *want* the emails, just that the content sucks.  The jobs it sends me are...irrelevant at best.  According to the most recent one I got, my search is for "game" within 20 miles of the United States (yes, I intentionally cast the net wide).  The jobs listed are, (with tags and comments in parens):

> - Mobile Engineer iOS/Android (no tags; company does casino gaming which was buried in the job description near the bottom)
> - 3D Software Engineer (C++, opengl, directx, goemetry; dealing with dental tech)
> - Generalist Software Engineer (hadoop, java, mysql ruby; company appears to be big data)
> - Ruby-on-Rails Developer (ruby-on-rails, html, css, javascript; appears to be finance related)
>
>   - humorously one of the "what you will do" bullet points in their job description says, "writing code" (gosh, you don't say)
> - Lead Developer to Change the Fashion Tech Industry (javascript, html, css, sql; for the fashion industry)

Don't those just fill me with excitement.

*ONE* at least even was tangentially related to my interests--casino gaming--but it had no tags and nothing in the one-line description piqued my interest ("Job Description We are looking for an iOS/.NET developer responsible for the development and...") which is, ironically, a first.  The others are even less tailored to me than my similar Monster email alert (those are at least 80% game industry, with the remaining 20% being red herrings as a result of computer intelligence being what it is: "Looking for programmer for a game-changing health care app" "Game developer looking to switch to finance" "Full stack developer needed -- Location has kitchen, game room...").

Also, it appears that the job alerts are not even editable without using the link included in the email (that is: you cannot get to the saved settings starting from http://careers.stackexchange.com or I simply cannot locate it).

Even so, if I plug the search into the search system [directly on the site](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=game&location=United%20Sates&range=20&distanceUnits=Miles) I get *much better results* than any of the emails I've gotten (and no, I'm not cherry picking here, these were literally the top five results when I did the search):

> - Audio Quality Lead Developer (for a service providing voice chat for **online games**)
> - Software Engineer (for Daybreak **Game** Company--they don't actually do games, alas)
> - Server Software Engineer (for Respawn Entertainment, "the team that brought you **Titanfall**")
> - Lead Software Engineer ("...highly qualified **game engine devleopers**...")
> - Lead **Game Systems** Programmer ("Develop **game system** software and **gameplay** for Disney Playmation")

So this isn't an issue where I saved a bad search and get alerts on it.  I saved what looked like a good search and the email blasts are pulling crap results.

Comment: Hi Draco: (1) Search works better because it's less constrained. Search can return any live job in the system, not just the jobs that we haven't sent you yet (which is what the subscription has to do). It's got a deeper pool, that's why it's returning better results. (2) It's run off a full text search, so anything with the word game in it is in (game-changing, are you ready to change the game, like to play games, ). That's where the spurious listings are coming from. Modulo other bugs (that hit on Dec 18-20), the system is working as intended.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to let us know what your experience is like. I don't have a quick answer as to how we're gonna improve your particular case, but there's a general push for matches to be as relevant as possible and we'll use this report as a datapoint to go explore. Sorry the e-mails haven't been more helpful.

Comment: In which case, it's misleading.  "Save this search as a job alert" doesn't really...function as advertised.  Thanks for the reply though, @JasonPunyon

Comment: @JasonPunyon I'm sure your ML guys would appreciate if you added a relevancy feedback on each job (so ML model can be improved with every feedback). Something simple like "Is this job relevant? Yes/No" would suffice.

Comment: It would be really nice to be able to filter by industry/market ("Advertising”, "Finance”), which is frequently self-reported already.

Answer (score 1):

Can you allow us to copy our careers page to jobs or allow us to keep them in sync?

Comment: They're different views of the same site; the content will be identical/synced.

Comment: That's good thanks.  I wonder why it's asking me to fill it out again?

Comment: I think they prompt you to fill in the info in either case, but it should be pre-populated with your existing data if you already have a profile. If it's not, there's probably an issue associating your two accounts. Maybe they use different emails or something? I'm not sure how the system works.

Answer (score 0):

CV `create PDF` is not nice at all or should I say it's horrible. Can't its output be like the CV `print` output? All appearing under `Settings`.

Comment: how do you create your PDF now (with image, etc.)? Any tips?