# Searching by zip code loses zip code after postback

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

When searching for a job using the new jobs tab in stackoverflow it seems to lose the location after you select a company.  For instance, click the **search companies** tab.  Enter the location 48310.  Click on any company such as **Quicken Loans**..look over Quicken loans then scroll back and click **search companies** tab again.

I was expecting that the zip code I had entered would still be there.  It's not..I don't know if that is intentional but that may be worth looking into.  If you click back it works however, I noticed the search jobs tab is a little different.  If you search by **search jobs** you are given the following links to take you back:

[image]

But using **search companies** you are not given these links, some users will simply click **search companies** again to go back.  Doing so removes the zip code filter forcing the user to re-enter it!

Comment: I guess we could give you an "active search" for your session that those tabs respect? Then next time you come back it expires out and you get a fresh search form?

Comment: Or place the same links similiar to what is done for search jobs, showing search results takes me back to my search companies with my filters already filled in.  I leave it up to you guys to decide.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the report. We now display a "<< search results" link at the top of the page whenever we detect you've arrived via the search page.

Comment: This link seems to randomly show up and disappear, can this be tested some more.  For instance, do a search, click a result, within your result click another link (any) now back out to your original result, the link is gone!

Comment: This was an implementation trade-off. Rather than holding onto state somewhere (cookies, Redis, SQL) it was quicker and simpler for the use case specified to simply propagate the current search parameters to the company page result view in the URL itself. The problem with a stateful approach is when to expire the state, i.e. when is your search session over? A day? I'll see if there's a low-impact way to do this in the code - otherwise we might have to decline, as we'll be experimenting with bigger changes to company pages in the coming months. Thanks.