# Create PDF in new jobs site does nothing

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

On the new jobs site if I go to **Create PDF** as shown and click on it to generate my PDF it does nothing:

[image]

Tested both using latest version of chrome and IE.  This is found in the **edit cv** tab of jobs.

Comment: Thanks, taking a look now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one is fixed in the recent prod build too.