# Analytics in Jobs seems broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I have a feeling there's some analytics data that is going unrecorded in the [new 'Jobs' section](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312452/careers-unificintegration-jobs-on-stack-overflow). Screenshot from a Windows 10 machine running Chrome 47. I'm able to reproduce the errors in Firefox as well.

[image]

On the positive side, these errors don't seem to hampering my browsing of the section!

Comment: Thanks, taking a look now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the report! Fix has been pushed to prod :)