# Clicking on "Edit CV" takes me to sign up

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I opted in to see the new beta "Jobs" section as noted in the question [Careers Unificintegration: Jobs on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312452/careers-unificintegration-jobs-on-stack-overflow).

I do not have a Careers account. When I went to my profile, I noticed a new option "Edit CV".

[image]

I clicked it out of curiosity and it took me to the sign in page for Stack Overflow.

[image]

Did I do something out of order here? Perhaps it is because I do not have a careers account?

Comment: Can't reproduce it. If I click on it, it redirects me to: https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/cv/create

Comment: Taking a look now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear that you *did* have a Careers account from back in 2011 that was automatically created as part of a deprecated featured called 'passive candidates'. I've literally just removed the last remnants of that from our code and transitioned the account to be a regular user.

That user has a fairly sparse CV associated with it already but you can edit it using the link you originally tried.

Thanks for the report!

Comment: Yup it is fixed now, with a link to create. Thanks!