# Allow users to mark jobs "not interested", "applied", et cetera

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

Currently, there are only two ways to see your status regarding a job:

1. Whether you put it in your favorites (the star).
2. And a little sign to indicate that you applied on Stack Overflow (an envelope).

It's as follows:

[image]

It would help if we could manually set some tags (for example: applied to, not interested, company not interested, ...) on jobs.

For one, it could allow us to mark the job as "applied to" when the application process is not on Stack Overflow. And it'll allow us to quickly glance at the job listing when going back to "recent searches" (which are sorted by relevance by default, hence can include a lot of jobs for which we already know our position regarding this job).

And it'll allow us to let the envelope be there only when the process is still ongoing. If I had no answer for a month/a negative answer, I want to mark it as such, not wait till the job disappear from the site (and it'll remove the whole *Good Luck* message when going on the job page :) ).

Comment: how about allowing to vote on the jobs?

Comment: Or vote on the companies; be nice if each company had a score like a user does. Points for responding to people, etc.

Comment: I guess that's an idea as well, but a bit outside the scope of my suggestion. Mine is merely adding a way for each user to sort the job offers, yours are more oriented toward public regards on the company/jobs.

Comment: @AIG Don't companies pay for postings? Allowing voting would be counter productive to that.

Comment: I just want to be able to somehow mark the posting as something that I looked at and decided that I'm not interested in. I spend a lot of time re-reading postings that on the surface seem like a good fit, but then there's that one thing halfway down the page on the right that's a deal-breaker that I forgot about.

Answer (score 24):

I would actually take this a step further, as this can make advertising a lot more accurate.

If SO supplies tags or statuses that any person can add to a job, then SO can track our behaviour towards certain jobs. If I add a status of *not interested* on several jobs that are tagged with *jQuery*, perhaps then I am not so much interested in jQuery?

Of course this is a simple example, and one that actually already has a preference in the resume... but you get the point.

Comment: It sure could provide a lot of data, and may be a way to improve the SO user experience/ provide a better service on the job board.

Comment: What if a job a lot of jobs are tagged with PHP and jQuery, and I indicate I'm not interested in them? But perhaps I *am* interested in jQuery jobs, but not those that involve PHP. Seems like a system might read too much into what you're tagging. If you were to manually say which tags you like and don't like (which I believe it already does) I think that would be better.

Comment: @mason That's an oversimplification on how "Big Data" operates.  If you are tagging-up jQuery, but tagging-down jQuery+PHP, a good algorithm will notice.

Comment: @Draco18s "A good algorithm" will notice, sure. But someone has to write the algorithm, and it's not a guarantee it will be written to take that into account.

Comment: There seem to be too many potential problems here... what if I'm not interested in 5 jobs in a row because they're just not a good fit (while the technologies used are great?) Plus I can't think of a useful way to tag a question in any other way than "not interested".

Comment: @Pekka웃 while I agree with you on that point, note that this idea having __many potential problems__ is exactly the reason why Stack Overflow could be the only one able to challenge such an idea, and why it would be a heavy advantage if SO implemented this

Comment: Why wouldn't you just add the jQuery tag to a "not interested" list, instead?

Comment: I'm skeptical that there are actually enough data points for this to provide accurate filtering. How many job postings are there in the first place? How many of those have you looked at? How many of the ones you've looked at have you formed a firm opinion on?