# External application not marked as applied

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

When you apply to a job that doesn't use the SO application process it is not marked as "applied" even if you apply. I understand that SO may not be able to verify this as cleanly as their own process, but it does get confusing.

I recommend changing the process slightly for external tools. Open the external tool in a new tab/window leaving the original Careers job page open with a "Did you apply?" dialog so we can say if we applied or not. If the user says "yes" mark the job with the usual applied icon.

Comment: Interesting idea. An even simpler version would be to just record the click and display something like "you've clicked on this link before" on the job.

Comment: Or just a checkbox on all jobs with an external application process that the user can tick after doing an application.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/315991/2747593