# How can I mark a job as applied when the company has a process outside Stack Overflow?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

I like that when I can apply within the Stack Overflow site it marks the result as applied.

Is there a mechanism for jobs that require applications outside of Stack Overflow to be marked as applied for?

I've been marking them as favorites but I don't feel that is what the favorites list was for.

Answer (score -2):

Unfortunately, there's no feature for you to mark jobs when you apply to them on an external site (and there's no way for us to know if you've applied or not once you leave our site).

The favorite list is for you to save jobs... but which ones you want to be saved, that's for you to decide and it doesn't have any consequences if you choose to save the ones you've applied to (we don't use your favorite list to determine which jobs are more relevant to you).

Comment: In this instance I don't need to the system to know if I've really applied. I think [this thread](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315991/allow-users-to-mark-jobs-not-interested-applied-et-cetera?rq=1) really knocks out what I'd like to see. It would be for my reference.