# Make jobs that you apply for outside the SO network know you've applied

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, stack-overflow-jobs

When you apply for a job on SO if the job allows you to use the SO features, that is the form directly tied to SO jobs where you send your "dev story" and you provide your resume SO remembers this and tells you that you have applied for a job.

But there are a lot of jobs on SO that force you to apply to the company outside of stackoverflow.  In this case, SO presents a big blue button with an arrow on it pointing outside to show you the application process is outside of SO.

When I apply for this job the job page doesn't know that I applied for it once I am done.  It opens up on SO jobs and doesn't have any clue that I already applied.

Feature-request is to allow me to set the status on a job I have looked on from SO jobs.  It initially is set to "Not Applied", as soon as I apply I can set this status (simply a drop down box) to "Applied".  In the future when I come across this page SO and I will know that I have applied for this job.

Similiarly there should be other statuses besides Not Applied, Applied but also "Interviewing", "Hired", "Cancelled".  Whether or not I put the correct status you guys should not care about - this is just for me.

Comment: Similar: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352308/how-can-i-mark-a-job-as-applied-when-the-company-has-a-process-outside-stack-ove

Comment: @Andrew - But I think implementing this is a good idea.  I don't really care that you guys at SO don't know whether I have applied or not.  As I said the status should NOT affect you guys in any way.  This is PER USER basis and is important to folks who are applying.  Please don't look at this as a programming problem "Well what if he didnt really apply but he set his status as applied".  I dont care that people do this on purpose or make mistakes and you shouldnt care either.  Its for the user not for you or your stats.

Comment: Presenting this feature will also help your guys algorithm only show me jobs I have not applied to.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for your suggestion.

As comments have noted, this idea is similar to [an earlier feature request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352308/how-can-i-mark-a-job-as-applied-when-the-company-has-a-process-outside-stack-ove), but your suggestion does request additional user input for status meaningful to the job seeker.  Besides, it has been a while since the previous request, so the idea deserves an update.

We (the Jobs team) like the idea of allowing job-seekers to specify whether they have applied to a job that has an external application process.  As you point out, it would allow us to stop showing the job in searches for that user.  Such a feature could also, for instance, enable us not to include such jobs in emails with recommended jobs.

We *know* that the information collected would be user input, so we would rely or not rely on that information accordingly.  We already record when someone clicks on the "Apply" button; this new feature would only augment that data, not replace it.

Given the above — and that I don't know when we'll get to this feature for sure — I'm marking this one [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred).  It's a good feature, and we like it, but it isn't the very next thing on our list.

Now, honestly, we *probably* won't prioritize the rest of your request (allowing the user to specify additional status information) anytime soon.  Certainly, such a feature would be useful for job applicants trying to track the status of multiple application processes.  Despite the feature's utility, however, we have more pressing features in the Jobs pipeline at the moment.

Comment: I dont think there is one single time I ask for a feature that it actually gets implemented.

Comment: When clicked on the button for external job posting, remember and ask user next time they are on Stack Overflow "did you end up applying for job x? we'll use your answer to refine your job search results"