# Why does SO continue to show me ads for jobs to which I've already applied?

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs, advertising

I saw an ad today for a job that I applied to three days ago. Seems to me like this doesn't make very much sense.

Comment: `Seems to me like this doesn't make very much sense.` True - but changing this can be *very* complex, depending on how the system is set up. It may not be worth the person-hours (and the additional resource drain of filtering ads based on what jobs an individual user has applied to) that would be needed to "fix" this.

Comment: It's not a bug, it's simply an oversight. I've updated the tags so the ad-server team can take a look. As @Pekka웃 says this is more complex than it would appear on the surface.

Comment: If you are logged in, this definitely shouldn't be happening. I'll take a look at that code this morning.

Comment: @rossipedia Interesting. I am in fact logged in when I see these ads.

Comment: Related: [Allow users to hide individual job listings](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/312509)

Comment: That feature actually exists: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/331771/115049

Comment: I was aware of that feature and I used it. Doesn't seem like it makes much sense for me to have to do that, though. I can't imagine under what circumstances it would be interesting for me to see an ad for a job to which I already applied. Mostly it just makes me think, "Did I already apply to that job or am I just confused?" Then I click on the ad, see that I already applied, and wonder why I'm still being shown the ad.