# Add a blacklist on jobs

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

I think it would be nice to have an "add to blacklist" feature (opposite to the favourite one). That's because my problem is that, often in different days,

- I keep looking on the same job
- open it and see that there's something I don't have (requirements or experience for example)

To avoid this, I would like to simply mark some jobs as blacklisted and avoid to see them again in my search, so I can save time and focus more on what I'm looking for.

Comment: Already ready already: [Allow users to hide individual job listings](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312509/allow-users-to-hide-individual-job-listings)

Comment: @JoshCaswell awesome! by the way I can't see it :/ [here's my screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6m3neob191wzmkp/screenshot.png?dl=0). Can you please check if the feature still enabled?