# Apply pop-up does not make it clear which version of resume will be attached

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I've used Careers in the past to find people as well as to answer employers' / recruiters' questions about whether I was interested in a job or not. However, I had never used careers to actually "apply" for a job until today.

[I have posted in the past about bugs and confusion in the Careers website.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195988/careers-home-page-needs-work) You can also see various other questions tagged with [careers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/careers) on my [profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/138999/jonh?tab=questions).

Today the experience of "apply" for a job was pretty awful. A few things I'd like to point out:

1. I was applying for a job when this popup came up:
   [image]

When I submitted my application, it sent me an email with an attached PDF of my resume. When I opened my resume, it was a much older version. If I look at my current resume, it doesn't look anything like the older version; it has different information http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jhermiz. Where / what is this resume from, and why did it try to attach the old version of my resume vs. the new resume? I would have thought it would use the latest and greatest career resume.

2. When I go to apply for another job, it cookies / saves the state of my cover letter. Why in god's name does it do that if the message at the bottom states "Hey you have already used this cover letter, you should make it unique"?
3. If I apply for a job listing a popup comes up asking me for my cover letter / resume. If I press <kbd>Esc</kbd> / cancel out of it and go on looking through the site and happen to "back" my way out using the browser - this popup comes up again even though I had cancelled or X'ed out of it.
4. Once I applied, I clicked on the link to take me to my "Application". I thought "great this company has my old resume, let me update it / message them informing this". Well, you cant... the textbox is locked, and it says you cannot enter a message until after the company reaches out to me!

Sorry I hate you Careers... I hated you years ago and I still hate you to this day. You are always broken! When I used you to find people, you were broken; when I used you to answer recruiters or people looking at my information, you were broken. You were even broken when I applied for a job. When will you ever be fixed?

Now the company I applied for probably doesn't believe a lick of what I said in my cover letter, given my cover letter doesn't match what is in my current resume. Thanks... no really; thanks!

Let me ask a serious question to the developers or QA team of the Careers site: have any of you actually used the site to test the experience of applying for a new job? If so, how do you find the experience? Did you notice all the weirdness or quirks? I know they exist, because they happen to me every time I use Careers. If you are just coding and rushing and hoping things are working - they are, they really are, but they don't work **as expected**. There's a big gap between working and what the end user expects.

Comment: Pardon the dust; multiple devs working hard on fixing problems with Careers right now, fully aware that there are problems. Hopefully we'll be making you happy - or at least less hateful - within 6-8 days.

Comment: @Shog9 - While I can understand that you've probably ruined my chances with company X.  It doesn't make sense to me that I cannot update this / message them in any way.  Why on earth was an outdated resume sent to them in the first place.  The pdf of the careers site is generated dynamically on the fly, don't you think the button "Use existing resume" should abide by that rule?  I've been dealing with open issues with the careers site long enough - I've had it with how broken that site is.  It's bitten me trying to hire / find people and now it's bitten me in the worst way possible.

Comment: Yeah, I think this is unnecessarily confusing. Looking into what we can do to correct your application first, but I'll leave this open as a bug as well.

Comment: Thanks @Shog9 - For all i care maybe someone could go to the backend and replace that pdf file (The one it sent to the company) with my most recent resume...that would be a great first step.  Someone(s) from the careers team really needs to sit down and follow the workflow of applying for a job.  Not just once but try to apply to multiple jobs.  I can almost guarantee they will sit there and say you know what - this is awfully confusing and maybe then we can get some real fixes.  Again this is not the first time I have pointed out that careers has a bad user experience.

Comment: Since the PDF gets sent via email, we can't make it disappear once sent... But we could contact them on your behalf with the updated one; would that be an acceptable work-around here? Again, I know this isn't fun - the big problem is that we don't get enough eyeballs on this workflow; it's kinda tucked away from the rest of SO, and only a few people like yourself take the time to speak up. The recent changes to PDF exporting were, I think, **intended** to make this *less* confusing... But clearly there are some rough edges yet. We're working on it.

Comment: @Shog9 - Yes I guess I would be okay with it - The company might think of it as being odd that someone from SO is emailing them about something like this but I don't know how else to address it like you have mentioned it.  Maybe Joel can hire me to do all the testing and the user experience for the careers site - as laughable as it might seem - it is needed and I would love it! :).

Comment: Vote to close?  Seriously? AHHHHHH

Comment: Ok; if you don't mind, send an email to careers@stackoverflow.com with the details on the job and the resume you WANTED to attach (yes, we can look these up, but... Let's make double-sure there are no further mistakes!) We'll pass the updated CV on along with a clarification that we're correcting an error in our system.

Comment: @Shog9 - Email sent - appreciate the help, please phrase it in a way that doesn't make it seem so odd...as odd as it already is lol.

Comment: Anecdotal, but my experience(s) with careers is very similar to this. Every time it was a not clear UX and I found buggy functionality.

Comment: @Shog9 love it!

Comment: Who migrated this and why was it migrated?  Maybe that can appear in the migration message (who and when)...

Comment: Why are the number of views lost when a post is migrated?  That is pretty bad.

Comment: Careers [is being shut down and integrated with Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312452/careers-unificintegration-jobs-on-stack-overflow), so Meta Stack Overflow will be its meta site. That's why they are now migrating everything related to Careers from MSE into here

Comment: SE Careers is a useful starting point, but don't limit yourself.  Usually I look at the company's website, github account and contributors, blogs, LinkedIn company page and people search, youtube, etc.  Not only do I learn a lot more about the company that way, but I also usually discover other ways to get in touch.  Applying on SE is tolerable as a last resort.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I said elsewhere, I'm really sorry this went so badly for you. We did a bunch of work on the apply button for [Jobs on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312452/careers-unificintegration-jobs-on-stack-overflow) and we took some of your issues here into account.

If you have a CV with us, the apply popup will now look like this...

[image]

There's only one step now, instead of the multiple steps in the old and busted process. You just fill out the form and click submit. Because there's fewer steps and less state I hope the two messages about what we'll include in addition to your application are clear.

1. A link to your CV is always included in the application, so we tell you that in the yellow bar, inviting you to edit it to make it right before you send the application. Changes to your CV are always live, so if you update your CV after you apply, they will see the changes when they go to the link.
2. In the resume section we tell you that if you do not upload a resume, we will generate a PDF of your CV and attach it to your application. It will be generated when you click the button, so it will be a snapshot of the information on your CV as of the time you applied. You can preview what it will look like by clicking the link there.

To answer your numbered points:

1. There is no more "Use Existing Resume" and we don't try to prepopulate your resume on this application with one from a previous application.
2. The same for the introduction field (we used to call it Cover Letter). We won't prepopulate the field anymore.
3. This shouldn't happen anymore.
4. We didn't make any changes to the messaging here, but you're right it's silly we don't let you follow-up as an applicant.

I hope this is better / less confusing.

Comment: You're awesome Jason - hey Jason's manager - give this guy a raise!  He follows through.  I tried it already a couple of days ago and 100% better..and cleaner.

Answer (score 22):

Leaving this open as a bug, because the workflow is unnecessarily confusing and potentially disastrous as it stands.

In the meantime, *please* be aware that you'll need to re-export your CV after editing in order to update the PDF.

As always, if something seems confusing or misleading, don't hesitate to post about it here. And if you have problems specific to your account, don't hesitate to email careers@stackoverflow.com with details - we'll do our best to get you sorted out.

Comment: Thanks - this is after all a job experience, job is life changing, family and money is all mixed in.  Thanks for acknowledging little old me.

Comment: I can't remember how this goes, do I accept this as an answer or wait for the bugs to be fixed?

Comment: I would wait...