# How can I update/remove my job application resume?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

I have applied for a job application, but after seconds I've noticed I uploaded the old version of my resume, but I did not find a way to update it or re-apply again.

Comment: At the moment, you can't upload a new resume. You can't withdraw your application either.

Comment: Possibly related? [Apply pop-up does not make it clear which version of resume will be attached](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312567/apply-pop-up-does-not-make-it-clear-which-version-of-resume-will-be-attached)