# Is it expected that I need to copy my CV from the old careers site to the new integrated one?

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I have just opted in to the new unificintegrated Jobs feature from [Careers Unificintegration: Jobs on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312452/careers-unificintegration-jobs-on-stack-overflow).  I already have a CV on http://careers.stackoverflow.com/ewanmellor.

I thought from reading the post that all my CV details would copy over to the new site, because I have it linked to my Stack Overflow account.  That didn't happen though, and now I've got a blank CV for my Stack Overflow account at https://stackoverflow.com/users/2499076/ewan-mellor too.

Is this by design?  I would (obviously) rather not have to copy all that content over to the new CV manually.

This is either a feature request or a bug, depending on whether this is by design currently!

Comment: Your last link there is to your SO profile. Not your Jobs profile

Comment: Nope, this is definitely not by design! Do you have a 'Create CV' link or just an empty CV at the moment?

Comment: Do you have [this little guy here](http://i.imgur.com/6Xzf1Ci.png)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Nope, you don't need to copy your CV from the old careers site to Stack Overflow. If you did link your existing careers account to Stack Overflow in the past then  you should be able to see your CV on Stack Overflow. But if you didn't then you can link them from *Create CV* page or from *Edit Profile & Settings* on Stack Overflow.

In your case, we found that you had two careers accounts and both of them were linked to your [Stack Overflow account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2499076/ewan-mellor). I have merged these accounts and you should be able to see your CV now.

Comment: Yes, that's fixed it, thanks Kirti.