# What is the difference between SO Jobs and Careers SO?

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow-jobs

As we all know, there is a subsite of SO called Careers, whose purpose is to find a job. The new Jobs tab on the main site appears to do the same thing. What is the difference between the two?

Comment: Interesting... this jobs questions OP is not  johnH..!

Comment: @TJ - Its JonH my parents forgot the h in John.

Comment: @JonH oops sorry mate.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There isn't really a difference.

SO Careers is really in the process of being moved in with the main Stack Overflow site, for a number of reasons. Most notably, different logins, and easier integration for users who want to use both without a hassle.

Comment: +1, will accept soon: Exactly what I was wondering. Thank you!

Comment: Why didnt they think it before? I mean they could do it while creating it careers site at first ! :)

Comment: @OldBunny2800 On the right side, there is a featured article with the official announcement (or use this direct link http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312452/careers-unificintegration-jobs-on-stack-overflow?cb=1 ) ;)

Comment: This isn't correct!  In fact SO careers will always be around for the employer side, the only part that is moving is the candidate side.

Comment: What is it different, the two job feeds: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312937/difference-between-the-two-job-feeds

Answer (score 4):

The real difference and most notable is that careers will stick around for the employer side, that is if you want to hire the best programmers!  The jobs tab is for candidates actually seeking employment.