# Difference between the two job feeds

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow-jobs

As from the "[What is the difference between SO Jobs and Careers SO?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312815/what-is-the-difference-between-so-jobs-and-careers-so)" its seems to be that both are similar. If same then why the two job sites' feeds are different in contents?

http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/feed

https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/feed

Are the two sources not coming from the same employers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SO Jobs and Careers are one and the same thing; SO Jobs is basically just a smart proxy for regular Careers.

The difference you're seeing probably has a couple of contributing factors.

1. We are running an A/B test on our search implementation and each side produces slightly different results.
2. One side of that test was broken over the weekend (fixed yesterday).

It's probable that on `careers.stackoverflow.com` you were on a different side of the A/B test than on `stackoverflow.com/jobs`.

We're (hopefully) graduating that experiment in the next day or so. At that point both sites will be consistent with each other.