# No Jobs tab on Meta SO

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow-jobs

Why are users not presented with the new Jobs tab on `http://meta.stackoverflow.com/`?

Since the Meta site is specifically for SO topics, it would make some sense to keep the navigation consistent.

Stack Overflow, with Jobs button:

[image: tada]

Meta Stack Overflow, no Jobs for you!

[image: sad]

Comment: ​+1 For the red free-hand... whatever that is.

Comment: +1 for sad frog face...and because it's a good suggestion/bug find

Comment: Jobs aren't in Beta for you on Stack Overflow? Are you special?

Comment: would actually be kinda cool if meta.stackoverflow.com/jobs redirected to http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/jobs

Comment: If you check "not interested in jobs" on your profile, that "beta" thing goes away, @TylerH.

Comment: I disagree @Shog9; top level nav items shouldn't change what they point to. Clicking "Jobs" shouldn't sometimes take you to a list of jobs and sometimes to a list of questions...but I guess a redirect just for is someone typed in that url might make sense.

Comment: What is a list of bugs but a list of jobs for a very specific set of people?

Comment: @Shog9 - Well with the new navbar this can be easily achieved.  I think it should just open jobs like so does.  I may want to go looking for a job while on meta.

Comment: I half expect the Jobs tag in Meta to redirect to the Work Here page.

Comment: @TylerH The image has been repurposed from [Jason's post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/312452/1677912). I do see the "beta" tag on my account.

Comment: In all seriousness, I kinda like having a few significant differences in the UI between meta and main. Might discourage a few people from posting programming questions in the wrong spot.

Comment: it'll end world hunger before it does that @Shog9

Comment: Given that [Meta is Murder,](http://blog.codinghorror.com/meta-is-murder/) the "Jobs" tab here should point to the *really bad* jobs.

Answer (score 14):

This is by design, there's no sensible thing to display on MSO for the Jobs tab.

If you're proposing that it should show all the questions for the Jobs tab then I'd disagree - that's exactly what the [jobs](/questions/tagged/jobs) tag is for! We don't special case any other parts of SO like this so it would be odd to do so just for the Jobs tab...

Comment: I'm fine with this answer but why not just post actual jobs here.

Comment: @JonH jobs for SO itself? We have listings on [se.com](http://stackexchange.com/work-here) but we've since renamed the company! Maybe meta would be a good place for those jobs to live long-term...

Comment: Ya I mean if it just opens up so jobs why would that hurt in any way.  To me your answer is sufficient, I just think it wouldn't hurt to link jobs on meta too.

Comment: I'm not sure you understood my question - rather it appears you've responded to others' comments on it. The Jobs tab on SO leads to the Jobs PRODUCT, which would be just as sensible on MSO as on SO. I didn't propose showing questions related to jobs at all.

Comment: @JonH: What, like, _meta jobs_? :D

Comment: I agree with mogsdad that is what I meant in my comments

Comment: But I *want* a job where my job is to have a job...

Comment: Error: Infinitely recursive job.