# Distance for last searches in Careers still shown in non-metric miles: "Meilen"

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

[image: Detail image]

In the last searches the distance is still displayed in "Meilen" (miles)
while the search itself already uses km.

Comment: Well, banish the word from the German language and an American company might consider :)  Dollars to donuts, it is actually kilometers to the dbase.  Hehe.

Comment: @HansPassant What exactly do you want to tell me...?

Comment: Oh, got the wrong size hat today.  This is the meta site for stackoverflow.com, we talk about SO issues here.  Consider using meta.stackexchange.com or send a message through the Contact us link at the bottom of the page.

Comment: @HansPassant I used the link provided by Shog9 in http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312452/careers-unificintegration-jobs-on-stack-overflow/312765?noredirect=1#comment284983_312765. Please confirm that I should other sites to report the bug.

Comment: I guess it isn't necessary, Kirti saw it too. She works for SE it seems.  Very unusual, SE employees don't usually show up here.  It is a confirmed bug, she saw it too, rest well, it is logged, miled and kilometered. Enjoy your Christmas

Comment: @HansPassant You too.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for the report, Thorsten! That's a good catch.

Some eons ago someone(*cough!*) made a change to show the distance units in search as per the user's location and they missed to propagate that change to *recent searches*. This is fixed now and in your next *recent searches* you should be able to see the correct distance units.

Comment: No problem, glad to help. Hope that y^H someone had no trouble for the mistake...