# Wrong use of German singular and plural in Careers for time units

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, plurals

If Stack careers is opened, we see the time in the past when the job was offered:
[image: Detail page]

Singular conjugates the word of the time unit, it is:

1 "Minute"   / 0 or many "Minuten" (minute)
1 "Stunde" / 0 or many "Stunden"  (hour)
1 "Tag"    / 0 or many "Tage"     (day)
1 "Woche"  / 0 or many "Wochen"   (weeks)
1 "Monat"  / 0 or many "Monate"   (months)

Comment: This is a super set of http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313327/distance-for-last-searches-in-careers-still-shown-in-non-metric-miles-meilen

Comment: @Braiam Why is the wrong use of singular/plural for a German time unit a super set of the wrong distance unit...?

Comment: Because while the other guy found one instance where it was handled wrongly, you found more in the same category.

Comment: @Braiam Incidentally the other guy was me :) ; it was a different error and if you read the link in the comments below provided by moderator Shog9 we should provide one question per bug.

Comment: Looks like Jeff Atwood needs a [giant N or E](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/9694/38765).

Comment: Confirmed. It's correct in the English copy (week/weeks etc.) so probably just a small oversight by our translators.

Comment: @Max In defense of the translators: It is a tiny detail which very often gets wrongly coded, especially in translation tables.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm I and the other million Germans who actually care about plural will expectantly await Jeff's arrival. You get him back once we have properly...erm...germanized him.

Answer (score 5):

Should be better now:

[image]