# Did "Careers Unificintegration" break custom profile URLs?

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I have a custom profile URL set for my CV. The CV gives it as http://careers.stackoverflow.com/[customhandle]

Both this URL, and the URL referenced in the [Careers Unificintegration: Jobs on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312452/careers-unificintegration-jobs-on-stack-overflow?cb=1) FAQ, specifically https://stackoverflow.com/cv/[customhandle] appear to be somewhat problematic at this time.

The former is perfectly 404-compliant. The latter manages to come up with a slightly amusing customized 404 page.

Just thought that I'd mention that.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for mentioning it, Sam. I see that you've chosen your custom URL, but you need to click the "Make Public" button on your CV's Settings page to make the CV show up at that URL.

[image]