# Stack Exchange Logo on Stack Overflow CV instead of Stack Overflow Logo

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

On my Stack Overflow Careers Developer CV the image for Stack Overflow is the Stack Exchange logo.  The tooltip says "Stack Overflow:

[image: cv]

It also looks like there's the Stack Exchange Meta logo just below it, albeit cut off.

[Link to my Developer CV for reference.](https://stackoverflow.com/cv/joshlieberman)

Comment: It's showing the SO logo in your CV for me

Comment: Something weird is going on with the CSS sprite map. Thanks for reporting it, I'll see what's going on. @Rob which browser are you using?

Comment: @SteveTrout Chrome, Version 49.0.2623.112 m on Windows 10 Home

Comment: Thanks @Rob - I see the problem on OS X but not Windows (Chrome in both cases). Excuse me while I go cry in a corner for a while.

Comment: Maybe it's a DPI thing - @JAL are you using a Retina/HiDPI display?

Comment: @SteveTrout yes, browsing on a MacBook Pro Retina 15.4-inch (2880 x 1800), Intel Iris Pro 1536 MB

Comment: Your CV shows the SO logo fine for me as well, Firefox 45.0.2 on Windows 7, on a Dell P2414H with a 1920x1080 resolution.

Comment: @JAL your link was right! CDN caching + media queries + partial code sharing = ouch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be better now. TL;DR cache invalidation is hard.

It was a combination of CDN caching, media queries, and our build process being a little weird from [the great job board migration](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312452/careers-unificintegration-jobs-on-stack-overflow).

We updated our favicon sprite sheet but didn't update the CSS including it (in this particular case), meaning it still pulled in a cached old version from our CDN (because the cache key is a hash of the CSS file).

However a *different* CSS file *was* updated. It also includes the sprite sheet, but the old (wrong) rule took priority. (Why are there two? We have some code sharing between the employer-facing view and your view, and it's not doing quite the right thing here.) That CSS also corrects the image's dimensions on high DPI screens -- using the dimensions of the updated image, of course.

The result is an old image was being served but it was stretched into the new image's dimensions. Sometimes.

Comment: Is this really fixed? I still see Stack Exchange logo on OP's CV: http://stackoverflow.com/cv/joshlieberman

Comment: @Meta it was fixed but not in a future-proof way, so now it's broken again. I'm fixing it again right now. (We have some pending changes that should fix it for good.)