# SuperSecretTrackingCookie2 on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support

Just out of interest, I was checking out what cookies were in use on Stack Overflow, and to my surprise, I found "SuperSecretTrackingCookie2". It's a subtle name, I almost looked over it, but *something* (I can't quite pinpoint exactly what) made me wonder if there is something nefarious about it...

The only reference I've found so far is [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84583/cannot-add-location-email-to-careers), dating back to 2011, it seems superSecretTrackingCookie v1.0 has been around a while...

Is anyone aware of:

- What this is?
- Does everyone else have this cookie?
- Whether it's necessary (in which case, maybe it's time to change the name)?
- What happened to `superSecretTrackingCookie1`

[image]

Comment: superSecretTrackingCookie1 was better at hiding.

Comment: <insert Jon Skeet fact>

Comment: Hmm, I don't appear to have that cookie

Comment: A/B testing? Some people get superSecretTrackingCookie1 and others get superSecretTrackingCookie2?

Comment: I don't have that cookie on Google Chrome...

Comment: Bad name, needs refactoring. It's not that secret.

Comment: We could tell you what `superSecretTrackingCookie2` does, but then we'd have to `kill -9` you…

Comment: Or `sudo rm -rf /` your memory.

Comment: I ended up with that cookie on the main site.  Doesn't exist on meta.

Comment: My `superSecretTrackingCookie2` has `Host: careers.stackoverflow.com`

Comment: `// temporary name for development TODO find a less explicit one`

Comment: I hate it when I feel like I remember something but there's no dupe. I could have sworn this cookie has come up before.

Comment: How do you know that there is no superSecretTrackingCookie3, superSecretTrackingCookie4 etc. on your computer right now? ***They evolve.***

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237370/what-is-the-iamhappywhereiam-cookie-set-by-careers-stackoverflow-com - mentioned in the comments under this question (2014)

Comment: @Mat, yeah, but no explanation was provided, except that the SO team has fun when naming their cookies

Comment: @sacul and that answer wouldn't also explain your question? I mean, "they name stuff for fun" would definitely explain "superSecretTrackingCookie" I think

Comment: @Patrice yeah, I guess in a sense that explains the name, but I guess I'm still curious about the cookie

Comment: This meta question and the mentioned Meta.SE could be known as: "The Secret Life of Cookies / National Geographic", special program with night vision cameras and all

Comment: I'm disappointed to not be part of the Super Secret Cookie Club :( Why doesn't SO care enough to track me...

Comment: @TemporalWolf Because superdupersecretcodetrackingcookie doesn't even show up in your cookie list.

Comment: It's part of A/B testing to see how much your cheese can move without you noticing.

Comment: @TravisJ Apparently, the answer is not very far at all. Replacing the cheese with cookies just brings notice faster, for better or worse.

Comment: It is only one of about *three hundred* reasons to use an ad blocker: http://cookiepedia.co.uk/website/stackoverflow.com/0

Comment: @Servy I was thinking that superSecretTrackingCookie1 suffered the same fate that Shog7

Comment: This is nothing. When they start setting `superSecretNefariousTrackingCookie1` then I'll be officially worried.

Comment: @Cerbrus you don't have it on Chrome probably because Chrome is already a "botnet" by itself and it would be too much tracking if a super secret cookie is added. https://wiki.installgentoo.com/index.php/Chromium#Google_Chrome

Comment: @ryanyuyu Nobody would question it if it were named `SkeetCookie`, tho.

Comment: @Pekka웃 That's the one where they set the `Evil` bit, right?

Comment: No secret coockies here :(

Comment: @TravisJ  That kind of testing was already done on recent ToS changes :) **Result** = they can take away the entire cheese and then tell us it's for a greater good, and we still won't do sh** about that ;)

Comment: sushhh... Its Area-51 project. Don't tell anyone.

Comment: Relevant: Permanent everlasting cookie: https://samy.pl/evercookie/

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Greetings and Happy Friday!

A very long time ago there was a website called Stack Overflow Careers. I worked on that website and needed to count things like unique visitors to jobs pages, and unique people using the search function. I created...the SuperSecretTrackingCookie.

Years later SuperSecretTrackingCookie fell out of fashion for SuperSecretTrackingCookie2, which fulfilled the same purpose.

Years after that Stack Overflow Careers was [Unificintegrated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312452/careers-unificintegration-jobs-on-stack-overflow) with Stack Overflow under the Jobs Tab. And the SuperSecretTrackingCookie2 made its way to Stack Overflow.

So no, there's no nefarious purposes, just counting. For anyone in the comments disappointed you didn't have the cookie, we'll bake you a fresh one if you view a job on /jobs.

Comment: I think the ambiguity of the name "SuperSecretTrackingCookie" makes people assume it is for nefarious purposes. As it turns out it is not, is there a possibility for the name to be changed to something less alarming, like UniqueVisitorCount? That might ease a bit of unrest this cookie's name brings.

Comment: @plasmaTonic, to be honest, I figured it was relatively harmless (read: as harmless as any typical cookie), I just wanted to get the story behind it. I like the humor in the name, especially now that there is a way for people to figure out what it is (this question should show up in the first few hits of a google search of `SuperSecretTrackingCookie`)

Comment: @plasmaTonic I'd tend to assume that a cookie called `UniqueVisitorCount` – with an innocuous name – would be from a Highly Dodgy Company, doing Highly Nefarious Things, trying to hide their tracks... so `SuperSecretTrackingCookie` is probably _less_ suspicious! (Until the HDC doing HNTs cottons-on and does a double-bluff!) ((Unless they already have:-)))