# Jobs messages in my inbox link to SO Talent, which I cannot signup/login for

Tags: bug, status-declined, stack-overflow-jobs

I have a variety of messages in my inbox labeled "jobs message". When I click on any of them, it takes me to `https://talent.stackoverflow.com/users/login`. This is undesirable in itself; I should not need to log in to a separate account to view messages in my existing account's inbox!

Worse, I don't have a Talent account.

Worst, I am denied signup for a talent account with my gmail address. So I can't even look at these (unsolicited) jobs messages!

Answer (score 4):

The messages you're referring to are from June 2015 prior to when we [migrated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312452/careers-unificintegration-jobs-on-stack-overflow) the candidate-facing experience of Stack Overflow Careers to Stack Overflow Jobs.

We didn't go and rewrite all those messages and because they direct you to `careers.stackoverflow.com` *and* you're anonymous according to the application hosted at that URL we have no way to determine whether you are an employer user or a candidate user so that we can redirect you to the right place (for context: both employers and candidates go to the same messaging UI it just lives in different places now). So, instead, we present you with a login screen and you can't get any further because you can no longer log into Stack Overflow Talent using a non-employer account.

Given the age of the messages concerned and that all messages sent since launch day back in December 2015 point at the right place, we won't be fixing this particular issue because doing so is a lot of work for a tiny amount of gain. Sorry!

Comment: Why don't you just remove all of the broken migrated messages? They are completely useless. It's spam you can't even click on!

Comment: There are two things that bother me about this:

1. The inbox date does not show the year, so it is visually hard to tell that these messages are as old as they are.

2. The inbox does not give me any way to clear out old messages, so I am stuck scanning through these things forever. Be leaving this stuff here you are incentivizing me to ignore the inbox.