# Creating a topic which already has good official documentation

Tags: support, documentation, documentation-topics

I wonder how can I procced with this situation. The tag [kendo-ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kendo-ui) have just been open for contribuitions in Documentation and I was about to create a topic, where I want to approach the *Templates* feature. I have a substantial knowledge about it, but I went to the its official docs to get some inspiration about what and how I will put it into the docs.

After reading the [official doc page](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/templates/overview), I realized that it is extremely complete and clear - with addition of nice examples and explanations. What I would add to it here in Documentation could only be another examples, but all types of implementations of this feature is well covered there.

I think that this feature is a requirement for any Kendo UI docs and it have to be in [kendo-ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kendo-ui) Documentation, but it seems to take sand to the beach writing a new topic for that.

How should we proceed in that case?

Comment: And ironically, if a tag is not well documented elsewhere, there's typically a reason for that and it's rather unlikely that people will be suddenly found to document it on SO. So I guess this is gonna be the most common question over the next months.

Comment: "How should we proceed in that case?" Don't create a second best documentation here. It's a waste of time and my even draw traffic to the second best solution. I always thought of SO Documentation as solution for all cases where the official documentation lacks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We built this platform so that we could give developers better documentation than what's currently out there. As I wrote when [we initially announced our integration plans](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310066/stack-overflow-serving-programmers-even-better):

> Some things have obsessively-curated and up-to-date documentation with plenty of practical examples that illustrate real-world use cases. So, we're going to focus on the other 97% of documentation.

The impetus for creating and committing to a topic *should* be the realization that something better could be made, along with some inspiration on how that might happen.

Back when I was picking up jQuery (like all the other cool kids), I tended to get my *start* from their official documentation which had plenty of examples, but often referred back to *my* own implementations for reference because my use cases were so much closer to whatever I might be currently doing than their very basic examples. *Better examples from real-world code* is probably a good way to approach it.

Other things you can do is include illustrations of very common pitfalls when it comes to approach, and let people know why something that seems like it should work and seems much more convenient is actually a pretty bad idea.

***Not everything out there can really be improved upon.*** But, that's a very small fraction of what's currently available. Still, when contemplating the addition of a topic, it's *very* good to know in advance how you plan to make it different from what exists, and set the initial tone of the topic to that idea.

In most cases, that's not going to be very hard :) But some, like you pointed to - there's not a whole lot of low-hanging fruit in the basics, perhaps you could try tackling step-by-step narrated examples of the harder stuff? It's hard to really give a blanket answer to that.

Spending some time in the existing docs *should* give you some inspiration, but it's totally okay if it doesn't, too - it just means that developers are already being pretty well served by what exists in that topic.

Comment: That was the first thing that came to my mind, *how can I improve those examples*. With real uses and scenarios as you said, I think. Great answer, thank you.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown And perhaps one of the best ways to find a place that can be improved is by taking a look at the current *questions* on SO, and finding out what points people don't seem to find in the documentation.  (Granted, that's often because it seems like users don't bother to look at it in the first place, but...)