# Reputation earned on Documentation should not unlock certain Stack Overflow privileges

Tags: feature-request, reputation, documentation

As we have all heard repeated, reputation represents a basic level of trust. From the [MSE faq about reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7238/280467):

> Reputation is a rough measurement of how much the community trusts you; it is earned by convincing your peers that you know what you’re talking about.

**Proposal: reputation earned from Documentation should be distinct from reputation earned on Stack Overflow, at least for the purposes of unlocking certain moderation privileges.**

While there are some similarities between the two sites, they are very different in their expectations and execution.  For example, documentation has a much different take on "broadness" than Stack Overflow.  It doesn't make sense to me for users who mainly contribute to broadly scoped documentation requests to also judge a similar (too broad) request on Stack Overflow.

Additionally, it is much easier to earn reputation *without domain knowledge* on Documentation via editing.  I do admit that writing Documentation to be as clear as possible requires a lot of editing/revising, so giving reputation for such tasks makes sense.  Those contributions help make Documentation better, but they  have nothing to do with how Stack Overflow actually moderates posts.

I'd be fine with showing reputation earned via Documentation in the user card, similar to how SE-network flair combines reputation from all sites with at least 200 reputation.  I'd also support reputation earned from Documentation to help unlock the Edit Everywhere privilege, since Documentation contributions prove editing skills at least as well as normal Stack Overflow reputation.

But I don't like the idea of an editor without very limited interactions on the main site voting on which posts should be open or closed or even reviewing the quality of posts via triage or close votes.  SE already enforces this in protected questions.  Users cannot answer protected questions until they have earned 10 reputation on that site from actual site activities (the network association bonus does not count).

Answer (score -29):

First: [Documentation is part of Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/310066/865899). It's a new tool, but not a separate entity. They're one and the same: Docs, Q&A, and Jobs are all part of greater Stack Overflow.

So, what you're asking for is to have Q&A rep/privileges be separate from Documentation rep/privileges. To that request I'll give the most annoying suggestion possible: that we should wait and see. Right now we're dealing with a stampede on Day 1 right when the doors have opened, as well as a bug in the rep cap logic that overinflated lots of people's reputation today. The fix and recalc are coming down the pike.

Once Docs participation steadies out, and we've got a rep scheme that's doing what we expect, we'll be able to:

- See how much rep people are actually earning on Docs compared to Q&A
- See how much overlap there is between Docs rep-earners and Q&A users taking mod actions
- Analyze the quality of those actions (are more flags disputed? do things get more upvotes after edits?)

And see what has and hasn't become a problem. These are just my dumb, top-of-my-head examples, but I believe we need much more information before we can determine if anything needs to be changed here. If you want more of a substantive answer, I'll tell you what my gut says: once we figure out the right balance for Docs rep levels, I don't think we'll need to make the distinction you're describing.

Documentation is for the Stack Overflow community, just like Q&A and Jobs and Chat. It's one more tool at your disposal to help you hone your skills as a developer and share your knowledge with the greater programming community.

Comment: I guess I just disagree with how much integrated it should be with Stack Overflow.  But if there are joined at the hip then I guess this is by-design.

Comment: @ryanyuyu And like I said, if there are problems arising out of this then we'll certainly address them. We aren't forcing anyone to accept Docs forever and always exactly the way it is today; it's definitely a work in progress. And If we find folks farming rep on Docs and using it to make unilateral but unpopular edits on Q&A (for example) we'll work with the community to figure out the appropriate measures to shut it down.

Comment: The problem with the "wait and see" approach is that it has real, genuine consequences. Today. I would much preferred that Docs.SO had started off with no incentives, then "wait and see" if participation falls off after the initial influx, then add rep where it was *proven* to be needed. Rather than giving rep for *everything*, creating a lot of users with more rep than they ought to have, then scaling it back later.

Comment: This answer begs the question of why there is no reputation awarded for Jobs. Perhaps it isn't as simple as "everything that is part of Stack Overflow contributes to your rep."

Comment: I'd also like to point out that, currently, there are privileges in docs that can only be obtained by participating in Q&A. The types of users who will use docs overlap with, but are not a subset of Q&A users. There should be a path to full doc privileges that do not involve Q&A. In the past, there was much talk about being able to use Q&A without using Careers. Where is that philosophy now? Why must I answer questions to be able to commit to writing docs?