# Add indicator saying if user has contributed to Documentation

Tags: feature-request, documentation, reputation, profile-page

We have Docs now, and some signs indicate that it completely changed the way reputation is perceived.

Some users may love this, but others don't as you can see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/329528/2510678) and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/328689/2510678).

If the rep is not going be split as suggested [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/329980/2510678), maybe a `green check` could be added in profiles that have contributed to docs (green check still looks like a good thing). So with a quick glimpse you can tell if someone has earned rep from docs or not.

Another way could be adding percentages:

```
3,582 REPUTATION (78% Q&A, 22% Docs)
```

Not good at UI personally, so I let that on you to refine.

BTW, I kind of implemented this on my own profile, but it has many limitations as you can see...

**EDIT (20/08/2016):**

According to [the docs update](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/331663/documentation-update-august-4th) the fix for the rep system is not even well defined yet, so having this indicator may be useful in the meantime (being that period not a short one).

A subtle way to display this info could be:

[image: green from QA, blue from Docs]

Comment: Maybe a scarlet "D"?

Comment: @JonEricson that's a good one haha, but I want to keep this as constructive as possible, at the end you are all trying to deliver a good product

Comment: I'm not sure if it's technically feasible off the top of my head (there be dragons in the rep history tables), but I kinda like the idea of providing a %  breakdown or something like it. Once we eventually get to a stable rep system for Docs, there shouldn't really be any stigma involved, and knowing the % is kinda neat IMO.

Comment: @AdamLear the data should be there I think, and the _"stigma"_ could be as subtle as a fixed width rep bar, in which Q&A rep fills his % in green, and the docs rep fill the rest in blue.

Comment: @FelipePereira "Stigma" as in "negative connotation". I'm just saying that after a while folks shouldn't hopefully stop thinking of rep gained from Documentation as lesser/not as valuable/not as deserved vs Q&A rep.

Comment: @AdamLear I know stigma has a negative connotation, that's why I _""_ it,  to make clear that showing the composition of rep is not a bad thing

Answer (score 11):

The point Jon Ericson was trying to make with his comment is that there shouldn't be a stigma attached to Docs.SO work. You *shouldn't care* if someone got their rep from one or the other.

Granted, that would require a rep-gain system for Docs.SO that actually *made sense*. But you should treat the *disease*, not the symptoms.

Comment: I mostly agree with your position, but also have to explain that my request can be seen a _"in the meantime"_ solution (or permanent if none of the current issues are addressed)

Answer (score 0):

There's a caveat with this.

If such a breakdown is implemented, **it should be optional to publicly display the percentages on one's profile** because you can't guarantee that no one will make fun of those who got more rep in Documentation than Q&A, [just like the accept rate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136951/lets-stop-displaying-a-users-accept-rate).

Comment: But if we make it opt-out, the system will be useless.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Why not publicly display it by default, then?

Comment: Oh, I'm for it. I was just saying it shouldn't be opt-out. Either we display this information, or we don't.