# What happened to careers.stackoverflow.com?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

Whenever I go to `careers.stackoverflow.com` I get redirected to `http://talent.stackoverflow.com`.

The *talent* site seems to be aimed at companies.  I am not a company and would like to get to some job listings :)

Is there something I am missing?  Was there some change somewhere along the way, or some setting that I messed up?

Comment: Actually, http://talent.stackoverflow.com now redirects to https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/talent  ... apparently, using www is suddenly "in"? They never did it before.

Comment: @NormalHuman : But if you are registered user in the talent, you will redirect to `http://talent.stackoverflow.com/employer/user-dashboard/current`

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Careers does not exist anymore. The candidate-side of the product was [integrated back into Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310066/stack-overflow-serving-programmers-even-better) as the [Jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs) tab [a while ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312452/careers-unificintegration-jobs-on-stack-overflow). The job search, and your developer story/CV now exist solely here on Stack Overflow without the need for a secondary site or a second login. The remaining employer-facing side of Careers has been transitioned into our Talent product. If you're not an employer, there is no reason for you to ever login on that site - there is nothing for a candidate to do there.

Comment: I was quite confused there for a while... don't quite know how I missed that but now I know :)

Comment: Wouldn’t it make sense to have some way to redirect candidates to jobs from careers in case people still have that URL somewhere? Since careers was previously a portal for both sides, it just redirecting to one side feels somewhat confusing.

Comment: @poke For a long time attempting to login to Careers with a candidate account automatically redirected you back to Jobs. But we can only redirect people for so long.

Comment: Why can you only redirect people for so long? Does redirecting someone who is a candidate rather than a business actually cause a logic conflict on your login script?

Comment: @Martin Considering that the careers domain is no longer used, and we were completely dropping the candidate-side database after some grace period for the small percentage of users who hadn't transferred to Jobs, there's no way we *could* continue redirecting people. Maintaining a permanent redirect system after a year, after multiple public addresses on our sites, and after multiple emails directly to the users who were still not transferred over is somewhat unreasonable. We gave everyone a very fair chance to get here.

Comment: ok, fair enough :)

Comment: imo the transition was quite confusing. I had no idea that there was jobs tab. I stopped using the stackoverflow jobs as I thought it was dead, but seeing this post, I see you just moved it.

Comment: I don't know if there's been something posted about this, but I was looking at someone's profile earlier where they had a link for "careers" in their StackOverflow.com account, i.e.: `https://careers.stackoverflow.com/member_name` and it redirected me to `https://stackoverflow.com/cv/member_name` being a "Page Not Found". Is this a bug, or does it mean that that member did not sign up in the new section? Or, that it wasn't properly redirected?

Comment: @Fred-ii- They likely never completed the transfer themselves. When we imported all the data on behalf of users, all of those profiles were automatically switched to hidden to protect privacy. Only users who transferred manually *before* the mass migration, or have explicitly switched it back to visible, can be seen.

Comment: @animuson Ah, that makes sense. I had a feeling that something like that would have been the reason. Thanks for clarifying that for me, *cheers*

Comment: I am *SO* Mandela Affected [sic] by this... Holy cow! NO WHERE IN MY PREVIOUS REALITY had careers.stackoverflow.com disappeared in December TWENTY FIFTEEN! I for sure, 150%, used that site in 2016, and I do believe 2017 as well...