# Please ask User Research International to stop posting research study "jobs"

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs, spam

[User Research International](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/user-research-international) has been frequently posting and reposting in Jobs "Research Study" listings. These are not contract or career positions. I've been flagging them but they keep coming.

Please reach out to them to adjust their behavior or do some more drastic action.

*Edit:* I did receive an update this morning from Stack Exchange on the matter to highlight the official policy:

> Our policy is that if it is paid, we still permit it. If you would like to avoid seeing these, please head to the company's page, then hit the [...] button and choose to Dismiss the company. This will prevent any further research studies from them being shown to you.

Still, it seems very spammy.

Comment: It may not be an actual "job", but it's reasonably on-topic and provides money in exchange for developer-related services. Is there a policy against that? (there may well be)

Comment: I would have expected a job posting to cost more than an ad on the main site. It's kind of weird they even *want* to use a Jobs posting for this. (A main site ad is probably less likely to rub people the wrong way.)

Comment: "Our policy is that if it is paid, we still permit it" is not a policy at all. There must be some sort of standards for job ads. One would think that a company that cares so much about pronouns might also care about slave labor, minimum wages, or clearly unethical enterprises.

Comment: That said, the problem with these particular ads is not necessarily that they are unethical, it is that they violate the spirit of a job site. Why should I wade through a bunch of ads that don't have anything to do with finding a real job?

Comment: We used to have standards here.  Folks knew when something was hinky, and so did the company.  I see those standards being gradually eroded over time.

Comment: @RobertHarvey That they didn't respond with their entire Terms of Service agreement for employers using the Jobs site doesn't imply they'd be OK with slave labor.

Comment: I don't think it's too bad but the reply from SO is also not very satisfactory. If jobs search on Jobs doesn't work well because of spam it's not our problem, it's their problem and they should solve it.

Answer (score -3):

I do agree that it's not a traditional job offering, but we continue to allow them on the platform because of the success they've seen. This tells us that while some users may not be interested in the opportunity, lots of our users are. I cannot comment on the specifics of their success, but we wouldn't allow them to continue posting if we didn't see value in what they offer.

We have allowed non-traditional job ads on the network, and we'll continue to do so as long as the company is doing so in good faith. Every job flag is reviewed, even though we may not respond to all comments.

We also offer a mechanism for blocking employers for this very reason. If for any reason you don't want to see offers from a specific company, you can always go to their [company page](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/user-research-international), click the three dots, and dismiss them.

Comment: [Wasn't this meant to be for developers, though?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/310066/1079354)  When did this pivot happened?  (Not being accusatory here, I genuinely want to know. I haven't used the product outside of two very bad experiences and have largely tuned it out since 2015.)

Comment: @Makoto I've worked here for almost seven years and we've always allowed developer adjacent jobs. DevOps, IT, CTO, Product Managers, etc. It's primarily for developer jobs but it's never been it's sole function.

Comment: Huh.  Okay.  I never really saw it that way; it was advertised as a thing for devs to avoid the bad experiences we've had when trying to find work on the other job sites.  I suppose I've learned something new tonight.