# The Developer Story Part 2: We didn't explain that very well

Tags: discussion, developer-story

Recently, we presented the community with our idea for [the Developer Story](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313960/introducing-the-developer-story) to get your thoughts and feedback; and feedback we got! We appreciate all the comments and answers on the original post.

In hindsight, we realize that we missed the boat, [didn't follow our own advice](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272607/can-we-talk-about-the-voting-culture-here-on-meta/272617#272617), and failed to include a lot of valuable information about this new feature; this post will address what was missed.  It really comes down to

[image: part 2]

---

**The Developer Story is our evolution of the traditional CV, and it's replacing the existing Jobs (or Careers) CV.** This isn't a new feature; it's part of the [integration of Jobs on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312452/careers-unificintegration-jobs-on-stack-overflow) and it's an upgrade to the function.  The Developer Story will allow users to show off their achievements in a new format.  If you're interested in job opportunities, then this is for you.  If you're not, then you can totally ignore this feature, as it will not change any of the existing Q&A features of the site.

### What problem are we trying to solve?

Resumes have been around for 500+ years and were first invented [to be an introduction for travelling Lords](http://www.lettersofnote.com/2012/03/skills-of-da-vinci.html). Using it as an introduction is great if you want to show off a list of credentials, but you are more than your degree or a list of places where you worked.  You are also **what you've worked on; what you've written.**  Technology has evolved, but tech resumes haven't so we're redesigning how this information is displayed.

When Stack Overflow Q&A launched, our community took a strong position that on SO, you should be *judged on what you know, not who you are.*  In other words, judge the content, not the contributor.  We strongly believe that hiring developers needs more of that attitude.  **The Developer Story is your story:** it gives you a better way to find a job you love based on **what you can do**, not who you are. Instead of presenting yourself as a bulleted list of action verbs, you'll be able to show off the stuff that actually matters to you, including the technologies you work with and any public artifacts like open source projects or applications you've written.

The design is different from a traditional resume because we're also trying to get employers to **think differently** about candidates by emphasizing what you've done.  We know that it will take some time, so employers will still have the option to see your history in a traditional sorted view, but even in that view we're presenting a more complete picture of your history.

### It's called "Developer Story" but I'm not a developer; can I still use it?

We have [difficulty naming things](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306346/naming-the-documentation-feature) because **naming is hard.**  We selected Developer Story because it seems to encompass a [large portion of our users](https://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2015#work-occupation), but if you have suggestions on what it should be called, we're all ears.

Even if your title isn't developer, we have jobs posted for developers, sysadmins and project managers; this feature is available to everyone on Stack Overflow regardless of job title.  It's not practical, at this time, to have multiple jobs sites and given that the majority of users are developers it makes the most sense to have it on Stack Overflow.  Employers, however, are able to sort for any title, so if your details are available and you're open to job opportunities, then you'll be seen.

### Why can't I share content from non-SO sites?

You can! You already have the ability to add top answers from other sites around the network, and we're looking at ways to share other achievements.

### What if I want my careers info separate from Stack Overflow?

The integration of Jobs into Stack Overflow means that we will no longer have two systems separating the data.  We will be migrating all existing CVs into the new Developer Story; the migration also includes honoring all existing privacy settings.  Privacy is very important to us, so if your current details are private, then they will stay private in the new version.  Also if you choose, you'll be able to make the whole Developer Story completely private, or only searchable to employers.

### Is Stack Overflow becoming a jobs site?

Stack Overflow is the online home of the world's developers, and we're focused on building a place that solves many of the problems developers face. We started with being the best place to get answers to your questions. Now we're expanding the ways that we serve developers by creating better [documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303865/warlords-of-documentation-a-proposed-expansion-of-stack-overflow) and improving your job search process to give programmers to opportunity to get a job that they love.

So no, we're not turning into a jobs site or even a documentation site.  Q&A is still our core product and always will be, as [Tim said](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310066/stack-overflow-serving-programmers-even-better)

> Nothing can detract from core Q&A. Losing our focus on what we've built together is not an option.

While Q&A will always be the crux of what we do, it's no longer the **only** feature of Stack Overflow.  We will always preserve the Q&A experience even as we add other features.

### Is Stack Overflow turning into a social network?

The developer story is a contemporaneous list of things that show others stuff you're good at doing. Any resemblance to other contemporaneous lists of things (including history books) is purely coincidental.

We wouldn't do that to you. Or us.

### Have we turned to investor-driven development?

No, we're still all about product-driven development. In fact we've historically been so focused on Q&A as a product that it's easy for folks to forget that we are a business that needs to generate revenue. In order to continue growing, we need to find other ways to serve developers in ways that no one else is doing (or doing well). Our investors expect us to continue to grow, but they don't tell us how to do it.

**Growth does not by any stretch mean abandoning our commitment to high quality Q&A,** but we understand the concerns that many of you have expressed. For a very long time, all that we did was core Q&A, and we just expected that people knew that's what we were doing. Yet here we are talking about a bunch of other stuff that's more distant from our main product, and we haven't been communicating about what we're doing with the main product very much even though [we're still doing a lot of things with it](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2016/01/year-in-review-2015/).

We've heard you, and you'll hear more from us when it comes to what we're working on inside of core Q&A. Now that we have more than one thing, we can no longer assume everyone knows what we're doing, and we're sorry to have assumed.

Yes, we need to do things in order to help Jobs/Careers realize its full potential, which will make our investors feel happy - but the core reason behind everything we do is and will always be serving the needs of developers in ways that do not diminish what we've worked hard building together.

### Put together, what does all this mean?

Our high quality Q&A platform is what built this business, and we'll never lose our focus on it or do anything to impede it. With your help, we changed how developers learn through Q&A, and we think we made it substantially better. Now we've found additional ways to solve other very real problems that developers face, and we're approaching those problems in the same considerate and powerful manner as we did Q&A.

We will always ask for feedback and we sincerely value the time that all of you consistently give in order to help us get things right, or sometimes a little less wrong; we're sorry that we weren't more clear when we came to you initially. To reiterate, you don't have to use this feature if you don't want to - and we're fine with that.

Comment: Hey, only 1 meme / image macro this time. I'd say we're already improving.

Comment: @CubeJockey: Confession Bear just got a whole lot more expressive...

Comment: @CubeJockey I was overly ambitious the first time. As the meme says "we screwed up."

Comment: I miss Jeff :((

Comment: Side note: Working here has the strange side effect of quadrupling your gif / meme collection _weekly_. I blame chat.

Comment: I really liked this way better than your previous post. Thanks for this (As an aside, the revision 3 of your original post should have been the first, then people would have understood it better)

Comment: I don't think employers really care how we present the information. I feel like this is just a visual update that doesn't really add anything else than a fancy CV to the picture

Comment: @Seth you know, I miss him too. Keep in mind we're executing a plan _that was always supposed to happen_; it just kept being put off because, well, it's hard from every standpoint (engineering is a big one). It has always been our intent to get Jobs into the main site _and innovate in that field_. I wish Jeff was along for this part of the ride because he has _very strong_ feelings about crappy contingency recruiters, stupid logic puzzles and the whole other stinky plethora of crap we hope to end by building a _better_ example of how hiring can be done.

Comment: Thanks for following your own advice this time around. This reads much more like a proposed improvement than an announcement of a fancy new feature.

Comment: Can you please at least *admit* that jobs expansion is necessary to keep the platform afloat as your main source of income? That's not a crime, but it's worse to omit it.

Comment: @dhtree, totally: Jobs & Ads are how we monetize, and we need money for goods and services to build a place that developers (and others) can help one another. As far as HOW to monetize, the history of the internet is littered with "help" sites that got funded by the military, paywalls, or oppressive ads.  We DO think that a better way to find jobs is an *actual service*, but if nothing else, I hope you'd agree that in the scheme of things, OUR approach to monetization (including ads, where we pass on a lot of $$ to keep them from being irritating) is pretty benign and respectful of our users.

Comment: @Jaydles Yeah - I think it's a brilliant and unique way to monetize. As I said, I have no problem with it. I'm just saying SO should openly say that that's at least a fraction of the motivation behind pushing jobs, which isn't wrong!

Comment: That would've made me understand why it was happening @dthree, telling this type of information is not bad all, it lets us know where you guys are coming from.

Comment: This still feels like you're saying "we're not turning into a social network/jobs site/unicorn factory" but your actions show otherwise.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg  Which actions, in particular? I'd like to try and understand how you arrived there but I'm having some trouble doing it.

Comment: @David for it to be a social network, there would have to be a social part. The only "networking" part of this is helping you "network" with prospective employers.

Comment: I'd like to see a logistics report on how presenting the information in a story mode/way/sense would/could benefit the current employer-looks-for-employee system.

Comment: No matter how you say it, this is still an awful idea. Very disappointing if this actually gets implemented.

Comment: @AshleyMedway No matter how you say that, unless you provide reasoning that can be discussed, it is an empty argument.

Comment: @JustDoIt I suppose the only way to get any information on that is to... just do it.

Comment: I'm not the one proposing the change, it's expected that for projects like this one, logistics have been taken into account @TinyGiant past statistics and such

Comment: I'm not sure if it would be feasible to get statistics on how many people out there with traditional CV's have a difficult time finding a job, other than you know... the fact that it isn't very easy to find a job if you aren't Jon Skeet. @JustDoIt

Comment: Fair point, then how about an actual explanation on how they think this is gonna be beneficial instantly/on the long run/any given time @TinyGiant I want to know the how and the why

Comment: @TinyGiant couldn't disagree more, as far as Software Development is concerned there are plenty of jobs, and securing them is about being competent and professional.

Comment: You can do surveys and polls and stuff; AFAIK, we've already been doing that, @Tiny. Anecdotally though, this tends to be very polarizing: folks with good work tend to not see ANY problems, folks without work see the entire system broken and rigged against them. You can skew your results very easily by picking the wrong sample.

Comment: @Shog "*You can skew your results very easily by picking the wrong sample.*" That's what I was getting at with my previous comment, though admittedly you always seem to be better at getting the point across.

Comment: Don't be so close minded @Shog9 there are plenty of ways to target an average sample, obtaining average statistics you guys have a database with the information of hundreds of thousands if not more samples.... And we don't necessarily need to know if they see any current problems with people that have a stable job, we just need to know how much it took them to land this job, how many other applications he sent before getting a call/interview, stuff like that; this proposal is about making employee/job hunting better

Comment: @AshleyMedway It currently requires more than just being competent and professional. It requires credentials, verifiable prior work experience in the field, and good references. You can be a great programmer, but without those previously mentioned things, you're likely to be passed over for someone who has those things, whether that person is as good of a programmer as you or not. What the developer story brings to the table is the ability to show what you've done outside of a work environment.

Comment: It's not something that you can do in a week either @Shog9 it's a process that requires time and dedication. It might even take months, but hey good things take time

Comment: So the story brings to the table what the CV already brought @TinyGiant ?

Comment: The CV doesn't allow you to show your knowledge in the field as inclusively as the dev story will. The traditional CV is quite limiting in what can be shown, and how it can be displayed. @JustDoIt

Comment: Is it? @TinyGiant

Comment: Yes @JustDoIt​​

Comment: Question, if a recruiter finds your story and decides to have you in the stack of potential employees, will he be able to save a pdf/anyfile of your resume(CV format) if so, is all the information in the story gonna be exported to it(rep, tags,sites,twitter)?

Comment: Umm I think that with this one I'll agree to disagree @TinyGiant

Comment: Depends on your situation, @Just. I had problems years ago when my CV was mostly short, overlapping, and tangential. Then later when it was long and narrowly-focused. In theory, you explain why that doesn't matter (or is even positive) for a given position in a cover letter, but in practice there tend to be a lot of administrative hurdles that are hard to clear if your education or work history doesn't fit a profile.

Comment: @JustDoIt They mentioned on the previous post that it would still be available in PDF format, I see they forgot to mention that here. Shame on them!

Comment: @TinyGiant Limited space here. We could have written an entire book but we wanted to address specific concerns and things we missed in the previous post.  But yes, we will still have the PDF format.

Comment: @JustDoIt Yes, as mentioned in the previous post exporting to PDF will still be available.

Comment: @bluefeet that's what I figured, I was being facetious with the shame part, if that wasn't clear.

Comment: @bluefeet by any chance, is there a sample of an exported file? maybe from the story example posted in the first proposal?

Comment: this feature is *completely* irrelevant to the way i use SO (ask and answer questions), so sure, sounds good. doesn't seem like it will affect me in any way.

Comment: @JustDoIt Considering we're still developing/designing it, not yet. We're hoping to have more details, in a few weeks.  I know that doesn't necessarily help, right now, but we're working on it.

Comment: Understandable, I think that *maybe* it would've been better to hold the proposal until the team already had some of these topics covered. @bluefeet , less threads to post, easier to answer questions from users. And it looks much more organized

Comment: I totally get that @JustDoIt. The point of these announcements is to get community feedback on things that we might not necessarily see or be aware of.  For example, based on feedback in the first post we decided to include 2 views for users because a lot of people asked for a sorted view.  Sometimes it's important to present an idea early to get other eyes on it, in case we miss something.

Comment: They're damned if they do, damned if they don't on that problem, @JustDoIt: _somebody_ will be unhappy with when they present the information. I would suggest that info early, info often is better; then those who want to know what's going on (and to influence it), can do so, and those who think it's disorganized can roll their eyes in disgust, click away, and wait for the beta.

Comment: Some of us are used to and expect to have more complete proposals @JoshCaswell some of you might not, and it's fine. The issue is that the proposal is yet too broad to even be considered a proposal. Which might influence the feedback obtained by each post. For example not knowing the *how* it's a huge deal breaker for me, hence why I'm am not particularly excited about the change. But that doesn't mean that I'm not open to a change of opinion, motivated by the right arguments.

Comment: Hey, only 1 meme / image macro this time. THIS PLACE IS GOING DOWNHILL

Comment: -1: still no free-hand circles.

Comment: Looking at the Developer Story mockup in the linked question, I don't see what makes it so special — it appears to be a slightly-harder-to-read version of the information in the existing CV. You can already include "the technologies you work with and any public artifacts like open source projects or applications you've written." Given that I've had messages on SO Jobs from recruiters that have outright failed to read my location settings or skills from my existing CV, I'm not sure spreading out this stuff along a timeline will make a big/positive difference.

Comment: "we will no longer have two systems separating the data" - Does that mean I'll be unable to manage my careers stuff by going to 'careers.stackoverflow.com'?  I like the careers site, and I like the reasonably decent job it does of letting me set up and export a resume.  I think integrating that more tightly with SO can be a good idea.  But integrating it more tightly with SO and then _killing off_ the standalone careers site is a mistake.  -1 if that's what you're doing.

Comment: @aroth I'd recommend reading [this announcement](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312452/careers-unificintegration-jobs-on-stack-overflow) and if you're so inclined [listening to the latest podcast](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2016/01/podcast-70-david-was-wrong-and-jason-was-right/).  The integration of Jobs/Careers into SO was announced a bit ago in order to make accessing job opportunities easier. No more separate logins, separate systems, etc.

Comment: @bluefeet - Yep, saw that one.  Was still unclear to me if the proposal was to add some careers stuff to SO, or to add some careers stuff on SO _and also subtract the existing careers site_ so that careers stuff is _only_ available through SO.  The use of a non-word like 'unificintegration' also tends to help keep the intent about as clear as mud.  And certainly one can have session federation and shared user credentials that work with multiple web portals.

Comment: Speaking of monetization... is there an SO store I'm missing? I'd buy swag.

Comment: How about "professional story" instead of "developer story"? :-)

Comment: Grmbl grmbl... This post is better than the last one, but since this feature was announced, I distrust it. I doubt any amount of writing will make that distrust go away, so go forth, make it and show the feature so I can not distrust it. Just... Please don't merge settings for jobs and SO. Facebook's settings are horrible enough.

Comment: The first time you use initialism in a post, it might be a good idea to explain what it stands for.  In this case, what's a CV?

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy A CV is [curriculum vitae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curriculum_vitae) or another name for resume.  It's also the term Jobs/Careers uses for resume.

Comment: @bluefeet:  I've only ever heard _cirriculum vitae_ used in 
Academia (with a capital A!).  In the tech industry, I've not heard anyone call it anything other than a _résumé_.

Comment: naming is hard +1

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy Pretty much everyone in the English speaking world outside of the US calls them CVs - IMO 'Resume' is a very yank-sounding word.

Comment: Get the hiring managers on there, because until I can get contracts here it's just another interesting project for me. (i did actually get an awesome contract, but consider it a bit of a fluke)

Comment: Why do we (as a community) continue reacting so strongly to their well meaning attempts to increase the value of the site? I agree that the changes aren't in high demand, so to say, and (especially in the case of the licence change) sound like very scary ideas. But the intent is real―they are trying to keep StackOverflow alive and growing! Let's not be too harsh on them, but keep on making constructive recommendations!!!

Comment: The main feedback from users on the last post was that "this is not an improvement, and is harmful instead". You have still failed to tell us how this is an improvement. A new _UI_ which _you_ think is better? Then most of the community disagrees. Got any other points? But this post does indeed bring my "anger" down from "please don't do this" to "please hold on for a sec and talk to me about it first". +1

Comment: Tl;DR; We have no idea what we're doing. Our investors are complaining we're not making any money. We're going to throw as much poo against the wall as we can hoping some of it will stick. We're sorry, please don't leave us. We need to make money from you, somehow.

Comment: "The Developer Story is your story: it gives you a better way to find a job you love based on what you can do, not who you are. Instead of presenting yourself as a bulleted list of action verbs, you'll be able to show off the stuff that actually matters to you, including the technologies you work with and any public artifacts like open source projects or applications you've written." Frankly, I don't understand what exactly you want to say with this? Either this part of the vision is a bit unclear or you still don't have expressed yourself good enough. To me it sounds like a list of buzzwords.

Comment: Funny, I'm much less concerned about where careers/jobs is going than about Documentation. Careers works ok as it is, and (apart from my so-far-unfounded worries about HR blocking SO entirely) I don't see why integrating it should make it worse. Documentation has a far more fuzzy user story at the moment, and personally I'm finding it difficult to stay engaged.

Comment: @bluefeet I know the first post said 6-8 weeks. Is that still the timeline, given the initial backlash of the proposal? Is there a way to beta test it, like we did for current profile, teams, docs, etc?

Comment: @HunterStevens [6-8 weeks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514) is one of the many memes of SO/SE.  As far as actual timeline we're working on it and are hoping to have some sort of beta but we're not sure when... hence the 6-8 weeks.

Comment: @bluefeet Oh, I always forget that it's a meme. And thank you for the reply. I'd love to beta test this feature out

Comment: @HunterStevens Once we get closer to beta/release of the Developer Story, we'll have more announcements.

Comment: Along with the "resume" vs "CV" confusion, I think there may be some unexplored cultural assumptions in the phrase "the design is different from a traditional resume" - CVs in the UK come in a wide variety of designs; often, they often include timeline- and bullet-based sections, *because those are easy for readers to follow*. The sales pitch is that this is *instead of* a CV, but to me it *is* a CV, just with a fancy template (heavily oriented for screen rather than print). That's not necessarily a bad thing, though - if you're going to impose a fixed template, it had better be a good one.

Comment: "curriculum vitae" basically means "story of my life". Euphemisms decay into simple nouns and are replaced by a new euphemism. Just call it a CV/resume, because nobody will really be fooled.

Comment: Good stuff, can't wait for part 3!!

Comment: Oh.. shit, don't turn this to another social network! I'm just here to learn and help people, I don't even like the fact that companies might be looking to my online "performance"..

Comment: @Shog9 "folks with good work tend to not see ANY problems", so if we don't like this feature we must do poor work... got it.

Comment: No, I think you missed it, @Joshua. How could I possibly gauge the quality of your work?

Comment: @Shog9 full discloser: I like this version/feature/explanation a little bit. If you are unable to judge the quality of my work, by what authority do you make the claim that "folks with good work tend to not see ANY problems"?  Did you mean those happy with their jobs?  <snarkThatIcouldn'tResist>If you cannot gauge my work, how does a Developer Story make it possible for others to do?</snarkThatIcouldn'tResist>

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Yes, happy with their jobs, @Joshua.

Comment: @Shog9 apologies for the miss on my part.  Still not certain that I agree with the assertion that resumes are not working for those that are unhappy with their work, but I'll re-resolve to read more carefully in the future.

Comment: For me, this site has always been about developers helping other developers (or would-be developers).  That is why I guess sneaking in recruiters seems so weird.  We are being told we need recruiters when really the monetized site is what needs recruiters.  I understand the business aspect totally, but sometimes for me all I see is a way to unite developers spread out across the world.

Comment: I don't see an overwhelming disapproval here... am i missing something?

Comment: I wonder how many of the people objecting to this feature have full-time well-paid jobs that they are happy with?  I suspect that would describe a lot of the "What's the point of this feature?" crowd.

Comment: How you can change something (CV) that survived 500 years?

Comment: as long as it's not Linkd ... that site is 110% useless. have never had a single employer check it and have never had a single hit from it. deleted my acc 2 years ago and cant even tell. however, i've been hired 3 times thanks to CV

Comment: Having had to hire dozens of people in days before, I'm of a mind that the "standard" resume design works well for a reason. Employers don't want to have to figure out *how* to read your resume, they just want to get the details quickly to put you in the bucket of worth looking at, or not. Whether this is good or bad is subjective, but I've always found that resumes that are "non-standard" often end up in the not suitable pile just because it takes cognitive overhead to find the relevant information. Every once in a while there's a movement to change Resume design, but the classic comes back.

Comment: At least the site is stable and has been a great help in getting answers to my problems. Blows away anything George Lucas ever did!

Comment: I am not sure problems with the system of hiring can be solved by alternate presentation of already available facts. I can already write a CV any way I want, although certain methods of doing so increase my likelihood of getting a phone screen, and an interview after reflection on the phone screen. That presentation already matches what traditional CVs can provide. The remaining problem there is the list I present is different for every job I apply to. A generic list doesn't work. Unless I can hand-curate for every job I apply to, then I don't think there's going to be improvement here for me.

Comment: IMO, if you truly want to solve the problem, then solving the difficulties in networking (i.e. people are afraid of it) and fixing the technical interview (i.e. people think a CS riddle is important for screening someone) are the true solutions. We've got to evolve past Spolsky's baseline. Push-and-hope to a recruiting machine, even with a portfolio equivalent, ain't gonna solve that.

Comment: (Maybe I should use meta right and make these an answer...)

Comment: Da Vinci wasn't a lord.   And that wasn't a resume in the classical sense: it was a sales brochure: not "what I've done and where I've studied", but "these are the services I offer".   But very interesting link.

Comment: @bluefeet I liked the presentation format of Developer Story and I would like to suggest new name for the same as Professional Timeline as it is also presented as timeline

Answer (score 339):

**tl; dr** People who want to game rep and badges (the least useful people on the site) are going to want to game it even more if it is tightly integrated with their resume, and more of them will appear. People who are altruistically making the site better (the most useful people on the site) are going to feel turned off and contribute elsewhere.

---

A lot of people expressed doubts about this in the previous meta post, because of a lot of quite nebulous but related reasons, such as Stack Overflow becoming a social network or the main Q&A purpose of the site being deprioritized. We all understand that the driver to integrate jobs-related things closer in Stack Overflow does not come out of nowhere, but it is motivated by the site making money. This is important for Stack Overflow's future, and there is nothing evil about making money. However, there is a strong and concrete reason why this is not zero-sum for Stack Overflow, and why the argument of 'If you don't like this, don't use it.' does not apply.

1. Stack Overflow's most important asset is **its contributors**. Specifically, the people who post good answers. Questions are important but less so.
2. Good answers do not appear, by magic, from a large enough number of people being on a site. Good answers exists because people take the time, care and effort to write them. Contributions to the site are not evenly distributed. A quite small number of people who have made an superhuman effort (the J*n Sk**ts, and a couple of tiers below them) have had a huge impact. If you took away all their contributions, Stack Overflow would be much, much worse.
3. In general, these people are motivated by altruism, and a love of teaching and learning. I believe that recognition by a community of those who have made an important contribution is a major, and honorable, part of this.
4. Many of Stack Overflow's biggest problems are caused by people 'gaming the system' to accumulate reputation points and badges. I would say that *all* the major problems of quality, consistency and balance are caused by them, except for those (admittedly very large) caused by very new users who don't have any understanding of Stack Overflow's ethos.
5. These people are motivated by a desire to *appear* like knowledgeable and productive members of the community, without actually necessarily being helpful.
6. The general drive, both by Stack Overflow itself, and by others, to use Stack Overflow as a recruitment screening tool, vastly multiplies the incentives to the latter group.
7. It also undermines the motivation of the former group, who now look like canny self-promoters rather than the most generous participants in a gift economy.

There is somewhat of a precedent in what happened when the [Debian Project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian) paid two developers to work full time. Lots of others who were making huge contributions in their spare time left the project because they felt the game had changed.

Comment: This is definitely something we're concerned about and watching for. You left out one other potential problem though: an awful lot of the best contributions on SO come from folks who are... bored at work. There's a real cost to the site if we get too good at helping folks find intellectually-stimulating work. It's a trade-off...

Comment: Where did you get "career rep and badges" from?  Based on the post it doesn't sound like they're planning to add gamification to the job process, just change the format of the information.

Comment: @davidism: I think it's referring to the notion commonly held by some users that rep and badges matter to potential employers. It gets worse when you consider that - for better or for worse - some employers out there do actually look at these numbers...

Comment: @BoltClock Ah, I see, so it's saying that they think there will be more people playing the system if the system is more tightly integrated with their resume.

Comment: @Shog9: Good thing I'm neither of those. I'm an altruistic contributor *and* a happy hobbyist developer.

Comment: Yeah, we tried to rope you in and failed... Curses!

Comment: It's one thing for an employer to read the posts I've made to SO, and another for them to look at the summary provided by badges, rep, and "top X%". The former is much much harder to game (but of course also more work for an employer to really use). The "Story" page doesn't seem to emphasize the stats too much: they're fairly small. On the other hand, they're also the second or third thing; maybe they would be better "below the fold".

Comment: The Careers CVs *already* allow you to link an SE account and display its rep, and if you have a linked SO account, we'll display any tags you're in the top 10, 20, or 30% for. Those items are presented a little bit differently in the developer story layout, but they're on Careers CVs today, and have been for quite a while...I'm not sure that this is as big a problem as you fear it might be, though it is something we're keeping in mind.

Comment: Probably important to remember that there are people who are in groups 1 2 and 3 of your list that used to be in groups 4 5 and 6, and that a good number of those in 4 5 and 6 can continue to move toward 1 2 and 3.

Comment: A legitimate concern for sure. This, by the way, is part of the impetus to explore things like Teams and Documentation. The value of a person's contributions throughout their career can't be reduced to something as gamified as rep and badges, and Q&A _needs_ to continue to be a labor of love.

Comment: What's always bothered me is the fact that I can't share what i've worked on, because it's all enterprise apps/tools that never appear outside of the company. In my case a developer story for me would be relatively empty if not for the contributions within SO itself.

Comment: @Shog9 - You are worried that the proposal for a more involved CV will lead to more participation in the site? That doesn't seem to be a problem. Also, badges are intended to drive positive contribution, and while gaming is possible in some aspects, it does not seem to be a major concern of users as it almost never comes up in meta. If a badge is causing negative behavior, then it should be removed. Overall, this whole answer seems to be more of a rant about "rep whoring" than a response to an expanded CV.

Comment: Unintended consequences are a killer, @Travis. We're discussing a feature that doesn't require any investment - you can log on TODAY and create a CV with no rep earned, and the proposal here is to make this even more attractive. Will that motivate destructive behaviors? Well, I *hope* not - we've certainly tried to avoid anything that'd lead to such outcomes. But you don't try your best and then stick your fingers in your ears and close your eyes... You watch to make sure you didn't miss something.

Comment: @Sho9 - This feature is merely an expansion on a long running existing feature, so any consequence should by relation be an expansion of existing behavior. It seems that if there were to be increased behavior, you should be aware of its potential as your eyes were open and fingers somewhere not firmly in your ears. What side effect has Careers had on Stack Overflow historically?

Comment: You know that for a long time Careers was invite-only / offered only to folks who'd participated constructively on SO, right @TravisJ? That changed a while back, but it wasn't exactly promoted heavily until very recently - the focus was on showing folks relevant jobs, not encouraging them to create CVs. Anyway, to answer your question we've seen *very* little negative behavior thus far - which is promising. There have been one or two instances where someone's tried to inflate their stats for CV purposes, but these have been handled in the normal fashion.

Comment: -1...  I don't really agree with the neo-communist attitude toward being paid, recognized, etc.

Comment: or the idea that the developer is some sort of ubermensch tainted by reputation, badges, and other worldly things

Comment: @KevinB Wish you had posted that separately so it wasn't buried in the comments.  I think a lot of people are in a similar situation.

Comment: I will when I get back to a pc if no one beats me to it

Comment: Whenever I complain about people gaming the site and scoring system I get the canned "Oh no, that doesn't happen here, we have systems in place to stop that." Why is such a blind-eye turned to it? Because it makes the sites look good to investors, that's why. Pop will eat itself, especially when it has investors.

Comment: @user3791372 agreed... such things as making a second third or fourth account to ask questions that you already have a canned answer for (which you can modify) is being protected against? Copying existing questions, to ask them in more clean language with one of your dupe accounts & answering it there, with your already cleaned up & documented answer, this is being fought against? Or maybe this is actually part of the site and I ought to do these things (and a number of others) to improve my pathetically low rep?? (I think a rework to the rep system is in order to make gaming less appealing)

Comment: "Good answers do not appear, by magic..." +1 million for this sentence. To make a long story short: if users of SO don't want that feature then mostly probably it's useless.

Comment: Way back when, the standard answer to "people are only doing the right thing for rep" was "who cares, as long as value is being added to SO?". Quite honestly, the devs who think employers will only look at *one number* are an *ideal* match for the employers who *do* only look at one number (if that isn't a myth)

Comment: I think 'gaming the system' needs some more explanation. Someone could play the game i.e. answer tons of questions, try to achieve as many badges as possible and still provide great quality answers. Maybe the motivation for those people are the very incentives offered by the site i.e. badges and rep -  it just so happens that they know their stuff. Likewise, I'm sure there are many well meaning people who are trying to help but do not write good quality answers.

Comment: That said I think the developer story will detract from SO's main purpose as a Q&A site. With this and the furore around the licensing maybe SO/SE is trying to introduce too many changes at once.

Comment: @br3w5 the influx of new people trying to Game will result in more work for moderators.  If the flux is high, and we survive, it would then be due to our creation of new finer-grained moderation queues.

Comment: The biggest problem SO has is its moderator zealotry and bureaucracy. Things that just slap question askers and answer makers in the face over and over again. Good luck becoming a 10K user if you aren't already a 10K user. The deck is so stacked against new users, I fear everything implodes upon itself as veterans just get tired of a meritocracy that's been replaced by fiefdoms

Comment: @NewAlexandria yes I agree with that but think the risk is from low quality content which could come from new users but I'm not totally convinced the the Developer Story will definitely encourage that. For the record I like the existing resume and I've seen this timeline based UI on several projects and sites over the last couple of years, and for me it feels like SO is trying to create something to fit that design trend (I'm sure I wrote this already in a comment but either I didn't post it or someone deleted it)

Comment: @user3791372 "Because it makes the sites look good to investors, that's why. Pop will eat itself, especially when it has investors." Huh?  SO already has paid staff, as far as I know, and the system gaming is no worse than it was on day one of launch.  I get the impression you've taken the argument beyond the logical conclusion.

Comment: this just means that the reputation system needs to be re-thought and the incentives have to better designed. Treat SO as a stock exchange rather than a karma-happy-funtime site like reddit.

Comment: @br3w5: Over the past year, I've been noticing a lot of high rep users who are trying to answer questions outside of their expertise, or trying to close questions because they don't understand the problem domain (and by extension, the question itself). If I look at where their rep came from, it's always from answering common questions from new developers, like _How do I install Ruby 1.8.3?_, and aggressively closing others as duplicates. I think this is what 'gaming the system' means.

Comment: If this particular feature lets users showcase examples of their submissions, then this feature should alleviate this effect rather than exasperate it. Rep and badge numbers aren't actually all that helpful in determining if a user would be a good fit for an organization or not. However, examples of how an individual solves problems and works with others can be quite helpful.

Comment: There are people (like me) who initially come on the site to gain rep & badges (because that's fun) but then after some time here realise the enjoyment is actually in providing good answers, and then become 'good' contributors. You don't want to be labelling these people a "problem".

Comment: I'm not sure "altruism" exists as a standalone concept. Most users post simply because they know the answer. This may be motivated by community kudos, a willingness to build their professional street cred, or just from the intellectual niggle that prevents someone from seeing misinformation and/or hanging questions, when you know what's in your head pairs well with the question. None of these reasons are altruistic, but they're not necessarily motivated by financial gain. Personally, I like the idea of knowing my answers are building up to something-- a career is a nice end-goal.

Comment: @CollinDauphinee i haven't experienced that (i don't think) but it's unfortunate if users default to upvoting the answer from the user with the highest rep rather than examining the content of all answers

Comment: What is an example of gaming the system?  I do not know what that means.

Comment: I think SO has features in place already that helps reduce "gaming" of the system but if this new feature creates more they can always add additional features to reduce "gaming" of the system even more.  It is better to have SO more integrated with a person's Resume than leaving it off because of the 5% or so that games the system.  It would be more helpful than harmful to have the developer story.

Comment: I have to agree with the post - @johnny, all that's done for the sake of rep alone (and w/o all the hard work), e.g. there is lot of 'social networking' already going on (Q&A targeting friends and returning favors), that's just one and not the worst - post-wise, things have changed for the worse IMO and it's becoming a pretty intolerant place (SO) lately - and I'm seeing myself commenting less and less - some of it is normal - but some are direct consequences of the rules applied - I do get SO/SE needs to make money but this may not help, just my thoughts

Comment: @NSGaga I know it's not the SO of 2008, but it is so intolerant I don't ask or try to answer (that and time).  Plus there are folks on there that must live on SO, so maybe they are doing a lot of friend/favors/gaming and I never thought that folks were doing that.

Answer (score 142):

I like the old resume, and I also like having it on SO. It's well organized, lets me communicate the information I want, and is also recognized everywhere else. How is the new system actually better? What can it do that the current one can't?

> ...based on what you can do, not who you are. ... you'll be able to show off the stuff that actually matters to you, including the technologies you work with and any public artifacts like open source projects

I don't feel that the current "traditional" system prevents me from showing what matters to me.  It shows the tech I work with, open source projects I've written, and anything else I want.  I want to show myself off as a well organized page, not as a bunch of stories spread left and right along a timeline.

---

Comments Summary:

I'd like to see some user stories or examples of how a developer should be hired that would only work well, or would work better, with this new story format.  *Tim says that they will work on explaining that.*

I'd like the ability to choose whether others will see my resume or timeline by default.  *bluefeet says that they will consider this during development.*

Comment: You can cook a crazy amount of things in an ordinary toaster if you get creative enough, but you're kinda bending how you do it to fit constraints. Yeah, you can do a lot in a CV - we think we can really improve the format itself to catch up with the way developers should be hired. A lot of work is also going into helping employers better understand how to hire (the whole process). We think it's a better, less constrained way for developers to show what they know - all I can say is give it an honest try and see what you think when it ships.

Comment: We heard the concerns from the original post we decided that we will have two views for you, the user; you'll be able to view your history in a sorted view or in the new design.  We just have a limited amount of space on what we could address in a single post and we don't want you all reading the Iliad here.

Comment: I agree with this answer 100%

Comment: @TimPost can you give an example of how a developer should be hired that would only work well, or would work better, with this new story format?

Comment: @bluefeet assuming the story will still be linked from the profile page, will we have a preference which controls which version *other* people see? Or will everyone else see the new format even if I like how the old one represents me?

Comment: @davidism I think you'll appreciate the fact that I'm mentioning that the proof wouldn't fit in this margin while not ducking the question. The feature itself isn't yet fully baked, so I don't want to give an example of something we ultimately _can't_ ship, but I'll talk to the team behind this and see if we can add an answer to this question to show some more preliminary stuff (it seriously doesn't fit in this margin).

Comment: I think it would be much better if instead of choosing to opt-out, you get to choose to opt-in

Comment: @TimPost totally understand that it can be complicated to explain.  I'm sure you guys have a vision for this, I just want to see it too.

Comment: @davidism I agree that (even with a THIS IS NOT CARVED IN STONE disclaimer) a little more might help. I promise to see what I can do, it might take a few days, we've _really_ got a lot going on with it. Stack Overflow is _really_ fast, for instance - so we don't want to promise something early on that might get long-term delayed by performance tests - but I will see what I can do.

Comment: @davidism We're still working through a lot the details on this and I'm not sure we decided one way or another on that.  Thanks for bringing it up though because it might not be something the devs/designers have thought about.

Comment: I have yet to see the actual benefit of the changes, if there's change but no improvement then it's a waste of time, effort, and resources.

Comment: @JustDoIt The benefit is evolving the way employers look for devs.

Comment: Looking at a fancy timeline? @TinyGiant , IMHO just by naming it "story" it automatically becomes less professional.

Comment: @JustDoIt As is said in the proposal above, feel free to suggest a better name.

Comment: @JustDoIt as Tim has said, they will work on making some concrete user stories and examples.  Reiterating that you haven't seen that yet isn't really productive at this point.  I understand the objection to the format, but let's give them some time to respond.

Comment: You're right @davidism I'm just used to having a well formatted proposal with expectations, reports, and estimations. I'll give time then.

Comment: @JustDoIt as far as proposals go, I would say this is quite a lot better than what we usually see here. Much much better than the first incarnation of the proposal.

Comment: I'm not denying that @TinyGiant but it still doesn't feel like quite enough.

Comment: I don't really understand the breathless enthusiasm that seems to solely accompany SO announcements, Microsoft demos and Laravel tutorials. Is it the same person writing all of them?

Comment: Will the current resume view still be available?  I like it very much, and have used the printed (well, technically pdf'd) version of it to land my last 3 jobs.

Comment: @AShelly yes, if you read the op and bluefeet's comment above, both will be available.

Comment: @JustDoIt 'by naming it "story" it automatically becomes less professional' Don't say that to the people in charge of User Stories, they'll get annoyed.

Comment: @davidism I really like the comment summary you did here, I think I'm going to start doing that where prudent, too.

Comment: @JAB that's my personal opinion, and you don't have to agree with it if you don't want to.

Comment: This. You're trying to say, "Hey this thing will be better than everyone else's product!" but there are no details as to how exactly. So "Introducing the Same Damn Thing (tm)" that I've had pitched to me from the bazillion recruiting websites and companies out there. What I -am- excited about is this being integrated with StackOverflow. What a great way to utilize this huge userbase! Putting me in touch with companies more easily on a website I already use? Cool! But I can't get excited about how this will replace "Boring Old Resumes" if you're not telling me how it's doing that.

Comment: I realize you're planning on putting more details out soon(and looking forward to it), but I just wanted to explain why some people might not be all that excited about what you have so far.

Answer (score 109):

## Naming

Looking for a "better" name? What about [**Stack Trace**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_trace)? (Or even *Back Trace*.) It's something that not only developers, but students, sysadmins, etc deal with. It logs the journey of some execution, in this case, the user's story.

**Edit**: After reading the comments, I now see the issue with having a technical name that recruiters/HR must read. Maybe "Developer Story" is the best thing then. (Any other ideas I have include "History", which just sounds boring.)

**Edit 2**: Additional name ideas from the comments:

- [heap dump](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314636/the-developer-story-part-2-we-didnt-explain-that-very-well/314664?noredirect=1#comment294187_314664)
- [Stack Trace™ Developer Story Powered By Red Bull®](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314636/the-developer-story-part-2-we-didnt-explain-that-very-well/314664?noredirect=1#comment296304_314664)
- [Developer Context](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314636/the-developer-story-part-2-we-didnt-explain-that-very-well/314664?noredirect=1#comment296405_314664)
- [Developer Log](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314636/the-developer-story-part-2-we-didnt-explain-that-very-well/314664?noredirect=1#comment298231_314664)
- ["Stack Trace" -> "Professional Trace" -> ptrace](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314636/the-developer-story-part-2-we-didnt-explain-that-very-well/314664?noredirect=1#comment299041_314664)

## Reception

There's nothing I would change with the Developer Story feature. Sure, it's possible to "game the system", but anyone who would has probably done so with the current CVs. (They already showed top answers, selected by the user.) I don't think an employer would necessarily turn down someone because another person had more upvotes than them.

I still think improvements could be made for other features (chat, moderation)... But this post clarified the connection that the Developer Story had to Careers Unification. Initially, it sounded like Yet Another Social Network that just *happened* to coincide with Careers.

Thanks for clarifying everything. I'm looking forward to the feature now!

Comment: how about "heap dump"

Comment: Yes! Yes! Yes! :)

Comment: Oh... That's clever.

Comment: -1 for those clever names. They may be more inclusive, but they're also more obfuscated and confusing, which is not something I'd want in a CV context.

Comment: I don't care about the name, but +1 for the second paragraph. That's just what I thought.

Comment: Agreed with @JeremyBanks especially if we are hoping for recruiters to be looking at this, they might not know what it is and overlook it completely.

Comment: @JeremyBanks I see where you are coming from. It was just a thought, though. If we want recruiters/HR to understand it, then Developer Story may be the best name.

Comment: Stack Trace™ Developer Story Powered By Red Bull®

Comment: Stack trace is usually associated with an error, which hopefully are few and negligible in the persons' past (or at least unnoticed)... that would sort-of lead to negative connotations. I do however like the suggestion by @Air but would suggest Developer *Context* instead of Developer Story, as context is what is being achieved over and above a standard CV/resumé and *story* reeks of being fictitious.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson StackOverflow is an actual error, if you didn't know already :-)

Comment: Ha Ha @noob, quite true, I think it's a quiet 'in joke' amongst developers that the paramount place to go for *real* help is named after an error. The majority of programmers I have conversed with were quite fond of subtle humor and 'in' jokes... so I humbly suggest the slight modification to the phrase postulated by the comment by Air be Stack Trace™ Developer Context Powered By Red Bull®.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson Yeah I like the modification too. It looks HR-ish xD

Comment: "Developer Log"?

Comment: **Stack Trace** is perfect! We _can_ expect HR people to adopt a new term every once in a while. Just think of all the buzzwords that came the other direction over the years!

Comment: "Stack Trace" -> "Professional Trace" -> ptrace

Comment: What about "Life Story" a resume is basically that, a person's life story, where they went to school, work, volunteer, their work history, what they would like to do, awards the received and etc. :)

Answer (score 71):

#### TLDR:

I wanted to be able to add things that weren't job experience and open source projects to the timeline, and that's possible, so my concern is already solved by the upcoming feature.

---

What's always turned me away from setting up a CV (besides the fact that I'm not really looking for a new job) is that it always felt very empty for me.

I've had one employer since becoming a professional developer and I've been with them for almost 8 years now. I don't have a large history of education, and I haven't really contributed to any open source projects (unless you consider moderation contribution, I did a lot of moderation on the jQuery forums before coming here, but I don't know how to include that in my CV anyway.)

The majority of the projects I've worked on since being here are all behind a firewall and closed source, so I can't really share them in the same way as open source projects. There are no public repositories to link to. There are no public facing endpoints to link to. No press releases describing these projects from a developer standpoint, etc.

This leaves me with a somewhat barren, boring CV. It would be nice if the CV (and/or developer story) could somehow facilitate sharing these projects that aren't publicly facing.

Comment: The developer story allows you to add "project" that are not online (in other words you can add a specific category/title/image/description). You'd also talk about technology: when you switched tech stack, when you discovered code etc. You won't have an empty page with the developer story :).

Comment: Ah, then it does pretty much exactly what i was asking for, I just didn't know what I was asking for. :)

Comment: @KevinB I think knowing this now, it would be helpful to update your answer. I still upvoted for you, though, because I am in the same boat. 95% (at least) of my commits are for closed source projects.

Comment: This was my biggest concern as well (mostly closed source or government work in my CV) so I'm glad you brought this up and @StéphaneMartin comment is reassuring.

Comment: This has been a problem for me as well. Open source development is virtually nonexistant where I live (Japan) and not all of us have had time since the advent of github and SO to noodle around trying to prove that we are masters of $buzzword. This leads to a chicken/egg problem: I would like to get a remote position where I could contribute to open source (and incidentally have a more interesting "modern" open source presence), but I can't get a job like that without gaming github and SO first. Its especially annoying to me since I've been in the oss community since the early 90's!

Comment: Me too! Those of us who have been doing solid work in niche (or maybe less "sexy") fields for decades feel left out by initiatives like this.

Answer (score 43):

> Is Stack Overflow becoming a jobs site?
>
> . . . So no, we're not turning into a jobs site or even a
>   documentation site. Q&A is still our core product and always will be,
>   as Tim said.

But documentation has its own beta site, so that's misleading isnt' it? Nobody externally would confuse these two different sites. 'Integrating' job search into any website, no matter what its base/original theme was, fundamentally changes what that site was about. You said earlier that 40% of the people that come to StackOverflow for jobs. If that is true, and you are now expanding CV's, with the stated intention of changing the way companies hire technical expertise, how would you describe StackOverflow to an HR person, or a hiring manager, or to a good engineering manager from a good company who doesn't want to see his talent get snatched away? How do you convince any of those people to not have *their* company block your website from their systems like they've already blocked LinkedIn for the very same reason?

It should not be 40% of the people coming to the job search site looking for a job, it should be ***100%*** and should be on its own specific website that is meant for just exactly that. Then if companies decide to block CareersOverflow or whatever you want to call it, it doesn't affect all of the rest of us who came here because of the original spirit of what StackOverflow is (was?).

Comment: I was under the impression that Documentation *would* be merged into Stack Overflow once it is out of beta.

Comment: @TinyGiant, That is the plan. But Jobs is in Beta and already merged into this site, and is clearly meant to be a primary focus of this site going forward. Documentation may or may not be merged. If it is, so be it. If it isn't, so be it. But it is still its own site with its own intentions. Nobody is going to block Documentation no matter where it's at. Many companies already block job search sites.

Comment: Jobs Beta is really the beta integration of the existing careers platform, not that Jobs itself is new, it is just a new name and a new place for something old. I don't think it is going to be a "primary focus" as much as a useful integration. The fact that companies block job sites is unrelated to companies blocking or not blocking a programming resource such as Documentation will be. That is most likely because the company you work for doesn't want you looking for a job on their dime, and by rights they shouldn't want that.

Comment: @TimGiant, you're making my point perfectly (+1). Trying to compare what happens with Documentation to what happens with Jobs is disingenuous. No company is ever going to block a Documentation site even if they get the false impression that that is all that StackOverflow is about. But if companies start getting the impression StackOverflow is a place for their talent to go look for jobs, which seems to be more and more the intention of the owners of this website, then that can, *and probably will*, start getting StackOverflow banned from their networks, and rightfully so.

Comment: I doubt that any company is going to block the number one most useful programming resource available to a programmer. They can just block the Jobs sub-directory and be done with it. Unless Stack Overflow decides to wipe the database of Questions and Answers (highly unlikely), Stack Overflow isn't going to stop being the number one most useful programming resource. No matter how much effort is put into Jobs, Stack Overflow will still be that resource. If your company bans your most useful tool, you should probably look for another job.

Comment: @TinyGiant, you're thinking like an engineer. Now think like an HR person, or a hiring/retention manager, or a non-technical engineering manager. Someone who may not know, care, or at all understand what 'tools' we use. They just got the impression, however imprecise that impression might be, that StackOverflow is (now) a job search site. If they are a little more in tune with the current culture, they may have even decided that StackOverflow is purposely leveraging its Q&A site to attract talent to their job search site. A point that might not be all that inaccurate....

Comment: It is an act of hubris to assume that StackOverflow can't be replaced, or that it can't take actions to effectively destroy its own place on the internet. Such a stark change of culture, from a Q&A site to a job search, can't possibly go unnoticed. It's being thrust in our faces right now. It's hard to imagine a lot of companies won't take proper notice.

Comment: That is a concern that would be better expressed on the original announcement of the move. This announcement is about improving upon the previous announcement. These are perfectly valid concerns, but there isn't much that is going to be done by expressing them here. Right now you're opposing the new CV saying that moving Jobs into Stack Overflow is a bad thing.

Comment: It's not a bad thing. LinkedIn is a great site. StackOverflow might be able to even do better. I don't doubt they have the skills to do improve on pretty darn good (and profitable). What I'm concerned about is what StackOverflow wants to be, and especially what they want to be seen as. If they want to stay a Q&A site and create a separate job search site. Fine. If they want to use their Q&A culture to attract talent to their job search site. Fine. But the results of the latter are predictable and perhaps even unavoidable.

Comment: They've already said that putting effort into Jobs is about helping devs and making the investors happy. I don't see the main focus of Stack Overflow being anything other than core Q&A any time in the future.

Comment: Is it really that common for companies to block career sites? For me that would be sign to look for a new (better) company.

Comment: ouflak for President!!!!!

Comment: Yeah really this is just bullseye material right here.

Comment: "They can just block the Jobs sub-directory and be done with it." -@TinyGiant, predicting my workplace's network policy exactly.

Answer (score 43):

Something that concerns me.....

As much of the code I post here has been written by me, while in work. I go to a great deal of trouble to remove all references to my company from said code. I do this because:

1. I'm not sure how my company will feel about me sharing code I've
   written in work online
2. I don't want to expose the working of our website online. Am I giving potential hackers information that they can exploit, etc.!
3. I don't want my employer to see my SO rep and presume I'm spending all day on SO instead of doing my job (I don't but I'm not sure they'll understand)

So I don't want who I work for plastered all over my SO profile. I want this to be seperate.

Comment: While there is no explicit opt-out feature, I think you can hide fields from being displayed to the public. You do bring up a good point, as this is not fully explained.

Comment: If this is implemented. I'll likely remove myself from the careers portal altogether. Who knows I might re-add myself if I started looking for a job. But if I'm looking for a job, why not just apply for the jobs advertised using a good old fashioned CV.

Comment: What is included in your timeline will always be your choice, it's entirely optional. Also, you'll have the ability to choose whether employers who are looking for candidates will be able to see you. The big advantage for both us and the developers is that *the moment you choose to apply to a job* you can turn on your profile and apply.

Comment: very good point. a huge number of software engineers work in financial services at lawyered up firms else government and they need to keep the anonymity as it is a "don't ask, don't tell" policy at such companies with respect to SO.

Comment: +1 for 3rd point. I also feel the same. If i show my SO profile then employer may think he spends more time on SO than work.

Answer (score 29):

99% of potential employers are going to want a traditional resume.  All you're doing is asking us to support [another standard](https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/standards.png).  Doubling the workload of job seekers isn't going to help anyone.

Comment: Both formats will still be available, and the story will be populated from the traditional view, according to the post.

Comment: 8 years ago Stack Overflow didn't exist, and it became a successful standard Q&A for developers. That's happening to Carreers right now. Despite Developer Story being an evolution of the traditional CV can potentially be a disruptive change, people are dealing really great with that kind of change. (I liked that xkcd comic - but I strongly disagree with your assumption that 99% would want a traditional resume.)

Comment: It is clear to me from bluefeet's comments that mention "two views" that what davidism said is correct, but I don't see it explained anywhere in the OP which says, in bold, that CVs are being replaced... I think confusion on this point is natural.

Comment: @Frank under "What problem are we trying to solve": "*We know that it will take some time, so employers will still have the option to see your history in a traditional sorted view, but even in that view we're presenting a more complete picture of your history.*"

Comment: @falsarella I think you are on a good point, a lot of employers initially run through resumes and just skim the contents, which can be a hit and miss for both employer and candidate. Rather than that, maybe this new CV style can help employers "skim" quicker and more efficiently.

Comment: And the iPhone was yet another phone, ugh.

Comment: While I am not upvoting this answer, I find it extremely offensive that someone voted do *delete* it.

Comment: I totally agree with the answer (living in the real world, as opposed to wanting to make a better world") and am disappointed that it has attracted so many downvotes. realistically, 99% (or more) of recruiters are going to want the traditional format. By all means, offer two, but keep counters and report back to us how many of each format are viewed. I don't think the new format will fly.

Comment: If I wanted to hire someone, and saw a huge amount of contribution to SO, I would seriously consider how much I was paying someone to support SO. Just saying. I think the option to completely remove badges/activity stats needs to be there to make the "story" look more traditional.

Comment: To me, this answer ignore the reality of tech industry. There is more and more screening layer at some tech companies. most layers are managed by people who simply want to get their money. To do that, they judge candidates by simply looking at their contribution on some web sites. And hiring companies for the tech industry are now looking at those kind of web sites like SO. And the developer has no power, because the actual company will forward your traditional CV to the hiring company and the hiring company will ask for your SO profile to judge you!

Answer (score 24):

> ...based on what you can do, not who you are. ... you'll be able to
>   show off the stuff that actually matters to you, including the
>   technologies you work with and any public artifacts like open source
>   projects

With all due respect, I believe you can still put that information in a traditional CV. Nobody restricts you to put what you have done in a traditional CV.

And for that matter, it should not be overlooked from where a participant has graduated for example - school is also important.

As well as places he/she worked. So maybe your new way of thinking about CV isn't that good?

Comment: Well, they're claiming it is a good idea somehow. As mentioned in the latter half of davidism's comment, they (Tim Post) hope to get back to us with why or how it might be better eventually.

Comment: I agree traditional CVs aren't useless and miserable. But you seem to take this a step further and say trying to improve on them is fruitless.

Comment: @djechlin: I didn't say that. Depends *how* you improve them

Answer (score 12):

After reading your first [post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313960/introducing-the-developer-story) I was pretty confused about the state of Developer Stories, but I still agreed with it.

I do have a hard time understanding the negative feedback, since your both posts unequivocally state this new feature **would not change anything, but** the current **CV** system.

Personally, I have never filled anything in the CV section and I don't think I will ever do in the near future because

> [SO for me, has been a place I can come to for relaxation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/314019/1967704)

as well. Any **evolution** to any part of the current system is welcome and I cannot find any reason why this would affect me or anyone else that may not care about the current CV system. (maybe this will convince some of us to use the new Developer Story, but then again, it ***didn't / doesn't / won't*** hurt us)

P.S. Keep up the good work and thank you.

Comment: At least part of the negative feedback is *because* they're changing the CV.  The objection is that they say they think it will make hiring and finding jobs better compared to the previous system, which many people like, but don't say *how*.

Comment: **Precisely** @davidism

Answer (score 12):

My nickle on this issue...

> Resumes have been around for 500+ years... so we're redesigning how
>   this information is displayed.

I think the issue that @bluefeet is trying to strike at is that CVs don't convey enough information about a developer regarding their potential for contributing to a job or project. But the real problem is that the human resources industry has progressed in this way exactly for this reason. More information requires more work and skill in human resources, and not many human resources departments are going to be ready to take on more work for themselves.

There's a similar situation in machine learning. When training a model we try to limit the number of features (information in the model) and yet retain a high score with data it hasn't been trained on. This rule of thumb breaks down when not enough features are present to account for cases which exist outside of the model's predictive abilities.

In a nutshell, what (I think) @bluefeet is getting at is that SO wants to target the cases which the CV model fails to handle. I think this is a good idea, not only for the sake of the developers who may find employment from it, but for the sake of employers who, in certain situations, find the CV model is just not working for them. For an employer it's a missed opportunity, and for society it's a loss of a tool or product which may potentially have benefited many people.

To that end, SO cannot afford to confuse their offering with a standard CV. Human resources does not want to lose faith in a system which appears to do its job, but they may be able to recognise a new service which targets the cases where the CV fails.

> We have difficulty naming things because **naming is hard**. We selected
>   Developer Story because it seems to encompass a large portion of our
>   users...

Isn't naming **np-hard**? And most likely not even decidable? If so, SO has their task cut out for them.

As a first step, SO needs to decide on whether they're making a change in society at large or limited to the SO developer community. If the latter, Developer Story, or @bish's My story, or the camel case MyStory may suffice. SO won't please everyone so they'll need to choose a name which is recognisable and work at promoting it. But if the former, SO needs to choose a name which all sectors of society can relate to as easily as they relate to *resume* or *CV*.

Answer (score 9):

I really like stack overflow. I like seeing the Stack Overflow attitudes on a "careers" site, particularly if potential employers take them seriously. I'd rather get answers about e.g. an employer's "Joel test" score than yet another video of new grads playing foosball in an open office. And I'd very much prefer an attitude of serving the programmer to one of serving the recruiter.

But at the same time, I'm already nervous about using the SO careers site, because of the existing expectation of links with Stack Overflow reputation.

Some of us are very badly represented by our SO reputation and badges, or for that matter by our contributions to publicly visibly source code.

- we've been continuously employed by companies that claim ownership of our entire oeuvre, and don't release it as open source
- we work with solid, even "old fashioned" technology where the good questions were answered early in SO's history, and we didn't arrive here until later
- we work on obscure technologies, where SO doesn't even have appropriate tags, let alone relevant questions - and there is any case a better place to take one's questions, such as project mailing lists
- we aren't into reputation grinding games

Any format for representing oneself where one can't control the order in which things appear, or get rid of sections that aren't useful, is not going to make things easier.

This is particularly true when it highlights things I know don't represent me well.

And then there's the problem of bureaucracies. They tend to come up with pointless requirements, often numerical. So how long until HR people are "helpfully" screening out all applicants with less than some magic number of reputation points, or badges, or similar - frustrating both hiring managers and potential employees?

I see the example format being potentially useful to some people. Of those, some would have the creativity to arrange their resume this way on their own. (And of those, some would be screened out by the clueless for having an unusual resume, where they might not be screened out if it were a site standard.)

But for some of us, it's made of fail, and that's what would happen to our employment prospects when we used it.

Of course I can't determine, from either thread, how much control we'd actually be given by this feature. Perhaps I'm worrying unnecessarily, and this would create no new problems, beyond those the SO Careers/jobs already has.

Comment: FWIW, we regularly get requests from customers for us to give them a sort or filter option for Stack Overflow reputation (when they're searching in our Careers candidate database product). I'm the product manager in charge of that experience, and I always will decline that request. Reputation and badges are a nice piece of context, and a differentiator from a traditional resume, but we definitely don't want to encourage recruiters to be reductionist. That's probably the biggest part of why the dev story is being created: to allow developers more control over how you appear to employers.

Comment: We're building the Developer Story so you can emphasize what matters to you, that could be what you've worked on or your SO activity but it is custom for **your story.**  You'll be able to customize it to show what's important for you as a developer, not what we think you need to show.

Answer (score 8):

If I understand it correctly (haven't dug into into it very deep as I'm not looking for job) the "Developer's Story" is the CV of this person:

So why don't you just call it "My story"? (Don't know if there are naming rights reserved by anything)

Comment: ["My epic"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epic_(genre)) is the only acceptable option.

Comment: My Struggle perhaps :o

Comment: @Loofer: I would have serious trouble using a service with that name.  (You might want to look at the German translation of it.)  (Apologies if that was supposed to be a joke.)

Comment: @Loofer while the historical context would eliminate that one, it *is* fairly accurate :)

Answer (score 8):

I am not really concerned about this in anyway. But to me, it sounds like "See, I have a *new* idea and I want to implement it!" and changing for the sake of changing rather than making any real difference.

There wasn't any convincing argument as to *why* this is *needed* and 
how it's better than the existing CV system. The "What problem are we trying to solve?" part just repeats "better" many times without really explaining *how*.

> "what you've worked on; what you've written."
>   "what you can do"

A traditional CV can very well contain this information too.

> "get employers to think differently".

May be. But unless one is looking for some sort UI/UX jobs, the new layout is not going to be very attractive but a bloat. Some of us are just *plain-text* guys, you know.

Let's say you don't have any open source involvement, doesn't have a github account etc. You are going to be at a disadvantage in comparison with others. An advantage with a "traditional" *free-form* where you can highlight what **you** want to show off and tell the 
employers you are **good at**. With the new layout, you are kind of forced to "cover-up" with certain bits that you don't have in your CV.

Again, I don't really have any problem with this new "CV" system. It has its own pluses and minuses. But it's in no way a "better" CV system (at least to me) but just "yet another" CV system.

Comment: *"Let's say you don't have any open source involvement, doesn't have a github account etc. You are going to be at a disadvantage in comparison with others."* That isn't true at all, you can add an item to the timeline that simply consists of a title and some text, so you can put whatever you want on it. ([source](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314636/the-developer-story-part-2-we-didnt-explain-that-very-well#comment294481_314732))

Comment: I wasn't saying it's not possible to do that. When most people follow (most have github account) layout, it's going to be like a template (See the sample layout in in your link). And the ones without such account have to "fill in" something else there. With a traditional CV, it wouldn't look that obvious.

Answer (score 7):

> Instead of presenting yourself as a bulleted list of action verbs, you'll be able to show off the stuff that actually matters to you, including the technologies you work with and **any public artifacts like open source projects or applications you've written**.

What if I work on closed source software and don't want to spend 12/16 of my waking hours writing code or blog posts?

Maybe others disagree, but I've noticed that most older and experienced developers (myself included) just don't do this sort of thing. I, personally, don't want to go home after 8-10 hours of work-related software development, and do even more software development. Am I less of a developer for enjoying a balanced lifestyle? Should my profile be penalized for it?

Overall, this post gives off the feeling that the CV is going to heavily focus on publicly visible software contributions, which a lot of developers just don't have. This something I already dislike about the CV; when I go to edit mine, I see something like '*90% completion! Add your website and github!*', as if it's expected that every hire-able developer has both.

Comment: I see your point, but I'm not sure I see how the timeline is *specifically* crafted for public artifacts. True, they are heavily supported, but that's because the world of IT has discovered that they are an excellent way to gauge a developer's ability (to a degree). Re the github and web site - that's a fair point.

Comment: @Pekka웃: I don't think we can know until we see the finished product, but the feeling I'm getting from this and the previous post are that they're going to be a major part of it; maybe they won't be.

Comment: [KevinB's answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/314732/2607247) and the comments below touch on this, actually. Sounds like we'll be able to add _any_ project we work on, open source or no. Open source just seems to have been an example they selected.

Comment: Count me as another, with no publicly visible code contributions on my github account.

Answer (score 3):

Thought I'd chime in. I liked Careers a lot (and actually have sent out some invites). The thing about Careers, though, is that its focus is specifically for jobs. It's a CV - that's what it's for, and it's great.

If you're going to do this Developer Story, you'll need to brand it as something different - and you'll need to be able to offer more. I'd like to be excited about what I can do with this new system. The idea of telling a story isn't bad; I don't know how well it'll do with recruiters, but when I hear "story" I think of a Github-like activity feed that supports customization, which sounds pretty awesome to me. I think that if you want to go farther with this, you're going to have to sell it as more than just a(nother) jobs thing; regardless of whatever feature set you guys decide to implement, this Developer Story needs to be for *us*, not for the recruiters.

Drop the "Developer Story" name and call it "Lifecycle" or something (something that will work with recruiters, but still have a meaning to developers) and make it enticing. I don't think that SO should ever become a social network, but I think if you're going to push this, you're going to have to toe that line pretty hard to keep it fresh. Otherwise, you're just upsetting the boat by slapping a coat of paint on Careers, which already does what it needs to do pretty well.

Comment: Lifecycle is an interesting name for it. Just as an FYI there will be custom fields that can be added to your Developer Story, they will not be preselected.

Answer (score 2):

I like where this idea is going.

I am a business owner who has taken up software development thanks to the wonderful resource that SO is. The developer story looks like a really intuitive way to quickly get to know potential employees on more levels than a CV/interview has to offer. For example, you can quickly gauge what types of technologies an applicant is experienced with and/or is excited about, based on the questions they are asking and/or answers they are providing. Like this, users can build a much richer perspective of themselves to present to employers, simply by using the site.

It could be a useful tool for companies who are trying to find different ways of thinking about their hiring process by giving information about people we may not have thought or known to ask for.

To me, there is no question that SO is an excellent QA site, and the best one it can be, primarily because of its iterative process of evaluation and making improvements. It is obvious this process has led to the discovery of key opportunities to make itself even more useful to the people it serves (and the people who serve on it) on a daily basis.

A key part of its success will be in providing a good perspective of the quality of contribution that a potential hire makes. Knowing how many badges a user has can give a rough idea of what the user is knowledgeable about. However, it doesn't give the whole picture, and certainly isn't offer any good points of comparison between two potential hires.

On the other hand, being able to see a few examples of how a user asks questions, approaches different types of problems, or explains solutions to others can go a long way towards evaluating if they are the right fit for a particular position.

Comment: This was what was confusing me: who is an employer who is tech savvy enough to read one of these story's, understand enough about what the story covers to make a hiring decision, but who doesn't have a lot of experience with interpreting CVs that have a traditional format also mentioning what folks would put into a story then ending with a section of the opensource they have worked on. it sounds great for this person but i simply don't think that the vast majority of people involved with recruitment would get any enhanced benefits out of a change in the format.

Comment: having said that comment i am still keeping an open mind!

Comment: It probably won't make sense for all employers, especially if hiring managers don't have the understanding necessary to interpret what they are reading (which is an altogether different issue). Also, I don't imagine this would replace a CV entirely, which would still be requested in an interview process. However, the type of employer who is pre-screening developers by searching through SO profiles might find it provides quick access to a little more information than a traditional CV does (by leveraging information only SO can provide).

Comment: Oh dear. I don't think my stack exchange record showcases my abilities. I'm knowledgeable in some fairly old techs where most questions were already adequately answered before I discovered SO. I'm also knowledgeable in some less popular areas, some of which don't even rate their own tags. I don't post answers unless I can improve on what's already there. And while the first time I came here it was with a question, I almost never ask questions on the main site - where I ask questions is where I'm clueless and (often) less than motivated.

Comment: I don't understand. Are you saying you prefer the existing careers system because it does a better job of obfuscating your abilities? You would rather have attention only drawn to your points and badges rather than to samples of your contributions?

Answer (score 1):

**Life Story**

What about "Life Story" a resume is basically that, a person's life story, where they went to school, work, volunteer, their work history, what they would like to do, awards they received and etc. :)

Comment: Make that "course of life story" and you've got the [literal translation of curriculum vitae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curriculum_vitae).

Answer (score -2):

While I think that this is a cool idea, I don't necessarily think that it is applicable to the Stack Overflow community. I didn't start using SO to build and document my projects that I have worked on. The whole premise of SO was not to be a social networking site, rather a place where people can go to ask questions and gain general knowledge about programming.

If you are going to add something like this to SO, I don't think that it should be based around building your own CV with things that are irrelevant to SO. Like others have said, I don't want to spend time documenting something that I was just working on for the entire day.

**Here is my suggestion** - simplify this as much as possible, and try to integrate it into the questions that you are asking. Most of the time, you can summarize/title your project in a few words, so have a section on your profile where you can put a quick summary and title to a project that you are working on, along with some sort of checkbox to say "Project Completed" or "Project in Development" and a list of questions that were asked relating to that project.

So now, if you go to ask a question on one of the projects that you entered, you should be able to quickly link the question to the project. Then when someone goes to your profile or even see's the question, they can then click through to see what project that question relates to. There can also be a clear timestamp / timeline for questions and stuff so a potential employer could see your progression. Maybe also put an option with questions so that if I come across something I used for a project, I can click "I used this question to help me with x". But not sure how helpful that would be. I think this is a simple solution, that can help illustrate the broader picture of questions. No one wants to have to document each project piece by piece, especially if they are already using some other site for source control. While I understand those sites can be linked, not everyone has that.

Like I said earlier, I like the idea of "Developer Stories", but not everyone wants to use it or even has the time to use it. So I think you can have a section in your profile that is labeled "My Stories" or "Developer Stories", like you suggested, but have it so that you can choose to add to it or have nothing to do with it, if that is your preference.

Comment: This is a replacement of the existing CV and will be used by individuals who are interested in hearing about job opportunities and/or applying for them via Jobs. As a result, we need to have the ability to include content outside of Stack Overflow which will allow users to show off what they've worked on, etc. I'm not sure how this would be integrated into questions they ask, many users don't ask questions so limiting it to questions wouldn't necessarily be helpful to a large portion of users.

Answer (score -6):

[As other have stated, too,](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/314643/263858) a strong likelihood exists that this change will bring an influx of low-quality contributors who will seek to increase their resume appearance for the purpose of acquiring a job.  I am going to 'skip ahead' an propose things we will need in that situation.

The influx of new people trying to 'game the system' (in order to  will result in more work for moderators.  If the flux is high, and we survive, it would then be due to our **creation of new finer-grained moderation queues**.

Finding ways to reduce the amount of analysis that a moderator / reviewer needs to do, will enable greater throughput while maintaining accuracy.

This may involve 'sharding' queues by the rep of the user, or a mix of rep, account creation date, badges awarded, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your point here. Why would there be an influx of people trying to game the system? What does this have to do with the Developer Story?

Comment: @bluefeet I've updated the answer to be more explicit in my interest to step-head from the top answer, and begin to discuss the solutions to the problem that is likely to manifest.

Comment: I disagree with the assumption. In fact, if implemented correctly, this system should reduce the employment-driven incentive to post low-quality content, as it has the opportunity to put a much higher emphasis on evaluating the quality of an applicant's submissions, rather than just the quantity. A few high-quality posts that exhibit a solid understanding of technology, a patient attitude towards others and an all-around good approach to problem-solving are much more useful to hiring managers than the numbers of badges or points a user has received.

Comment: @AdamStarrh if your right then I think such will come through emphasizing one's review activity, too. This will promote the dimension of community involvement and increased commitment to quality Q&A. Someone who doesn't provide as many answers, but does a great job reviewing and moderating, would be a valuable asset to certain teams.