# The Developer Story: Private Beta has started!

Tags: discussion, developer-story

### Update:

Private beta has started.  The initial invites were sent to some of the users who opted in.  As mentioned below, we'll be inviting users in batches to monitor load and allow us to watch for bugs and fix issues.

---

It's been 6-8 weeks since [we last posted about the Developer Story](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314636/the-developer-story-part-2-we-didnt-explain-that-very-well) but our project team has been diligently working, and **we're getting ready to start private beta on March 30, 2016**.

As a reminder, the Developer Story is our version of the CV. If you're interested in job opportunities, then this is for you. If not, then you can ignore this feature (however, we think it's a great way to showcase yourself even if you're not job hunting, so you might want to try it out anyway).

### How do I sign up?

Since this is a private beta, we're limiting the initial access to it to those who sign up. As we have done with [Documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319319/documentation-the-update-en-ing), access to beta will happen in waves once it begins March 30th.  Opting-in early will increase your chances of getting in on the beta period before anyone else.

To opt-in, go to your [user preferences page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current), look at the bottom. Check the checkbox to opt-in, or un-check it to go back to normal. Checking the box puts you in a waiting list.

> [image: preferences]

Once private beta begins, we'll add people in batches to verify behavior under load and to ensure we've fresh eyes as we fix the inevitable bugs. Users who opt-in will be notified via email once they are able to access the Developer Story.

If you find bugs, then please post here on [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) using a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) and [developer-story](/questions/tagged/developer-story). At the end of private beta, you'll also be separately contacted asking for feedback on the Developer Story.

**Private beta is scheduled to start March 30, 2016, so sign up now!**

### FAQ

#### Can I apply for jobs using the Developer Story during private beta?

During private beta you'll be able to fill out your developer story but **you will not be able to apply for jobs using it**. If you want to apply for jobs during private beta, you'll need to use your existing CV.

#### Will employers see my Developer Story in private beta?

No, this is a private beta period so employers will not be able to see your developer story.

#### Will other users be able to see my Developer Story?

During private beta your Developer Story will only be visible to other people if they're part of the beta.

#### Will the data be synced with Careers? In other words, if a user sets up a Developer Story and has a Careers CV, will edits to the Developer Story be visible on the CV?

No, you can test the Developer Story without having to worry about a potential employer seeing the test data in your CV. The reverse direction is possible, though: If you have an existing CV, then you can import its data into your Developer Story without having to recreate everything manually.

Comment: Is there any recommended channel that current Careers users can use to ask questions about the change, and about how the Developer Story will be formatted? For example, I have been unemployed for a long time due to family reasons, and I feel that the current way that Careers lets me organize my job profile is helpful. But when I look at the original example of the Developer Story, it seems to center heavily around a person's current position of employment, and I worry that given that I am unemployed, but looking, the move to Developer Story will unintentionally hurt me.

Comment: @Mr.F MSO is the right place to ask questions or suggest changes and.or give feedback on things. My suggestion would be to sign up for the beta testing and see how it works. Once you've had the chance to test it out, then you'll have a better idea on how it will work for you. But keep in mind that the Developer Story will have 2 views - a traditional sorted view and the new view.

Comment: I just registered to check how it will look like. We need to wait one week until we can see anything right?

Comment: Sure, @rekire - though we would usually say 6-8 days ;)

Comment: no meme ? this is must be good.

Comment: @Oded 6-8days? Oh. ;-)

Comment: @Mr.F, FWIW, we definitely want feedback like that if it's relevant once you can try it.  One of the goals of the Dev Story is to help let developers share their achievements and look their best, regardless of how well they match "traditionally" overweighted things. (We know that "school fanciness" matters a LOT less in hiring a dev than classic resumes may inply.) That doesn't mean it WILL address your exact case, but things like over emphasizing your job this moment vs. your overall talent/experience is just what we're trying to fix.

Comment: Just to be the devil's advocate, one of the Unix tenets was, very roughly, to for a tool to choose to do one thing & do it really well.  My feeling was SO focused on being a great Q&A site & did that function exceedingly well.  And hence, some of these latest forays worry me.

Comment: It's my birthday, therefore I'll get in and get hired.

Comment: @Josiah that's the spirit! The private beta CVs will not be shown to companies, though, for that we'll wait until it's public.

Comment: Have the initial invites been sent out ?

Comment: @JonH Some initial invites were sent out, be on the look out for it.

Comment: Great - I had signed up a few days ago so look forward to helping out as much as I can...@spolsky please hire me =).

Comment: @bluefeet I CTRL+F5 on that page and it still says Yes, so it's probably a server side caching.

Comment: "*During private beta your Developer Story will only be visible to other people if they're part of the beta.*" I'm in the Beta and I'd like to see someone else's profile (to see how Dev Story looks from another user's perspective). How do I do that?

Comment: Never mind... I found @bluefeet 's [profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/story/426671)

Comment: This title makes me think of [game dev story](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/game-dev-story/id396085661?mt=8)

Comment: @curious_cat SO has been doing Q&A "really well" for a very long time. The toolset hasn't changed much. I'd much rather have the developers of the best Q&A site on the internet working on another problem instead of twiddling their thumbs.

Comment: @Ryanman Maybe. But why not start a new venture entirely independently of SE? Different problem, different tool.

Comment: When would be the next set of invites be released

Comment: @SushantYadav The next round of invites is scheduled to go out on April 13th.

Comment: @curious_cat "But why not start a new venture entirely independently of SE? Different problem, different tool."- Still it's not too far away. Basically it's a social network feature for programmers. SE has some money invested in it and just wants to expand the business before somebody else does. My guess: It won't affect Q&A much, neither negative nor much positive. Unlike Q&A, dev stories doesn't solve an important problem. With a blog and a github account you basically have a developer story already, I guess. But nevertheless I wish all the best to this project. Maybe it's the next big thing

Comment: It would be nice if we could choose to share the public url even during the beta period.  Maybe not today, but as you get closer to launching this.

Comment: @curious_cat The Unix philosophy pertains to software development, so it has no relevance to a company offering web services. For example, you wouldn't tell a business to constrain itself to producing only one product or offering only one service (because, to the contrary, it needs to diversify and spread risk).

Comment: @SpaghettiCat On the contrary, management consultants often tell a business to focus on its core competencies & divest other businesses that are distractions. All I'm saying is diversification makes sense not always. Sometimes you diversify, sometimes you focus.

Comment: @curious_cat Alright, but you didn't justify why in this case diversification is bad. The Unix philosophy is not such justification: it is totally irrelevant to this discussion.

Comment: @bluefeet, I'm curious to know how many users are already in the private beta. It seems like you're rolling this feature very slowly, aren't you?

Comment: @gdoron At this point, we've got about 1k users in the private beta. Yes, it's been a slow enrollment because we're making sure we're fixing bugs, making adjustments as they are being reported.  If we opened it up to too many users at once, it'd be much more difficult to manage incoming reports.

Comment: @bluefeet makes sense. thanks.

Comment: Will this improve searching/matching of jobs with skills? The current s/m does not work - e.g. shows ruby-jobs when there's no mention of ruby anywhere on my cv

Comment: @bluefeet what is the status about it, and how is it going on .. i am stil waiting to be part of it , so want to know how things are going

Comment: @Webruster Beta is still in progress, as the dev team is still fine-tuning, fixing bugs, etc.

Comment: Has the private beta ended? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326959/developer-story-who-actually-sees-it

Comment: Related: *[Sunsetting Jobs & Developer Story](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415293/)*

Comment: Looks like the Community bot is trolling the community.

Comment: Re *"Closed. This question is off-topic."*: That is one way to put it.