# New tab "Developer Story Beta" not visible

Tags: support, developer-story

I received following email with link to the post for Developer story.

"*Hello,
You're invited to be one of the first to test the [Developer Story](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319524/the-developer-story-private-beta-has-started?utm_source=Dev%20Story%20Private%20Beta%20Invite&utm_campaign=acac40acd1-Dev_Story_Private_Beta_Wave_1_Invite3_30_2016&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_e7c745f248-acac40acd1-331522753). It's currently in private beta*"

Once I click on this link and try to go to my profile, new tab 'Developer Story' no visible in my profile.

But, when I open new window and goto stackoverflow.com, I can see 'Developer Story' tab in my profile.

Comment: I guess, I can not access 'Developer Story' when viewing my profile in http://meta.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: [Caching...](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/)?

Comment: I can confirm your user has "developer story" activated and you should be able to see it. I've added some general troubleshooting tips for the next user.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some general troubleshooting tips for developer story:

- What site are you looking at?

  Developer story is only available on `stackoverflow.com`, i.e. you should see it [here](//stackoverflow.com/users/story/current).
- Are you part of the beta?

  You can verify your enrollment status [here](//stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current). If you scroll to the bottom of the page and you are part of the test you will find the following sentence: "You are currently testing this."

  [image]