# Developer Story - Who actually sees it?

Tags: support, developer-story

I am asking as I see this in [previous post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/319524/1757321):

> Will employers see my Developer Story in private beta?
>
> No, this is a private beta period so employers will not be able to see
> your developer story.

Does the above still hold?

[image]

Visibility here indicates it is public. Public? To what extent, because I couldn't access the link when I logged out. I was told page not found.

Please enlighten me.

Answer (score 3):

Currently, "public" just means "visible to other people who are in the beta program". This allows you to help test the rest of the functionality without worrying that you're inadvertently putting misinformation about yourself out onto the 'Net.

Once the beta ends and this feature is available to *everyone*, public will actually *mean* public, and you'll be able to use those linked privacy settings to fine-tune who sees what.

Comment: Okay, any ETA when the beta ends? I personally do not see any issue with the Developer story at the moment, and looks and feel better.

Comment: @Rexford There is no launch date yet, hopefully soon.

Comment: "visible to other people who are in the beta program". That means, if a company on SO has enabled their beta, they should be able to see a developer story of an applicant?