# Developer Story - Still not ready for public time?

Tags: support, status-completed, developer-story

Just about a month ago, I asked who actually sees a [Developer Story](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326959/developer-story-who-actually-sees-it), and [shog9](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/326962/1757321) gave a beautiful answer:

> This allows you to help test the rest of the functionality without worrying that you're inadvertently putting misinformation about yourself out onto the 'Net.

Unless there's something I don't know of, but I think the Developer Story part is stable enough to launch. Besides, it can only get 'better' when outside of 'beta'.

For someone like myself who loves to 'Advertently put misinformation about myself onto the Net', I don't really care taking Developer Story for a spin, and not just beta-spin, but real public spin.

Or, how about providing the option for those of us interested to enable our Developer Story and make it entirely public, like publicly public for real?

At that point, someone like myself wouldn't care if the Developer Story is slapped with the 'Beta' term for eternity. In the current state, it works fine, yet still in beta, and one can't have it show publicly.

I'm great at filling balloons with air, and I want employers to see that via the all-new shiny Developer Story.

Any update on breaking Developer Story from 'beta'-bondage? Or providing the option to display story publicly although still in beta?

Comment: Please no more releases until Documentation settles down  a bit!

Comment: @IanRingrose Wow, okay, that sounds unexpected. I thought it would have been a first-come-first-serve scenario, but I guess I'm wrong. well, thanks for the update. Wondering what'll come next to render Documentation also a 'no more release' candidate

Answer (score 12):

We are finishing up some details - for example removing the integration with [teams](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/330427/the-un-shipping-of-teams) which is being removed.

We expect to ship this in the next 4-6 weeks.

---

It's going out today (Oct. 11 '16). Have fun!

Comment: Is that the little brother of "6-8 weeks"? :)

Comment: @Pekka웃 indeed it is - we are unshipping teams in 1h though. Most of the time left will be polish, polish and polish.

Comment: Polish or Polish? @Sklivvz

Comment: @Neal is it you cowboy?

Comment: eh? @Knu I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: @Sklivvz - Is there any news on this? new shipping estimation?

Comment: @Thatkookooguy it's shipping before the end of the month

Comment: @Sklivvz just saw it now ;-)

Comment: @Sklivvz Maybe this (or another announcement post) should get the [meta-tag:featured] tag for a little while?

Comment: @Stijn we're deploying gradually, there are a bunch of steps happening rn some of which will be way more visible than a featured post :-D