# How do I get developer story?

Tags: support, developer-story

I'd love to get my developer story. I've been waiting for a while. Can I get in?

Comment: [They expect to launch it soon](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/332006/247702).

Comment: _"Once upon a time, there was a young boy named Daniel..."_

Comment: @Cerbrus go on...

Comment: *"And he didn't get a developer story. The End"*

Comment: @meagar wah wah.

Comment: [Here are some Developer Stories](https://developer.android.com/distribute/stories/index.html) based on everyone's favorite tag. Oh, you want it to be about *you*? How arrogant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There have been some minor delays with the launch, but [we do expect it to go live soon](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/332006/247702).  In the meantime, we've gone ahead and added you, so you should be able to create your Developer Story.

Comment: While this is certainly a solid and unbureaucratic gesture, I wonder whether it's scales to the rest of us people registered and (more or less patiently) waiting for an Developer Story-invite...