# Developer story: first impression

Tags: discussion, developer-story

I've just experimented a little with the developer story, importing my SO Careers CV and creating stuff from scratch.

However, if I put myself in the shoes of an employer who has 60 seconds to get a first impression of an applicant (or whatever the time per CV is), I think it gives a very.. unstructured impression. Let's go back to the problem this system is trying to solve, from [The Developer Story Part 2: We didn't explain that very well](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314636/the-developer-story-part-2-we-didnt-explain-that-very-well):

> ## What problem are we trying to solve?
>
> ...
>
> When Stack Overflow Q&A launched, our community took a strong position
> that on SO, you should be judged on what you know, not who you are. In
> other words, judge the content, not the contributor. We strongly
> believe that hiring developers needs more of that attitude. The
> Developer Story is your story: it gives you a better way to find a job
> you love based on what you can do, not who you are. Instead of
> presenting yourself as a bulleted list of action verbs, you'll be able
> to show off the stuff that actually matters to you, including the
> technologies you work with and any public artifacts like open source
> projects or applications you've written.
>
> The design is different from a traditional resume because we're also
> trying to get employers to think differently about candidates by
> emphasizing what you've done. We know that it will take some time, so
> employers will still have the option to see your history in a
> traditional sorted view, but even in that view we're presenting a more
> complete picture of your history.

Maybe it's something about how I've approached the developer story, but I think the key point is that a chronological view emphasises **time**, not relative **importance** of projects/"what you've done".

Somehow I think that a simple "featured projects" section would work better to address the problem that the developer-story is apparently trying to solve.

The social-network timeline view might be suitable if the aim was to offer a semi social, semi professional network for developers or something like that...

Comment: I recently got the invite and I too feel the same way.  I also don't really think this feature is needed.  It's pretty and all but who really cares about it - this isn't facebook...but it's implementation is done in a way that make you feel like you're on facebook.  I personally don't like it - sorry.  As someone who programs and hires - I don't think folks hiring care about this format - I'd stick with the traditional CV.

Comment: Reading the section of the original post again, I again get the feeling that problem and solution are not very well defined. In short: they didn't really think it through. "what you know, not who you are" This is certainly not 100% orthogonal. I am what I know; "judge the content, not the contributor." just a phrase?; "what you can do, not who you are." needless repetition; "you'll be able to show off the stuff that actually matters to you" isn't this alway the case?; "The design is different" Different doesn't need to mean better. "a more complete picture of your history."  takes more time.

Comment: "offer a semi social, semi professional network for developers" SoftwareLinkedIn?

Comment: And if the goal is to offer a "semi social, semi professional network for developers", that is *really* bad.

Comment: @Linuxios Yes it would be, but that's not the goal.

Comment: Additionally, there are acknowledged inherent biases when employers see a photo on a CV. SO could do their small part for improving diversity in software by making CV's about the person's work, and not what they look like.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Here are some personal thoughts on this (okay, I work on this feature, so I'm probably biased – still, you'll see that I'm telling my own story).

There are really two sides to the Story.<sup>1</sup>

<sub><sup>1</sup>Sorry, but it's almost impossible *not* to make these kinds of puns.</sub>

## 1. The CV 2.0

One side is the idea of the Developer Story as a kind of better CV, something that's used to apply for jobs and showcase yourself to prospective employers. We believe that we're on to something that will be a huge improvement to the traditional résumé, tailored specifically to developers.

Now, as your quote from bluefeet's post says,

> […] we're also trying to get employers to think differently about candidates by emphasizing what you've done. We know that it will take some time […]

We don't expect an instantaneous *Eureka!* moment from recruiters that are looking for developers. And this isn't about anything like ignorance. First, there are things that *we* will initially get wrong, things that stand in the way of the Developer Story replacing the traditional CV as is. That's why feedback like yours and from other beta participants is very valuable.

For example (you're somewhat touching on this), in the very first version, it seemed that all Story items stand equally, and that simply shouldn't be the case. One change we've already made in response to this kind of feedback is the fact that job experience items are now highlighted. That's just a first step; we're planning to give you more control about what exactly you want and don't want to emphasize – it's *your* Story after all.

Some developers may not have a lot of job experience yet, but have been teaching themselves amazing new skills. Some developers don't have a lot of public artifacts like blog posts, conference talks, or open source repos, but they have worked on a lot of interesting projects in their time and are proud of their contributions there. Some developers may never have had a formal computer science education, but they may have worked their way up from internships to senior developer ranks at interesting companies. Some developers may be coming over from a non-technical job history and while they're new to coding, they have a lot of knowledge and skills that will be just as useful (or more) when working with a team of developers. And a thousand other unique people. We want the Developer Story to work for all of them, and that's something that the traditional cookie-cutter résumé format isn't very good at.

The other thing is that even when we've reached the point where we think that the Developer Story has surpassed the CV's usefulness, we're not going to throw employers into cold water and say "No more CVs for you, here's what you'll get in the future. Good luck."

That wouldn't be good for anyone. It would be bad for the employers because they suddenly have to completely re-think the way they evaluate candidates, and even if they take the time and eventually come to agree, this kind of change is painful and needs lots of thoughts on our parts about guidance (side note: there's an [awesome book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1491919019) about this topic that I encourage anyone who does product work to read).

It would be bad for our business, because overwhelmed and confused employers are going to leave and give their money to other platforms instead; platforms that, while more generic, don't just yank the rug from under them.

And it would be bad for the developers, because if they've polished up their Story in order to get a new job, but no employer finds the Story helpful, then that work was in vain.

So while we think that eventually we'll have something that's better in every way, we know we have to tread carefully on our way there and make sure we get things right for everyone.

This is the reason why the so-called "Traditional view" exists; a representation of the Developer Story that re-frames it in the format of the classic CV. It allows you to build up your Story and make it great without having to *also* make sure you're keeping your CV up-to-date. You're doing both at the same time.

## 2. The Story in every sense of the word

The second side of the Story is the one that for me personally as a *user* of the Developer Story is in fact more interesting. I have a job that I love and I'm not seeking to go job hunting anytime soon. And so the Story's functionality as a CV is not very important to me (although it's nice to know that should I ever want to entertain something new, then I wouldn't have much work to do because when I created my Story, I got a CV for free).

I haven't had a very traditional developer career. While I have been programming since I was a kid, I've never had an actual full-time developer job until Stack Overflow hired me when I was almost thirty years old. I did go to university to study business mathematics, but I never actually finished my degree because I couldn't convince myself that I would enjoy the job prospects that typically come out of studying in this field.

I considered finding my future in design and took jobs that I thought might get me there (and sometimes used my programming knowledge at these jobs to fix very practical problems, even though I wasn't employed as a developer).

And then one day I got an email from Jeff Atwood asking me to come work for Stack Overflow, and now, six years later, I'm still here.

So that's my story (lowercase "s") in a nutshell. Now tell me, how do you put that in a CV? The answer is you can't, really. I do have a Stack Overflow CV (it makes sense for me to dogfood our own product), but I've never been very excited by it.

The experience section? Only one relevant entry for a developer. The other entries mention some programming-related things I have done at other jobs, but they've always felt out of place in a developer résumé.

The education section? One entry, unfinished despite being pretty long, time-wise.

I have some interesting Stack Overflow and Meta answers on there and some nice open source stuff, but on the traditional CV they've always felt like fillers at the bottom where a recruiter wouldn't even look after skimming the classic top sections.

So my CV has always reeked of failure to me.

But now, I've clicked the import button and turned my story into my Story, polished it up a tiny bit to make it look nice, and I love it.

Suddenly I've turned my failure CV into what I think is a beautiful representation of how I got to where I am now as a developer. It's telling my story in a way that I feel good with.

And once it's out of beta, it will be the link that I will put in those places where you generally put "about me" links, because that's exactly what my Developer Story is: A page about me; the story of Ben, as told by Ben.

If you're a beta participant, you can see it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/story-beta/balpha).

## A note on "social"

One final thing because it comes up time and time again (including in your question and in the comments on it). There is nothing social network-y about the Developer Story. It's completely non-interactive, it's controlled by you and you alone, nobody else can comment on it or "like" anything in it.

Yes, it's a timeline in the traditional sense of the word, but not everything that is a chronological list of things is automatically a Facetweetinstachat.

We don't want your Developer Story to spark engagement or interactions or connections, with one exception: *If* you choose to use your Story to find new opportunities, then maybe it'll connect you to your next job.

But beyond that, your Developer Story is not one of many nodes in a social graph.

It's your Story and yours alone.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. I think I now have some idea how I can use the developer story - to explain (tell the story of) how I got into coding, similar to you, and then how I got to where I am now. That's quite a different focus compared to my CV, which is about why you should hire me and what I can offer. The former plays into the latter, but it's a really different emphasis. Thanks!

Comment: This is a great explanation but again I looked through your story and I still think its too much info for anyone to hire you.  You mentioned the traditional CV lacked because "Jeff Atwood sent you an email to work at SO"...but your developer story doesn't tell that either, and really to any outsider if in fact you did list that who besides you really cares about such an event?  Don't get me wrong, I like your developer story, but to others aside from you yourself this is just too much information.  Maybe you mentioned it correctly it is YOUR developer story so its important to you and only you

Comment: @JonH Yeah, I agree it may be a bit too much for the purposes of advertising myself on the job market -- but as I said, I'm not very interested in that right now. I'm approaching my own Dev Story from the view point "If someone is interested in who I am, because they stumbled over me somewhere, this is what I want to show." You're probably right that if I started actively looking for jobs I'd look at optimizing it a bit for marketability.

Comment: @JonH And making it easy for the user to make this sort of transition from using the Story as a CV to using it as a, well, story (and vice versa), and/or getting better at supporting both cases at the same time, that's definitely an interesting area for us to look at.

Comment: Thanks for this. Until today I'd been thinking of "Developer Story" as a thin euphemism for "employment timeline"; I hadn't really considered that one might legitimately use it to *tell* a story. UI could probably do more to reinforce this; there's a real strong "just the facts, ma'am" vibe to the layout and guidance that mostly just reinforces more traditional résumé-writing norms.

Comment: "Now tell me, how do you put that in a CV? The answer is you can't, really." This actually explains a lot of reasoning behind that project. Although I think of CVs as less strict (more like timelines with highlights, so more close to developer stories). Basically developer stories are supposed to be a better CV focused on a custom order of items instead of fixed categories.

Comment: > Some developers don't have a lot of public artifacts like blog posts, conference talks, or open source repos, but they have worked on a lot of interesting projects in their time and are proud of their contributions there...

I have three letters for you - NDA.