# I don't want developer story

Tags: support, developer-story, email

Just today, I got an email from you guys that my CV will look like a Facebook time line story. It bugged me a lot; please don't give me this.

Even if it's a big thing for you, take confirmation from me before changing my CV's look and feel.

Comment: You added the `developer-story` tag to this question. You may want to read some of the other questions also tagged with `developer-story`. You may just find the answer you're looking for.

Comment: I've gone over the first 3 pages of the tag search and dind't find it either. There are plenty of folks who never opensourced anything, even if they did a lot of serious work (just pick any Linux driver developer for a commercial company for a quick fit). In short, a CV is a CV, not a blog, I agree that a complete overhaul may not be a good idea for everyone.

Comment: Consider the HR folks - they usually have no idea what you're talking about in a blog post, all they want to see is years of experience and specific keywords. This will make the site useless for 99% of them as well.

Comment: While we have created a new way to display your CV via the Developer Story, you will still be able to view your details in a traditional view.

Comment: I thought this was [opt-in](http://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current) during the beta. Did the beta just end?

Comment: The beta is ending imminently. The email was sort of a "heads-up" as to this fact, @BSMP.

Comment: @Shog9 Oh, I didn't get the email so I didn't know what it actually said. Thanks.

Comment: What is a 'CV'? I hate three letter acronyms and I have two letter acronyms even more! Why can't we just use english?

Comment: @bartonlp Even though CV is short for the latin expression curriculum vitae, it is a different term for resume which is used throughout the world.  It very much is an English term.

Comment: You don't end your sentences with a point also in your CV?

Comment: @bartonlp Curriculum Vitae. Or just google CV...

Comment: I hate to say this but there is no scarcity in social media platform. The Developer story looks like one of them.

Answer (score 40):

From the email:

> #### Will employers still see my CV?
>
> We will migrate your CV to your Developer Story. If your CV was visible to employers, they'll be able to see both the traditional view and the new Developer Story view of your information.

In other words, your CV isn't going to change, and folks who want to see the traditional presentation will still be able to. The new "story" format simply provides an alternate way to read and modify it, one we *hope* is more flexible for readers... And allows you to present your qualifications in a less stilted manner. [balpha talks about this at length](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320953/developer-story-first-impression/321017#321017):

> I haven't had a very traditional developer career. While I have been programming since I was a kid, I've never had an actual full-time developer job until Stack Overflow hired me when I was almost thirty years old. I did go to university to study business mathematics, but I never actually finished my degree because I couldn't convince myself that I would enjoy the job prospects that typically come out of studying in this field.

Read the whole post - it's probably the best introduction to this "story" thing I've found. An awful lot of us don't have a very impressive-sounding "bullet list" of credentials that we can use to pad out a traditional CV; Story offers a way to present our experience that isn't tied to how much money we've spent on degrees or time we've spent job-hopping. At least... That's the hope.

Comment: +1 Excellent references you're quoting there in your answer.

Comment: @Shog9 I don't want [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/cv/xameeramir) to show the developer story. Show developer story wherever you want.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, that won't change, @student. http://stackoverflow.com/story/xameeramir will show the "story" layout, /cv/xameeramir will continue to render the CV format.

Comment: @student what Shog said - /cv/whatever URLs continue to render as they did before.

Comment: Can't help but feel you're desperately trying to drive more business to SO careers and attempting to monetise us in the process...

Comment: Can't say I'm particularly desperate about it, @Basic... And I should note that these emails were only sent to folks already enrolled in the program, so *this* isn't likely to drive much in the way of business. But yeah, the whole point of Stack Overflow Jobs - formerly Careers, [formerly Jobs](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/jobs-at-stack-overflow/) - is to fund the rest of the site. Has been for 7 years now. What's your concern?

Comment: @Shog9 I don't object to SO making money from Jobs, I object to your using my data in ways that weren't agreed beforehand to drive your business. There's a reason I avoid Facebook and all the other social media garbage out there (horrendous privacy concerns). Judging by the OP's question (and the positive score), I'm not the only one who doesn't want to be enrolled in some timeline without explicit consent. Now, if you were to make this opt-in, I'd have no problem but you're apparently not willing to do that?

Comment: It is opt-in, @basic

Comment: @Shog9 Allow me to clarify (and possibly apologise)... I meant opt-in after the beta ends. If the "I would like to participate in the private beta of the Developer Story." options remains valid once the beta ends, then please accept my apologies for casting false aspersions. Can you please confirm that? (I'd also point out that the specified option was ticked on my account and I haven't explicitly ticked it, so that sounds more like an opt-out). Perhaps it's because I've used Jobs to hire people in the past?

Comment: I don't follow, @basic. Whether you have a story / CV, whether you put anything in it, and who can see it, are always options, and they're off by default. Always have been.

Comment: Opt-in means someone has to actively choose to participate. I haven't explicitly done so (to my recollection) but the "participate in Beta" checkbox was ticked in my preferences page. Perhaps that's because I personally have employed people using jobs? In any case, if that option is ticked by default after the beta ends, it's not an opt-in. In other words, for an opt-in, nobody will have a Developer Story unless they explicitly ask for one. Is that clearer?

Comment: Wait - you got opted in to dev story without checking a box in your profile, @basic? That should not have happened.

Comment: @Shog9 I can't say for certain (we all know users are often wrong) but I have no recollection of ever ticking that box (and, to be fair, it's not the sort of thing I would opt into). I'm more convinced because I also hadn't noticed the "profiling" options just above that (which I just removed myself from). So... What can I say. I don't believe I've ever opted in. The only explanation I could think of is that I've used SO Careers at work to hire people, and wondered if that may have auto-registered me in some way? I've never even looked at the beta DS page and wasn't aware of it pre-email.

Comment: Wait... I don't see the option enabled on your profile; you don't have a public CV *or* Story listed on your profile, @Basic. You're enrolled in the "New Nav" beta; that's it. The only thing I can think of is that maybe you have a (private) CV hanging around from back when you were using Careers and were sent the email because of that. Would you mind posting a separate bug report or sending us an email? I'd like to have someone who works more closely with this take a look.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124224/discussion-between-basic-and-shog9).

Comment: @Shog9 you say it's opt-in in the comments, but in your answer you quote *"We **will** migrate your CV to your Developer Story. If your CV was visible to employers, they'll be able to see ... the new Developer Story view"*. I don't see how these claims are compatible. Which is it?

Comment: Did I miss a 180? Because you now say "simply ... an alternate way" but bluefeed said before ["The Developer Story is our evolution of the traditional CV, and it's "**replacing** the existing Jobs (or Careers) CV."](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314636/the-developer-story-part-2-we-didnt-explain-that-very-well). (Emphasis mine).

Comment: The entire system is opt-in, @Mark. We're not taking people's profile information and creating CVs/Stories from them, we're not listing folks who don't ask to be listed, we're not making anything public that you don't explicitly say should be made public. That's how it's worked for years, and - confusing email aside - **nothing is changing with that.** The bulk of the work happening right now is taking data that formerly lived in a separate system (Careers) and integrating it into Stack Overflow, at which point it'll be called "Story" to differentiate it from your normal SO profile.

Comment: @Shog9 so, if I'm understanding you correctly, the new display format itself is *not* opt-in for people with existing CVs. Maybe that's fair enough, if it's just a new view for the same data - but it's worth stating explicitly, given that that's the precise thing that many participants in this conversation seem to be offended by.

Comment: See my comment above to Mark, @MSalters: it's "replacing" an entirely separate piece of software that formerly existed under careers.stackoverflow.com. In that system, your "CV" was your profile; on Stack Overflow, your profile is still your profile, but you can now augment it with a "Story" to which you can add background information if you want to participate in /jobs (which is the integration of the job listing part of the now-defunct Careers system). *On top of this*, there's the actual public CV / Story portion, which are views of your info you can choose to provide others. Naming...

Comment: The "default" display format will be the "Story" view once migration is completed, @Mark... But if you've been sending folks links to your CV, those will still work and still link to the CV view (see my comment above to student) - unless you start sending out links to /story/whatever *or* choose to make your Story world-visible on your profile, folks aren't gonna suddenly start seeing something different. AFAIK, employers can choose whatever format they want to see from applicants (or send you to their own system, which many do today).

Comment: ...needless to say, this is all confusing as hell to try and explain in comments. The point of the email was supposed to be reassuring folks who'd been using the old CV system that we *weren't* about to pull the rug out from under them; I kinda suspect that'd have been a lot easier to do if the folks who got it could've actually seen what we were talking about. Hopefully in a few days we can just make this all generally-accessible, post an announcement or send another email, and y'all can poke at it instead of trying to make sense of my confused terminology here.

Comment: Either this answer is plain wrong or the UI is very confusing. I used to have a Careers profile, and now I no longer have a Careers profile but I have a Developer Story instead (with completely wrong data, to boot). I never opted in to any Developer Story. Can I get Careers back, or did you discontinue that?

Comment: Careers is now *Talent* and *Jobs*, @Gilles. Your data *shouldn't* have been affected though; the goal was to import it into your SO profile without alteration, with CV and Story as the available means of viewing it. If something got lost or corrupted, please post a bug report so we can get it fixed; we're keeping the source data around for a while just in case there were bugs with the import.

Comment: [Filed](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336588/data-import-from-careers-to-developer-story-is-broken). It would help if I could compare with the Careers data, but I'm sure it wasn't *that* incomplete. I feel very much that with Developer Story I'm getting exactly what I paid for.

Answer (score 9):

I share your pain.

I used to have a profile on Stack Overflow Careers. I was happy with it so far — very few hits (unsurprising given that very few employers in my country use it) but the few I got had good relevance. Contrast with Linkedin which spams me with generic emails from recruiters.

Now my SO Careers profile has disappeared and I have a “Developer Story” instead. It [got created with bad data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336588/data-import-from-careers-to-developer-story-is-broken), [it's difficult to edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336590/how-can-i-control-the-tags-i-show-to-employers), [I don't even know how it looks to employers...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336589/how-can-i-see-how-my-developer-story-appears-to-employers).

I'd like to be in control of what I show to employers, and an unreadable jumble of boxes with little relation to my professional activity is not what I want to show. Please let me replace that by a link to Linkedin. Linkedin is not very good at matching prospective employees with prospective employers, but once the parties have found each other, it got the CV right.