# I seem to have been opted-in to the new Developer Story automatically

Tags: bug, status-norepro, developer-story

Following a discussion with Shog9 in the comments/chat on the [I don't want developer story](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/335135/156755) question, there seems to be some confusion as to how I've been opted in to the Developer Story.

I don't recall signing up for the Beta, it's not the sort of thing I would normally opt in to. In addition, I hadn't previously noted the `Manage personalized predictions` in the settings page (which I've just opted out of). I normally opt-out of this kind of thing whenever possible.

All of which leads me to believe it's extremely unlikely that I opted in to the Developer Story beta. I can't say for certain (we all know how error-prone users are and I consider myself part of the crowd) but I have absolutely no recollection of doing so (at least not when it was labelled as it is now).

So... I *believe* that I may have been opted into the beta in error.

Possible other causes:

- I've used SO Careers/Jobs professionally to hire people.
- I've attended SO-organised events in London

I have no idea if either of the above may have caused my account to be included in the Beta automatically.

In any case, as requested by Shog, I'm raising bug report to get this investigated.

For what it's worth, I've since unticked the checkbox, so should no longer be part of the beta.

Comment: It is no longer in beta, that's what happened.  This *is* the kind of feature that needs to be sold with a pretty bow on top, nobody would ever volunteer for this.  It benefits the paying customers of SO, not you and not me.  You were sold, it is their business, only option you have is to opt out completely.  I think, you did enter Hotel California :)

Comment: @HansPassant Yes, that was the thrust of the point I was making at shog9, who insisted that it should be opt-in and that since I haven't explicitly opted-in, it's a bug and should be reported (hence this post). Frankly, I'm rather irritated that my data is being monetised without explicit consent. Not that it doesn't happen elsewhere, but there's a reason I avoid Facebook, etc... Maybe it's time to add SO to that list.

Comment: Hmya, you'd have to wonder a bit how a company can get so dysfunctional that one of their employees needs to report a bug to other employees by having a user like you report it.  Instead of, you know, have him report it instead.  Shog9 just doesn't have a good cover story, there is none, still needs some credibility with users like you and me to get his job done.  Aww.

Comment: I can't reproduce this with my own account (because I explicitly opted in) or any of my test accounts (none of them were forced into the beta), @Hans. So me reporting the bug does no good; if there's more information needed, that'll have to come from Basic here, I'd just be a middle-man. Also, it'd be really nice to know if this has happened to anyone else, which isn't likely to come out if I pass this along privately.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, m0sa was kind enough to dig into this for me. We track clicks to that checkbox in two ways: a high-level event log that records various actions taken on the sites, and the low-level request logs that records every request made to any site on the network. The latter are prohibitively noisy unless you know *exactly* what and when the event you need occurred, but fortunately the former are much more readily queried:

[image]

Those are the events associated with that beta-test and your account. I've redacted the IPs to protect your privacy, but they were different between April 1st (when the feature was turned on) and yesterday (when it was turned off). However, yours is the only account we've ever logged associated with the first IP. Here are the matching server logs for that time, IP, and account:

[image]

Now... This eliminates a lot of things; critically, we didn't opt you in accidentally, and we didn't opt you in because of past involvement from the employer side of things.

It does *not* eliminate someone else messing with your account, however. It's somewhat notable that the timestamp for this is April 1st - traditionally a day for pranks and [other tomfoolery](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unikong). It's possible that someone you know (someone with access to a PC or phone left logged into the site) thought it'd be funny to set you up with a "Story" (although I should hasten to add, I can find no evidence that any Story was added on this date nor would such have been visible in any case). If you think this might be the case, email me and I'll pass along the relevant IP in case that might help.

Otherwise, my best guess is that you were poking around the various options to see what they did, and simply forgot about it.

Comment: As I said, I can't rule out user error... A checkbox 5 months ago may well have slipped my mind, so for the sake of argument, let's assume that. My IP changes every few weeks or so, so the different IP is not unexpected. Thanks for taking the time to dig into this for me, it's much appreciated.

Comment: No problem - don't hesitate to post if you run into anything else weird. New code, potentially sensitive data, gotta take everything seriously.

Comment: Unaccepting as I appear to have been opted in to having a developer story tab without my consent. What happened to opt-in only? (I've just opted out _again_)

Comment: Are you talking about [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rXUd.png), @Basic? If so, I'm guessing that got checked when you were opted in before, and took effect again today. Asking around.

Comment: Yeah, that's the one I mean. Having reviewed my settings when we discussed this previously, I'm certain I would not have left that ticked if it was visible... Are you saying that you may have implied this setting? I'd love to know how many other people have been opted in implicitly...

Comment: I know we don't *imply* that setting, because I had mine off in the private beta and it's still off today, @Basic. I do believe it was lumped in with some other settings in the very early days of the beta, so it's possible you turned it on then and didn't notice it to turn it off the other day when you were opting out of the other visibility options.

Comment: I hear what you're saying. I was willing to accept user error the first time (we've all made mistakes), but I can't believe that having gone through my preferences doing a privacy pass, I failed to notice a setting about the thing that _caused_ the privacy pass. When did this option become visible (to users)?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, it's been there since the start of the private beta, @Basic. However... I'm honestly not sure what it looked like back then. I know the UI for the privacy settings changed *significantly* over the course of the private beta; it's entirely possible that its purpose was less obvious when last you saw it.

Comment: My apologies, @Basic: [there is indeed a bug here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336166/visiting-the-developer-story-preferences-tab-makes-the-story-tab-visible-even-i). Don't know for sure if that's what you ran into, but... It is possible. Thanks for the report.