# Provide some sort of access to developer story preferences from the developer story tab

Tags: feature-request, developer-story

If it weren't for seeing the title of *[Visiting the Developer Story Preferences tab makes the story tab visible, even if I never touch the checkbox](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336166/visiting-the-developer-story-preferences-tab-makes-the-story-tab-visible-even-i)*, I wouldn't have guessed there was a Developer Story Preferences section. I think it'd be helpful to either duplicate control of the story preferences in the story tab or provide a link to `stackoverflow.com/users/storypreferences/userid`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There actually *is* a link - it's just tucked off to the side a bit:

[image: Update privacy]

If you click that, it'll take you straight to the relevant preferences tab.

That said, you're not the first person to miss this; I overlooked it the first few times I saw the page too. The designers have been looking at options for making this a bit more obvious.

Comment: [this is somehow relevant](https://twitter.com/vickyharp/status/736228835046219779)

Comment: Ok, glad it's being looked at. I don't suppose the designers will see this, but ftr I wouldn't count that as a link to the story preferences - it's a link to a specific story preference setting. Only users who know that the story privacy settings are a subsection in the story preferences tab will recognize that link as a way to explore the story preferences