# What if you don't want a "Developer Story"?

Tags: discussion, support, developer-story

I don't really like the format, don't think it does a good job of expressing my history, and don't think it fits my personality.  I have a traditional, plain text, straight forward resume because that's who I am-  I'm not flashy, not obsessed with bragging, and very function over form.  And my traditional resume works very well for me, my success rate of both getting and passing interviews is tremendously high.

The new format-  definitely not me.  I would never have a graphical resume.  My resume is a plain .txt file, on purpose.  Its short, simple, and to the point.  I'm already at the point I need to trim it to keep it to size, I don't want to waste space on graphics and headers.  I would never put so much emphasis on skills I've used, because I believe any language or platform can be picked up on the fly (heck, I'm doing that right now).  I'd be closer to removing my skill section than bragging about it.

The mix of SO questions and jobs-  horrible.  An employer might be interested in seeing my karma, as that shows that I'm an active helper on this site.  They don't care about individual questions.  The whole thing reeks of bragging, and I'm not the bragging type.

Mixing in projects-  probably works for some people.  For myself, I work 10-12 hours a day.  My spare time is rarely spent programming, I'd rather study other fields, play video games, relax with friends and family. I also have no interest in marketing libraries or projects so there's no value to it for me.  (I can see this working for other people, so I'm not saying don't let them use it-  I'm saying I don't want it).

What I do have-  positions at multiple top tech companies, several in senior positions, and lead developer position in at least 1 well known startup.  I want to emphasize the positions showing where I've been and the technical leadership I've shown.

The left/right/left/right format-  unreadable.  I'd throw out a resume that came in to me that did that.  I don't want mine to look like that.

Also, as someone who frequently hires for tech positions-  this is a horrible horrible format.  Here's what I look for in a tech resume:  I read the last 1-3 jobs.  I skim the rest.  I look at the school on it (certain schools earn bonus points) if they're new to the field.  If its more than 2 pages, the pages past 2 do not get read-  and really past page one doesn't get more than a glance.

With your format-  I'd have to scroll all over the place.  Not doing it.  I'd have to click to read the details of a job.  Not doing it.  When I see a resume I want key points immediately and either put it in the pile to contact or get rid of it almost immediately.  I don't want to interact with it.  Your format is less useful as a hirer than a traditional resume.

So yeah, don't want it, don't ever want to see one in my inbox.  Either let me have a traditional resume on your site or please delete mine, I'll go through other channels to contact companies.

Also-  why is there a photo?  At all?  Given all the studies showing bias against minorities based on just names, putting a photo there seems both unprofessional (I have never seen a photo on a resume before) and an unnecessary risk of injecting bias.  Get rid of it.  In fact if you want to do something interesting-  remove the name entirely so it doesn't effect their reactions.

Comment: I believe there is an opt out option, so it should be rather easy to not have a developer story. I believe the official terminology was "Too much nope has never been a problem.".

Comment: Hmm... a lot of vitriol for a feature they've been talking about for a long time, and I don't see much commentary from you on the two posts introducing it, and later explaining it later. Also, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/335131/215552

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan The first I've ever heard of it was this afternoon when I suddenly found out it existed and I had one (and its not like I'm an occasional visitor).  And I think its full of horrible ideas.  Also please note that neither you, nor anyone on the other thread I've seen about it, was able to give a single reason as to why it was a better format.  I didn't even see them try to say  "we're doing this because X, Y, and Z will provide better value", they just said they thought it would be cool to remake it because....  actually they couldn't even come up with that much.

Comment: @GabeSechan As Travis said, you can opt out. You also have the option of using the old format. Go to `stackoverflow.com/story/${username}` for the new one (if it's enabled and public) or `stackoverflow.com/cv/${username}` for the old format. It's your choice if you share one, both, or neither with potential employers.

Comment: I'm not saying it's the bee's knees or any other being's appendages. All I'm saying is that it's been talked about since at least [January, when Introducing the Developer Story](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/313960/215552) came out, and I'm sure that was a Featured post on Meta. You can see how that was received (-46 at the time of this writing). The [followup](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/314636/215552) was much better received at 283... A quick search would have told you what you needed to know regarding the developer story thing.

Comment: @GabeSechan: "*I didn't even see them try to say "we're doing this because X, Y, and Z will provide better value",*" So what, [the blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2016/10/Bye-Bye-Bullets-The-Stack-Overflow-Developer-Story-is-the-New-Technical-Resume/?cb=1) explaining what they were doing and why didn't actually explain it? Or did it simply not justify the change in your mind? Because there's a difference between those two things.

Comment: @NicolBolas No I don't think it did.  Things like "Tech has evolved but resumes haven't" aren't reasons, they're empty prose.  It does a lot of telling what they're doing but not how it provides value.  Its marketing material with no real content.  Also, half that post is about job search features on careers, which are a whole different issue (one that I have fewer to no issues with)

Comment: And on rereading-  the marketing drivel rate is higher than when I first read it.  SO no, it doesn't provide any arguments for the changes whatsoever.

Comment: @GabeSechan Why is it a problem to give people more control over how their CV/Story/Resume looks on Stack Overflow? They even explained that this is so users whose experience doesn't really fit with a standard resume format would have a chance to create one which better showcases their talents/experiences. "The emphasis is all on the seniority of your titles and how impressive your companies or schools have been. Which is a great way for some developers to put their best foot forward. Have a Masters in CS from Yalemouth? Cool! That’s one good signal. But it ain't the only one."

Comment: @MikeC For others?  Fine.  I don't want it on mine.  And I don't want to ever see one for any job opening I ever post-  its a horrible format for the hiring manager, more time consuming to read and evaluate.  I would be far more likely to auto-pass on anything in this format.  My bet would be on it not having its intended effect, and probably having a negative one.  Also, there are variations on traditional resumes that would be better for those people (such as the simple idea of putting their projects before their experience, since whatever is first gets read most).

Comment: This might be more use as multiple, less ranty questions. If you want to know how to opt out, just *ask that*. If you want to keep using your text format, how does this stop you doing that?

Comment: @jonrsharpe It was part that, part feedback on a horrible idea.

Comment: @GabeSechan Then don't use it and keep doing things your way. Personally, I would not be happy to get a resume in just plain text format. It tells me you couldn't be bothered to give me something more interesting to look at. It will definitely stand out from the stacks of other resumes going by my desk but not in a good way. That's just my opinion. This is like someone offered you a free motorcycle. You don't have to drive it but it might be a better option for some (gas use, parking, etc.). Now you've put a sign in your yard saying "Ban the free motorcycles!" Don't use yours, ignore the rest.

Comment: @MikeC I wouldn't be happy to get anything else-  it means that their accomplishments can't stand on their own.   It will stand out, but not in a good way (btw, less than 10% of the resumes I get are anything other than the most basic of bullet formatting, which I'm ok with but wouldn't win them any points for doing it better).   Exception:  if you're going for a design job, in which case your resume is a part of your portfolio.

Comment: @GabeSechan Why would it mean that their accomplishments can't stand on their own? Maybe they have a sense of aesthetics. Maybe they enjoy working with people and people like interesting looking things. Maybe they know that reading through multiple pages of "Previous Work, Technologies, etc." gets very boring and they want to stand out. Maybe you hate fun. I don't know but it really shouldn't bother you that other people have an option that works better for them.

Comment: Because if they could, they wouldn't feel the need to waste time making it look pretty while simultaneously making it more difficult to get the basic information. I'm sure there's exceptions, but I've found trying to make resumes look pretty as opposed to functional is a strong signal of absolute lack of talent, which is why a functional one didn't work. And as a hiring manager I wouldn't want it- unless you're a designer I'm hiring you for those unethical abilities, *please* bore me with them. Don't make my job more difficult by making me wade through garbage, I'll just move on to the next.

Comment: That said- feel free to rearrange the sections to put whatever you want in a more prominent locale. I'm not reading the whole thing anyway, so make site I see what you want.