# Data import from Careers to Developer Story is broken

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs, developer-story

Until recently, I had a Stack Overflow Careers profile. (Not publicly linked to my Stack Exchange identity.)

Now this seems to have gone. I have a Developer Story instead. (Not publicly linked; does it link to my Stack Overflow profile for employers?)

The information listed on the Developer Story page is seriously wrong. Now, I don't remember exactly what I'd filled in on Careers — I didn't spend any time polishing it — but I'm sure that I didn't list my degree as still ongoing or my current job without a start date. The data import from Careers is seriously broken.

How can I view what employers used to see on Careers? I don't seem to have saved a copy.

I went and at least fixed the glaring errors in my Developer Story (and by the way the UI for that is counterintuitive — it seems you can't do that from the traditional view!), but I really don't appreciate this. Yes, I know, I got what I paid for...

Comment: I've checked your old Careers CV data and the story is an accurate representation of what we have. Is it possible that you had multiple Careers accounts?

Comment: @DeanWard I'm pretty sure I didn't. I'm also pretty sure that I listed the date I got my degree, not the date I started it (I may or may not have entered a starting date — I didn't spend all that much time copying data from Linkedin). I'm also reasonably confident that what the Developer Story shows is not what the employers who contacted me on Careers saw, because I don't see how those employers would have been interested.

Comment: Did the message from the employer come into the SO account you're currently logged into?

Comment: @DeanWard Yes, it's still in my inbox.

Comment: The last message thread that began on 2016-08-11 was linked to the CV in Careers that was imported to your dev story. Only thought would be that they saw something about you elsewhere and used our candidate search product to look you up?