# How can I see how my “developer story” appears to employers?

Tags: support, developer-story

How can I see how my “Developer Story” appears to employers? (It isn't public.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Employers can see both the timeline and traditional views of your developer story exactly as you see it on your profile (except it's read-only, of course).

If you apply to a job in /jobs we attach both a link and a PDF of your developer story to the application message. You can see that by clicking the 'Save as PDF' button in the right sidebar in your profile.

Comment: So employers do get a link to my SO profile? This is a big change from Careers!

Comment: No, never to the profile. The link that is generated is to talent.stackoverflow.com and it never exposes your SO/SE details if you decided not to show any of your SO/SE accounts on the story. You can still keep your story and SO profile totally separate from the employer's perspective.

Comment: The PDF export has a link to my SO profile (in the “Projects & Interests” section), and I can't find any setting for that. If I associate my SO profile with what I show to employers — which I'm not sure I want to do at this point — then I'd want to highlight other SE sites as well, at least [crypto.se] and [security.se].

Comment: You can change the network sites linked to your story by clicking 'Edit' in the header area. I'm not sure why we don't render those on the exported form; appears to be a legacy thing from the Careers days. I'll add a bug report to get it looked into.

Comment: So if I don't want to link my SO/SE identity in my Careers/Jobs/DS identity then I should untick all the sites under “Pick the network sites you want to display”, right? (And wait 6–8 units of time until the cache expires I suppose.) The UI is not intuitive.

Comment: It's been 15 minutes since I removed all the linking I could find from my DS to my SO account, and the PDF export still has a link to my SO profile.

Comment: And could you tell me where I gave my consent to showing my SO profile to prospective employers? I thought I'd left that off in Careers and it defaulted to on in DS.

Comment: Gah, yes, there's a bug here (in the PDF generation); logging it now.

Comment: Your SO profile is marked as being linked with your CV, that's what we used for the import, so consent was implied based upon that.

Comment: “Your SO profile is marked as being linked with your CV”. Where?

Comment: In the Careers database

Comment: I meant where in the user interface can I control whether it's linked. I don't intend to break into your database.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that if you remove all your top tag percentiles you should find that your SO profile no longer gets linked in the PDF (i.e. it's by design based upon the percentiles).

Comment: That's legacy data, you asked where the consent came from: that's where.

Comment: Ok, *that* (unticking all the SO tags under “Select the top tags you want to display”) worked. Wow, you should really make that less hidden!

Comment: I've added a couple of bug reports around this, should be picked up tomorrow.

Comment: We agree that it was unintuitive to have to remove the top tags in order to remove the SO Profile from the "Projects & Interests" section of your PDF export. Now it is controlled by "Pick the network sites you want to display" in the  edit header section of your Developer Story. We are currently looking into adding other network sites besides Stack Overflow in your PDF Export.

Thanks so much for your suggestions @Gilles!