# How can I control the tags I show to employers?

Tags: feature-request, developer-story

In my <s>CV</s> “developer story”, a bunch of Stack Overflow tags appear never the top.

The thing is, they aren't that good at reflecting my *professional* interests. For example, the first tag is [bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash), but I am not looking for a bash-related job. Ok, I can hide it¹, but that's not what I want either, because I do have that skill after all — I want to downplay it. I'm competent at [cryptography](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cryptography) yet the tag doesn't appear at all — but I can list [encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/encryption) which is just silly.

1. Please give me more choice as to which tags appear there, and in what order.
2. There's also a free-form list of tags, but in the “normal” (“traditional”) view, it appears way further down under “Tech you want to work with”. That's not a very visible way of listing the keywords that define me professionally.

¹  <sub>In case you haven't found how to do that, because it's pretty hidden: you have to select the “Story view” tab, hover² your mouse over the area with the tags and an Edit button appears.</sub> 
²  <sub>I haven't tried on a mobile device or with keyboard controls.</sub>

Comment: You can display your tech stack at the top of your Developer Story (you can put anything you want there that reflect your professional interests).