# Why is my CV link not visible?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, developer-story

The [CV link](https://stackoverflow.com/cv/xameeramir) on [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/u/2404470) is not showing. How do I fix it?

[I'm literally not interested in that fancy story feature](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/335131/2404470), I wanted that old CV link on my profile.

Answer (score 3):

CVs are no longer a thing and are superseded by Developer Story. The link on your profile is no longer required (there's nothing to link to anymore) so it was removed.

Developer Story in the traditional view is the equivalent view and that is accessible from either the Developer Story tab in the profile (if you set it to visible in your preferences) or via the /cv/{name} public URLs that can be configured when you edit your story.

Comment: But I don't wanted this to happen, Can you allow me have that link back?

Comment: Unfortunately it won't be coming back; hence the [tag:status-bydesign]

Answer (score -3):

Make absolutely sure that the CV is in the right field. Hope this helps to some degree.

Comment: What is the meaning of the right field?