# How to read a developer story?

Tags: support, developer-story

I've so far found reading the developer story a bit confusing, which is part of the reason why I don't really use it. Others have expressed the desire to re-arrange the order for various reasons, but that's not the topic of my question, I'm interested in understanding the current order.

I always have the tempation to scroll to the bottom of the page, read upwards (thinking this will give me the items in chronological order), but then the employment headings appear out of place. However, I think I've now understood that the developer story is:

1. Intended to be *only* read top-to-bottom
2. Once you come across an Employement (or education) section, read that, and then think "While this happened, `<name>` also ..."

   - ... wrote a blog post about X
   - ... contributed to OSS project Y
   - ...

Is this correct?

I suspect CVs are usually written in reverse chronological order to highlight the current (and likely most impressive, relevant) position/achievement. Stories on the other hand are usually in chronological order (even the textual version of balpha's "developer story" [in this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320953/developer-story-first-impression) is written in chronological order)...

Comment: I can't quite grasp why you're surprised that reading the page backwards results in an odd experience.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition: "Weblogs" rot the mind. Their reading should therefore be banned.

Comment: "I always have the tempation to scroll to the bottom of the page, read upwards", I think this is the main problem. Things are made to be used in a certain way, using it differently may not result in what you expected and you end up confused.

Comment: I haven't found reading the developer story to be confusing, just awkward and uncomfortable. Some things are not as significant as others, they're not meant to all be grouped together.

Comment: Many stories actually employ flashbacks and flashforwards to tell different timelines out of order for dramatic effect.

Comment: I'm not exactly surprised about reading the page back to front leading to an odd experience... But I am a little surprised that it's still hard to find a comfortable way to read the developer story (you could think of it as finding a narrative to read in your head).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just like a traditional CV or resume, the Developer Story is displayed in reverse chronological order.  However, instead of bundling all of the Experience together, like a traditional view, we include your open source contributions, blogs you've written, and even your top posts from the community on the timeline in the same vicinity as your experience, if the dates overlap.  This allows you to tell a broader picture of who you are as a developer.

For example, if you had a non-developer position, but you contributed to open source projects or wrote blogs about programming during the same time as that position, these would appear on your story in the same general area (if dates are provided).  On a typical resume or CV, you'd most likely have your experience towards the top of the page, and then a separate section with these other contributions and they might not jump out at an employer because they weren't displayed in the similar timeframe.  The story allows you to have these contributions show up at the same time.

Does this type of display prevent you from going to the bottom of a Developer Story and reading from bottom to top?  No, it doesn't. Before I started answering this, I tried it on several users and still got a good idea who they were as a developer. You still get the overall story of a user, just in a reverse order to the display.

As you pointed out, since it rolled out we've gotten a lot of suggestions on how to improve the Developer Story, including allowing for manual re-ordering of entries.  The team has been heads down doing a lot of research, UX testing, and prototyping of some changes to the Developer Story which we hope to have rolled out soon.  I'm going to be posting something covering what the team has been up to and the plan for these changes in the next few weeks.

Answer (score 2):

The top of the timeline is the most recently finished event.
You can experiment with your own, or see that on [mine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/819417) i wrote some blog posts while employed at Bugaboo.