# Animated GIFs in answers

Tags: discussion, edits, answers, images

I've been told that animated gifs are 'not allowed' in answers and had it removed and been told off for 'starting an edit war' for rejecting someone else's edit to my answer about which I was not consulted.

Link below (look at the edit history).

My point is that this isn't a frivolous point and surely Stack Overflow isn't now so fuddy-duddy that you can't make a valuable point with emphasis using a visual.

It is (IMHO) amusing to make the point about the power and risks of C in terms of a Spiderman quote. At the end of the day good lessons are memorable lessons and in case people hadn't noticed it's 2017 and people use visuals to making striking points and assist learning.

This isn't a joke the gif wasn't there (solely) as a joke. One of the points in the answers says 'have fun'.

Is it really the case that we shouldn't have a bit of fun while answering questions? 
Does everyone think that's what Stack Overflow is and should be?

I find that depressing and realizing that Stack Overflow got 'old fashioned' pretty fast.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43752438

Comment: That image was just *noise* and a distraction. Please don't use meme images in answers.

Comment: Looks like noise. We remove noise. Gifs and memes make users more likely to vote their reaction, rather than vote on the content. It's easy to upvote things that are funny and move around, but that's not what we want voting to be about.

Comment: If it doesn't pertain to answering the question it should not be in the answer section.  That GIF had no place in the answer.

Comment: @NathanOliver It absolutely pertains to answering the question. It's a way of emphasizing the point.

Comment: @DanAllen: the GIF failed at emphasizing anything, sorry. It was a distraction, not anything that brought emphasis.

Comment: If the GIF is "hey, once done, this is how your new animation looks". Sure. If the point is already made and you are trying to be "fun" by adding the GIF..... no

Comment: You're all a load of grumpy cats..

Comment: @ThingyWotsit SO is what it is today, at least IMHO, because of its quality and rules.  I've been on a lot of other sites and this one is a cut above because it is not silly.  I want code, not meme's.  If I wanted meme's I would go almost anywhere else.

Comment: @ThingyWotsit I actually really like memes and usually enjoy them when I see them. On Stack, I come for SOLUTIONS, clear, without fluff. Start allowing memes and this will turn into yet another crappy forum, where the right answer is hidden under a bunch of funny crap I don't feel like filtering through (at least not when looking for a technical solution)

Comment: With great memeing comes great responsibility. [You must learn how to weild your power wisely, grasshopper.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169205/do-moderators-earn-a-salary/169210#169210)

Comment: For more reading on how we hate fun, you may also be interested in [Is it worth having guidelines for highly colloquial and comedic writing styles?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/327295)

Answer (score 41):

We are trying to build a repository of quality questions and answers. Everything that distracts from that is noise and should be removed.

Your GIF image was such noise. It was nothing more than a an animated meme image and a distraction.

This doesn't mean we don't like a bit of humour in answers. If you use a joke or two that *improve the quality of the answer*, then that's much appreciated! But when it becomes a distraction and draws attention away from the actual content, then it should definitely go.

Comment: As an aside, adding to this, it doesn't actually matter if it was an animated GIF or not. If it was a noise image it probably shouldn't be there either, it's just the fact that it's animated increases how distracting it is and lowers the threshold at which it might be considered "noise". A [sufficiently annoying still image](http://i.imgur.com/ZlOYMUP.png) would get the same treatment.

Comment: @JasonC So that's what you've been up to...

Answer (score 17):

On Stack Overflow, [we hate fun](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/01/04/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/).

The animated gif emphasizes the point, but it does not really add anything to the answer.

Stack Overflow became as big as it is, because it sticks to doing only what is necessary. It was already clear that great power means great responsibility, without the Spiderman gif.

If we allow this kind of thing, more and more answers will have animated GIFs, and our Q&A will slowly turn into a memefest. That won't happen overnight, of course - but we nip it in the bud.

Answer (score 4):

All thanks for the feedback.
An important rule of communication is to understand your audience's communication needs and preferences.
It's pretty clear that people don't want that kind of stuff.

It feels like "If you want to post memes (bluergh) try Facebook and Tumblr. We want text and the occasional line-drawn diagram. Thank You."

I ought to be happy. I spend most of my day frustrated by people who won't read and understand text. There aren't many algorithms that are improved by being summarized in 20 words and super-imposed on a picture of a sunset or cute kitten.

I still think that Spiderman GIF just fitted the point so well but if it's a point of principle that you don't want to go there. Fair enough.

Given the language lawyer nature of the site I'll take away that no one has actually cited any rule against it. The answers are a statement of preference and philosophy rather.

The outcome is the same.

**Memes? NO THANKS!**

Comment: there are... *places* on so where memes are welcome. just not Q&A or DOCS or JOBS.

Comment: You can get away with this kind of thing sometimes: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11227902/, but you need a really really good answer or a really really good reason. [Sober images play better](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aanswer%20url%3a%22*imgur.com*%22).

Comment: @jscs: the train tracks splitting gives a visual aid for "branching", so the image greatly enhances the answer -- the answer wouldn't have been the same without. The nice link you posted of all answers with images mostly contain visuals that give a graphical representation of the answer, making it easier to understand and quicker to parse. In the few answers I checked, I could only find 1 meme: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35075021/3705191 -- which again, is a fun and creative way of making the answer easier to understand via a visual and fun mnemonic that's memorable. OP's GIF added nothing 

Comment: Nothing wrong with visual aids, *if* they 1) add to the *answer*, 2) help people find & parse the answer quicker, or 3) render the answer inferior *without* the image. The question was how to easily know when to free a returned pointer, to which you nicely made a list of common rules of thumb, with some personal spice added. Your real answer was however "check the documentation and know your libraries". That's your main answer, not the advice at the end :) The Spiderman GIF does not 1) add to the main answer or 2) help make the answer easier, and 3) would've made your answer the same without.

Comment: However, if you'd presented your list of rules in an image format that somehow made it easier to parse or understand or remember the answer, then including a meme would've been perfectly fine imo :) E.g., the part about "always render unto free() what malloc() and family rendered unto thee" could've easily been turned into a meme picture of a family (tree) with malloc, calloc and realloc related to free. That would've been fun *AND* memorable, making it easier to remember. Still, a GIF is too distracting, so image only imo. The text at the end of your answer is already a nice (text) meme 