# Developer Story Update — Share Your Story

Tags: discussion, developer-story

We’re getting closer to the launch of Developer Story, our replacement and improvement of Stack Overflow CVs, and we’re looking for a few volunteers to help us show — not tell — the world what this is all about.

As you may be aware, [our goal for Developer Story](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314636/the-developer-story-part-2-we-didnt-explain-that-very-well) is to replace traditional resumes with something that shows off what you’ve actually built and what you know, not where you happened to have gone to school or the name of your last employer. In traditional resumes, the list of new programming languages you’ve learned or open source projects you’ve contributed to often get relegated to the same extra curricular section as hobbies or sports. We think this is an outdated way of showing what a developer is capable of doing, and why they should probably be interviewed. Emphasizing a feature you’ve built from end to end is more reflective of what you can do than where you got your college degree. (In fact, [according to our annual developer survey](https://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2016#developer-profile-education), 56% of developers don’t even have a college degree in computer science or related fields.)

We’ve been working hard to continuously improve Developer Story while it’s been in beta thanks to many of you who’ve tested it out and given us valuable feedback.

Now that we’re set to launch, we have one more request for help: In order to show people new to Developer Story what it can do and how it works, we’re looking for a few volunteers to give us permission to feature your Developer Story on social media and in press mentions.

If you’re interested in helping us out here, [fill out this form](https://docs.google.com/a/stackoverflow.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdBm5Sop5Kv8tZ2cXROe3q-lPNmn02ymGQUGWnXYZqURC0DjQ/viewform).

Comment: The "Nope" options on the form are a bit redundant, aren't they?

Comment: Too much nope has never been a problem. Ever.

Comment: Nope @CubeJockey

Comment: Is `Page Not Found` expected to be shown on the example link http://stackoverflow.com/story-beta/example123?

Comment: @techspider clearly an example link to share, not an example dev story.

Comment: @CubeJockey It really wasn't that clear to me. Also, the "share your Developer Story public link - titled "Story view" - here" is kinda misleading, didn't even notice the place to give the link till I saw it a second time

Comment: @CubeJockey - hufff... i figured a link somewhere on the page quite not strikingly visible as this example link :)

Comment: @Lamak - same here :)

Comment: To me it looked like a developer story sample to check how yours should look like

Comment: @techspider / lamak; Reread the direction as "*[...] share your Developer Story public link [] here. [The link] should look like <example link>*"

Comment: @CubeJockey I did reread it, obviously, that's why I said I didn't notice the textbox till a second time. The point I'm making is that it wasn't that clear

Comment: @CubeJockey - I too initially read that link as the sample link; After your comment, I went back and scrolled up and down to find the instructions where I can create... I even tried http://stackoverflow.com/story-beta; then  I noticed it was in header; then the third time, damn, where should I put the link after creation?  It was hard for me to see the text box beneath the point.

Comment: @Lamak is better than me; He was able to figure in two visits but it took me three visits :)

Comment: Will this help me get a job? Careers was a failure for me :(